# Random CSS Color code

Tags: code-golf, random, css

[This blog post](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/) about generating random CSS color codes in JavaScript have multiple solutions for generating a random color in JavaScript. The shortest I can find is this:

```
'#'+(Math.random()*0xffffff).toString(16).slice(-6)
```

If you are not familiar with CSS color code [read documentations here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/)

Can we do better? What about other languages?

Comment: Yours is broken, you're missing a `+` after the `'#'`

Comment: You can remove the slice by doing this `#'+(Math.random()*0xffffff|0).toString(16)`

Comment: What is the "0xffffff" needed for? I'm not seeing much of a difference in my results without it.

Comment: @path411 Theoretically, `Math.random().toString(16)` can produce a representation with less than 6 hex-digits after the (hexa)decimal point, in which case the function would break. For example, _0.1658172607421875_ becomes _0.2A73_ in hex.

Comment: Linked from *[Random color generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator/5365036#5365036)*.

Comment: I don't understand why it multiply by 0xffffff. Shouldn't it be 0x1000000 (or \$2^{24}\$) instead?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### PHP 23 bytes

```
#<?=md5(rand())&ÿÿÿÿÿÿ;
```

Where `ÿ` is character 255. Bitwise and will truncate the string returned from `md5`, which is already in hexadecimal format.

Comment: This is one of my favourite solutions on the site.

Answer (score 9):

Three character codes are valid too, so I can save some chars (`4095 == 0xfff`):

### Ruby, <s>24</s> <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 18

```
'#%03x'%rand(4095)
```

If I *have* to use a 6-char one, then:

### Ruby, <s>28</s> <s>27</s> <s>26</s> <s>24</s> 20

Shaved one character off because `8**8-1 == 0xffffff`

```
'#%06x'%rand(8**8-1)
```

Thanks to chron for the format string, saving 4 chars!

---

Cheating (with [this xkcd strip](http://xkcd.com/221/) in mind):

### Ruby/JS/Python/Perl/lots more, 6 (or 5)

```
"#a83"
```

I assure you, I generated it randomly!

An even cheatier version:

```
"red"
```

Comment: You don't need parentheses for method calls in Ruby, right?

Comment: @Mohsen Yes, but Ruby gets confused and thinks I'm calling `to_s` on `4095` if I omit them.

Comment: You can get it down to 20 with a sprintf format string: `'#%06x'%rand(8**8-1)`

Answer (score 8):

## Javascript

```
'#'+Math.random().toString(16).substr(2,6)
```

Just a little shorter at 42.

```js
function randomColor() {
  return '#' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 6);
}

for (var n = 0; n < 16*9; n++) {
  var el = document.createElement('SPAN');
  el.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
  document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(el);
}
```

```css
span { width: calc(100%/16); 
       height: calc(100vh/9);
       margin-top: -7px; 
       display: inline-block;
     }
```

```html
<div id='demo'></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. It works fine in every browser I've tested. +1

Comment: `#'+Math.random().toString(16).slice(-6)`

Comment: @Mohsen nice! Didn't know slice could do negatives.

Answer (score 5):

## Fish 79

```
vnnnnnnnn 
601234567;
>xxxxxxxx<
 89""""""?
 nnABCDEF:
 vv""""""-
 vvoooooo1
 >>>>>>>>^
```

Not the shortest solution in the world, but it was fun to code :)

It's also not a uniform distribution, but all outputs have a non-zero probability 7 and F are most likely digits.

Outputs:

```
python fish.py randomColor.fish
07FFF7

python fish.py randomColor.fish
07EFD7

python fish.py randomColor.fish
366F67

python fish.py randomColor.fish
977FD7

python fish.py randomColor.fish
97F7F7

python fish.py randomColor.fish
87F6FF
```

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>28</s> 24 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to @Julian!*

```powershell
"#{0:X6}"-f(random 16MB)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0m52sAqwqxWSTdNoygxLyU/V8HQzNdJ8/9/AA)

Comment: You can omit the `-ma` as it is implicit and save [4 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0m52sAqwqxWSTdNoygxLyU/V8HQzNdJ8/9/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ṫ`, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
\#k66ƈṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=%E1%B9%AA&code=%5C%23k66%C6%88%E1%B9%85&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
\#      # Push a #
    6ƈ  # Choose six...
  k6    # Hex digits
      ṅ # Appended to the #
```

Comment: You can outsource a byte to a flag using this method: [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=Ṫ&code=%5C%23k66%C6%88%E1%B9%85&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: @Underslash Nice, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### APL (17)

```
'#',(⎕D,⎕A)[6?16]
```

Explanation:

- `6?16`: 6 random numbers from 1 to 16
- `⎕D,⎕A`: the digits (`0..9`) followed by the alphabet (`A..Z`) (but only the first 16 values are ever used, i.e. `0..F`)
- `'#',`: add a `#` to the front

Comment: `6?16` is 6 **non-repeating** random values though, that narrows the colorspace a bit...

Comment: @mniip Yeah, it should be `?6⍴16` instead.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 44 bytes

```python
from secrets import*
print("#"+token_hex(3))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehODW5KLWkWCEztyC/qESLq6AoM69EQ0lZSbskPzs1Lz4jtULDWFPz/38A)

Did you know this built-in python module? It was added in python 3.6 to include some random function for paswords (more informations [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html)).

### How it works ?

Basicaly, I generate a random 3-bytes long hexadecimal string ... Yeah, that's it.

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>32</s> 31 bytes

I also have the slightly less elegant :
(also works in Python3 in <s>34</s> 33 bytes by adding parenthesis for the `print` function)

```python
print"#%06x"%((id(0)>>16)%8**8)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69ESVnVwKxCSVVDIzNFw0DTzs7QTFPVQkvLQvP/fwA)

This one uses the fact that at each execution of the code, python uses an indivdual memory address for each object. This memeory address change at each execution of the program. As the last 16 bits of this id are not random, I shifted the result before using a modulo to have the right number of bits

Thanks to pxeger for -1 bytes

Comment: You can use `id(0)` for -1 byte, though I'm not sure relying on ASLR alone is necessarily a valid random source. (Python doesn't "assign an `id` number", it uses the memory address of the object, which is assigned by the kernel, and is typically only a bit random, so it's really only suitable for seeding a PRNG)

Comment: @pxeger I don't know if it is a valid random source, but it seems that it choose evenly a number on the wanted interval at each execution. As I saw the same trick on other problems using random, I thought I could use it here. Otherwise I have also my first solution :p

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 37 bytes

```sh
<<<\#`tr -dc 0-9a-f</*/ur*m|head -c6`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsYmRjmhpEhBNyVZwUDXMlE3zUZfS7@0SCu3JiM1MUVBN9ks4f9/AA)

- `</*/ur*m`: input from `/dev/urandom` (shortened with wildcards)
- `tr -dc 0-9a-f`: keep only characters in the range `0-9a-f`
- `head -c6`: take the first 6 characters
- ``` <<<#`` ```: prepend `#` and print

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `Ṫ`, 7 bytes

```
\#6(k6℅
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=%E1%B9%AA&code=%5C%236%28k6%E2%84%85&inputs=&header=&footer=)

### Explanation

```
\#6(k6℅
\#      Push "#"
   (    For _
  6     in range(6):
    k6    "0123456789abcdef"
      ℅   Random item

Ṫ Concatenate the stack
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 32 bytes

```
print(f"{hash('a'):x}#"[:-8:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

### Bash (51)

```
od -N4 -An -tx /dev/urandom | cut -c2-7 | sed s/^/#/
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes

```python
from random import*;print(f"#{randint(0,16**6):06x}")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VoWRcUZeaVaKQpKVeDJEBsAx1DMy0tM00rA7OKWiXN//8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
import time
print(f"#{int(time.time()%16**6):6x}")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVq6AoM69EI01JuRpEg4T0QISGpqqhmZaWmaaVWUWtkub//wA)

Random generation by modulo of current time saves two precious bytes

Also 0 before 06x can be omitted

Comment: using `f"{i:6x}` will give leading spaces instead of 0 when `i` is less than 6 digits long in hexadecimal. You should instead use the format `f"{i:06x}`. But you also can gain 1 byte by replacing `16**6` by `8**8` an 2 bytes using `"%06x"%i` instead using the previous f-string syntax : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVq6AoM69EQ0lZ1cCsQkkVxAYJ64EIDU1VCy0tC03N//8B "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 57 bytes

```
import colors,random
randomize()
echo 0xffffff.rand.Color
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/M7cgv6hEITk/J7@oWKcoMS8lP5cLQmVWpWpocqUmZ@QrGFSkgYEeSEbPGaT4/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
6ØhX¤€”#;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/s8IyMiENLHjWtedQwV9n6/38A)

### Explanation

```
6ØhX¤€”#;   Main niladic link
6           6
     €      Map
    ¤       (
 Øh           "0123456789abcdef"
   X          Choose random
    ¤       )
        ;   Prepend
      ”#      "#"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 24 bytes

```julia
'#'repr(rand(UInt))[3:8]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPhfUJSZV5KTp/FfXVm9KLWgSKMoMS9FI9Qzr0RTM9rYyiL2v@Z/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Gö6 msG i'#
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=R/Y2IG1zRyBpJyM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), <s>29</s> 26 bytes

```
'#o6['0'??'9G[p'(+,0]po,]p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/19dOd8sWt1A3d5e3dI9ukBdQ1vHILYgXye24P9/AA)

At a high level, here's how this one works...

1. write out `#`
2. loop 6 times...
3. each iteration, write out a random digit in `0-f` range

And for people who like gory details about stacks. :)

```
'#o6['0'??'9G[p'(+,0]po,]p
'#o                        - push "#" on stack, print it as char
   6[                  ,]  - loop 6 times
     '0'?                  - push "0" and "?" codepoints on stack
         ?                 - pick a random number between them
          '9G              - is it greater then "9" codepoint?
             [p    0]p     - if/then, called if pick is > "9"
               '(          - push 28 on stack (Note 1)
                 +         - add 28 to random pick (Note 1)
                  ,        - decrement (Note 1)
                      o    - print top of stack as a char
                         p - clear the loop artifact from the stack
```

Note 1: Mapping the codepoints `:-?` to `a-f` means adding 27 to the codepoint.  The shortest way to do that would be to push `'` onto the stack, but the code for that (at least on TIO) `''` doesn't work.  So this code loads 28 (which is `(` then decrements the result with `,` instead.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 54 bytes

```java
n->"#"+Long.toHexString((int)(Math.random()*0xffffff))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9Pb8IwDMXvfAqLXZKhhu2MxnlIcOI47WASN4SlSdW4iGnis3fpH8q7WHZ@znu@4BWLi/nptMeU4IAuwN9iAVnrNegzBkt48gQuMDUlahre5g52GYdJR25csMCUGERGwNkQG5KbgbiP39btyTsNiZFzuUZnoOpdxbj99Q3Y2CQfKaYkibit58EOUvQtuxjgYx4@aRt9SQZ0NNSFYrt8Wa72MVjF8ZNuo43o80lxQD6rBoOJlZCvb7dykJTd5ul@/E1MlYotqzqvsg/i4a76U0XxLuXE5xvv3T8)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), <s>46</s> 43 bytes

*-3 bytes, thanks @ceilingcat*

```c
main(){srand(main);printf("#%08X",rand());}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9YtSU7@/z83MTNPQ7O6uCgxL0WjJDM3VcNAU9O6oCgzryRNQ0lZ1cAiQkkHLAkUrv3/HwA)

4 byte color codes are valid, the last byte is used as alpha.
C is weird with random numbers because of how old it is. While the code above is *technically* a valid answer, it does a really bad job because different compilers treat `rand()` differently and often use a suboptimal generator, in addition to not actually guaranteeing every possible color. Importing a better library for generation isn't exactly a good idea for Code Golf though.

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9YtSU7@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0lZ1cAiQkmnKDEvRaMYTIIUaGpqWtf@/w8A "C (tcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

`0xfff == 4095`, so we can just take a random integer from 0-4095 and convert it to hexadecimal form. We save a few characters using prefix and infix notation.

```
RandomInteger@4095~BaseForm~16
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8oMS8lP9czryQ1PbXIwcTA0rTOKbE41S2/KLfO0Oz/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Zsh (coreutils), 26 bytes

Using `jot`, [originally](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/9b50d9027575220cb6dd09b3e62f03f511e908b8/usr.bin/jot/jot.c) in BSD Unix. [Try it Online](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/K79EQbc8Rlm1QkG3SMFQwUDB0Mzc3NzI0Oz/fwA).

```pascal
jot -w\#%x -r 1 0 16777216
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Red, 18 bytes

```
random 255.255.255
```

Comment: I don't think it gives the number in hexadecimal or adds `#` to the front.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Can you provide some way to test this?  As Bubbler pointed out it looks like it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 43 bytes

```python
from os import*
print("#"+urandom(3).hex())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P60oP1chv1ghM7cgv6hEi6ugKDOvRENJWUm7tCgxLyU/V8NYUy8jtUJDU/P/fwA)

1 byte less than current top Python 3 sol by @Jakque, as I don't think that one by @Ivar Matstoms is fair