# Print numbers from 1 to 10

Tags: code-golf, number, kolmogorov-complexity, sequence

This might be a very simple challenge, but I am surprised it hasn't been done on code-golf yet:

**Print all Integers from 1 to 10 inclusive in ascending order to standard output.**

Your output format can be whatever your language supports. This includes arbitrary separators (commas, semicolons, newlines, combinations of those, etc., but no digits), and prefixes and postfixes (like `[...]`). However, you may not output any other numbers than 1 through 10. Your program may not take any input. Standard loopholes are disallowed.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

## Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=86075,OVERRIDE_USER=42570;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78448/36398) (duplicate?)

Comment: Not exactly duplicate, this doesn't take input

Comment: If the only change is hard-coding a single parameter then that falls under the banner of "*trivial change*", and by the standards of this site still counts as a dupe.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The other challenge has a huge problem with the integer limits though. The way it's specified every TC language that doesn't have 64-bit integers needs to implement them. (And that affects quite a lot of languages.)

Comment: @MartinEnder It's too bad the other question has the silly limitation, but I still think it's a dupe when one can port over 2/3 or more of the answers with only minor modification.

Comment: @xnor Quite frankly, I'd rather close the other challenge as a duplicate of this one. The requirement pretty much ruins it.

Comment: I dislike the other challenge's requirement, but it's not something that we could (or should) close it for. As it stands this is a dupe of the other, more general challenge.

Comment: Is it forbidden to print any number other than the 1 to 10?

Comment: I can't believe every single of the (currently) 71 answers assumes the base should be decimal…

Comment: Does a click on "OK" qualify as separator and suffix?

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou Hehe, that's brilliant. Just a simple output of `1 10` would suffice in base-2. xD

Comment: Could you clarify whether having no delimiter at all is allowed, too? I.e. `12345678910`?

Comment: Could you please add a leaderboard snippet? 100+ answers is a lot to sift through manually.

Comment: There are languages which are so verbose that it's worth considering whether hardcoding a string consisting of all 10 numbers is shorter than actually writing a loop. Is that intentional?

Comment: Cheaty-as-heck answer: do `1111111111` and argue that it printed all numbers from 1 to 10 in unary

Comment: The "Winners by Language" section is not working

Comment: Do we have to print delimiters? May I print a leading or trailing delimiter?

Answer (score 77):

## C, 36 bytes

```
main(i){while(printf("%d ",i++)<3);}
```

This works because the loop terminates after the first 2 digit number.

Comment: There's no mention of being able to pass in parameters to the function.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko What are you talking about? This is a standard technique in golfing to initialise an int to 1. You don't need to pass any command line arguments. In fact, doing so will cause the program to produce the wrong output.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko By [consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7172/31625) we have agreed that programs may assume they will not be called with unnecessary input (in this case, no additional command line arguments, beyond the program itself). That means `i` here will always be 1 when this program is run. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry, I've not written C but assumed it's default value would be 0 as in every language I've used.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko In C, the first argument to main is the number of command line arguments (including the executable name itself). Since no additional arguments are passed, that count is 1. The second argument to main is the actual list of command line arguments, but that argument is ignored in this program.

Comment: @MatthewRoh +1 for the +1 about that part :)

Comment: @ChrisBouchard `argc` (or `i` here), could be zero in 1) non-hosted environments 2) when a program is called with `exec()` and specifies 0.

Answer (score 59):

## HTML, 44 bytes

```html
<ol><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li>
```

This is longer than hardcoding the output, but it is more interesting this way. It creates an ordered list (`<ol>`) with ten empty list elements (`<li>`). By default ordered lists are delimited by decimal numbers starting with 1 and a period.

HTML5 is very forgiving regarding unclosed tags, so it closes the `li` tags implicitly.

Comment: +1 for abusing HTML5's forgivingness (?).

Comment: Cold-blooded.  I love it.

Comment: Actually, NinjaBearMonkey and @HyperNeutrino, this isn’t “forgiveness” per se; HTML5 is pretty explicit about which tags are allowed to be left unclosed. It’s just that lists and list items are two that are.

Answer (score 47):

## Bash, 12 characters

```bash
echo {1..10}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ echo {1..10}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

#### Bash + coreutils, 10 characters

(Just trying to be funny and using `': No such file or directory↵ls: cannot access '` as separator.)

```bash
ls {1..10}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ ls {1..10}
ls: cannot access '1': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '2': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '3': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '4': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '5': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '6': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '7': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '8': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '9': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '10': No such file or directory
```

#### Bash + coreutils, 6 characters

(Just trying to be boring. Or not just trying…)

```bash
seq 10
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ seq 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Last one is just seq/coreutils, bash not involved.

Comment: @hyde: Without bash the call to seq wouldn't be possible, would it?

Comment: In my vision, if we leave out `bash`, then `seq` would be the interpreter. But then `10` is a valid program in “seq” language?

Comment: Never try this at your console: echo {1..1000000000} 
If you curious, do with your own risk.

Comment: @Brain90, there is no danger on my poor 8Gb RAM machine. ;) “bash: brace expansion: failed to allocate memory for 1000000000 elements”. At least with `bash` 4.3.46.

Comment: @manatwork, sorry for the mistake. I execute this 
$ echo {1..100000000000000} -> 14 digits zero. 
LED storage indicator goes crazy, and hang. 4Gb RAM.

Comment: @manatwork seq is not a programming language per the consensus definition here. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073

Comment: @Sparr, didn't claimed it is. Is a “function” defined in one of the shell's “libraries”.

Comment: @manatwork "then seq would be the interpreter. But then 10 is a valid program in “seq” language?" <-- seq is not a language or an interpreter of a language.

Comment: Is the 10c version allowed as there're extra string in front of and behind

Comment: @l4m2, the challenge text explicitly allows arbitrary separators, prefixes and postfixes. I agree, that is probably not what the challenge author intended to say by allowing “etc., but no digits”. That is why although my solution not literally violates the requirement, I posted it only as a funny alternative.

Comment: Seen that part . sorry

Comment: The `ls` version doesn't work for me (on macOS 11.6), it prints `10` before it prints `2`.

Answer (score 31):

### Jelly, 2 bytes

```
⁵R
```

Explanation

```
⁵  Return the fifth command line argument or 10
 R Range
   Implicit output
```

Comment: `⁵R`, two bytes

Comment: Why on Earth would someone invent a language in which a command returns either the fifth argument or the integer 10?..

Comment: @AndreïKostyrka Because Dennis

Comment: Is there an encoding where `⁵` is just one byte? Since it's 3 bytes in UTF-8, the length of the program should be 4 bytes.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík Jelly uses its own codepage

Answer (score 21):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

Code:

```
TL
```

Explanation:

```
T   # Constant for 10
 L  # Range
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=VEw&input=).

Comment: When I saw this, I felt the need to say "tl;dr". :P +1, by the way.

Answer (score 21):

## Brainfuck, 58 bytes

```
-[----->+>+<<]>--<+++++[<++<++>>-]<<-[->>>.+<<.<]>>>>--.-.
```

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LVstLS0tLT4rPis8PF0-LS08KysrKytbPCsrPCsrPj4tXTw8LVstPj4-Lis8PC48XT4-Pj4tLS4tLg&input=)

Comment: Beat me to it, and shorter too, will post mine anyway as I don't think we've used the same trick. Have my +1 :)

Comment: I was close with 67 bytes, but not close enough: `++++++[>++++++++<-]>>>++++++++++[-<+<<+>>>]<[-<.+<.>>]<<-[>-<-]>.-.`

Answer (score 18):

## LOLCODE, 79 bytes

```
IM IN YR l UPPIN YR v TIL BOTH SAEM v AN 10
VISIBLE SUM OF v AN 1
IM OUTTA YR l
```

This code may need some tweaking depending on the compiler you're using. Some want you to add HAI/KTHXBYE, some want you to declare the variable ahead of time. One compiler breaks if your loop name is shorter than two characters, even though the loop name is never used.

Answer (score 15):

## CJam, <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
A,:)`
```

1 byte saved thanks to [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)

Output: `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`

Explaination:

```
A,      e# Push a list from 0 to 9.
  :)    e# Increment all values.
    `   e# Stringify the list.
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=QSw6KWA&input=)

Comment: i like the smileyface. (Isn't there an error in your explanation: A, creates a list from 0 to 9)

Answer (score 15):

## R, 4 bytes

```
2:10
```

The ":" is probably one of the most used R commands. Improvement by Barranka in comments.

Comment: Should they require printing a string, not returning a vector, consider `cat(1:10)`.

Comment: Is there a leading whitespace?

Comment: Given that the output is `[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10`, maybe it would be better `2:10`, which will output `[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10`

Comment: @Clashsoft, that was a mistake - thank you. And yes, Barranka, good point - upvoted.

Comment: Uh?! The requirement is "Print all Integers from 1 to 10", not from 2.

Comment: Come on, Prof. Robert, read the comment by Barranka :-)

Answer (score 14):

## Ruby, 8 bytes

Separated by newlines.

```
p *1..10
```

Comment: *Separated by newlines.

Comment: You can do that?

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev yes, the star causes the code to break down to `p 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` and commas cause `p` to separate them by newlines.

Comment: OK. I didn't think that the operator has a lower precedence than range.

Answer (score 13):

### JavaScript (ES6), 29 bytes

```
alert([...`${1e11/81^14}`]+0)
```

Outputs `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`. Not the shortest answer but I thought it was a fun calculation.

Comment: why not `alert([...'1'+234567891]+0)`

Comment: @edc65 a) it's not as fun b) it's not as short as the previously posted JavaScript answer c) it's not even as short as `alert([...'1234567891']+0)`.

Answer (score 12):

## Pyth, 2 bytes

```
ST
```

First time I've used a golfing lang to answer!

Explanation:

```
S    1-indexed range. [1, 2, ... A].
 T   Variable. Initialized to 10. (Ten)
     Implicitly printed.
```

Comment: Ninja'd by seconds :/

Answer (score 12):

### Brainfuck, 41 bytes

```
+[[-<]>->>->-<-]<<[-<<+<<.+>>>>>.<]<<+.-.
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

[Try it online](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=K1tbLTxdPi0-Pi0-LTwtXTw8Wy08PCs8PC4rPj4-Pj4uPF08PCsuLS4).

Comment: Nice! – – – – –

Answer (score 11):

### Mathematica - 13 bytes

```
Echo@Range@10
```

Saved 4 bytes thanks to [MartinEnder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)!

Output: `>> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`

Answer (score 11):

## Actually, 9 Bytes

```
19`;1+`na
```

[Try it here!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=MTlgOzErYG5h&input=)

Explanation:

```
19`;1+`na

1           Push 1 to stack
 9          Push 9 to stack
  `;1+`     Push Function inside ` to stack
   ;        Push top element to stack
    1+      Add 1 to top element
       n    Run function x times (9 times)
        a   Invert stack
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf!

Answer (score 10):

## [DC](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Dc), 12 bytes

...a little bit mean now...

```
[zzpA>L]dsLx
```

Unrolled:

```
[   # start string constant
z   # push stack length (0 on 1st cycle)
z   # push stack length (1 on 1st cycle)
p   # print top of stack
A>L # if 10(decimal) < tos: execute L
]   # end string constant, push it
d   # duplicate the string
sL  # store a copy in L
x   # execute tos (which is the other string copy)
```

One of the `z` (push stack length) operations has no corresponding operation which takes it from the stack. This way the stack grows with each iteration by one. This is abused as the loop counter.

This loop starts with an empty stack, so the 1st `z` pushes `0` in the 1st iteration so the printing happens after the 2nd `z` which correspond to duplicating the result of `1+d` in the version below. This way the comparison needs to test for bigger than `10` here instead of `bigger than 11` below.

---

## [DC](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Dc), 14 bytes

Just straight forward...

```
1[p1+dB>L]dsLx
```

Unrolled:

```
1   # push 1
[   # start string constant
p   # print top of stack
1+  # add 1 to tos
d   # push tos (duplicate)
B>L # if 11(decimal) < tos: execute L
]   # end string constant, push it
d   # duplicate the string
sL  # store a copy in L
x   # execute tos (which is the other string copy)
```

Comment: I wish you'd explain these =(

Comment: @EvanCarroll — Writing `dc` programs is easier than explaining. But I tried... ;-)

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
10:
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MTA6&input=)

The code generates the vector `[1 2 ... 10]` and implicitly displays it, with the numbers separated by spaces.

Answer (score 9):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 13 bytes

```
01+:a)?;:nao!
```

Explanation :

```
01+:a)?;:nao!

0                 push initial value of n on the stack
 1+               increments n
   :              duplicates n on the stack
    a             push 10 on the stack
     )            pops n and 10 of the stack, push n>10 on the stack
      ?;          if n>10, stops program execution
        :n        duplicates n on the stack in order to display it
          ao      display 10 (x0A, linefeed)
            !     skips the next instruction, which since ><> loops is the push 0
```

You can see it in action on the [online interpreter](https://fishlanguage.com/playground).

Comment: Could you please add an explanation?

Comment: Run the program nao!

Comment: @Cyoce ><> is great to write enthusiastic pieces of code, I've got this [motorcycle gear checker answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111041/motorcycle-gear-checker/111144#111144) in the same vein ;)

Answer (score 8):

## Perl 6, 12 bytes

```
say @(1..10)
```

The `@()` is needed to convert to an array

Alternative solution:

```
say @(^10+1)
```

Builds a range [0,10) then adds one, then converts to an array.

Comment: For Perl 5.10, 14 bytes and almost like yours: `say for(1..10)`

Comment: @PaulPicard do post it! Perl 5 is a different language.

Comment: Can you remove the space for `say@(1..10)`?

Comment: @Cyoce alas no, it's an error.

Comment: 10 bytes: `say 1...10`

Answer (score 8):

### PowerShell, 5 bytes

```
1..10
```

Creates a dynamic range with the `..` operator from `1` to `10`, then that array is left on the pipeline. Output is implicit. Default `.ToString()` method of an array is newline, so this will be newline-separated when run in a clean shell.

Answer (score 8):

## Vim, 12 bytes

```
i1<Esc>qqYp<C-a>q8@q
```

Outputs

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Explanation:

```
i1<Esc>qqYp<C-a>q8@qZZ
       qqYp<C-a>q      -- Macro q: duplicate line and increment (6)
i1<Esc>                -- Insert 1 (3)
                 8@q   -- Run macro q 8 times (3)
```

Tested on Neovim 0.1.4, which to my knowledge is keystroke-compatible with Vim.

Comment: Nice. I came up with `iYp<C-v><C-a>1<Esc>d^9@-ZZ`. Same byte count.

Comment: [Shorter](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100102/31716). :)

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell, 17 bytes

```
main=print[1..10]
```

Outputs `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here... I'm almost certain that it should be `[1..10]`. I don't have access to a haskell compiler, but I'll double-check in the morning.

Comment: @Zwei Ranges don't include their upper limit in Haskell.

Comment: @C.Quilley They totally do. You might be thinking of Python.

Comment: Huh, I was sure I had tested this code. Apologies for the earlier assertion.

Comment: I don't think you need the main= part; the rest has the type of a haskell program, IO (). Correct me if there is a specific ruling against this.

Comment: @Lazersmoke True, you could save `5` bytes. (Others, see [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11935/48198) if not sure)

Answer (score 7):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 3 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```
⍳10
```

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u237310&run)

Comment: too long.........

Answer (score 7):

## J, 6 bytes

```
1+i.10
```

Output: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Explaination:

```
1+       NB. Add one to...
  i.10   NB. A range from 0 to 9.
```

Comment: My thought was `>:i.10`, but that's the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

## [MarioLANG](https://github.com/tomsmeding/MarioLANG), <s>34</s> <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
+<
:"
+
:
+
:
+
:
+
:!
=#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL//9f24bLSolLm8sKGSty2Sr//w8A)

Thanks to Jo King for <s>-7</s> -9 bytes!

code:

Mario falls down, incrementing and saying his number five times,
then he steps on the elevator, rides up and falls down again,
incrementing and saying his number another five times.
Then he walks left and falls out of the code.

14 bytes shorter than the easy way:

39 bytes

```
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
==================:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL//9f2woDctliAKv//wE)

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes you just can't see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 6):

## Java 7, <s>53</s> <s>51</s> 52 bytes (loop)

```
void l(){for(int i=0;++i<11;)System.out.println(i);}
```

Alternative **51 bytes** (hardcoded is shorter.., but considered a [default loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/1063#1063), so not allowed):

```
void h(){System.out.print("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10");}
```

Alternative **54 bytes** (recursive):

```
int i=1;void r(){System.out.println(i);if(i++<10)r();}
```

**Ungolfed & test code for all three:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/d87Zic)

```
class Main{
  static void h(){
    System.out.print("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10");
  }      

  static void l(){
    for(int i=0; ++i < 11;){
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }

  static int i = 1;
  static void r(){
    System.out.println(i);
    if(i++ < 10){
      r();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    h();
    System.out.println();
    l();
    System.out.println();
    r();
  }
}
```

---

EDIT: For funsies: As correctly pointed out by *@SkippyLeGrandGourou*, the base of the 1 to 10 isn't specified in the question, so here is (non-code-golfed) Java code that outputs 1 to 10 in the bases 2 to 10:

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/lgTRM9)

```
BASE-2: 1 10 
BASE-3: 1 2 10 
BASE-4: 1 2 3 10 
BASE-5: 1 2 3 4 10 
BASE-6: 1 2 3 4 5 10 
BASE-7: 1 2 3 4 5 6 10 
BASE-8: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10 
BASE-9: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 
BASE-10: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Loop can be `for(int i=1;i<11;)System.out.println(i++)`, saves one byte.

Comment: @zyabin101 Changed the order so the hard-coded answer is non-competing. Still left it in the answer though, since it's pretty funny (and sad) that hard-coded is the shortest way to print 1-10 in Java 7..

Comment: @zyabin101 Except when the question is tagged [tag:kolmogorov-complexity].

Comment: @Neil Oh, right. o_o

Comment: Java 8's the clear winner here thanks to lambdas! `()->java.util.stream.IntStream.range(1,11).forEach(System.out::println)`. Why you say it's longer? It's Java 8... Java 8 is shorter by default! I didn't even put braces before and after the code! I can even count to 98 without getting an extra character! See? Java 8 rules!

Answer (score 6):

## Fuzzy Octo Guacamole, 7 bytes

```
1.25*$:
```

Multiplies `2*5`, takes the range of that and `1`, and prints the whole stack.

```
1.25*$:
1.      # Push 1 to the stack and switch stacks
  25*   # Push 10 to the stack
     $  # Push every number in the inclusive range on the top of inactive stack and top of active stack ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
      : # Print the stack, which is a list containing the numbers.
```

Answer (score 6):

## PostScript, 12 bytes

```
1 1 10{=}for
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

(Most PostScript interpreters don't actually have a proper stdout, or even a command line, but GhostScript has both and can be used to run this program.)

Answer (score 6):

## [Aussie++](https://github.com/zackradisic/aussieplusplus/), output to STDERR, <s>29</s> 28 bytes

It turns out that causing errors is shorter than any straightforward way of doing it.

```
G'DAY MATE! 1 2

4

6

8

_
```

Tested in commit 9522366. The trailing newline is required. Produces the following errors:

```
[line 1] OI MATE! EXPECTED ; BUT GOT '2'
[line 3] OI MATE! EXPECTED ; BUT GOT '4'
[line 5] OI MATE! EXPECTED ; BUT GOT '6'
[line 7] OI MATE! EXPECTED ; BUT GOT '8'
[line 9] OI MATE! EXPECTED ; BUT GOT '_'
[line 10] OI MATE! EXPECTED ; BUT GOT 'EOF'
```

Maybe I misinterpreted the challenge, but it didn't specify that you had to use the same separator for all numbers.

### Aussie++, output to STDERR with consistent separator, 30 bytes

```
G'DAY MATE!;
;
;
;
;
;
;
;
;
;
```

No trailing newline is required. Produces the following errors:

```
[line 1] EXPECTED NUMBER, STRING, BOOLEAN, NIL, OR IDENTIFIER BUT GOT ';'
[line 2] EXPECTED NUMBER, STRING, BOOLEAN, NIL, OR IDENTIFIER BUT GOT ';'
[line 3] EXPECTED NUMBER, STRING, BOOLEAN, NIL, OR IDENTIFIER BUT GOT ';'
[line 4] EXPECTED NUMBER, STRING, BOOLEAN, NIL, OR IDENTIFIER BUT GOT ';'
[line 5] EXPECTED NUMBER, STRING, BOOLEAN, NIL, OR IDENTIFIER BUT GOT ';'
[line 6] EXPECTED NUMBER, STRING, BOOLEAN, NIL, OR IDENTIFIER BUT GOT ';'
[line 7] EXPECTED NUMBER, STRING, BOOLEAN, NIL, OR IDENTIFIER BUT GOT ';'
[line 8] EXPECTED NUMBER, STRING, BOOLEAN, NIL, OR IDENTIFIER BUT GOT ';'
[line 9] EXPECTED NUMBER, STRING, BOOLEAN, NIL, OR IDENTIFIER BUT GOT ';'
[line 10] EXPECTED NUMBER, STRING, BOOLEAN, NIL, OR IDENTIFIER BUT GOT ';'
```

### Aussie++, output to STDOUT, 41 bytes

```
G'DAY MATE!
GIMME "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";
```

Again, no trailing newline is required.

Answer (score 5):

### Python2 - <strike>19</strike> 17 bytes

```
print range(1,11)
```

Saved 1 byte, thanks to [KevinLau - not Kenny](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/kevin-lau-not-kenny)!

Output: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

Comment: Use `range` instead of `xrange`, assuming Python 2. In fact, this current version doesn't seem to work on my machine in either Python version.

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny I could've sworn that I tried that, and got nothing to STDOUT. Thanks!

Comment: Important: It's only Python 2

Comment: @MegaMan You're right. I just felt leaving it out, since almost every other Python2 answer does that. I'll edit the title.

Comment: Please see [my first answer on the site](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86430/34642), it is in Python3 :D

Comment: @ABcDexter I checked it out, very nice! The reason I didn't use Python3, was because I was forced to cast the `range` object that returns an iterator, to a list.

Comment: @TuukkaX Yes, exactly. I'll try some other languages too. Thanks :).

Comment: @TuukkaX: You don't need to cast, but it would be a titch longer in Py3: `print(*range(1,11))`

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yup, my bad. ABcDexter already submitted that Py3 snippet :P

Answer (score 5):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 13 bytes

I've got two solutions at this byte count, but it doesn't seem optimal:

```
_10$*
1
$.`_
```

```
11$*_
\B
$.`
```

They both use `_` as separators, prefix and suffix.

[Try the first online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=Cl8xMCQqCjEKJC5gXw&input=) [Or try the other one!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=CjExJCpfClxCCiQuYA&input=)

Answer (score 5):

## [Sesos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/sesos) (binary), 5 bytes

Hexdump:

```
0000000: 2c4bbc 3301                                       ,K.3.
```

[Try it online!](http://sesos.tryitonline.net/#code=c2V0IG51bW91dAphZGQgMTAKam1wCmZ3ZCAxCmFkZCAxCnB1dApyd2QgMQpzdWIgMQ&input=&debug=on)

#### How it works

The binary file above has been generated by assembling the following SASM code.

Sesos is a language "based on [brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck)", but is "concise, can be typed easily, has somewhat flexible I/O, and is safe for work".

```lisp
set numout    ;sets the output to printing a number per line,
              ;instead of characters.
add 10        ;now the tape is [10,0,...]
jmp           ;start of loop
              ;sets an entry marker and jump to the jnz instruction.
    fwd 1          ;forward the data head 
    add 1          ;add 1 to the cell under data head
    put            ;output (as number)
    rwd 1          ;rewind the data head by 1 cellby 1 cell
    sub 1          ;subtract 1 from the cell under data head
                   ;the tape goes from [0,10] to [1,9], to [2,8]
                   ;to ... [8,2] to [9,1] to [10,0] and then halts.
              ;(implicit jnz) end of loop, goto "jmp" if not zero
```

In brainfuck: `++++++++++[>+.<-]` (assuming decimal output).

Answer (score 5):

### PHP, <s>25</s> 23 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to manatwork.*

```
 <?=join(_,range(1,10));
```

Creates an array of [1 .. 10] and echoes the values separated by `_`s.

Comment: You could take advantage of the freedom to choose the separator. Using “_” as [Martin Ender](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)'s [Retina solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86097) does would reduce the length by 2. (At the obvious price of an undefined constant notice, which is fine as PHP's suggested production configuration not displays notices anyway.)

Comment: @manatwork: That is very strange, I had no idea that was even possible. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Same length: `for(;$i++<10;)echo$i,_;`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: That's longer because it requires the full `<?php` and not just `<?=`

Comment: @BusinessCat Not exactly. It is meant to be executed using the `-r` argument. And [the `-r` argument is free](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2428/14732)

Comment: Short open tags are still valid and still `on` by default; they only [removed `<%`, `<%=` and `<script language="php">` in php 7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_alternative_php_tags). `Your output format can be whatever your language supports.` --> `print_r(range(1,10));` is two bytes shorter with `-r`

Comment: @Titus: I avoided using print_r or var_dump because I wasn't sure if it was allowed. I know it says any arbitrary separator, but those functions will print extra numbers (the keys of the array) which may be against the rules of the challenge.

Comment: True. and the `join(_` is prettier anyway; just keep it like that. But let me add two variations of Ismael´s idea: `while($i<10)echo++$i,_;` and `while(++$i%11)echo$i,_;` (same length, but with `-r`)

Comment: Question answered: challenge edited to `you may not output any other numbers`. Never mind, this is nice.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
for(i=1;i<11;)alert(i++)
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I think you can save a byte by doing `alert(i++)` (and removing the other `i++`).

Comment: Too bad the question stipulates that the order must be ascending, otherwise you could've saved a byte by using a decrementing while loop instead of the for loop like so `i=10;while(i)alert(i--)`.

Comment: Doesn't the code have to be embedded in a function?

Comment: @ericw31415 https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/56627

Answer (score 5):

## MATLAB/Octave, 4 bytes

`1:10`

Simply prints the numbers 1 through 10 as a vector, with spaces separating them (may have newline if your window is not wide enough)

Comment: Does it matter that this also outputs `ans = `? You may need to wrap it in a `disp`

Comment: @Suever no, I don't think so. "Your output format can be whatever your language supports. This includes arbitrary separators (commas, semicolons, newlines, combinations of those, etc., but no digits), prefixes and postfixes (like [...]). However, you may not output any other numbers." There are no extra digits or numbers.

Answer (score 5):

### Plain TeX (58 bytes)

```
\newcount\c\loop\advance\c1 \the\c\ \ifnum\c<10\repeat\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## ><> (Fish) 10 bytes

```
1l:naoa=?;
```

This is my first submission and I know their is already a Fish answer but I don't have the reputation to comment.

The main difference is using the l to place the length of the stack onto the stack allowing us to bypass 'adding one' saving a byte.

Using l also means we don't need to preserve the stack value (just the length) so we do not need to duplicate the top of the stack to preserve our values, saving another 2 bytes (one for the duplication of the stack value and another as we do not need to skip any instructions for preserving the stack).

Answer (score 4):

## Groovy, 11 characters

```groovy
print 1..10
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ groovy -e 'print 1..10'
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 12 bytes

```
show([1:10])
```

In Julia, `x:y` is a range, inclusive.  To cast to a list you need to put brackets around it. Otherwise it will just print the literal characters `1:10`.

1 byte saved due to @Dennis. Turns out `show` works the same as `print` in this case.

Comment: `show([1:10])` is *12* bytes, not 13. That needs to be fixed in the header.

Answer (score 4):

## Atari Basic, 29 Bytes

```
1 for i=1 to 10
2 ? i
3 next i
```

Comment: `1 for i=1 to 10:? i:next` is probably more concise? I'm certain that Atari BASIC allows multi-statemented lines

Comment: Also if Atari BASIC is similar to Commodore (Microsoft) BASIC, you won't need to say `next i` - simply `next`

Answer (score 4):

## BrainFuck, 55 Bytes

```
+++++++++>-->-[-----<+>]+++++++++[-<.+<.>>]<<[->-<]>.-.
```

Output:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
```

(Indents as seperators)

Try it here:

https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#KysrKysrKysrPi0tPi1bLS0tLS08Kz5dKysrKysrKysrWy08Lis8Lj4+XTw8Wy0+LTxdPi4tLg==

Answer (score 4):

## , 7 bytes

```
⩤ 1,Ⅹ
```

Prints out

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Implicit print, `Ⅹ` is 10 and `⩤` is `range(a, b)` so the overall pseudocode is `stdout.write(range(1, 10))`

*Note that, while it is only 5 characters, it still takes up 7 bytes, this is due to the `Ⅹ` and the `⩤` not being ASCII characters. (Ⅹ is the Roman numeral version)*

Comment: O my god, another ESMin golfer! Yay! Also, `⩤⁽1Ḋ` is 4 chars/7 bytes (`Ḋ` is the variable for 10, and `⁽` groups numbers/variables into arguments).

Comment: @MamaFunRoll Yeah, ESMin is awesome! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

## T-SQL, <strike>53</strike> 46 Bytes

Saved 7 bytes thanks to @t-clausen.dk

```
DECLARE @ INT=1z:PRINT @ SET @+=1IF @<11GOTO z
```

Also 17 bytes (though it feels like cheating):

```
PRINT 12345678910
```

Comment: Can be done easier, here are 2 examples - [fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/530339)

Answer (score 4):

### Morse code, 65 bytes

```
.---- ..--- ...-- ....- ..... -.... --... ---.. ----. .----- ----
```

Copy and paste here to try it out (and listen to the code): http://morsecode.scphillips.com/translator.html

Answer (score 4):

### Hexagony, 31 bytes

```
<8!~\\\..)\M\~={{'$;$@.......9$
```

[Try it Online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=ICAgPCA4ICEgfgogIFwgXCBcIC4gLgogKSBcIE0gXCB-ID0KeyB7ICcgJCA7ICQgQAogLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAuIDkgJCAuIC4KICAgLiAuIC4gLg&input=)

Still feeling that there are too many no-ops.  Had a 34 bytes first draft:

```
<{."@;.)!.8.{{..M.\\.\'.$(...0=..1
```

#### Expanded 31 bytes solution

```
   < 8 ! ~
  \ \ \ . .
 ) \ M \ ~ =
{ { ' $ ; $ @
 . . . . . .
  . 9 $ . .
   . . . .
```

As in the first draft, uses a `<` to deflect the IP to NW direction.

This trick is found to be quite useful (for me) when the ending path is short enough after a loop.

Instead of using `10`, I used `9` and negate it so the loop is still running 10 times (`-9 -8 ... 0` all to the "Left" branch).

Although I managed to increase the number of no-ops in the main loop (NW), I can't modify the main loop due to positioning concerns... *Maybe* easier to golf off more bytes without using the negation trick.

And though I very much like re-using ops, this time I left a lot of no-ops and used a lot of `$` skip commands to keep the loop running.

Oh I really *love* this language!

Answer (score 4):

## Vim, 9 keystrokes

I saw that there was already a [vim answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86252/31716), but it's not the shortest, so I thought I'd post the shortest one for completeness sake.

```
10O0<esc>v{g<C-a>
```

This only works in vim 8, or later versions of vim 7.4.

Explanation:

```
10                  " Ten times:
  O                 " Open a newline
   0<esc>           " And insert a 0
         v{         " Visually select everything
           g<C-a>   " And create an increasing sequence
```

Comment: huh. Didn't know about the g<C-a> trick. GG.

Answer (score 4):

### Brainfuck, 53 bytes

```
++++++++[->++++++>+>++++<<<]>>+[-<+.>>.<]<--------.-.
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwqide0gDDttMMPGxibWzg4obKOtZ2enZxNrowsFerp6//8DAA "brainfuck – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Brian & Chuck](https://github.com/m-ender/brian-chuck), 17 bytes

```
1	1{?
!{.+>-?>.-.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyrKTMzTTc4oTc7@/9@Q07DankuxWk/bTtfeTk9X7/9/AA)

**code:**

```
Brian:
1   1   ("1", 9, "1") constants
{?      restart Chuck's code

Chuck:  
{       Move Brian to the leftmost character
.+      Print and increment character
>-      decrement counter
?       if counter is greater than zero, switch to Brian (restart Chuck's code)
>.-.    print 10
```

Answer (score 4):

## RUBY, <s>24 bytes</s> 18 bytes

```
n=0;10.times{puts n+=1}
```

thanks to [@A_](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85052/a)

```
10.times{|n|p n+1}
```

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/39BAryQzN7W4uiavpkAhT9uw9v9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## Excel 6 bytes

`=ROW(`

Select the cells A1:A10, type the above (once only) and ctrl-shift-enter as an array formula (which links the cells in an array, with one common formula).

Note the total lack of numerals entered in this process. :-)

[image]

Comment: Not sure this is allowed. It requires a specific state (A1:A10 selected) and input (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

Comment: @Cyoce It doesn't require any numeric input. The range selection could potentially be specified with `f5` `A1:A10` `enter` which would be 8 more keystrokes.

Answer (score 3):

## Elixir, 18 bytes

```
for n<-1..10,do: n
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Note: This is using `iex`, the Elixir REPL.

Answer (score 3):

## [Whitespace](http://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php),

<s>71</s> bytes, thanks to [LeakyNun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun),

## 63 bytes, thanks to [Kevin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

Spaces substituted with `S`, tabs with `T`, linefeeds with `L`:

(extra spaces inserted for readability)

```
SSSTL LSSTL SLS TLST SSSTSTSL TLS SSSSTL TSSS SLS SSSTSTTL TSST LTSSL LSLTL
```

[Run it!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgZOLC0QocIEITpAAEHIB2QpgSZCIApgDFAdzwQRQE1DN//8A)

---

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: @LeakyNun Ok, i'll update the code. I used Notepad++ for the bytecount.

Comment: Yes, precisely. I've updated the edits you suggested :)

Comment: You can save a lot of bytes by changing the two labels to just one byte.

Comment: You can also remove the `LLL` at the end.

Comment: i.e. [here](http://ideone.com/1PbWuF): `SSSTL
LSSTL
SLS
TLST
SSSTSTSL
TLS
SSSSTL
TSSS
SLS
SSSTSTTL
TSST
LTSSL
LSLTL
LSSSL
LLL`

Comment: that would be 71 bytes

Comment: You can remove the exit and second label: `SSSTL LSSTL SLS TLST SSSTSTSL TLS SSSSTL TSSS SLS SSSTSTTL TSST LTSSL LSLTL`. It will exit with an error after it has outputted all 10 integers, but that's allowed [according to the meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/52210). [**Try it online (63 bytes).**](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgZOLC0QocIEITpAAEHIB2QpgSZCIApgDFAdzwQRQE1DN//8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [ShadyAsFuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ShadyAsFuck), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
PPPPPz_G]
```

This is basically `++++++++++[>+.<-]` in BrainFuck and outputs the numerical values as [character codes.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-the-form-of-byte-values/4719#4719)

[Try It Online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=KysrKysrKysrK1s-Ky48LV0&input=&debug=on)

Comment: Removing a byte: `PPPPPz_G]`

Answer (score 3):

### Stata,  40 bytes

```
loc i=1
wh `i'<11 {
di `i'
loc i=`i'+1
}
```

Output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! Do you need all the whitespace?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the whitespace is required, alas.

Comment: You can use a global (gl) instead of local. Then you access the variable with $i. That should save some bytes.
I'm happy to find another STATA user on PPCG!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 14 bytes

```
_=>12345678910
```

In the question, it doesn't say anywhere that you must use a delimiter. In fact, it says that I can use any output format that I want, so this answer is valid.

Answer (score 3):

## Sinclair ZX80 (4/8K ROM) or Sinclair ZX81/ZX Spectrum (27 tokenized BASIC bytes for the ZX80, 38 tokenized BASIC bytes for the ZX81)

```
 1 FOR I=1 TO 10
 2 PRINT I
 3 NEXT I
```

Or (direct mode, probably works on all 8-bit variants of BASIC):

```
 PRINT 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

### Sinclair ZX Spectrum (and other BASIC variants except the ZX80/ZX81):

```
 1 FOR I=1 TO 10:PRINT I:NEXT I
```

Simple, no?

Answer (score 3):

## x86 assembly (32-bit, Linux), 40 bytes

Prints out the numbers from 1 to 10, separated by newlines. The last number is not followed by a newline.

```
0: 31 db 43 89 d8 b4 0a 50 89 da 42 89 e1 c6 01 30
1: 00 01 50 8d 04 12 cd 80 58 40 3f 73 ee 66 c7 01
2: 31 30 30 e4 cd 80 48 cd 80
```

Ungolfed:

```
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
   2:   43                      inc    %ebx
   3:   89 d8                   mov    %ebx,%eax
   5:   b4 0a                   mov    $0xa,%ah
   7:   50                      push   %eax
   8:   89 da                   mov    %ebx,%edx
   a:   42                      inc    %edx

0000000b <loop>:                                                                                     
   b:   89 e1                   mov    %esp,%ecx                                                     
   d:   c6 01 30                movb   $0x30,(%ecx)                                                  
  10:   00 01                   add    %al,(%ecx)                                                    
  12:   50                      push   %eax                                                          
  13:   8d 04 12                lea    (%edx,%edx,1),%eax                                            
  16:   cd 80                   int    $0x80                                                         
  18:   58                      pop    %eax                                                          
  19:   40                      inc    %eax                                                          
  1a:   3f                      aas                                                                  
  1b:   73 ee                   jae    b <loop>                                                      

0000001d <end>:                                                                                      
  1d:   66 c7 01 31 30          movw   $0x3031,(%ecx)                                                
  22:   30 e4                   xor    %ah,%ah
  24:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
  26:   48                      dec    %eax
  27:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

The most notable part of the optimization is the `aas` instruction, which checks if `%al` is 10 or above, and, if it is, sets the carry flag, and decrements `%al` by 6. It is meant to be used to adjust for subtraction—you might find the corresponding `aaa`, which *adds* 6 instead, used in a real program here. I have instead made use of it because subtracting 6 gets me 4, which is exactly the number I need for another `write` syscall—saving me another `lea` instruction.

Answer (score 3):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <s>61</s> 59 bytes

```
[S S S T    N
_Push_1][N
S S N
_Create_Label_0][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
S T _Print_integer][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   S T S N
_Push_10][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
S S _Print_char][S N
T   _Swap][T    S S T   _Subtract][N
T   T   S N
_Jump_to_Label_1_if_negative][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_0]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgZOLS0GBCwg5gQjMB5FAPogNhFApoAgnJ1gWKAQU4/r/HwA)

**Explanation:**

```
Command    Explanation                 Stack          STDOUT    STDERR

SSSTN      Push 1                      [1]
NSSN       Create Label_LOOP           [1]
 SNS        Duplicate (1)              [1,1]
 TNST       Print as integer           [1]            1
 SSSTN      Push 1                     [1,1]
 TSSS       Add (1+1)                  [2]
 SNS        Duplicate (2)              [2,2]
 SSSTSTSN   Push 10                    [2,2,10]
 SNS        Duplicate (10)             [2,2,10,10]    
 TNSS       Print as character         [2,2,10]       \n
 SNT        Swap top two               [2,10,2]
 TSST       Subtract (10-2)            [2,8]
 NTTSN      Jump to Label_1 if neg.    [2]
 NSNN       Jump to Label_LOOP         [2]
 
 SNS        Duplicate (2)              [2,2]
 TNST       Print as integer           [2]             2
 SSSTN      Push 1                     [2,1]
 TSSS       Add (2+1)                  [3]
 SNS        Duplicate (3)              [3,3]
 SSSTSTSN   Push 10                    [3,3,10]
 SNS        Duplicate (10)             [3,3,10,10]
 TNSS       Print as character         [3,3,10]        \n
 SNT        Swap top two               [3,10,3]
 TSST       Subtract (10-3)            [3,7]
 NTTSN      Jump to Label_1 if neg.    [3]
 NSNN       Jump to Label_LOOP         [3]

 ...

 SNS        Duplicate (9)              [9,9]
 TNST       Print as integer           [9]             9
 SSSTN      Push 1                     [9,1]
 TSSS       Add (9+1)                  [10]
 SNS        Duplicate (10)             [10,10]
 SSSTSTSN   Push 10                    [10,10,10]
 SNS        Duplicate (10)             [10,10,10,10]
 TNSS       Print as character         [10,10,10]      \n
 SNT        Swap top two               [10,10,10]
 TSST       Subtract (10-10)           [10,0]
 NTTSN      Jump to Label_1 if neg.    [10]
 NSNN       Jump to Label_LOOP         [10]

 SNS        Duplicate (10)             [10,10]
 TNST       Print as integer           [10]            10
 SSSTN      Push 1                     [10,1]
 TSSS       Add (10+1)                 [11]
 SNS        Duplicate (11)             [11,11]
 SSSTSTSN   Push 10                    [11,11,10]
 SNS        Duplicate (10)             [11,11,10,10]
 TNSS       Print as character         [11,11,10]      \n
 SNT        Swap top two               [11,10,11]
 TSST       Subtract (10-11)           [11,-1]
 NTTSN      Jump to Label_1 if neg.    [11]                     Label_1 not found error
```

Answer (score 3):

## [dotcomma](https://github.com/Radvylf/dotcomma), 67 bytes

```
[[[[[[[[[[.,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,]
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/dotcomma/?p=WyJbW1tbW1tbW1tbLixdWy5dLixdWy5dLixdWy5dLixdWy5dLixdWy5dLixdWy5dLixdWy5dLixdWy5dLixdWy5dLixdIiwiIiwwXQ)

A simple approach which nests `[[...][.].,]`, which adds one to and then pushes each number from one to ten. The "root" of this is `[.,]` which pushes one.

**Explanation:**

In dotcomma, dots and commas are the only operators. Their behaviors are extremely context dependent; `.` will be `1` when preceded `[`, or it can be used for adding, or it can be used in a loop, or a conditional.

In the case of `[.,]`, the `.` is a constant for `1`, and the `,` takes that and pushes it to the stack. After this, `[.]` is another `1` constant, wrapped in a block. The `.` after this takes the previous blocks, `[.,]` and `[.]`, and adds them. This results in `2`, which is pushed by `,`. This is nested with another `[.].,`, which continues up to `10`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 15 bytes

```
10 [1,b] stack.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeUmJeeWqxQUJRaUlJZUJSZV6Jg/d/QQCHaUCcpVqG4JDE5W@//fwA)

- `10 [1,b]` Create the range [1,10].
- `stack.` Prettyprint each element of a sequence.

Comment: The challenge spec is forgiving enough, so simply printing the array with `.` seems OK.

Comment: @Bubbler That's not an array. :)

Comment: Oh, my bad. So `stack.` is indeed the shortest way to (implicitly cast and) print it I guess.

Answer (score 3):

## [Piet](https://github.com/cincodenada/bertnase_npiet), 40 Codels

Original (10x4): [image: Original Image]

Scaled: [image: Scaled x20]

Code runs in a tight loop where the output is printed, followed by 32 ASCII. Previously printed number is compared to 9, and the output is used for both incrementing the counter and redirecting the code execution flow.
After 10 increments, the  code will get stuck in an infinite loop, performing invalid ops.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdI9ixRBEAbg3F/xosh5gUV1TfWXYKDsoWtwHKIgnoH9NSImCxoY@dfXmtmdPYysoGeannqmqrsP38ev45HP8QIpe4YOjeDOBa7YsKwsQ4dmTVD1AtDd7Rs6x/7t7v2jk@DM2L5/yFRw4rBNa8SUyjDjn0h0NsSM1k@ZNohm@6c6eI0J7EazsuJAF1s9Gfvdqw@/7fmHNmPa6vDtId15NMcOzjXBxNzsk7YaXxZhpZguhi7GLIygYm3nyJhEMkp1gsxdoCVnZImLgf5sf5DrxXhHdDgb3oy5pxl51Anec7bWfEMNlilZOrIGj1KaP/Xy0Yohun5O41JHMEOmUjBSCJDhK0K0KSd7Y3XWn8@2EJc9fUI00/03onuiG7rajGhGqNZxnseMkWtDn2ZLT1OHL8mmdVbEaVgvP7YjefnZhp@bkcxwxTJrkYjsfMJQEXSualucFq1XuNnFtZcr@kSPiXYrdTayGTWJh9VSkEINtjOXo@blrLwO09b78fRyOfY3t7vNKGaoBEaye/i/eP2Vjse/)

Answer (score 2):

## Dyvil, 20 bytes

```
for(x<-1..10)print x
```

### 21 bytes

```
for x<-1..10{print x}
```

Two ways to do the same thing: for-each loop over the range `1..10` with type-inferred loop variable `x`. The loop body calls the built-in `print(int)` function with the argument `x`.

---

### 22 bytes

```
print{for x<-1..10{x}}
```

This version calls the built-in `print(AutoPrinter.()->void)` method. An `AutoPrinter` instance is implicitly available to the `{for ...}` block, which is passed as an anonymous function. The `AutoPrinter` class has an `applyStatement(any)` method, which is called when an expression like `x` appears in a statement context. The implementation forwards to `print(any)`, which prints the expression.

---

### 24 bytes

```
(1..10).forEach(print _)
```

Functional approach; creates an `IntRange` object and calls its `forEach(int -> void)` (higher order) method. The argument is an anonymous lambda function that passes the argument to the aforementioned `print(int)` method. In this case, `print _` is syntactic sugar for the lambda expression `x => print x`. Again, the types are inferred by the compiler, so that it internally becomes `(int x) => print x`.

---

**Output in all cases:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

*Saved one byte thanks to @mat*

```
10yb.
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=MTB5Yi4&input=&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

```
10y        Get the list [0:1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10]
   b.      Output is that list minus the first element
```

Comment: 5 bytes: `10yb.`

Comment: @mat Thanks, I didn't thought of that, even though it's even simpler!

Answer (score 2):

### Lua, 25 Bytes

```
for i=1,10 do print(i)end
```

Answer (score 2):

## Julia 0.2, 11 bytes

```
print(1:10)
```

Pretty self explanatory. `1:10` is a range, and print expands it.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 5.10, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

Almost the same as Perl 6:

```
say for 1..10
```

I could've done something like `say"@{[1..10]}"` which is the exact same thing as in Perl 6, but it is too long. :p

Each number is outputted on a separate line.

Thanks to manatwork for saving 1 byte!

[Try it here!](https://ideone.com/jRlWtu)

Comment: No need for parenthesis around statement modifier's condition.

Comment: @manatwork Indeed, thanks!

Comment: OP says separators are ok but not required. I'd just use `say 1..10`

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 20 bytes

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Standard output is implicit outside of PHP tags when reading from a file or standard input.

I'm assuming that an empty separator does not meet the 'arbitrary separator' constraint.

Comment: Hardcoding the output is a [standard loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/1063#1063).

Comment: @Neil, except [tag:kolmogorov-complexity].

Answer (score 2):

### Brainfuck, 66 Bytes

Sadly, Someone found a [58 Bytes solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86099/41019), but as we both have different way of solving this, I'll post mine anyway.

```
+++[>+++>++<<-]>>+[>+++++++<-]>[>+>+<<-<+>]<--<[>>>.+<<.<-]>>>>.-.
```

Output: `1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10`

Here's what the tape looks like at each step, the `*` shows where the pointer lies.

```
+++[>+++>++<<-] tape (0*:9:6)cell-2: counter for printing;cell-3: used for ascii-value of 1
>>+[>+++++++<-] tape (0:9:0*:49) 49 is the ascii value of 1
>[>+>+<<-<+>]   tape (0:9:49:0*:49:49) duplicate it 3 times
<--<            tape (0:9*:47:0:49:49) one will be used as a delimiter "/"
[>>>.+<<.<-]    tape (0:0*:47:0:57:49) outputs the numbers 1..9 separated by "/"
>>>>.-.         tape (0:0:47:0:49:48) outputs 10
```

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 29 bytes

```
(dotimes(n 10)(print(+ n 1)))
```

Comment: Perhaps this would save 1 byte? `(dotimes(n 10)(print(1+ n)))`

Answer (score 2):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 9 bytes

```
[1|10:?a]
```

Explanation

```
[       ]  FOR <x> = ...NEXT; note that <x> becomes the symbol a-z, based on availability
 1|10      <x> goes from 1 to 10, an increment could be specified with ||
     :     End of FOR-loop specification
      ?a   Print the value of a
```

EDIT: A non-competing entry saves me <s>one byte</s> two bytes:

```
[q|z:?a
```

QBIC now supports variable params for FOR, and q through z are initialised in QBIC to represent 1-10, so saved a byte on the 10. Woohoo! Also, QBIC now detects any unclosed language constructs (IF/DO/FOR) at the end of a program and auto-closes 'm.

EDIT2: QBIC now has a variable number of parameters for its `FOR` loops. It by default assumes a loop from 1 to 10. Providing 1 parameter (`y`) makes it run from 1 to `y`, Providing 2 parameters (`x` and `y`) loops from `x` to `y`. Providing 3 parameters changes the interval: `FOR a = x TO y STEP z`. Using the defaults gives us this 4-byter:

```
[|?a
```

Answer (score 2):

### Convex, 3 bytes

```
A´`
```

[Try it online!](http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=QcK0YA&input=)

Answer (score 2):

### [Swift 3 (Jun 20, 2016)](http://swift.org), 20 bytes

```swift
print(Array(1...10))
```

[Try it online!](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57910ac86d5431d6544f35b6)

Just doing `print(1...10)` (un)surprisingly prints `1...10` to STDOUT, so we need to unwrap the Range object into an Array. A Set would be shorter, but does not guarantee order (and in practice doesn't, either).

Answer (score 2):

## Cheddar, 7 bytes

```
->1|>10
```

Prett simple. `|>` is range operator. `[0, 10]` is:

```
->|>10
```

Comment: What does `->` do? Also pretty*

Comment: @Cyoce `->` is a function with no arguments. Like `()=>` in JavaScript but in Cheddar if you have no args you can drop the parens

Answer (score 2):

### Python3 : <s>22</s> 19 bytes

```
print(*range(1,11))
```

---

[Output](http://ideone.com/TZPKIL):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: That output is not for that code. `range()` with a single parameter generates starting from 0.

Comment: @manatwork Oh, my bad. Updating it :)

Answer (score 2):

## [UGL](https://github.com/schas002/Unipants-Golfing-Language/blob/gh-pages/README.md), 20 bytes

```
cuuuuu$+$Rl$d:_lorO:
```

[Try it online!](http://schas002.github.io/Unipants-Golfing-Language/?code=Y3V1dXV1JCskUmwkZDpfbG9yTzo&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 37 Bytes

Minified:

```
........./..\..10$\("\.$...).>{<!@.._
```

[Try It Online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=Li4uLi4uLi4uLy4uXC4uMTAkXCgiXC4kLi4uKS4-ezwhQC4uXw&input=)

Layed Out:

```
   . . . .
  . . . . .
 / . . \ . .
1 0 $ \ ( " \
 . $ . . . )
  . > { < !
   @ . . _
```

Comment: The challenge isn't entirely clear about this, [but I think using no delimiter at all is not the OP's intention](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86075/print-numbers-from-1-to-10/89721#comment218842_86075).

Answer (score 2):

## Latex, 62 Bytes

```
\documentclass{book}\begin{document}12345678910\end{document}
```

Thanks [@egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)

Answer (score 2):

## R, 9 bytes

```
cat(1:10)
```

`cat` prints, `1:10` creates the numbers 1 to 10.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 30 bytes

```
((()()()()()){}){(({})[()])}{}
```

[Try it online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KCgoKSgpKCkoKSgpKXt9KXsoKHt9KVsoKV0pfXt9&input=)

#### Explanation

For a documentation of what each command does, see the [GitHub page](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak).

```
((()()()()()){}){(({})[()])}{}

((()()()()()){})                 push 10
                {(({})[()])}     while top != 0: pop top, push top, push top-1
                            {}   pop
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 47 bytes

```
()->{for(int i=0;i++<10;System.out.print(i));};
```

## Ungolfed test program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = () -> {
        for (int i = 0; i++ < 10; System.out.print(i));
    };

    r.run();
}
```

## 36 bytes + imports

```
()->IntStream.range(0,11).toArray();
```

Doesn't include imports :(

Answer (score 2):

### Emmet (HTML) - 6 bytes

You'll have to excuse me, I'm new to code golf but I think I understand the concept.

```
{$}*10
```

Output:

```
12345678910
```

Alternatively, if it's required for the numbers to be seperate, adding a `p` infront of the braces will put it into `<p>` tags, like so:

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
```

It also requires a tab to make it "go", I've left that out of the byte count.

Please let me know if I've stuffed up somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [TrumpScript](https://github.com/samshadwell/TrumpScript), 45 bytes

```
Say "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"!
America is great.
```

Don't even try using a loop... it's much much longer.

Edit: to clarify, TrumpScript uses only numbers greater than 1,000,000, so counting from 1 to 10 would require a lot of variables.

Answer (score 2):

## [Dip](https://github.com/mcparadip/Dip), 2 bytes

```
Tl
```

<sup>Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 16.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge-98, 9 bytes

```
1+:.:9`kq
```

Shortened from 11 thanks to a suggestion from ais523.

A step by step description:

```
1    push 1 to stack.
+    pop top two stack items and add them. push result.
     popping an empty stack returns 0, which is why
     this works the first loop around.
:    dup top.
.    print top of stack as integer.
     Funge-98 standard states that integer printing
     puts a space afterward automatically.
:    dup top.
9    push 9.
`    pop two items, first b then a.
     push 1 if a > b, else 0.
k    execute next char n times.
     n is top of stack.
     if n is 0, the next char is just skipped.
q    quit.
```

This program loops because Funge-98 lines wrap around.

### Old Versions

#### 11 bytes

```
1+:.:a\`!kq
```

Comment: The `not(10>TOS)` (`a\\`!`) calculation is taking up quite a lot of space here, and you might be able to shorten it. Wouldn't it be shorter to translate this simply as TOS>9 (`9\``)?

Comment: Right, that is a lot better! Down to 9 chars now.

Comment: My solution would have been [`a-:!k@b+:.`](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/P1HXSjHbIUnbSu//fwA) for 10 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 3 bytes

```
TR_
```

It's extremely simple:

```
T  % Push 10
R  % Generate range (1 to 10, including both endpoints)
_  % Output representation of stack (1 2 3 4 5..)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 (REPL): 17 Bytes

```
list(range(1,11))
```

Outputs a list of ints!

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/FVui/0)

Comment: Provide a reason for down voting please.  This meets the requirements of the challenge in less bytes than the other Python 3 example on here.  I would also love to have commented on that solution, but i need rep to do anything on here...

Comment: I did not downvote, but if you actually run this as a python program, it won't output anything; this only works in the REPL. I don't see that as a reason to downvote. though.

Answer (score 2):

## Commodore BASIC, method 1 (28 bytes)

```
0?1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

#### Method 2 (<strike>27</strike> 26 bytes)

```
0FORI=1TO10:?I:NEXT
```

#### Method 3 (<strike>40</strike> 39 bytes)

```
0I=1
1?I:I=I+1:IFI<11THEN1
```

#### Method 4 (<strike>32</strike> 31 bytes)

```
0?I:I=I+1:IFI<11THEN0
I=1:GOTO0
```

#### Method 5 (20 bytes)

```
0?"12345678910
```

#### Method 6 (25 bytes) CBM BASIC V2 only [C64/C64Mini or VIC-20]

```
0I=I+1:?I:ON-(I<10)GOTO
```

I'm working out the memory used with `? 38911-(fre(0)-65536*(fre(0)<0))` on a Commodore 64.

Answer (score 2):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 4 bytes

```rb
10.+
```

In J-uby, `n.+` is the same as `[*1..n]`.

Comment: So, what is J-uby? Is it like Ruby's analog of Pyth, combined with J or something like that?

Comment: @ZacharyT it's not like pyth. J-uby is an extension of ruby that gives it concise fictional programming features in the style of J. I'm now adding other methods as aliases to make it more suitable for code golfing. The most important principle is that any valid Ruby code is valid J-uby code.

Comment: (It's not fictional, it's functional). So it's just somewhat like the Babel ES6 transpiler, in the fact that it converts `J-uby` code to `Ruby`?

Comment: @ZacharyT auto correct is annoying. And since Ruby is awesome, you can just `require 'juby'` and then it is a j-uby program through metaprogramming.

Comment: Yeah, I love how you used Ruby's wacky language features to enhance it. I wonder what someone could do with Perl this way, considering you can define new operators?

Comment: @ZacharyT If I ever learn Perl I'll have to try that. It certainly is the authority on wacky language features.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 9 bytes

```
seq(I,I,1,10
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 23 bytes

```php
while($i<10)echo++$i,_;
```

prints a trailing delimiter, run with `-nr`.

or

```php
<?=join(_,range(1,10));
```

(already posted by [BusinessCat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53880) [a year ago](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86121))

or

```php
for(;$i++<10;)echo$i,_;
```

(by [Ismael Miguel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14732) in a comment to BusinessCat´s answer)

---

**21 bytes** without the delimiters: `while($i<10)echo++$i;` or `<?=join(range(1,10));`

**21 bytes** with native array output: `print_r(range(1,10));` (run with `-r`)

Comment: But the first one was already posted almost an year ago by [Business Cat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53880/business-cat) in his [PHP solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86121), where you also participated in the discussion… [confused smiley]

Comment: @manatwork True ... Didn´t find that when I browsed the answers. I added references.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 30 bytes

```
((()()()()()){}){(({})[()])}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0NDQxMGNatrNas1NIBktIZmrGZtde3//wA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Commercial](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/commercial), 649 bytes

```
A now 1 dollar off!
B now 1 dollar off!
A has been selling out worldwide!
A: made by the makers of B
A has been selling out worldwide!
A: made by the makers of B
A has been selling out worldwide!
A: made by the makers of B
A has been selling out worldwide!
A: made by the makers of B
A has been selling out worldwide!
A: made by the makers of B
A has been selling out worldwide!
A: made by the makers of B
A has been selling out worldwide!
A: made by the makers of B
A has been selling out worldwide!
A: made by the makers of B
A has been selling out worldwide!
A: made by the makers of B
A has been selling out worldwide!
A: made by the makers of B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7cvBDYAgEETRu1WMJXj1hp0ssihxYRPQEKtHCjCxAW@Tn3mrxsh5DSStGSStmOBUhDLU@3FYXprBTgWWOaGwSEgb9DpRNYurwXF/zIjkGPbGuXPfB@fSMZYf//gTt/YA)

I tried to do this in a loop, but Jumps in Commercial are weird and I couldn't get it to work properly

Answer (score 2):

## Fortran 95, 32 bytes

It was the only language I know that was not used yet :P

```
program o
print*,(i,i=1,10)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 16 bytes

```kotlin
print((1..9)+10)
```

### Beautified

```kotlin
print((1..9)+10)
```

### Test

```kotlin
fun f() =
print((1..9)+10)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    f()
}
```

### TIO

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM+8+VVpqnkKahqWD7v6AoM69EQ8NQT89SU9vQQBMil5uYmaeRWJRebKXgWFSUWGkTXAJUl26nqVDNpQAEQL1ctf8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 53 bytes

```
++++++++++[->+++++>+>+<<<]>-->-[-<+.>>.<]<--------.-.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGw6ide3AtB0Q2tjYxNrp6trpRuvaaOvZ2enZxNroQoGert7//wA)

**Explanation :**

```
++++++++++              # set initial counter to ten
[->+++++>+>+<<<]        # creates ascii cell, second counter, and newline
>-->-                   # fixes ascii and counter cell values
[-<+.>>.<]              # prints digits one through nine
<--------.-.            # prints the ten
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: It's not really different enough from the [previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156277/76162) for me to upvote, but I appreciate the explanation. Also, [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86457/76162) is much shorter

Comment: And welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg), 12 bytes

```
1(91+|:. ,1+
```

Output is separated by spaces

## How it works

```
1   Pushes 1
(   Begins for loop
91+|   For loop will run 10 times
:.     Output the top element of the stack
 ,     Output space
1+     Add one to the top element of the stack
End bracket gets added automaticly
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fUMPSULvGSk9Bx1D7/38A)

Comment: I am working on supporting \ in loop conditions as in [this](https://tio.run/##y05N///fUCOGq8ZKT0HHUPv/fwA) (1 byte less)

Comment: Oh yeah, I did try that and was wondering why that wasn't working, but I just compromised with `91+`

Comment: That isn't working because you can't escape a character in a for loop repetition indicator. If you read the implementation, you will find that the escaping character is simply skipped. (I just created a PR for it. JonoCode9374 will probably merge it.)

Comment: Whoops, there is an issue in my source code that [makes](https://tio.run/##y05N///fUIOrxkpPQcdQ@/9/AA) it in fact 2 bytes less. (A 1-to-10-printing program written using 10 bytes!)

Comment: Should we create a Keg chatroom to discuss new features and golfing?

Comment: Yes of course. I have created one, but no one chatted there. It is possibly because I created it too early.

Comment: I have [created](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86075/print-numbers-from-1-to-10/189669#189669) a solution that is 1 byte shorter. (I have neither an idea how I wrote my program nor how the program does the countup.)

Comment: Oh wow, thought mine was pretty optimal. Can you link me to that chatroom?

Comment: I can't find it anymore. It is probably frozen. You might want to create a chatroom yourself.

Comment: Ok, [done](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97278/keg)

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure REPL, 12 bytes

```
(range 1 11)
```

I think this is self explanatory code

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG. The challenge asks for a program to output to `stdout`, meaning you either need to add `println` or potentially declare your language as "Clojure REPL" per standard rules.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you

Answer (score 2):

## [Turing Machine Language](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), 199 bytes

```
0 * 1 r 1
1 _ _ r 2
2 * 2 r 3
3 _ _ r 4
4 * 3 r 5
5 _ _ r 6
6 * 4 r 7
7 _ _ r 8
8 * 5 r 9
9 _ _ r a
a * 6 r b
b _ _ r c
c * 7 r d
d _ _ r e
e * 8 r f
f _ _ r g
g * 9 r h
h _ _ r i
i * 1 r j
j * 0 r k
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?5db60fb3a75255c879d641e48c52f2f1/zrIAgi4i0wEpIsoxMi6yCIquotMRqaLKOTsusGbNswUIrrBWrbMNGq6wdu@zAQWusE6fswqXPN27WxPqM8Qc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Putt](https://github.com/ajmwagar/putt), 2 bytes

```
X:
```

```
X # Roman Numeral for 10
 : # Ranger operator pushes [1..N]
    # Putt implicitly prints
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Hexadecimal Stacking Pseudo-Assembly Language](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Hexadecimal-Stacking-Pseudo-Assembly-Language), 54 bytes

```
203039400000120000201A8540000012000020000A400000120000
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyguSMz5/9/IwNjA2NLEAAQMjUCkkYGho4UpqggQOCKL/P8PAA)

```
203039 input 0x3039 (decimal 12345)
400000 push that on stack
120000 print it
201A85 input 0x1A85 (decimal 6789)
400000 push that on stack
120000 print it
20000A input 0xA (decimal 10)
400000 push that on stack
120000 print it
```

Answer (score 2):

## BrainFuck, 41 Bytes

```
-[----->+>+<<]>---<++++[->+.+.<]>+.>--.-.
```

## Output

```
12345678910
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN1oXBOy07bRtbGLtgEwbbSCIBoroaesBRbT1gIJ6unr//wMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 50 bytes

```
1x1f1a1o2x1v0m9a1a1o1v0x1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f8s1o1s1o
```

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
1x1f                   # Function 1
    1a1o               # Add 1 to the register and output
        2x1v           # Store the new value in variable 1
            0m9a1a1o   # Output a newline
                    1v # Read variable 1 into the register
1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f     # Call function 1 nine times
8s1o                   # Subtract 8 and output
1s1o                   # Subtract 1 and output
```

Answer (score 2):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w), 2 bytes

```
Tk
```

Constant 10, then range from 1 to that. Added for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry), 38 bytes

```
<({<({})({}){}>}){}>{(<><<>()>{})}({})
```

#### Verification

```
$ ./flurry -inn -c "<({<({})({}){}>}){}>{(<><<>()>{})}({})"
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Since multiplication and exponentiation is much cheaper than increment, addition, and high number literals, 9 (being `3**2` or `3*3`) is much cheaper to produce than 10. Since producing 1 is almost free (via popping from empty stack), I push a 1 manually and then loop 9 times to push 2 through 10. Then the stack is printed in integer mode, from bottom to top.

```
<({<({})({}){}>}){}>  Number 9
<...>  Function composition (multiply numbers)
 (...)  Push and return the number inside...
  {<({})({}){}>}  The number literal 3
 {}     Pop 3 back
       evaluates to 3 * 3 = 9

{(<><<>()>{})}  Lambda function: Increment, push and return
{...}  Lambda, which implicitly pushes its argument
 (...)  Push and return the result of...
  <><<>()>  Increment
  {}        the argument

({})  Initial value 1, pushed to the stack

The entire program is roughly 9 (\x. push (succ x)) (push 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [dotcomma](https://github.com/Radvylf/dotcomma), 67 bytes

```
[[[[[[[[[[.,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,]
```

The shortest is the direct approach: Put a 1 on queue and then, nine times put the previous value plus 1 on the queue. Output implicitly.

```html
<script src="https://combinatronics.com/Radvylf/dotcomma/master/interpreter.js"></script><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script><script>$(document).ready(function () {$("#btnInterpret").click(function () {$("#txtResult").text(interpret($("#txtCode").val(), $("#txtInput").val(), $("#lstOutputAs").children("option:selected").val()));});});</script><style>.textBox {background-color: white;border: 1px solid black;font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace;width: 100%;}</style>Code: <textarea id="txtCode" type="text" class="textBox" style="height: 200px">[[[[[[[[[[.,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,][.].,]</textarea><br />Input: <textarea id="txtInput" type="text" class="textBox"></textarea><br /><input id="btnInterpret" type="button" value="Run" />Output as: <select id="lstOutputAs"><option value="">Number array</option><option value="true">String</option></select><br />Result:<br /><div id="txtResult" class="textBox" style="overflow-wrap: break-word"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Grok](https://github.com/AMiller42/Grok-Language), 13 bytes

```
}q
{p1+YzP9>!
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
₀ɾ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%80%C9%BE&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
₀   # 10
 ɾ  # Range [1, N]
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## BRASCA, 9 bytes

```
1lr,[nlo]
```

[Try it!](https://sjoerdpennings.github.io/brasca-online/?code=1lr%2C%5Bnlo%5D&stdin=)

## Explanation

```
1lr         - Push range(1,10) to the stack
   ,        - Reverse the stack
    [   ]   - While the stack isnt empty: 
     n      -   Output the next number...
      lo    -   and a newline!
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CSASM v2.4.0.2](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.4.0.2), 43 bytes

```
func main:
push [1..10]
conv ~arr
print
ret
end
```

Prints `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]` to the console.

**Explanation:**

```
func main:
    ; Push a Range
    push [1..10]
    ; Convert it to an array: [1..10] -> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
    conv ~arr
    ; Print the CSASM representation of that array
    print
    ret
    end
end
```

---

If the output had to *only* be the numbers 1 through 10, that would be this **72 byte** program:

```
func main:
lda 1
.lbl a
push $a
print.n
inc $a
push 11
push $a
sub
brtrue a
ret
end
```

**Explanation:**

````
func main:
    ; Store 1 into $a
    lda 1

    .lbl a
        ; Print $a
        push $a
        print.n

        ; Stop looping if 11 - ++$a == 0
        inc $a
        push 11
        push $a
        sub
        brtrue a
    ret
end
```
````

Answer (score 2):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 16 bytes

```
9{$:':</)!'/>;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/9@yWsVK3cpGX1NRXd/Ourb2/38A)

Expanded:

```
   9 { $
  : ' : <
 / ) ! ' /
  > ; } }
   . . .
```

Admittedly, this solution feels a bit questionable. Its output is

```
123456789	10
```

This is each number from 1 to 10, separated by the Unicode characters of their values. So, for example, 9 and 10 are separated by tab, which is Unicode character 9. Technically the problem doesn't specify that all the separators must be the same, though perhaps its implied. If you feel this is invalid, here's a 17 byte version that uses lowercase e as a separator (nothing special about e, it can be any character that isn't a special character in Hexagony).

```
9{.e:'<)!'://}};>
```

Here's another 17 byte alternate that prints the numbers separated by newlines, but never terminates (it prints 1 to 10 and then runs forever without printing anything else).

```
_10<>-<{)!'//=;{>
```

I'll just explain the 16 byte code because the others are just minor variations on it. Starting in the top left and moving right, `9}$` writes nine into a memory slot, then moves to an adjacent memory slot, and uses `$` to jump into the main loop on line 3. The main loop starts with `)!`, which increments the
value in the current memory slot and then prints its decimal value. This cell will cycle through the values 1 to 10, printing each. Then, `':` backs up to a new memory slot and divides 9 by the number that was just printed. Because Hexagony uses integer division, the result will be one as long as the number is less than or equal to 9, and 0 once its greater. This gives a termination condition, as another `':` backs into an empty slot and divides 0 by this number. As long as this value as 1 this calculation will be inconsequential, but when it equals zero, the program will crash trying to divide by zero. After this, `}};` moves back to the incrementing memory slot, prints it as a Unicode value, and then reenters the main loop.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! IMO "Your output format can be whatever your language supports. This includes arbitrary separators" means that this format is perfectly acceptable, but if you're really concerned, you can leave a comment below the question asking once you've reached 50 reputation. I've edited your answer to include the unprintable characters

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Ah cool, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 16 bytes

```c
;=w 0W>10wO=w+1w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltc9vIDf4s/Yq1MpZIikpI2p25kUR5kpyd8dSxc3bSfLDVmKZWNucoSiUp69zE/espgH3hUi9p097NRCR3H2CBZ7EA1hf37uP4@4ski9PlhA@LcpLMXz6MmuZImtzVhuLyacHXQHmS3deGymQmMBM@TTLO0pSl8@yefpp69OP5p/fMrz6vPl6yoPr82@tLdlh9npy/Zb9Un5efmF@BT86uDOz5pzMD@un8/eurv1qFzSz8abN/@X@x9ezrK1hWTMYPUc4cuxIwUWCrVjEascNq7vz4M05mMEkefWP4PhyuYXAZwqCbgElTG4E1zJuLizMC4c8ROdlH3wxDLt8JAMgbtj5G6ZLb9nU2tptN8gN25XrMQnbZOr44sb4PwhXzPo98b3URrrr@6rsNw62BwDoA5tEM0PAyaDZB9SLKC27Z7GuzkWQlSwbNBozSMi5zpssshhESjuG7nC3cYpFdB@Pwq@d6z6CjkYA6wsPTw4FXr1B9smCrh6TkxSKKebMB7ym3YBzELWGGy1o35U12M73J2dfn67Fl91@0bDKlkUyZpa0NWedFx2ZChRrdg9GbDIa7XTECdjZ4WnBz4FmYEz/w@Hc2necsW87ueF5Ie5iVFJPkPimVVlgd3fFd7ZF4Osz3WJc50vJu12Y91vE6sARamtgs5@Uyz5gKDCFGsTFYt@ExypPoLuXKCjAina94bsWwnjKEffvGlHExfcVExJeOLelJtriehL4LexTq4TXr8KjJkARINlkuLNxSJjntMfjaNFgc/EJoE2bcdDqVTa2O2DQQBg@0UQyUQKKAd7BsERUlKx84KIvyEsByAxzFKG5obKMnyljj/Ow0Fn59mza6UZFB5mPolsk8A7MxYj08I7FipFguFki4raJKjZj0m/EHtBtkow4VyosM4hiSFkautFyw8rGjT7YYOMEBTGB9TFxopgoyynnCVQvtRlOjNJ3H1qHn@jY6iMPaCXIwW6ZplD@Zjlb7c2lsz4eOtowWlPLLbE2alvBxCZkUtnl6/Obt7W97Z79eGP6aWu@SrWqDTbV7Nb3vTq92aCx5TiqjbML@sYzUJ6p9NJc42FxC@P@uo6k43UIFCR/WheuYZ8qU@TLDDRrIvOuU88JSqZLiHyK7TGJGs3fL6XVwOJZ2iH1uU3bQBhQLOFXl1AIo@L@fppOWSjtUd1xUsq4AzoRWICqaWL@GGzL/oO4nOo@heMRaZb7kLQhBPY4RCePTCBIITrQwsFoVCegn@i5LD9Hx5c18nsLMXZ2Bnb5Wbv3IIefnPTLNvNswM0Ubsz/VRgjacp6mlmmqyzwXCsT/YHK2YTIW4fevP5y7WIpFoMHn6bXveR6EE7gCn@qrSP7Jv5QMHwMjRg1vkQH4cvEnoN@D0FcVHRMcFnV80G8gHgcAODk9O3bYFHLjoKFDW66HWTiOFm7KM2oADK5UZyQ4g3O3i4x1QSxNWNmw3lgJtRJQiofExQBqSoKTOm/Es8XaDhBJybhKIUhTMsZlilVSxg@WA8xsNFLIUYz1CTJmX4nKRi@HjGPZbe@PKf6HuyuQHwAJNggb73mZQr9mtYnLNjKEFWqSZPbA0Ee9Z5ljDYOHTTVWaDsW2kRbhmcNOz/M@Uoa91RmpsqGN5W1Aq9n3lYzKIn/pMYKcwsY5Bp2N1zMFzyzjIXdVt6iOgxWhTNRhmC3w8A7/IXGZeW2RLmfgukTdAr6IwgIF5sngENhpi9cA5ZWm2fBIOuG1GfgeQCkLckEPbQWEYkanJAFZkNQ0Vh58ht4wv@AHgnP0oafe7U9paZ7D/PEBvBsY/NhlbTOiwH/tdOXTZiIo9BkWecVmd9b59RzWpjhbZXiR6NDu@raNpKNEr2izsvaL1DQDPhtwkAn9BXmupCn7FYFVROYvHmUSbW7CoSsCOYOyJMrWbioWMCwF7cKJE3sZ4061m7TTaXXQ@hY9JA31Ms2lFn7L50C7LHgy2bqIOWG@cuyULuvY0I0UsKgrjaIshBkI0x4GFrG9ohWtVHfbXHtQzQ01UzFUiD2HJtLOgxiAwiFw5gqQ@VlYG8P1Tgq1UO2dH63oslW76jLhlbPpWcpc4T0q7cRnUa0Yx9ct1cIOdXubGFhvfht4cHZ4EHs6zYWZltccwgTmkpIADK8RWUm7NzADQpBg16P9EmiqCCtb7RgtKyd/lc/JObVdmL2fyi0v13o78RmzSHRl9NYYHo5kLQL1kPW8zXLhAXqfThnPR/OmG@Cg59EDyE91rBhiFBat69GPEU5ER2MPMl1YFMz4ITEf3P9QNAkuQIdOCVYLDHwjg35A895p2DZHDrUJC2TjK2iJ@CNTeZw4Sv5Pc9BZjHPeFYmEfbocJLnbMXZQ/TIASgVIbxksyhbQvg8vcRR9O4OGQcqiIlimZZ4I6fFdcJTkJ6JUUuuUWbKaciaetS3G@ntNkTDhjWUR5ffKMXa@AReZ5OUT9htZfat1vIV30TbYyxSOTNCZb2e@rYJ3pBQxzD9WefBIQXrWuHDpFfLi2E9Kx4x8/APzWOAon35B602E4AjVmvDaNBlRjZEHZ6QVCU3EHUAsXshVBujCxrBocTQmk/mfTbjs3iBYZax0e3R/@vK6E9wZaRc2dviSyh9ka4c7WZfrLrFZJw@YjVAoBGBKqB72@ysPrR7KvOYCrR57Sr9oS/basORKSlTiZb/9t/IyxxkqNHyg07fRNfa3HVsWGXd@vRPXxNUb1vdExDXqN0VdCokDGochzVpI02iBCK6XS0mTP4M7ok/KZmNZs07ZvYuUuy03rUj1JA/CvoHBi3vxJUhNDqsrlmANu8dmbx4uPosHNQa2itB9JrSwXrJC7aVvANb9wGBlj6kwf/QEKFh@MStiHXzr9shszcKwENctetjk0QNgoh/MUkPQnTlSYDVJ3waQZIEz1SHmWQwmUzoTzRRXEKZ6uzHHew5ccRmO@6IqEzXQOgG5TV9FiUZNqssyu9jl5Q6Drw/2vjHILo94v8fsTyypn6Ne/7@bw)

```php
# set w to 0
; = w 0
# loop while w < 10
: WHILE > 10 w
   # Output ++w
   : OUTPUT (= w + 1 w)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Aõ
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QfU)

```
Aõ
A     :10
 õ    :Range [1,A]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)), <s>24</s> 19 bytes

```
print(*range(1,11))
```

Explanation:

```
       range(1,11)  # numbers 1 to 10
      *             # splat to print
print(            ) # print the numbers out
```

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 5.6, 18 bytes

```swift
print([_](1...10))
```

[SwiftFiddle link](https://swiftfiddle.com/vpi75u4xfrcgxgqjdme2yroriq), since TIO uses Swift 5.0.

Same method as [this Swift 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86172), but using a new syntax for type inference. `[Int]` is short for `Array<Int>`, and `Array<_>` means "an array, but infer the element type" (mostly the same as just `Array`). Therefore, `[_]` is short for `Array`. Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 24 bytes (3×9=27 codels)

```
utqrnFecnnneutMj?lkad mm
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJwlisEOgjAQRP9lztOEQUHsrzQcDNSEBJWkejL8O1Pd3cPsm_fF9JozYkodG57Z8kKdqOv_RiYZdKZ1nasmmQ_UwJ62eqr96arNSJS8ISKEAGJdHs5qPP5ymRDvt7VkYnlun7c77AfvaR-k)

[image]

[image]

Outputs `?1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?10` where each `?` is `\x08`. Uses 8 as the separator and the test to leave the loop (>8).

The position of the arrow is a little weird, but it starts at the top left corner facing right. Since the stack is initially empty, the first loop has a bunch of no-ops at random places, and the separator itself is on the stack when it hits DP+ the first time. If the separator is 9, then it goes to the exit path right away.

```
+ dup dup outN    [] no-ops
4 dup + dup outC  [8] print ascii 8
>                 [8] no-op
DP+               [] keep in the direction because 8 % 4 == 0
```

`1 +` can be used as a pattern to initialize the loop with a 1 and increment each loop.

```
1 +           [n] start loop with a number
dup dup outN  [n n] print n as a number
4 dup +       [n n 8]
dup outC >    [n n>8] print ascii 8 and make a boolean
DP+           [n] turn to the exit path if n > 8 (after 9 is printed)
```

Now we can print 10 and exit.

```
roll      [9] no-op; dummy cmd due to fixed colors
1 + outN  [] print 10 and exit
```

---

I tried to think of some dark magic approaches like "divide the number by 5, use DP+ at the lower left corner and end the program at the lower right corner" (since DP+ 0 and 1 would lead back to the start while 2 would reverse the pointer direction), but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

## [Cognate](https://cognate-lang.github.io), 16 bytes

```
Print Range 1 11
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708OT89L7EkdcGCpaUlaboWGwKKMvNKFIIS89JTFQwVDA0hwlBZmCoA)

Pretty self-explanatory, but here's a fuller version:

```
Print the Range of numbers from 1 up to but not including 11
```

(Lowercase words are treated as comments.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate) `-a`, 8 bytes

```
[1-9]|10
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdVm0km6iUuyCpaUlaboWK6INdS1jawwNIFyo6AIoDQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 1.5 bytes (3 nibbles)

```
,10
```

Program saved on disk conists of the 3 hex nibbles `d1f`:
`d` = `,` literal code = range 1..
`1` = encode integer
`f` = integer value 10

[image]

Note that [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html) appends a `6`-nibble, not part of the program code, to pad the saved file to a whole number of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 14 bytes

```
9:"
 ("
!)
\"@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f0kqJS0FDiUtRkytGyeH//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3VTAA)

Prints 1 to 10 separated and terminated by newlines.

```
9    Push 9

:"   Loop in the order of : ( " "
("   duplicate, decrement; exit if top is 0 at (
     [9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 | ]

!)   Loop in the order of ) ! \ "
\"   increment, print, print newline; exit if stack is empty at "

@    Halt
```

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 14 bytes

```
 "):
 \ !
@%0#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fQUnTikshRkGRy0HVQPn//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3VTAA)

Prints 1 to 10 separated by newlines. This was the only loop I found that fits in 8 commands, which puts the halt command at a costly position.

```
"):   Loop in the order of " ) : ! # 0 % \
\ !   increment (pushes 1 if empty); duplicate; print;
%0#   push stack height (1); multiply by 10; mod (change 10 to 0);
      print newline
      exit at % when the number becomes zero
@     Halt
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bc, 14 characters

```bc
while(i++<10)i
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ bc <<< 'while(i++<10)i'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 35 bytes

```
@for /l %%i in (1,1,10)do @echo %%i
```

Hardcoding would have saved 10 bytes...

Comment: you can cut the CR/LF to save two bytes.

Comment: @peterferrie But there is no CR/LF...

Answer (score 1):

## [Bubblegum](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 17 bytes

```
00000000: 026f eafc 0f98 211e 5d50 d0aa 25bc 6f2a  .o....!.]P..%.o*
00000010: d1                                       .
```

Outputs `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`. The program is compressed using BB96, whereas other schemes are longer due to compression-format headers.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 2 bytes

```
TS
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=TS)

```
one_range(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

### [ListSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/ListSharp), 37 bytes

```
[FOREACH NUMB IN 1 TO 10 AS i]
SHOW=i
```

Pretty straight forward

as a sidenote =>
is this cheating?

```
SHOW="10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1"
```

Comment: Hardcoding the output is a [standard loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/1063#1063).

Comment: "Often, this vulnerability is an indicator of a dumb question"

Comment: @Neil, except [tag:kolmogorov-complexity].

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 15 bytes

```
(cdr(range 11))
```

Racket's interpreters implicitly print return values of expressions to standard output, which is nice.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 26 bytes

```
for i=1,10 do print(i) end
```

Prints them in seperate lines.

Comment: Duplicate of [Katenkyo](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41019/katenkyo)'s [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86093) posted ~9 hours earlier.

Answer (score 1):

### Excel VBA, 47 Bytes

```
Sub t()
For i = 1 To 10: MsgBox i: Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You can lose 9 bytes by condensing your whitespace down and removing the `()` following `Sub` to `Sub t`
`For i=1To 10:MsgBox i:Next`
`End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 14 bytes

```
print(1 to 10)
```

output

```
Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Minecraft 26

```
say "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"
```

I know there is no special clue in it but I don't know.

#### Real answer:

```
scoreboard objective add a dummy
```

Repeating

```
give @p wool
stats entity @p set AffectedItems a @p
scoreboard player set @p a 0
clear @p wool 0 0
tellraw @p {"selector":"@p","objective":"a"}
```

Comment: IIRC you don't need the quotes when using the say command. But this is not relevant, because your answer with the say command is invalid anyway, because hardcoding the output is a standard loophole everywhere other than at [kolmogorov-complexity] challenges. See http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1063/29672

Comment: @CocoaBean This IS [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 12 bytes

```
(range 1 11)
```

Prints `'(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)`.

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge, 14 * 3 - 1 = 41 bytes

```
0v          <
 >:1+::.55+-|
            @
```

Quick and dirty befunge '93 solution. I'm sure it could be improved, maybe I'll look into it tomorrow. 41 bytes is the 14 * 3 grid in total, excluding a final newline, there are actually 16 characters in the source.

Answer (score 1):

## Go, 73 bytes

```go
package main 
import "fmt"
func main(){for i:=1;i<11;i++{fmt.Println(i)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://play.golang.org/p/0bf4tTEIEn)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! This is a great first post.

Comment: Normally, we use a header like I edited in with the number of bytes in your submission.

Answer (score 1):

## [Element](https://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), 13 bytes

```
10'[1+2:`\
`]
```

[Try it online](http://element.tryitonline.net/#code=MTAnWzErMjpgXApgXQ&input=)

This outputs one number per line with a trailing newline.  This can be shorted to 12 bytes if I replace the newline with a letter (like the letter `x`).  It works by creating a FOR loop, which repeatedly increments the top of the stack, duplicates it, and outputs it.

Comment: Nice! You're in your element! :D

Answer (score 1):

## JS, 75 Bytes

```js
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; for(a[0];a[0]<a.length;a[0]++){alert(a[a[0]]);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge-93, 12 bytes

```
1::.9`#@_1+#
```

Explanation:

```
1             Start stack with the number 1
  :.          Print the number on top of the stack
 :  9`        Set (number on top of the stack) > 9
      #       Skip the next character, which would otherwise stop the program
        _     Is the number in the top of the stack true (i.e. not 0)?
       @      If yes, stop the program
         1+   If no, add 1 to the top of the stack
           #  Skip the next character. Since we're at the edge of the program,
              it would wrap to the beginning, so the character being skipped is
              the "1" at the left edge. That is, "don't put 1 on the stack again"
```

Comment: [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/31DbykrPMkHZIf7/fwA "Befunge-93 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Maple, 10 bytes

```
seq(1..10)
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

## F# 17 bytes

Equal to Haskell !! yuppee.

```
printf"%A"[1..10]
```

Output:

```
[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10]
```

For each number on a separate line, 28 bytes:

```
Seq.iter(printfn"%d")[1..10]
```

If you remove the standard output permission, simply `[1..10]` prints out the numbers in F# interactive.

```
[1..10];;
> val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Linux ASM, 52 Bytes

```
file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

08048060 <_start>:
 8048060:   31 c9                   xor    ecx,ecx
 8048062:   31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
 8048064:   31 d2                   xor    edx,edx
 8048066:   31 ff                   xor    edi,edi
 8048068:   43                      inc    ebx
 8048069:   66 81 c7 20 31          add    di,0x3120
 804806e:   57                      push   edi
 804806f:   89 e7                   mov    edi,esp
 8048071:   42                      inc    edx
 8048072:   42                      inc    edx
 8048073:   83 c1 0a                add    ecx,0xa

08048076 <loc_16h>:
 8048076:   87 cf                   xchg   edi,ecx
 8048078:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
 804807a:   83 c0 04                add    eax,0x4
 804807d:   83 ff 01                cmp    edi,0x1
 8048080:   75 08                   jne    804808a <loc_2ah>
 8048082:   c7 04 24 20 31 30 ff    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0xff303120
 8048089:   42                      inc    edx

0804808a <loc_2ah>:
 804808a:   cd 80                   int    0x80
 804808c:   66 ff 41 01             inc    WORD PTR [ecx+0x1]
 8048090:   87 cf                   xchg   edi,ecx
 8048092:   e2 e2                   loop   8048076 <loc_16h>
```

Answer (score 1):

## golflua, 13 characters

(Rewrite of [Katenkyo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41019/katenkyo)'s [Lua answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86093). Appreciations should be expressed by upvoting the original answer.)

```
~@i=1,10w(i)$
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ golflua -e '~@i=1,10w(i)$'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Verbosy](https://github.com/Sweeper777/Verbosy) 31 Bytes

```
~0 /0 ~10 /1 :a: ^0 o \0 -1 >-a
```

Verbosy is a language that I wrote btw. The explanation can be found in README.md.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 30 bytes

```
for(i=0;i++<10;)console.log(i)
```

But I still love it that good old `for` beats all the pretty **ES** versions:

`[...Array(10)].map((_,i)=>console.log(i+1))` 43 Bytes
`alert([...Array(10)].map((_,i)=>i+1))` 37 Bytes
`alert(Array(10).fill().map((_,i)=>i+1))` 39 Bytes
`i=[...Array(11)].keys();i.next();alert([...i])` 46 Bytes
`alert([...[...Array(11)].keys()].slice(1))` 42 Bytes
`alert([...Array(11).keys()].slice(1))` 37 Bytes

Comment: why do you need the `|0` in the second functional solution?

Comment: @Paolo Bonzini: not needed ... copy&paste leftovers

Comment: Someone already did this, although they used `alert` instead of `console.log`.

Comment: @Neil: Thought I had browsed all answers. Can you link it?

Comment: @Titus It was [one of the first](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86124/56633) ;)

Comment: Actually I thought about replacing `console.log` with `alert`, but see my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

### LOLCODE, <s>67</s> 55 bytes

```
VISIBLE 1 AN 2 AN 3 AN 4 AN 5 AN 6 AN 7 AN 8 AN 9 AN 10
```

Comment: `VISIBLE "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"` is only 30 bytes.

Comment: Oh wow. i'm dumb.

Comment: I can't do that exactly though because the challenge is to print integers, not strings.

Comment: Is there any difference in the result?

Comment: Not to the user reading the output, but to the compiler yes.

Comment: Alright, it's a [loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1063/48934) anyway.

Comment: This is [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] which is an exception to the loophole, right?

Comment: [wait](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86214/48934)...

Comment: I don't know, people here seem to [avoid that loophole](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86085/48934).

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Correct.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript with [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/#range), 20 Bytes

```
alert(_.range(1,11))
```

Comment: [A similar solution was posted here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86189/56633). Posting a comment suggesting a byte improvement may be a good option next time :)

Comment: That´s not one byte, that´s 50%.

Answer (score 1):

## JShell (Java 9), <s>37</s> 36 bytes

```
for(int i=1;i<11;i++)printf("%d ",i)
```

Java 9 has a REPL called [JShell](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222). You'll need an [early access build of Java 9](https://jdk9.java.net/download/) to run it. Once it's installed, just run `jshell`, paste, and voilà !

Realized after looking at other solutions that newlines aren't a requirement. Saved 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

## Brainfuck, 34 bytes

With input checkbox checked.

```
,.>,-.>++++++++[<<+.>.>-],.-.!1!1
```

Output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: I don't think this challenge is supposed to take input.

Comment: Are you sure this is a correct solution? The code isn't supposed to take input at all, something that the `!` suggests.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), 5 bytes

Code:

```
1+!10
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

### [ROOP](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ROOP), 15 bytes

```
123456789
h(10)
```

Solution with hardcoded numbers, I'm still trying to find a shorter program.

In this language each digit becomes an individual object. Number `10` is written in parenthesis to make it a single object. The operator `h` prints all objects that are currently in the program, separated by a space, then halt.

Comment: seems that `7` is missing

Comment: @roblogic wow, you are right, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, 5 bytes

```
11,(;
```

[Try it online!](https://copy.sh/golfscript/?c=MTEsKDs=)

Comment: The official interpreter produces no whitespace (or comma) between the values.

Answer (score 1):

## CoffeeScript, 19 characters

```coffeescript
console.log [1..10]
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ coffee -e 'console.log [1..10]'
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

[On-line test](http://coffeescript.org/#try:console.log%20%5B1..10%5D)

Answer (score 1):

## MoonScript, 17 characters

(Rewrite of [Katenkyo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41019/katenkyo)'s [Lua answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86093). Appreciations should be expressed by upvoting the original answer.)

```
for i=1,10print i
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ moon <(echo 'for i=1,10print i')
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 9 bytes

```
seq(X,X,1,10
```

TI-BASIC is tokenized, so `seq(` is represented as 1 byte, as are all the other characters. The `seq` function is actually more powerful: the first `X` is an expression, and the second `X` is the variable that is used in the expression using the values 1 to 10, instead of using the predefined variable for `X`. For example, the squares of the numbers from 1 to 10 would be `seq(X²,X,1,10`.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript, 31 bytes

```
for(i=1;i<11;i++)console.log(i)
```

Just a for loop that prints the number on every execution. The range of the for loop is 1 to 10.

Comment: This is essentially the same as [another answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86316/29750).

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 20 bytes

```
(print (range 1 11))
```

Output:

```
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

### C++ : 67 bytes

```
#include<iostream>
int main(int i){for(;i<11;std::cout<<i++<<",");}
```

---

[Output](http://ideone.com/npMK6A):

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Comment: I think it would be enough to just count the pure code without the main function and the include, the C# solution also didnt do it http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87419/53809

Answer (score 1):

### VIM, using Bash and coreutils: 9 bytes

```
:!seq 10
```

Comment: Technically this is 10 bytes because you need to hit `<CR>` for the command to work.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Good point. However, it does not need `<CR> `for the command to work if the command is passed to vim from the shell `vim -c ':r!seq 10'`. Of course one has to hit `<CR>` to execute the command from the shell, but this is then 'technically' not part of the vim command. Slightly different, but one could even argue that a C program without a newline wouldn't be valid either [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31574898/2535529).

Comment: Actually, if you were to take that approach, you wouldn't even need the colon, so it could be 8. I think technically that would be a vimscript answer (or ex?), rather than vim. You could post that as a separate answer I suppose

Comment: It can be even reduced to 7 bytes, if you only care about displaying the numbers 1 to 10. Then the `r` can be omitted too.

Answer (score 1):

### K,  5 Bytes

```
    1+!10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Explanation;

```
!2    --> 0 1
!5    --> 0 1 2 3 4
!10   --> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1+!10 --> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 54 bytes

```
n=>{for(int i=1;i<11;)System.Console.Write(i+++" ");};
```

Comment: Only one byte shorter than `n=>{System.Console.Write("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10");};`. Silly C#!  Edit: Actually, if I take out the spaces VS added, this comes in at 51...

Comment: @BMac Yeah but solutions like that are no fun! And with the above I could pass `I`  through as an argument and force it to 1 saving 4 bytes and probably some other changes :) On second thoughts that's disallowed so no I can't do that

Answer (score 1):

## [RETURN](https://github.com/molarmanful/RETURN), 7 bytes

```
1{11
}.
```

<kbd>[Try it here.](http://molarmanful.github.io/RETURN/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

## Fourier, 12 bytes

Prints a leading newline

```
10(10aX^o~X)
```

[**Try it online!**](http://fourier.tryitonline.net/#code=MTAoMTBhWF5vflgp)

Answer (score 1):

### GNU sed, <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```sed
c1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

With `coreutils`, the code is only 7 bytes long!

```sed
eseq 10
```

Adding to the diversity of languages used so far, I present a sed solution. The [consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5476/are-languages-like-sed-exempt-from-no-input-rules) is that sed is exempt from the "no input" rule, since the script doesn't start without.

**Run:**

```sh
echo | sed -f script.sed
```

Answer (score 1):

## Silicon, 3 bytes

(Silicon uses CP037, so 3 bytes, not 4.)

```
0Â\
```

Explanation:

```
0Â\
  \     Push a list with the numbers in the range...
0       Zero
 Â      Ten
```

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously/Actually, 3 bytes

```
9uR
```

Try it online: [Seriously](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=OXVS&input=), [Actually](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=OXVS&input=)

Explanation:

```
9uR
9u   push 9, increment (10)
  R  range(1, 11) ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 50 bytes

```
void m{for(int i=1;i<11;System.out.println(i++));}
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Just so you know, the downvote was cast automatically by the Community user when your answer was edited. [I consider this a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276269/community-should-not-autodownvote-low-quality-autoflags-cleared-by-edits). I'd upvote, but I don't know Java and have no idea how to test your code. Could you maybe include a link to an online interpreter?

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 3 bytes

```
⍳10
```

Explanation:

```
⍳   range
10   10
```

Comment: Of course, your `⎕IO` must be 1.

Comment: @ZacharyT Which is its default value

Comment: Depending on the APL you use.

Answer (score 1):

## k, 5 bytes

```
1+!10
```

Explanation:

```
1+ //Projection of +, add 1 to the argument
!10 // "til" 10 - i.e. generate a list of numbers from 0 to n-1
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: You can also do `1_!11`, which seems faster (at least in kdb+).. count 0..10 then drop the first element, rather than adding 1 to each item of a 10 item list.

Answer (score 1):

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 64 bytes

```
((import "lists")(def f #::((each (seq 1 10) #N::((print N))))))
```

Fairly simple, but unfortunately fairly verbose. I'm counting the `import` because modules don't automatically load (ie, `each` and `seq` are from the `lists` module, and need to be imported manually.)

To use:

```
(
    (import "lists")(def f #::((each (seq 1 10) #N::((print N)))))
    (f)
)
```

## Alternate Answer, 68 bytes, recursive and no modules

```
(def x #::((def y #N::((print N)(if (< N 10) ((y (+ N 1))))))(y 1)))
```

Defines a recursive function `y` which calls itself until `N` is 10.

I've made this a little more readable here:

```
(
    (def x #::(
        (def y #N::(
            (print N)
            (if (< N 10) (
                (y (+ N 1))
            ))
        ))
        (y 1)
    ))
    (x)
)
```

Sadly my language is a bit verbose, but Lisp-like language tend to do that. I'm more interested in ensuring the language can handle everything I'd want to throw at it.

Answer (score 1):

## DARTMOUTH BASIC,42 BYTES

EH, WHY NOT?

```
1 FOR I=1 TO 10
2 PRINT I
3 NEXT I
4 END
```

Comment: Do you need the `4 END` with DARTMOUTH BASIC? Does the symbolic listing not end when there is nothing left to interpret?

Answer (score 1):

## [ASMD](https://github.com/mcparadip/ASMD), 5 bytes

```
T(i{p
```

<sup>Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 20.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org): 30?/31/49 bytes

---

#### Variable of function type: 30 bytes

```
val a={(1..10).map(::println)}
```

This might be considered cheating.

Invokable via `a()` like the later function. Functions are first-class citizens in Kotlin, so they can be assigned to variables aswell. The type of ´val a´ is technically `() -> List<Unit>`, a function that takes nothing and returns a "list of nothing", but we wouldn't be on code golf using a language that doesn't have implicit types, would we?

---

#### Function: 31 bytes

`fun a(){(1..10).map(::println)}`

---

#### Executable: 49 bytes

```
fun main(a:Array<String>){(1..10).map(::println)}
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL with any `⎕IO`, 9 bytes.

```
1-⎕IO-⍳10
```

## APL with `⎕IO=0`, 5 bytes.

```
1+⍳10
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

```
1oB
```

This is very simple: `o` creates a semi-inclusive range between two values, and `B` is pre-defined to 11. Thus, this creates the range `[1..11)`, or `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, which is automatically sent to STDOUT.

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=MW9C&input=)

Comment: Why not just `Aõ`? (EDIT: Should have checked the date first!)

Answer (score 1):

## Brainf***, 57 Bytes

```
++++[>++++<-]>[>++>+++>+++<<<-]+++++++++[>>+.<.<-]>>>+.-.
```

This is my first attempt at a program in this language. I think it's pretty optomized

Comment: Are you sure? I'm afraid this in best case outputs the characters with codes 1..10 (“␁␂␃␄␅␆␇␈␉␊”), not the numbers 1..10.

Comment: Yeah, so that's my bad. The Esoteric IDE that I'm using has it print out 1,2,3...10

Comment: Okay, I've redone it. Does that look better?

Comment: Yepp, except the `.` immediately after the last loop, which outputs an unnecessary ␀ character.

Comment: Ha. Forgot about that. I was using that for troubleshooting. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 4 Bytes

```
1:10
```

Output:

```
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

The colon operator acts as a range function in Matlab, working from the preceding number to second one, with a default step of 1. (1:3) returns [1,2,3]

As for printing, MatLab Auto prints any line not terminated with a semicolon; Printing a line actually saves space!

Answer (score 1):

### Brainfuck, 59 Bytes

```
+++++[>++++++++++>++<<-]>-<+++++++++[>.+>.<<-]>---------.-.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 12 bytes

```
\;;u>)ONo-?@
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=XDs7dT4pT05vLT9A) I will add an explanation within the next few hours.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 19 bytes

```
FOR I=1TO 10?I
NEXT
```

Nothing to see here

Answer (score 1):

## Batch: 36 bytes

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,10) do (echo %%i)
```

Breakdown:

```
for: for operation in batch. Similar to C.

/l: option for the above command

%%i: define %%i, or %i in CMD, just like how you would define i in a for loop in C

in (1,1,10): pretty much "in (start, step, increment)", or in C " for (start, increment, step)".

do: well, run the code after this each time %%i is between 1-10.

(echo %%i): print %%i which is going from 1 to 10
```

Answer (score 1):

**Q/KDB+ 8 Bytes**

```
1+til 10
```

Explanation:

```
til 10
```

Outputs list of numbers 0 to 9

```
1+
```

Increments each number in the list by one

Output:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Comment: 1 byte shorter using k shorthand `1+(!)10`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3: 24 bytes

```
print(list(range(1,11)))
```

Simply print a list of the range.

Outputs:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Answer (score 1):

## Microscript, 7 bytes

```
10c1p]h
```

## Microscript II, 10 bytes

```
0s{1+Ps}s10*
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 3+1 = 4 bytes

```
\,t
```

Runs with the `-n` flag to separate the output with newlines.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/Rqfk////unkA)

Explanation:

```
\,         Inclusive range of 1 to
  t        10
```

Comment: @DLosc Thanks, that shortens it considerably. But how does it owrk though? Does `\,` create a range-object with the values 1 to `t==10` inclusive, which it auto-prints (as that range-object is the last variable touched by Pip?)

Comment: Yep! Exactly. (It's possible this is "using features newer than the question," because I can't recall when I changed the behavior so non-infinite ranges would output like lists, but that's allowable anyway. `\,` is not an issue--it was added [last January](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip/commit/08fed2f026bcbf6e5566d544c9d7245284a4a85f).)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 19 bytes

```
@x=1..10;print"@x";
```

The ".." operator can print an ascending list of numbers or letters.

So `@x = A..Z; print "@x";` will print capital letters A through Z.

I saved quite a few bytes by removing all spaces.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://www.php.net/) (with goto) - <strike>46</strike> <strike>38</strike> 34 bytes

More byte-saving suggestion from Shaggy:

```
<?php Z:echo@++$i;if($i<10)goto Z;
```

And people say that `goto` is the work of the Devil. Or something.

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c7e13077ac573c8ddbdaeb66a8c6be6d56404989)

#### PHP (goto-less) - <strike>30</strike> 29 bytes

```
<?php while(@$i<11)echo@$i++;
```

#### PHP - 11 bytes

```
12345678910
```

Well, someone had to?

Comment: Save 4 bytes by replacing `ten` with a single character variable name and another 4 by removing the `php `.

Comment: Thanks, then I won't have `goto ten` but anyways

Comment: Why is the 11-byte version non-competing? This is a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] challenge; hardcoded answers are allowed.

Comment: Okay I will amend if you say that I must.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 26 bytes

```
BEGIN{for(;i<=9;)print++i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686Lb9IwzrTxtbSWrOgKDOvRFs7s/b/fwA)

I don't see an `AWK` answer, so here we go. I chose to use `<=9` rather than `<10` just to add a little variety since they have the same byte-count. :)

Comment: Initially I had `i++` in the `for`-loop, but that required a space in the `print` command.

Comment: A `while` loop would be the same length here.

Comment: True, @CalculatorFeline, but since a `while` loop is never fewer bytes than a `for` loop, I've gotten out of the habit of using them.

Comment: I think you can change `BEGIN` to `END` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: If you use END, then AWK will expect to receive input. The try online would work, but if you typed it in, it would wait until input was supplied. You could just do a <ctrl-d> in bash, but it still expects something as input when you have an END statement.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 5 bytes

```
Ｉ…·¹χ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npWPGpYd2n5o5/n2//8B)

Explanation:

```
Ｉ        Implicitly print the elements (casted as string) of
  …·      the inclusive range
    ¹χ    from 1 to 10 (default value of the χ variable)
```

Comment: [4 bytes now](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z85sbhEQVtboSgxLz1VwdDg////umX/dXWLcwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Carrot](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/), 20 bytes

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Or if we don't need a separator for 11 bytes:

```
12345678910
```

Anything before a `^` in Carrot is placed onto the stack and then that is implicitly output at the end of the program.

With the current version of Carrot this seems to be the shortest way of doing it although I would like to post a none hard coded version if I find one.

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
#t&$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X7lETeX/fwA)

### Explanation

```
#t       Set default input (n) to 10
  &      Mode: Sequence 2 (print first n items in sequence, 1-indexed)
   $     Each item in the sequence is the current index
```

Answer (score 1):

### T-SQL, 27 bytes

Boring answer.

```sql
PRINT'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'
```

Less boring with a WHILE, **51 bytes**

```sql
DECLARE @ INT=1WHILE @<11BEGIN PRINT @ SET @+=1 END
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubically](//git.io/cubically), 16 bytes

```
(*1+1/1%@LUL'B)8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P9fQ8tQ21DfUNXBJ9RH3UnT4v9/AA)

```
(*1+1/1%@LUL'B)8
(                 do..while loop
 *1+1/1            add 1 to notepad
       %           print notepad as integer
        @          output notepad as ASCII (delimiters)
         LUL'B     algorithm with period 10
              )8  loop while cube unsolved
```

Output (`?` denotes an unprintable):

```
1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9   10
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>4</s> 2 bytes

Well, I guess I think more about legitimate functionality/usability, but this is Code Golf, where usability comes after functionality.

-2 by not formatting my output.

```
ST
```

Explanation:

```
S        1-indexed range from 1 - ...
 T       Ten
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pzjk/38A)

## [Pyth](https://www.github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
VSTN
```

Explanation:

```
V        For...
 ST      in the 1-indexed range from 1 - 10 (T)
   N     Print the current item
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pyw4xO//fwA)

Or alternatively...

```
VThN
```

Explanation:

```
V        For...
 T       In range from 0 - 9
  hN     Print (the current item + 1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pywkw@//fwA)

Pretty simple.

Comment: Your output format can be whatever your language supports. This includes arbitrary separators (commas, semicolons, newlines, combinations of those, etc., but no digits), prefixes and postfixes (like [...]).

Comment: This means that ST is valid

Comment: @Tornado547 wow, that is odd. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 11 bytes

```julia
show.(1:10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/@/OCO/XE/D0MrQQPP/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forte](https://github.com/judofyr/forter), 64 bytes

```
12PRINT42-41:LET42=42+1:LET11=11+3
13LET99=11
99LET12=12+3
40END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKkn9/9/QKCDI0y/ExEjXxNDKxxXIsDUx0gYzDQ1tDQ21jbkMjYEcS0sgh8vSEiRuZGtoBBQ3MXD1c/n/HwA)

#### How?

In Forte, you do things by redefining numbers. For example, `LET 4=5` is a statement that defines `4` to be `5`. From now on, anytime `4` occurs in the program, it is replaced by `5`--even as the result of expressions like `2+2`. There are no looping constructs in the language; control flow is accomplished by redefining line numbers.

With that introduction, let's look at what this program does.

The first line executed is line `12`. This prints `42-41`, which (currently) results in `1`. Next, it redefines `42` to be `42+1`--that is, `43`. From now on, anytime `42` occurs in the program, we'll actually use the value `43`. Finally, it redefines `11` to be `11+3`--that is, `14`. This is setup for the loop we're about to enter.

- *Redefinitions: 11->14; 42->43*

Line `13` is executed next. It redefines `99` to be `11`--except `11` has previously been redefined, so `99` actually becomes `14`.

- *Redefinitions: 11,99->14; 42->43*

Now, the previous instruction has an effect on the control flow, because `99` happens to be a line number. Line `99` is now considered to be line `14`, and thus we execute it next (rather than line `40`, which would otherwise have come next). This line redefines `12` to be `12+3`--that is, `15`.

- *Redefinitions: 11,99->14; 12->15; 42->43*

And now the next instruction is the newly christened line `15`, which prints `42-41` again... except that `42` is now `43`, so it actually outputs `2`. It then redefines <s>`42`</s> `43` as `44` and <s>`11`</s> `14` as `17`.

- *Redefinitions: 11,14,99->17; 12->15; 42,43->44*

The next instruction is line `17` (the original line `99`), which redefines `15` to be `18`. And so lines 12/15/18 and 99/11/14/17 keep alternating back and forth, incrementing each other and printing ever-increasing values of `42-41`, until we reach line `39`. This prints `10` (`42` now having reached a value of `51`), redefines `42` and `11` again (but that won't matter), and then we move on to the next statement, line `40`--which ends the program.

Simple, right?

Answer (score 1):

## [17](https://github.com/RaspPiTor/17), 48 bytes

17 was made after the challenge was released, so it is not competing, though it still scored worse than most other answers because it isn't a golfing language, or very usable at all.

Outputs 1 to 10 seperates by \x11 (ascii value 17)

```
0{#
1 +
:
10 @
9 >
0 @
# $$
$}777{0 10 @
0 0 @}
```

Block 777(first block run): Initialises value 17 to 0. Runs block 0

Block 0: Loads value 17(relies on returning of 17 from stack when empty stack), adds 1, duplicates, stores at 17, if value > 9 pushes 1, else 0, stores value at 0, loads from 17, prints number, print ascii charater 17(relies on returning of 17 from stack when empty stack again)

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 6, 11 bytes

Two solutions with the same count:

```
print ^10+1
```

and

```
print 1..10
```

Output: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Try both of them on [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@gKDOvRMFQT8/QwJoLwlGKyVOCseMMDbQN//8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Sd](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Sd), 50 Bytes

```
++++++++++@**********.-/.-/.-/.-/.-/.-/.-/.-/.-/.!
```

#### How it works:

```
++++++++++                                          | Set variable 1 to 10
          @                                         | Mark read location
           **********                               | Set variable 2 to 10
                     .                              | Replace the instruction in position given by variable 2 with the ascii character given by variable 1
                      -/.                           | Subtract one from each variable and repeat
                         -/.-/.-/.-/.-/.-/.-/.-/.   | Repeat some more
                                                 !  | Print all values before the @ (as ascii)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 bytes

```
1ᴇř
```

```
1     push 1
 ᴇ    10^1
  ř   range from 1 to 10
      Implicit output
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f8OGW9qMz//8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>4</s> 2 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
ＡＲ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjIxJXVGRjMy)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes

```
Am
```

[Run online](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=Am&i=&a=1)

Added for completeness.

```
A       Push 10
 m      Map over range, implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jotlin](https://github.com/jrtapsell/jotlin), <s>15</s> 12 bytes

```
p((0..9)+10)
```

Gets the numbers 0..10, makes a list out of them, and then prints the result

Answer (score 1):

## [QUARK](https://github.com/moonheart08/quark-interp), Non competing 7 bytes

5.625 bytes encoded.

```
1 10⋯
```

This is incredibly simple. Just pushes 1 and 10 to the stack, and creates a inclusive range out of them. The interpreter prints out the contents of the stack when the program ends, so no print command is needed. (Plus the print command doesn't work with arrays yet, and prints out a garbled mess, so :P)

Answer (score 1):

## [`rig`](https://github.com/yotam180/rig), 3 bytes

rig is a work-in-progress esoteric stack-based language. I'm just having fun with looking for challenges it can already solve, with its few commands.

```
τr+
```

is a valid code that prints "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"

[Try it here](https://yotam180.github.io/rig/src/interpreter.html?c=%CF%84r+)

Why?

```
τ    - push 10 to the stack              [10]
 r   - push range(10) to the stack       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  +  - increment every element           [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
     - implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## KoopaScript, 78 (28, 20) bytes

```
def i a if \%va is \%v set a 0;setath a \%va + 1;if \%va smaller 11 print \%va
```

This prints the numbers 1 to 10, as well as a lot of information about the currently running code (because reasons). KS doesn't actually have a way to break loops yet, so this keeps running until the interpreter is reloaded. It stops printing at 10, though.

```
def i a               - Define a function with the name i and call it 1000/NaN (i.e. many) times a second
if \%va is \%v        - if the variable with the name a is undefined,
set a 0;              - set it to 0
setath a \%va + 1;    - set the variable a to <the variable with the name a> + 1
if \%va smaller 11    - if the variable with the name a is smaller than 11,
print \%va            - trace the variable with the name a
```

To avoid printing debug info, either load this in an init script, or use this slightly longer (90) version that disables logging:

```
def i a set verbose;if \%va is \%v set a 0;setath a \%va + 1;if \%va smaller 11 print \%va

set verbose;          - set the variable called 'verbose' (which handles whether to trace debugging stuff) to ""
```

Alternatively,

```
print "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"
```

This is only 28 bytes and technically does what the specification entails. Other commands, e.g. if, display all the numbers, but, as it's caused by an error in the program, it doesn't display if logging is disabled.

Technically,

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

prints all the numbers with commas between them, in the debug log. That brings it down to 20. I guess it's up to the reader (stacker? golfer?) to decide which one is the most correct

Answer (score 1):

## [Stack Cats](https://github.com/m-ender/stackcats), 28 + 4 (-nm) = 32 bytes

```
-(:!_:!_:-_-_]>{<:_-!:]}]<)-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZLBasMwDIbve4q/tzagkITQQwg57bjTdgwmZMXQ0MYusVmhpc/eSZCsS4o3YWOBvs9Yws63u8Ou9e5@p3WxamRRQ42qrmXR0KpQN1VuiIsIRZ2qF4DFUBmJAlWSUDplmTgIaXWGkcxA2ZTloyMaPWl1jpHMf5wc24fDsbQE3U5omsxYQFVzVvHDuZU6WnDA9Vf@rnvdf@oByZJCWcxvM0giPuI4frqRg6c/Yw2lf9AyFPWgZdKCwkQBGrjxfrP2hPO@O2oYdA7Gelz0YEMOVCkd2i@NY@v@YXnga37DhvBx6E7we41BO89fzfSv3w)

Stack Cats is a reversible esoteric language by Martin Ender. All of its commands can be reversed by applying the command's mirror image, and the whole code itself must be the mirror image of itself. Since half of the code is always redundant, it has `-l` and `-m` flags which allow to omit half of the program. `-m` appends the mirror image to the right (except the center character), so the full program is `-(:!_:!_:-_-_]>{<:_-!:]}]<)-(>[{[:!-_:>}<[_-_-:_!:_!:)-`.

Stack Cats operates on an infinite tape of stacks, all of which are initially empty with infinite amount of implicit zeroes at the bottom. Here is a summary for the relevant commands:

- `-` Negate the top.
- `!` Apply bitwise NOT to the top.
- `:` Exchange top two elements of the current stack.
- `_` Pop `a`, Pop `b`, Push `b`, Push `b-a`.
- `>`, `<` Move the cursor right or left.
- `]`, `[` Move the cursor right or left, along with the top. (Also called "Push")
- `(`, `)` Enter or exit a loop if the top is strictly positive.
- `{` Enter a loop and remember the top.
- `}` Exit a loop if the current top is equal to the remembered top.

Also, due to the limitations of the language, the input/output occurs only at the start/end of the program. At the start of the program, each input is pushed to the initial stack, which has a `-1` at the bottom. At the end of the program, all values on the stack are printed from top to bottom, with optional `-1` at the bottom ignored. So this program starts with a single `-1` on the stack, and ends with `1..10` on the current stack.

How the code works:

```
Code    Stack                  Description
        [-1]
-(      [1]                    Negate the top; Enter the loop
:!_     [1 0]->[1 -1]->[1 2]   Swap top two (with implicit zero); Bit-NOT; Subtract
:!_     [2 1]->[2 -2]->[2 4]   Same
:-_     [4 2]->[4 -2]->[4 6]   Swap; Unary minus; Subtract
-_      [4 -6]->[4 10]         Generate 10
]>      [4] [10] [*]           Push 10 to a new stack; Move right again
{                              Remember 0
<:      [4] [n 0*] [...]       Swap with implicit zero
_-!     [4] [n n-1*] [...]     Generate n-1
:]      [4] [n-1] [... n*]     Push n to the right
}                              Loop while n is not zero
]<                             Remove last zero
)                              Top is 1; Exit the loop
-(...)-                        Skip the rest
```

There is a standard construct `<(...)*(...)>` which allows to ignore half of the program, in order to program more effectively by human. I used a similar one `-(...)-(...)-` which utilizes the initial `-1`, but it only works with no-input programs and the final top should be strictly positive.

Ignoring half of the program is quite a waste of space, so [there is an open bounty for more efficient golfing with both halves](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14846/78410). I'm aiming for this in the long run, though it's not yet clear how to even start tackling the problem.

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 4 bytes

```
{io}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f@/OjO/9v9/AA)

Increment, then output; repeat ten times.

Answer (score 1):

### [(K+R)eg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg), 6 bytes [(SBCS)](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/wiki/Code-Page)

6 bytes:

```
\
ï_(.
```

11 bytes:

```
9(9|:"1-)1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fUsOyxkrJUFfTUOX/fwA)

[One byte longer](https://tio.run/##y05N///fUsOyxkrJUFczxlDl/38A)

### How it works

```
9(9|:"1-) # A countup program from 1 to 9 and then (astonishingly) adds a 0; I have no idea how it works.
1         # Push 1
$         # Swap top 2 items
# The stack is implicitly outputted.
```

Comment: `0ėɧ` 3 bytes in the new interpreter

Comment: `ėø` once I add the `ø` operator

Answer (score 1):

## [TacO](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacO), 7 bytes

```
@%10
 i
```

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0lMzv//30HV0IBLIfP/fwA)
The number `10` is the first branch of the looping construct `%`, so TacO runs the second branch, which just contains `i`, 10 times, giving `i` numbers 1-10.

Answer (score 1):

## [Seed](https://github.com/TryItOnline/seed), <s>4232</s> <s>4039</s> 3981 bytes

To be golfed.

```
11 806065440241409087125357198607542800075970572928765093042958164984128856153119364694304946533565974155065813564463607464907294493213625991570210498180131922642836049048379926678214090306958078942950505666942158861663318082805922649360548872276728753092705551896201785489318797454097467866454815778688721780170362909784978852186756623253868868917034035335528463229661772327867673360158173714723733025733656646487909489808220640703644162017799947346882823939914644265408484708544566367174322747059393061445510836708923637982737011363312927325448282786060215442674975310709523697911998742881715764878830975686475127091070151990734113230052589483007904386955837951416230150553553131824081272209795780490205576443141598594094128682959852257277648831764416301409205933849585487706444517684177487650836580944108733813423567329150282262574305747736976499413900964122878760201959007114022481011295839141271138446203186069264532462250500186116493184286012088625239590991537830133224608224949348931933311034455280978164515936125672561757104517575527099692465553902153481143524868360127998596923638301974413167583429193105287970847431486813381197765539764522094782334194830005111603128673518265195317929281022739571069159575305773074583173243911197334517405412628068284686691469982559791730541223895403558031955848768117060646768348463561209935808045637507281128179915889035768211511504144114447348017724691523076211025635445333081644368060430405389019848215116047520242946447978917490619742817523907421559319563570816232286092378925478777387843124296450405990835394943021252863488969545687903232603331252281246680860082655523490245738107512918342578050153655018310720283275985429190062871812385817909146120892975424714212971890662091259299688100739835789852338707333214399083184648552682989269071097042033924364887158088125417342061047907455595001558776113845342454604060641417114322284932278126981432767955018317987960683429833483125151020913178712494155310545261553444170641615117711305756617133820567957209040625095889033833683868477968222981257864647555382502179925116320599028456728151421211950504164587366555426478479957000176097833838329163859553682184378396176530388849222864560228925976975341162944244301834305126128097819354250219559409487388887032429560483598135806164050794728591878728116747953265919795701481292222092677282626562421120330436952746759320383166496345689472683465785160396471114988424810146619802843389460581036625456336614635949441077117888570209114560201469774858952308539634363125726651042307946127813908314293240378846347559662225224004298822713302904050471977675138246925540751643515879128105969891674920959645532198204680833150120401421252646736795292132103275342152265451058336500878555688383134027160586652276624279294501247326175308886148638933724425782375226226354458022684652099014849380343822015940473137950787091045988775407006084669595433268270085699081145780497235745383972369977375564713816849012360495596752065665250235877504147680897910657602532177993907221958136528121236676455264099257048759319470710174615005668917675853889646496531814039709503285164186416096735666867062585670181891889551756178657495723233678891549411496581200696462439988553007997103954989290028776888309286564702133992674291744804531900851060090385178725409757099606879757766288322010567612896350258272282241111517435795569303408578713936760574865986977532034796036053889911992836923158428809242575557886427002935479153509101800373188079516076598125218940752155364580400861924119667725548877677649837117601878482958020472764206345843076482381692875591020886968748894499648171413242376922343979630964910668516043571246988639289969853916731069660002514237788846617524295024699798200028558752532671916185460167291108476912591550362203490594401624213451585637461718363114331483866061411154610681167668195013207060532734483192219734129165226320299742868143084807270641847983148272764305800992489421803505337228286598600236556437401089147741524552516814465259338644189950504662
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LdeLsR03DAPQVlKCRP37iStI//NysM@TeHy9q5VIEACp//78@ffnp/d/btttrzlbzT7ba/f0WmOd/u5uZ826rfn7nbZOvbpnr/ZGm/XW7Xu@O3vdu3Zfo/c39txvev3mXmOs7cPZ13LE7f455x62nT5stpvzjepj13qvr9Oq@/L22/ror2o73XJr5x3nvdr73PrCHG0LoJ37Eknz395Orr7u3X3vMexyBb@@fQTW1rz3VJ19ZLFGeyWntfp9u1o/1/vnqyPi5QhBnru331dofuZryyxtIn5W3OnPXdXvPs6vAbms2/dl0WwjGKy6sq56e/dzLLKXIIaQRNvPOH167EGrlce2ApBA2hNS0qi2Z8uxc/YvWGC8ecZ0WN0ab8DPN7OUst1552nymXYa@/QzHX88WxZCrnuzeoOtZa/GBu4tgbSuGKBT6COZObO7cHEEstn@SFmlBfOWD995qv7uUSmpACqB3wtdiNw9z@pgfvmgLyuboB1So7VVS/UsbTKdgHtrpcyrJ8lhvfKAbyDDLWnZCRKOXKqAFOW98@bwwXp3PVULG/dFCf8ucNZJRHf082FnV4sqQAzVWyn6OdCFiCXIfM78OA4c/MJQOCkK9s5CYLBgagNLYS1gyWKeEySwzPHjtfa2MJDMRoLsgpFjd3IVMgE54hkqJiNgXKqoJkk44/hcozyosLp52CMzb0GMMdXwq2CfXaOacUDYhwrPHaqQ3hsfleVIk3g4w8Hw1U4LVGPTOBlQ7aH0ltzXsUilnhBoF@wvNbeTwMcS@I4WRfwC9f5ok5MJRdadAi6InlO70kZGiHhSHF/2IGgpZG0MqpVKTmoe@PDLgra6VOEgzzPoEplhp3QvxtOhd2Qt3i1tP1bAP4OdrBQYajDNKfaU0aT4rkoc7kaCxByRCL/WCnF9mhU17lvRqnoDzV9hgHBPrJELSHxGwuAS9BvW4d@imsXELPTnpBT3MiaU5FHIjiYsFduRC@tjHAe01iH32dbQu12VR6FaijPHjh/HQBsredAVTGUzT88qLs01LQRvTIYKdiqQCMIJWFi9UvxsfbIrxwlzFMwnRI2WUMNOtcl2ipHjaPPyK@xxfCGIj0TNHaFDy0RKtqVAMQj1o8e5xWvvllrhz4gqJxNTrSj/9XAicl3kTFH@unEPiVxGGJV@nGlNnU635bjxRNRWqpBd7dOFJpMU1LNGyuTyxODd44CdusYTvPyoHtWOBxSBuF9WtMMExBdnsOOGU6cHXUw2@D7iEdxLMkJACvXiuZRxAqnUXrSIGhj8KZYwJEpx8yMJKUfgkMa0F7e1z9bKPOL172/ibPY86z@lXDS9gVJ5WxLyPt1XAXpcDzlFnJ8IFDLyrzDhxDMwf6WfRFjsLEcA9SUcxvF@qUifCJWWxKIgJbqX/Dj6jDXbmhYUO701HBv18UAOsQd97wOdpOJFM@7BC3dKrRUgEnicS7q8M/6SE28ckjWATMWRF8@8eYI1ErRxL4SCk93YY4WTHCFthVZ2hoIihOAVdwVj/2telDe/cO38eb1g7KbaIzy2GzxRqkehhgCk1lr0VrH0uHG0qoPBCo89@1qJjnDT8CqOpMFZxTQ0YXuSNhTpkQYqAwFleaJqWvQjD7rIASnoBuuKfxGUCnWDDMv@/J5MCDmwAoh8G4pr5ioVF/Gjx12iPN0m5dVBb8YhpOgfStnjpTVpmbGPS6iOZ8Epp7kIhWZs5UU1sBof76ECmgb/@FcqbgiRKPXOlhnO@FDhUKtQR43PZ9K0ixmO5JQzSt5aAHkwzRhx7J/7ZBgQ4oqDQFSK1WYMgUGsdKrZPv5gMehGOApnzV/ylXKzqsrEIvgVqtKYMmEXUQdkE5ToApcEM7mlJukGM9sz1UoDg0ZmPm0GuGPw2M9y2F129/9nseBXJlWKhafmZMrvzR3q3sMn@/WMH4bKb2KZqETvAYA9aWb6B1KrYXzEM1Nv7CUl@gYSQ5xhgKZGfnrHZkEeOjBEhzu3vnk2dYibZ9RbofSIs3z94gTAdCcvMz4E2Ix78fYK9dXWNyibvXZaafBtUTBDu@czf7Meh9MfOEbLbJxmkRYtOo6e@ZsY@S1yvMxyKhL2TvMGnZtgdGATtU4cQ5EpnRjM6QgBMy5A/opwxnf0BdX1xoz40vBexv2CWo5KW4YkimTS4@COtC7O3mgC3e43MHKEYEXfPDlKTGcwXKTXjrQIAapDhn@/IudvTF/f0NLSoPwOR@yWmsYV4x2EAuF1Mz1mPqLNnvFAsaSyDcR4Rm6813Tsm4x0YnEBUsEVwc@4dq4QQe@beHMx0VFpIpOv4MM5zIWCWwtyVNzqZD5bIZPbCBlC3J3lxSZODog2gBqJpW2PGCzVaKmuPwKlVn60vpuL8mXENCH3uG0MbWbQRWzUJY50LI7EZFpm3grncmFDtvQXgWkBJx3dtUthMq@b3EQ@2K8xSJ3kOTK@hn77s7PAlEavglurvBkQ4z7UPzKJbRWBbs8usa14nWy@W1k@e7laZMlN91zhsxuJz/tN@7SNKveMivtr6bksul4F9MdoXEz758QZ6cLDEU6bAmJ9umvGSw1u51KTunrZ9mfz4k/fkmDLIOdcTT0N90VGuYakT8UirDBIZIjaadi5P9Ha13DT4eKjIQ9Q9SN1VP2Ze6eaKu6K5SDWL2MkmjHHUvOntIwxJzfgikzh6YB40Hf/yI0Enl9vRdufn/8B)

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript 45 Bytes**

```
alert("10charstrn".split("").map((e,i)=>i+1))
```

This is currently quite poor, but if there happens to be a JS constant which is an array of length 10, this could improve a lot.

Comment: `Array(10).fill()` is the first thing that came to mind for an array of length 10. (`Array(10).map...` does not work, at least on my browser.)

Comment: I mean, just `alert([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])` is way shorter

Comment: I'm pretty sure `alert([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])` is already an answer somewhere within these seven pages of answers... might as well golf the method that's already here methinks

Comment: `(top+'').split('',10)` <-- saves 1 byte compared to `"10charstrn".split("")`. `top` refers to `window.top`, and the string representation is `"[object Window]"` (15 chars). The `.split()` method takes a separator and an optional limit. Since all you need is 10 chars, split into an array, this should do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://tio.run/#keg), 5 bytes

I am too lazy to change my answers to conform the new code page, unless I get notified.

```
ėÏ_(.
```

Push 10(saving a byte), take iota [10..0], remove last, and then print.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 13 bytes

```perl
say for 1..10
```

#### Example execution

```perl
perl -E 'say for 1..10'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/index.html), 163 bytes

```
this is asking a lot
o,i admit i was a victim
i was tired of this situation
o,i had a break
i couldnt be sicker of it
thats a very different outcome than i thought
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?JY1BDsMgDATvvMIP6KcMmGARsARLq74@dVJpL5ZndlF1kYdX03EQ02kI9lLi3BWk9GF/0lsTtIf/CZ2SyQrhlpdiM9TGo1XOjscp3JxOts88QFEcS03mbSkCKuOplfmlrKXIFMdsI1kX7@Xh06i2j4rripx/)

Outputs the numbers from 1 to 10, separated by ASCII 0 (NUL) characters.

For being such a simple type of program, this was an interesting challenge to golf.

Answer (score 1):

## [Intcode](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Intcode), 49 bytes

```
4,15,1001,15,1,15,8,15,16,14,1006,14,0,99,-1,1,11
```

Why am I still doing this? Because it's fun. That's why.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 28 bytes

```
System.write((1..10).toList)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9Kzfv/P7iyuCQ1V6@8KLMkVUPDUE/P0EBTryTfJ7O4RPP/fwA)

### Explanation

```
System.write(              )  // Output
             (1..10)          // Numbers from 1 to 10
                    .toList   // Converted to a list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Intcode](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Intcode), <s>44</s> 42 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to rootbeersoup

```
204,8,9,8,1205,8,0,99,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHRjtsgEHz3V9BIrSCsdGA7uRqy/RHEQ@xwnOXEtkgudb4@XZIqqoq0iJmd2V1gvl0@p7G6H8IH2/MOepiEKdiMERMq20l0yq8bWgXLmitvhUl2wc7NsvU2hctXGlm47o/crTq3@BWsFgo6yuRX3p1c6714us@8hSBM555umdY8p39p4TEU7PdnfwwsfsOmoRlYzE28PT1GqO0AEePbm1YK4nfa7YiaVE/TYAY4udHjkBUwkMCO8iHoP1jcVVNi213cNWaBG165FnDlpbBnXoFbEG@wSIo1xe7mXfxReWFnifXfAoiVOXMNPRcPvnzxtZl4rvcfvTEz5g59fjMtwvEc2CyrV35LecLs33zWvwSNSfIx6LNu0U2HwJC5e6lq@AlaNaBBl2pDQEGTUQkV1LCBLbwTSYy6@4J@lZzAjvtTe9gb1o8X3o/z14VuAmxOhMX9Dw)

Isn't it unfortunate that a just-hardcode solution outgolfs [the other intcode answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196675/46076) by six bytes?

Comment: Saves 2 chars: `204,8,9,8,1205,8,0,99,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) `z`, 4 bytes

```
10aM
```

Just does a range from (implicit) 1 to 10.

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 8 bytes

Still wasn't used to the flags...

```
Ï_(. ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//@f63B/vIaegs7//wA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Spice](https://github.com/Slord6/Spice), 55 bytes

My solution is posted as to the language spec, which currently fails because of an [interpreter bug](https://github.com/Slord6/Spice/issues/5). To run against the interpreter the score falls to 63 bytes due to 2 `NUL` statements being required.

```
;a@ADD a 1 a;SWI a 10 0;LOD std::sort.spice ^a a;OUT a;
```

Or with the additional `NUL`s.

```
;a@NUL;NUL;ADD a 1 a;SWI a 10 2;LOD std::sort.spice ^a a;OUT a;
```

### Un-golfed Explanation

```
;a@          - declare variable 'a'
ADD a 1 a;   - ADD a[0] to 1 and insert at a[0], empty "a" implicitly 0
SWI a 10 0;  - If a[0] < 10, jump to line 0 (ADD...)
LOD std::sort.spice ^a a; - Use std lib to sort a 1->10
OUT a;       - Output a
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 6 bytes

It hasn't been done? Then great. Generates 0 to 10 and removes 0, then it evaluates.

```
11,1>`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/39BQx9Au4f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rogex](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Rogex), 27 bytes

```python
90B300d00901e00100701a20f00
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRdb9owFH3Pr/DoQz5IghNWWrZaU1dVEy/btD4CkxzijGghiZzQFWn/nV07gSXGoD7UDxjfe8659ol9y129LvLxbcn36aYseI2qXeUizoyS/0IEDQaD/RR/HmMcYzzFAcM4wPgGBzTECcZ7yLdI@PV5VfO0tGy/nduUxZm/KjZlmjHLvLI@Ed@xfefvYrQYdReOBX8XzmJkukCYffn67cfjw/3TI8htI2swcEHN1mrOf1Ivwd506Zhi7zouasgbtiFzvHTC64kQ@l5UBBvRNklgqmjMYcqeaQaTEbMESHltVS51I/uDgWCkCaKEmNhslm0oUkJilDyVXJbHxDTtY45lLSHQEpKCb6jgmS@m3SNLIlWIDWm15lb1H238WYMtqDnfXcZySxy@IRUlgcW8yS0/yhgNOrFhcIiG3Wh4iIJHoqRFgyENbTeYQL3WBtA@8UHsOdDYA@MK0QpFtGJQSs0JWqiniSG/mNhGmpfb2rJtFdSYFWpsPqMgD3IiEOgF5M7vnx5mM0MnW/C4vzEpJt3pfzsoLwguDVzwUoGGKhTu7lzc0aUeP@7gBVQgh0ToK8D3GqCnA15rgI4OONEARzrgTQco0kMCUAVzq2A8DWaqYDQQqn0lgNO8KkmIOgTZCk41V13IrvLZS1pbWBWKOyjZTIQlshnU7Qbgri0VElM6ChwKESL5/etXlCxnMXRArHQP@UzJuBftNgJ0h/qtQHlvnbYgKpuJiWgeH@tBQe1DQhFn9PdJRp5MlWT6t3ioMSQoeJ1QclnI0wm1LkCRseJ9ovH@nc77VVZUZ7333tB71nh/qPcW3p@zrK3xeu/ZZaFL3nsH74@3df8P)

### Explained

```python
90B 300 d00 # Set the loop value to 11
901         # Set the buffer to 1
e00         # While the buffer isn't equal to 11
    100 701 # Print the buffer then increment it
    a20     # Print a space
f00         # End loop
```

Rogex answer number 2! Also, my 101<sup>st</sup> answer! (´• ヮ •`)

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 13 bytes

```
25W[1A~!:1M~]
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/?code=25W%5B1A%7E!%3A1M%7E%5D&input=)

Comment: The integer complexity thing in 1+ is frustrating...

Comment: yup lol, I should try golfing 1+ sometime

Answer (score 1):

## [1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1%2B), <s>25</s> 22 bytes

```
1:1(|1+":1+":1+":)()()
```

...

EDIT: The boring solution is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 32 bytes

```
X's0
while 10-X
let X be+1
say X
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 1):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle) `-u`, 40 bytes

```
v0 ~
v1~/
AB~
v000000<
AB\ 000^
v =@
!1<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/7/MQKGOq8ywTp/L0QnIMAADGyAnRgHIiOMqU7B14FI0tPn//79uKQA)

Explanation pending. I need to sleep first.

(I also found a [36-byte program](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/1@xrowrLqaOq8wQBGy4HJ1igHQckK/vAOTUccUZ2vz//1@3FAA) that outputs 0 through 9, but I haven't found a good way to turn it into 1 through 10.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), <s>13</s> 4 bytes

```
`9`R
```

I found a better way. :)

```
`     incrementing the empty top of stack pushes a 1
 9    push 9 onto the stack
  `   increment the top of stack to get "10"
   R  generate the inclusive range of int between the top 2 stack entries
```

The stack entries are printed as numbers by default when the code exits.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z/BMiHo/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Headascii](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass#Headascii), 50 bytes

```
++++[]]]][]]]+O^+O+O+O+O+O+O+O+ODONE.{UPN)!@}:R-P!
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@thejonymyster/HA23#index.js) Code will need to be copied and executed like this:

```
erun("++++[]]]][]]]+O^+O+O+O+O+O+O+O+ODONE.{UPN)!@}:R-P!")
```

Outputs each number separated by newline. Nontrivial challenges scare me :')

```
++++[]]]][]]]+O^+O+O+O+O+O+O+O+ODONE.{UPN)!@}:R-P!  full program
                                    .               code block delimiter

++++[]]]][]]]+O^+O+O+O+O+O+O+O+ODONE  block 0
              O  O O O O O O O O O    send
++++[]]]][]]]+                        49 (ascii 1)
                +                     50 (ascii 2)
                  +                   51 (ascii 3)
                    +                 52 (ascii 4)
                      +               53 (ascii 5)
                        +             54 (ascii 6)
                          +           55 (ascii 7)
                            +         56 (ascii 8)
                              +       57 (ascii 9)
               ^                D     49 (ascii 1)
                                  NE  to code block 1

{UPN)!@}:R-P!  block 1
{      }       Loop
   N)   :      Until last value
 UP              Put value on string register
     !@          Print and clear string register
         R     Recall last value (49)
          -    Minus 1 (48, ascii 0)
           P!  Concatenate to string register and print
```

Sending inputs to code block to loop print saves 5 bytes over printing each individually, but it might be possible to save more bytes by doing some sort of for-loop type structure from the beginning. Storing 9 as well as 48 seems expensive, though.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.7](https://julialang.org/), 14 bytes

```
print((1:10)')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69EQ8PQytBAU13zf50GkP4PAA)

`1:10` returns a `Range`. Note that in Julia 0.2 we can just use `print(1:10)`. This does not work in later versions (I've tested this starting from Julia 0.4).

We could use `print(collect(1:10))`. But this is costly. But we can use a trick by using the `'` transpose operator.

<s>There is also an answer for Julia 0.6 which uses `show.(1:10)` as this prints 1-10, it prints additional stuff in newer Versions of Julia due to the nature of broadcasting, namely,</s>

```
12345678910
10-element Vector{Nothing}:
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
```

Comment: use `show` instead of `print` for -1 byte

Comment: `show.(1:10)` is fine in any version as the additional output is produced only in the REPL. You can mute it by appending a `;`

Comment: @amelies cool! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 20 bytes

```
(1..10).each{|i|p i}
```

Cannot be any simpler than this.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWWzQM9fQMDTT1UhOTM6prMmsKFDJrIVJQFTCVAA)

Comment: `1.upto(10){p _1}` is 16

Comment: @Razetime Damn you are right.

Comment: @Razetime For some reason when running on ATO it refuse to run and running on TIO returns error so I am gonna leave this for a while.

Comment: You should report this problem to [pxeger](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122645/attempt-this-online). If you wanna verify it, try running it on `irb` in your terminal.

Comment: I have reported this to him, and run the code on `irb` also seems to run fine.

Comment: [8 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWKwoUtAz19AwNIFyoKEwWAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Flobnar](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flobnar), 22 bytes

```
+<> v:
,-|\@1
.9>> +
:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJT8pLLPr/X9vGTqHMiktHtybGwZBLz9LOTkGby@r///@6KQA)

```
\@1
> +   Set TOS to 1 on init (and increment TOS on every iteration)
  :

:
+<    Print TOS as number, print 0 (return value of `.`) as char,
,-|   and check if TOS - 9 is zero
.9
:

> v
| @1  Return to start with updated TOS if nonzero,
>  +  evaluate to TOS+1 (10) otherwise (which is printed at the end)
   :
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$3\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 2.469 bytes

```
a10
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJhMTAiLCIiXQ==)

I dare you to golf this further.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 52 bytes

```go
import."fmt"
func f(){for i:=1;i<11;i++{Println(i)}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6FjdNMnML8otK9JTSckuUuNJK85IV0jQ0q9PyixQyrWwNrTNtDIGEtnZ1QFFmXklOnkamZm0tRO9msGqQWRqaCtVcQG1cUJkFCyA0AA)

## [Go](https://go.dev), 39 bytes, prints to STDERR

```go
func f(){for i:=1;i<11;i++{println(i)}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6FjfV00rzkhXSNDSr0_KLFDKtbA2tM20MgYS2dnVBUWZeSU6eRqZmbS1E-WawapB2DU2Fai6gNi6ozIIFEBoA)

Answer (score 1):

## shell commands, 7 bytes

```sh
seq 10
```

or also

```sh
jot 10
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which shell? with coreutils?

Comment: Hello @qwr Those are external tools. [GNU Core Utils provides `seq`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/seq-invocation.html#seq-invocation) since 1.13 shell utilities release ; but it's available under other Unixes too. In fact, it appeared in [Version 8 AT&T UNIX](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_8th/1/seq) first, then [NetBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/seq.1) 3.0, and was ported to [FreeBSD](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=seq&manpath=FreeBSD+12-current) 9.0. It's also part of the [native Win32 ports](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).  (to be followed)

Comment: (continuation) The alternative [`jot`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?jot) first appeared in 4.2BSD and is available under most GNU/Linux too as specific package: [`athena-jot` for Debian based, `outils-jot` for Alpine.](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=jot). It's [fancier](https://www.networkworld.com/article/963725/what-the-jot-command-can-do-for-you.html) than `seq`, and all implementations share the same options. (end)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, 5 bytes

```
+1⇡10
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__KzHih6ExMAo=)

Answer (score 1):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/yasepl-esolang), 10 bytes

```
=a`1+<}4,9
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf SE, nice language

Comment: @noodle-man thank you noodle man

Answer (score 0):

## jq, 12 characters

(11 characters code + 1 character command line option.)

```jq
range(1;11)
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq -n 'range(1;11)'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=range(1%3b11)&j=null)

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (using external library) (39 bytes)

```
x=>console.log(_.Range(1,10).Write(""))
```

Link to lib:https://github.com/mvegh1/Enumerable/

Explanation of code: _.Range creates the array [1,..10], Write joins the array into a string, console.log puts to StdOut

Comment: I was thinking about using something like Underscore's range, but figured something pure would be a bit more impressive. Nice solution!

Comment: Thanks! Yeah yours is way shorter than mine hahaha, I need to learn the ... syntax!

Comment: MDN has an article on the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) :) -- I started with `[...Array(10)].map((v,i)=>++i)`, but that was 30 bytes and I was hoping to do better than the first JavaScript answer on here (24 bytes)! Then I realized that a String is, more or less, just an array of characters. So I tried the spread operator, and viola!

Comment: Ahhhh ok wow I see what its doing. Not bad!!

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (Node.JS 5 / Harmony / ES2015), 19 bytes

```
[...`123456789`,10]
```

**Output**

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

[Try it here](https://repl.it/CeaY) or run `node -p -e "[...'123456789',10]"`

(For older versions of Node.js, like LTS 4.4.7, use `node --harmony`)

Comment: Previous attempts were: `[...Array(10)].map((v,i)=>++i)` and `[...Array(11).keys()].slice(1)`, but both ended up with `30` bytes, which was less than the other `JavaScript` submissions here.

Comment: 1) Your code does not print the integers; but as `-p` clearly adds functionality to it, there should be some penalty for it imo. 2) When I log that to my console (without node), I get an array with nine strings and one integer 3) This is pretty close to a hard coded result.

Comment: There were both an `[...Array(10)].map((_,i)=>i+1)` and an `[...Array(11).keys()].slice(1)` elsewhere, just wrapped with alert making them 37 bytes

Comment: @Titus (1) This is Node.JS, not browser-based JavaScript. They are two different things. However, I can kind of see your point with `-p`. (2) "This includes arbitrary separators (commas, semicolons, newlines, combinations of those, etc., but no digits), prefixes and postfixes (like [...])." (3) Arguable.

Comment: @PaoloBonzini You're late to the party. Both of those were posted by Titus four hours ago. Both of which I left in the comments here and on another answer roughly 24 hours ago :) Granted, I didn't put them in my solution, but that's beside the point. -- As for using an `alert` instead, I defer to (1) in my response to Titus. I primarily develop in Node.JS and use the Node.JS REPL, not browser-based JavaScript. These are two different platforms; similar implementations of a similar spec, but arguably not the same exact thing. I respect the position, though.

Comment: @Swivel: (1) accepted, my mistake. Keep telling people that JavaScript is not Java, now I fall for the same trap. (2) accepted. (3) now that I think of it, yes it is arguable. Ok, I learned some Node.JS from it.

Comment: @Titus No problem at all! Learning is what it's all about! :) I've learned a ton looking through the answers on `code-golf` and others; I'm sure tons of others have too.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 20 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediates window function that takes no input and outputs to the VBE Immediates window

```vb
For i=1To 10:?i:Next
```

Answer (score 0):

## [LibreLogo](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/LibreLogo_Toolbar#LibreLogo_programming_language), 20 bytes

**Code:**

```
print set range 1 11
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Triangular, 15 bytes

```
S](l.U@..i/AS%<
```

Formats into this triangle:

```
    S
   ] (
  l . U
 @ . . i
/ A S % <
```

1. The first command, `S`, stashes the top of stack (`0`) in memory. (This is only so that the `U` will work the first time.)
2. `(` opens a loop.
3. `U` pulls memory onto stack.
4. `i` increments the stack value.
5. `<` directs the IP left, hitting `%`, which prints the top of stack as an integer.
6. `S` stashes the top of stack in memory.
7. `A` pushes 10 to the stack.
8. `/` directs the IP up-right, hitting `@`, which prints the top of stack (`10`) as ASCII (`\n`).
9. `l` checks if the second-to-last stack value (the counter value) is less than 10.
10. If so, jump back to `(`. Otherwise, exit the program.

Comment: [14](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/vzCnwEEv01FPT0ffStXm/38A "Triangular – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 23

```
time {puts [incr i]} 10
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/KHUI17082)

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 10 bytes

```
llnao:9=?;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PycnLzHfytLW3vr/fwA)

#### Explanation:

This program pushes the length of the stack instead of trying to increment the top of the stack, because `l` is shorter than `1+`, and you can do it to an empty stack.

```
l             Push the length of the stack. The first time through pushes 0.
 ln           Print the length of the stack. The first time through prints 1.
   ao         Print a linefeed. (ASCII value 10)
     :9=      If the top of the stack is 9 (i.e. we just printed 10), push 1. 
              Otherwise, push 0.
        ?;    If the top of the stack is non-0, end the program.
              
              Wrap to the start and Repeat. At the end of the loop, we end up
              with one more value on the stack than we started with.
```

Comment: Whoops, I didn't see the other ><> answer that also uses the length of the stack as an incrementer. I'm going to leave this up, but you should really go [upvote them](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99729/62574) if you're going to upvote me. It's even the same byte count.

Answer (score 0):

## [anyfix](https://github.com/alexander-liao/anyfix), 3 bytes

```
⁴RK
```

Note that TIO says that this is 5 bytes but that is because of the unicode character `⁴`; in the codepage of anyfix (which is the same as the Jelly codepage), this solution encodes to 3 bytes.

### Explanation

```
⁴   10
 R  Range [1..10]
  K Join on spaces
```

Alternatively, `⁴RY` separates by newlines. `R⁴K` and `R⁴Y` also work because one of the key features of anyfix is that it works with prefix, infix, and postfix (though `K` and `Y` will work regardless of what's on the stack because if the top of the stack is not a list or does not exist, then it will use the entire stack as a list). Alternatively, `R⁴` or `⁴R` and the `@l` interpreter flag will make it output `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]` because `@l` makes it output the stack as its string representation in Python.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8yrTMus@P//UeOWIO///wE)

Answer (score 0):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), 18 bytes

```
( . cr ) 1 10 loop
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/overview) (noncompeting), 3 bytes

Here's the hex:

```
0A 49 27
```

Finally, a reasonable solution. Explanation:

```
0A - Push 10 to the stack
49 - Pop n; Push [1 ... n]
27 - Pop n; Output n
```

Answer (score 0):

### [TLDCode](https://github.com/Thelonedevil/tldcode), <s>12</s> 10 Bytes

```
='1'p9{c+}
```

Clears the stack of the default input, pushes 1 to the stack, parses it from a string to a number, reapeats `c+` 9 times, which copies the top of the stack and pushes to the stop of the stack, then incremetnts it. Implicitly prints the stack with `_` as the seperator.

Output

```
1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10
```

Previous attempt (12 bytes)

```
'1'pe9{n+e}=
```

Pushes 1 to the stack, parses it from a string to a number and prints, then repeats `n+e` 9 times, which prints a new line, increments the top of the stack and then prints the top. Then it clears the stack to avoid the implicit printing of the default input.

Output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firebird, 113 bytes**

The compacted select, used to calculate the score is below:

```
WITH RECURSIVE T AS (SELECT 1 AS I FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL SELECT 1+I FROM T WHERE I < 10 ) SELECT * FROM T
```

The formated select:

```
WITH RECURSIVE T AS (
  SELECT 1 AS I
  FROM RDB$DATABASE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1+I
  FROM T
  WHERE I < 10
)
SELECT *
FROM T
```

Short explanation: I start with a select on a system table from firebird, witch always has only one record. Then, using recursion on that projection, I add the column "I" until it reaches 10.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Seems like a decent first post, but I think that you could improve it by giving a short explanation for how it works.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I should have add a short explanation on my answer. Already updated it.

Comment: Can you remove some of the spaces/newlines?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Yes I Can! Will do that now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7, 17 bytes

```
print range(1,11)
```

Why 11? The `range()` function is non-inclusive for the end argument.

[repl.it](https://repl.it/IyYw/0)

Comment: Duplicate of [TuukkaX](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41754/tuukkax)'s [Python2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86080) posted 11 months earlier. (With sufficient privileges you could see that there are already 3 completely or partially identical deleted answers too.)

Comment: @manatwork Oops. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3, 20 bytes

```
print(Array(1...10))
```

Comment: Welcome on Programming Puzzle & Code Golf. About the downvote on your answer: it was automatically applied by the system when @Toto edited your answer from the "First Post" review queue; but no one actually downvoted it. Happy golfing!

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 24 bytes

```python
print(list(range(1,11)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIyezuESjKDEvPVXDUMfQUFNT8/9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), **19 Bytes**

```
print range(11)[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EoSgxLz1Vw9BQM9rQKvb/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [AnyDice](http://anydice.com), 10 bytes

```
output d10
```

Try it [here](http://anydice.com/program/912).

This program creates and outputs a single 10 sided die. This lists out the numbers on the die (1-10) next to a bar graph of the probabilities in the standard output form.

Answer (score 0):

## [Eukleides](http://www.eukleides.org/), 26 bytes

```
for i=1 to 10
print i
end
```

Beats hardcoding by 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## ><>, 17 Bytes

```
1>:nao1\
;\?(b:+/
```

Pretty basic:

```
1                       | Push 1 to the stack
 >                      | Make sure pointer is going the right direction
  :n                    | Duplicate the number and print it
    ao                  | Print a new line
      1\                | Increment, redirect pointer
      +/                |-┘ 
   (b:                  | Check that the result is less than 11
;\?                     | If it is, continue looping, else end.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), 10 bytes

```
(;.@%<10)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/1/DWs9B1cbQQFPt/38A)

```
(            do..while loop
 ;            pop (nothing initially, n<10 after that)
  .           increment (0 initially, n after that)
   @          output ASCII value of n for delimiter
    %         output n as integer
     <10      push n<10
        )    loop while top of stack truthy (n<10)
         &   exit (no implicit output)
```

Output (`?` denotes an unprintable):

```
?1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8    9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Bitwise](//git.io/Bit), <s>208</s> <s>191</s> 175 bytes

<sup>-17 bytes using the registers 3 and 4 instead of function frame registers</sup>
<sup>-16 bytes using position-based jumps instead of `LABEL`s</sup>

```
.A:
AND $1 $2 3
XOR $1 $2 $1
SL 3 &1 $2
JMP &-4 $2
RET $1
.G:
NOT $1 3
A $2 3 4
A 4 &1 4
SR 4 &31 4
AND 4 &1 4
RET 4
.L:
G $2 $1 3
RET 3
A 1 &1 1
OUTI 1 &1
L 1 &10 2
JMP &-4 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY0xC8IwEIX39ytuCN0MpsmULaAUS2wkreAsOHRW8OenebHgdN@9u@/uuX6@6/tVig4eYTqJMqJ6sXikvLMymKNY6dhhvN6kOzhiPi8c6sFjSsSqhWaLq@BoOMyZZIm8v6d0HXT0GH4/qsuMFwxXDNJ9uTRGbOUo/@99KRs)

Explanation:

```
.A:          # subroutine: arg3 = arg1 + arg2
.G:          # subroutine: arg3 = arg1 > arg2
.L:          # subroutine: arg3 = arg1 < arg2
A 1 &1 1     # add l1 (literal 1) to r1 (register 1)
OUTI 1 &1 -1 # output r1 as integer
L 1 &10 2    # set r2 to r1 < 10
JMP &-4 2    # jump 3 lines back in the code if r2 is nonzero
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

## FALSE, <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
0[1+$11-][$."
"]#
```

Explanation:

```
0 {push 0}
{conditional function}
[
 1+ {add 1}
 $11- {check if 11}
]
{loop function}
[
 $. {print number}
 "
" {print line break}
]
# {while loop (run second function while first returns true)}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 20 bytes

Anonymous function that takes no input and outputs to the console

```
0Forx=1To10:?x:NextX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwC2/qMLWMCTf0MDKvsLKL7WiJOL/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python3 - 19 Characters

```
print(*range(1,11))
```

**Output:** 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Answer (score 0):

## Rust, 42 bytes

```
fn main(){for i in 1..11{print!("{},",i)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [jamal](http://verhas.com/peter/progs/perl/jamal/), 17 characters

```
{@for i/1..10/i }
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jamal.pl number.jam
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (potentially non-competing)

As a function (6 bytes):

```
_=>110
```

Full program (10 bytes):

```
alert`110`
```

This prints all number from 1 to 10 inclusive in binary...
If you closely read the question, there is never any mention about mandatory separators (thus allowing 123456...) nor the output's base...

Comment: Afaik, it alerts "110" literally...

Comment: @CreaZyp154 1 10 is 1 to 10 in binary

Comment: I'm confused ngl...

Answer (score 0):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 6 bytes

```
[+p]10
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%5B%2Bp%5D10&inputs=)

Loop 10 times while incrementing and printing each time

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 55 B

This complete `program` requires a processor compliant with (at least) ISO standard 7185 “Standard Pascal”.
All numerical values supplied to the built‑in `write`/`writeLn` routines have an **implementation‑defined** *minimum* printing width.
Considering an implementation defines this width to be `8`, the program

```pascal
program p(output);begin write(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)end.
```

prints

```pascal
       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10
```

If you are a user of the [FreePascal Compiler](https://FreePascal.org/), you need to insert a `{$mode ISO}` compiler directive comment or supply the `‑MISO` parameter to the `fpc` compiler command.
Otherwise the built‑in [minimum width is `1`](https://StackOverflow.com/q/64685655/9636977), which just concatenates all numbers *without* any intervening space.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 18 bytes

```swift
print((1...10)+[])
```

Self-explanatory. This literally just creates a `ClosedRange<Int>` from `1` to `10`, and then converts it to an `[Int]` by concatenating an empty array literal. (If we don't do this bit, it'll just output it as `1...10` instead of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.