# Source permutation

Tags: code-challenge, sequence, integer, permutations, self-referential

A [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of a set \$S = \{s_1, s_2, \dotsc, s_n\}\$ is a [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) function \$\pi: S \to S\$. For example, if \$S = \{1,2,3,4\}\$ then the function \$\pi: x \mapsto 1 + (x + 1 \mod 4)\$ is a permutation:

$$
\pi(1) = 3,\quad
\pi(2) = 4,\quad
\pi(3) = 1,\quad
\pi(4) = 2
$$

We can also have permutations on infinite sets, let's take \$\mathbb{N}\$ as an example: The function \$\pi: x \mapsto x-1 + 2\cdot(x \mod 2)\$ is a permutation, swapping the odd and even integers in blocks of two. The first elements are as follows:

$$
2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9,12,11,14,13,16,15,\dotsc
$$

### Challenge

Your task for this challenge is to write a function/program implementing any<sup>1</sup> permutation on the positive natural numbers. The score of your solution is the sum of codepoints after mapping them with the implemented permutation.

### Example

Suppose we take the above permutation implemented with Python:

```python
def pi(x):
    return x - 1 + 2*(x % 2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCoAgFAX3neIhBFq60DbRorsEabn5ysfATm8RzXJgJt/lTDS1tvuAHGVVS4cX9uViQsUICwM3yIoeTrWQ@LWRwBsdXtr5DzJHKrJqAbNC6G@l2gM)

The character `d` has codepoint \$100\$, \$\texttt{pi}(100) = 99\$. If we do this for every character, we get:

$$
99,102,101,31,111,106,39,119,42,57,9,31,31,31,31,113,102,115,118,113,109,31,119,31,46,31,50,31,44,31,49,41,39,119,31,38,31,49,42
$$

The sum of all these mapped characters is \$2463\$, this would be the score for that function.

### Rules

You will implement a permutation \$\pi\$ either as a function or program

- given an natural number \$x\$, return/output \$\pi(x)\$
- for the purpose of this challenge \$\mathbb{N}\$ does **not** contain \$0\$
- the permutation must non-trivially permute an infinite subset of \$\mathbb{N}\$
- your function/program is not allowed to read its own source

### Scoring

The score is given by the sum of all codepoints (zero bytes may not be part of the source code) under that permutation (the codepoints depend on your language<sup>2</sup>, you're free to use SBCS, UTF-8 etc. as long as your language supports it).

The submission with the lowest score wins, ties are broken by earliest submission.

---

1. Except for permutations which only permute a finite subset of \$\mathbb{N}\$, meaning that the set \$\{ x | \pi(x) \neq x \}\$ must be infinite.
2. If it improves your score, you can for example use a UTF-8 encoded Jelly submission instead of the usual SBCS.

Comment: @JoKing "zero bytes may not be part of the source code" re: the second question

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/141315/194).

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), score  <s>288 250 212</s>  199

-38 thanks to Erik the Outgolfer!

```
C-*+
```

Swaps even with odd.

The score is \$67+45+44+43=199\$ - see [self-scoring here](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxxnXS3tRw1zD618uLMl0@FR05rDM7yAzEPryh5tXAdkBP//DwA).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99ZV0v7f9DRPYfbHzWtcf//39DAAAA)**

Comment: Apparently, Leaky Nun's `-*ạ` has a score of 300... however, [`-*_@`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxxdrXiHRw1zD618uLMl0@FR05rDM7yAzEPryh5tXAdkBP//DwA) has a score of 250. Maybe I should post that as my own, although it's the same permutation.

Comment: Ah nice observation by Leaky Nun, so `-*N+` scores 212

Comment: It wasn't an observation, it was [a self-answer to his (now pretty old) challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118825/41024). ;-)

Comment: `C-*+` sound like some future variation of `C++`.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), Score =  <s>276</s>  268

```javascript
$=>(--$^40)+!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/NasMwEITvfoopCLTCsTC0Jxs5lJInSG@lJUKJ84MjBVkpBqNndyXaQy49Lfsxsztz0d96NP58C5V1@8PSq4WpjqqKfb3UonyqF5MwFHoZ3Db4sz2SaIvxfk2sbosPKWVWfMre@Y02JzJQHeYCMM6ObjjIwR1px9lsIm/wd43NZNMw0py0f0vsNZAQDy/kTe@3QftAzyKu0FM2il/nlOOQ/V8PYvOEDhZr8JKjAecxowo2il3KD@QGpcLUFjHtj1n5uwt6aPgqa0S7/AA)

Comment: but `54^54` is `0`

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks for notifying. I somehow missed that part. Should be correct now.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), Score: 201

```perl6
*-!0+^40+!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcrBCoIwGADgu0/xK6KVNSZIh0ZChw5Bh8DoGA73C4LbdJuQT7@MLtH5@wY0/d7LGWIORxhrv9mFNHsWNAupr4kznWTBwkm7cBTziJwfpysLAstnSG9o5OS467SCCscJVYMHSLernJCc0nVZkqRl33tRAl8ooNECB90pZz8z5kQbYX/jXTveQ9Vog/@D2Eky/wY)

Port of [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181263/76162). This benefits from xor (`+^`) having the same precedence as `-` and `+`, and the use of a Whatever lambda to reduce overall characters. Other than that, I couldn't find a way of representing it differently that got a better score.

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), Score <s>804</s> 702

```perl6
{{(++$∉ords(q[!$%()+-2?[]_doqrsx{}∉])??++$+22-$++%2-$++%2!!++$)xx$_}()[-!$+$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BS8MwGIbv/RXpyLqE2I@tBw8WVxQ8CB6EiZdSuthkUlmTNUmho/Suf9M/0mXMg3r5Ds/3wPMepNlfT80RYY5uUbudhoEwhr8/v7QRlrR5iOeEsjjJ8qIUujW2H0b/LWiWeY8lSYwZm//cMPSM9j0uR0LzOMQMl8U4bcGZukkDn4l2PjOLMJ/Bw@vdUxoElh/R4lmapnPc1VqhjWw7qSp5gxZXZAWwWi7peg3RLr24j0rIXgpUaSEPulbOnk3M4bz4t/iiHd@jTaWN/G@A7ZqL5Wmlmze45@9/QadqvwOsNg4@fCadTg)

The first quine-y type answer here, and I think it scores pretty well.

This produces the sequence \$23,22,25,24...\$ from the question body with the range \$1,2,3,4...21\$ inserted at the indexes of the unique sorted codepoints of the code. For example, the 30th through 35th elements of the sequence are \$50, 53, 52, 1, 55, 54\$ since the 33rd codepoint is `!` and that's the lowest codepoint in my code.

Comment: O_o that's a massive improvement

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) score: <s>742</s> <s>698</s> 694 points

```python
lambda a:a^96or~~96
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBBasMwEEXX0SkGupCGGGGnxeCAVj6GcYgiy46KLQlZgXaTq7tSm7YEtJk/82f@k/@MV2cPm3KDBgGU0m2Wy2WQII/y1NQu3O9NvSWdrzEYz5DoD60YHQXdZxMSH4yNQFflgqYFrLeFjcyFgSlEGF0ABcbC06xZ4WLetYrGWUivqzivysNrn/0uRD2wRXo2FkHaSbOqSM03RBTiSSAk5SIvEB0oOavbLKMG56NZ5Az2@7Y8pQMBLOecpGSr6HqSdZMz/S8rSzySXZt@IOfkQftZKs1oU9PibM5Idj/UU6JuU5VX7UXHMuz0C/vH2mJhsH/APniyA3Pe7Qs)

-44 points thanks to Ørjan Johansen; -4 points thx to xnor.

Comment: Ørjan Johansen: Fixed (and it saved me 44 bytes!)

Comment: Good save (although that's not bytes)

Comment: That's some generous crediting!

Comment: Wouldn't have edited if you hadn't pointed out the flaw :)

Comment: It's cheaper to replace the space before `96` with `~~`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 6 bytes, score 260

```
T`O`RO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JME/Icj/v542l4oWl@F/CxMuSzMuc0sQaWEEZAAA) Link includes self-scoring footer. Simply swaps digits `1` and `9` and `3` and `7` in the decimal representations, so that numbers that contain no digits coprime to `10` are unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 22 bytes, Score <s>247</s> 245

```cs
A=>A>65?A-1+A%2*2:66-A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY49D4IwEEB3fkVDYmilmBYjA6WYLk5uDs6mUr3BQvhwIfx2PJgYHG645L17Z7vEdjBfBm8L8D3HKRvQs9GlKbPT2SQyNrt0n@ZZlphZBV3fgn8RWz8rHf6nQhW4uq0e9k2/j5Y4An7lWXBvoa@u4CsaRqOYopyMciJJScZ0CrnjFPPM8QaoY0xt8dvwQVggtVw64Eqtxk@pZQuJvcUloKWCQgqhII7Zxkd17Ui8AEsAUJszwdPjDw)

Simple, if less than 66, return 66 minus input, else use the formula in the question that swaps even and odd numbers.

Comment: What's wrong with the previous version `A=>A<66?66-A:A`?

Comment: @JoKing *Except for permutations which only permute a finite subset of \$\mathbb{N}\$, meaning that the set \$\{ x | \pi(x) \neq x \}\$ must be infinite.* The set isn't infinite, since the only values in the set are 1-65, since above 65, all values of A map to A

Comment: Oh darn, I didn't notice that. That means my own answer is invalid too :(

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 9 bytes, score <s>1088</s> <s>1051</s> 1000

```
Ans-cos(π2fPart(2⁻¹Ans
```

Swaps even with odd.  Even maps to `Ans-1` and odd maps to `Ans+1`.

TI-BASIC is tokenized, so this program will have the following hex-values:

```
Ans   -    cos(  π    2    fPart(  2   ⁻¹  Ans
72    71   C4    AC   32   BA      32  0C  72
```

Thus the score is: \$113+114+195+171+49+185+49+11+113=1000\$

**Output test program:**

```
For(I,1,10
I
Ans-cos(π2fPart(2⁻¹Ans
Disp Ans
Pause
End
```

Which outputs:

```
2
1
4
3
6
5
8
7
10
9
```

---

**Notes:**

- TI-BASIC's token values can be found [here](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/tokens).
- `Pause` is used in the output program to better see the permutation, as the calculator only has 8 lines.  Press **[ENTER]** to view the next permutation.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes, score 681

```
⁻⁺²³²ι⊗﹪⊖ι²³³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/37PynOL3@9Zem7Ho47l/x817n7UuOvQpkObD206t/NR1/T3O1c96pp2bidYaPP//9HRBhWOLjoKQNIJRDoZgUljBNvVEkRauoLVmILZLghxFPXGsbEA) Link is to self-scoring version with header to map over an array of byte codes. (Charcoal has a custom code page so I've manually inserted the correct byte codes in the input.) Works by reversing ranges of 233 numbers, so that 117, 350, 583 ... are unchanged. Explanation:

```
     ι          Value
 ⁺              Plus
  ²³²           Literal 232
⁻               Minus
         ι      Value
        ⊖       Decremented
       ﹪        Modulo
          ²³³   Literal 233
      ⊗         Doubled
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, score 985

```
(\((.),(-))->(.)*200+mod(-39+(-))200+1).(\(*)->divMod((*)-1)200)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY/BSgMxEIbv@xQ/rWDSmrBrvSgqlFV6sVIonmwPIZvtLjabZZIKIj77moBYxIMHL8PMfDMfM43yL2a/H97FGA/zx8XTfHGPcrXCWHxkre0dBdypoGTZKMqsajvcoHIZtOuC6YLHtcDOhPKrzNAfwjoQRss39OR2pOyph9eOzBVGEVPbBZzAH2yMVvVgNSQcVfzbeZSs055H7QhG6QY6XqF0MPTD9Zcl8RrPhZQXeb79tXpEWR2/2wxsw5jkZ0xwLm5jNjnP86l1FROzy2nqprrgMs5N4kTVvi4jTHmREB/wb8Un)

Comment: I don't think this is a permutation, since adding `a*200` has no effect modulo 200 so `a`  doesn't matter.

Comment: @xnor Good catch. That's supposed to be outside of the mod. At some point while golfing, I must have messed up order of operations. Fixed now, thanks!

Comment: I think there's another issue that 40 maps to 0 but the challenge requires positive integers, which makes approaches like this tricky.

Comment: @xnor Fixed. (Sigh, there goes my score.)

Comment: Using `sum[1|...]` over `if..then..else` should help.

Comment: @ბიმო That helped a lot, thanks!

Comment: [looks a bit better :P](https://tio.run/##lYu9DoIwFEb3PsVNdGjFEvxZTMCEoGFRw@IkJlwsSCOlpFQX9dmRwbi7nOQ7@U6F3a2o6/7JR7ALD/ExjLcQJQmM@JtI1WpjYYMW3ahCQxTKBgIQmsBFN7ZobAc@h2tho@8k0BrZWBhDd1cDFbZAS3BBG8F@ESkDSHua0nyKjK9p7gzv0@yF/tI7s8nc8xzkixVzaSbkY69FNijW/118AA)

Comment: Btw. what happened to 161?

Comment: @ASCII-only I'm not convinced that adding a `\\` and causing a warning makes it look better :P

Comment: @ბიმო I originally either subtracted 39 or added 161 to the remainder. Now, instead, I always subtract 39 and add 1 to the quotient in the cases when I would have added 161 before.

Comment: [better? :P](https://tio.run/##lYu9DoIwFEb3PsVNdGjFEvxZTMCEoGFRw@IkJlwsSCOlpFQX9dmRwbi7nOQ7@U6F3a2o6/7JR7ALD/ExjLcQJQmM@JtI1WpjYYMW3ahCQxTKBgIQmsBFN7ZobAc@h2tho@8k0BrZWBhDd1cDFbZAS3BBG8F@ESkDSHua0nyKjK9p7gzv0@yF/tI7s8nc8xzkixVzaSbkY69FNijWk7@TDw)

Comment: @ASCII-only Sure, edited.

Comment: I meant that your function doesn't map to 161, so it's not a permutation.

Comment: @ბიმო Ah, I thought you were asking where the constant in my code went. Okay, fixing...

Comment: @ბიმო Fixed. (Interestingly, fixing that improved my score.)

Comment: [1208?](https://tio.run/##nY7BagIxFEX3@YqLFprUJszUbiq2INPipopQXGnBp5nRoWYyJFGQ0m8fI4jFrZsHh8M9vA35n3y7bX5lG5@D8XA6GH4gm0zQln@sNLV1Ae8USGUbcsxQWeEV2jKsbBXyKnj0JdZ5yM7IUO/CV3BojQ6onV07MvcefmVd3kMraldWAXfwOxOvoRq8gIJ1Wlya/5GTLzBLlXpOku@rwLViRfxr3vA5Xz6SkG/Lh6ck6RirOcnuizhBKhRf6HI/snoROZJMO6LBDaMj)

Comment: @ASCII-only Yep, nice savings!

Comment: [1018?](https://tio.run/##pY9BS8MwGIbv@RUvm2BiTWzVi6LCqLLLJoPhyQkLSboWl6YkmSCy315TEId48ODlI09e3ofvq2V4Ndtt/8HHmE0ep0@T6QPKxQJjvieN7ZyPuJdRirKWnljZtLiFdgTKtdG0MeCGY2Ni@YUE3S4uo8do/o7Ou42X9jggKOfNNUYp9k0bcYSws2la2YFWEHBes2/nQbIcegGV8zBS1VBpC6mi8T9cf1mGvMJzIcRlnr/8qh4iUqXrVj1dUXrGTilnjN@l18l5nmfWacovrrLhd@CCCbrWzdvc6XXiRLzIWI//tD8B)

Comment: btw, you don't need bytecount since that doesn't matter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90852/discussion-between-ascii-only-and-joseph-sible).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score: 488 [in 05AB1E's code page](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
È·<-
```

Swaps odd and even like the example function.

Will try to improve the score from here.

[Try it online with input in the range `[1, 100]`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9oYODqZ6@koGunoGTvBwT/D3cc2m6j@1/nPwA) or [Try it online with the codepoints.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/e/h8v9wx6HtNrr//f9HKzlbKOkoOZkDCWNnIGHkohQLAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
È     # Check if the (implicit) input is even (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
 ·    # Double (2 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
  <   # Decrease by 1 (1 if truthy; -1 if falsey)
   -  # Subtract it from the (implicit) input (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck, 47 bytes, score 2988

```
,[-<+<+>>]<[->[>+<[-]]+>[<->-]<<]>[-<<++>>]<<-.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hYqxDYAgEEVHYYDznOBylYUdA5ArhEhUAgGjJk6P6AK@4v/iPbtPa/KnCxX@MEhUu7ZAwCxkkA1DOxFgQ8goRMJvBl9A2NdmuSFVl7wUm9IWF6Wv@w7@UDY6NWTn1ZjD/AA)

I used the permutation given in the introduction. Since this is bijection you can use it as a simple symmetric cipher similar to ROT13 or Atbash. My solution works on unbounded cells. However, by restricting yourself to 8-bit cells, you could save 2 points by replacing `[-]` with `[+]`.