# Digit stream with no 42

Tags: code-golf, string, number

You should write a program or function which receives no input and outputs a stream of digits.

- The stream should contain at least once every positive integer number which does not contain the digit sequence `42`. E.g. The string `1231` contains the integers `1 12 123 1231 2 23 231 3 31 (and 1 again)`
- The stream should *not* contain the digit sequence `42`.
- If your interpreter can't handle infinite output gracefully you can add code to only print the first `n` digits. This added code does not count to your score.
- Note that the stream `203204205...` contains `42`.
- No randomness should be used.

This is code-golf so the shortest entry wins.

Comment: This is basically [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63834/count-up-forever?noredirect=1&lq=1) with an additional substring check.

Comment: @Fatalize Right, now it seems too simple. I forgot that skipping the number is not a problem.