# Be the First 1 (leave only the first Truthy)

Tags: code-golf, array, logic

#### Intro

Every year, [Dyalog Ltd.](http://www.dyalog.com/) holds a student competition. [The challenge there](http://www.dyalog.com/student-competition.htm) is to write *good* APL code. This is a language agnostic [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) edition of this year's eighth problem.

I have explicit permission to post this challenge here from the original author of the competition. Feel free to verify by following the [provided link](http://www.dyalog.com/student-competition.htm) and contacting the author.

#### Problem

Given a Boolean* list, "turn off" all the Truthies after the first Truthy.

No Truthies? No problem! Just return the list unmodified.

#### Examples

```
[falsy,truthy,falsy,truthy,falsy,falsy,truthy] → [falsy,truthy,falsy,falsy,falsy,falsy,falsy]

[] → []

[falsy,falsy,falsy,falsy] → [falsy,falsy,falsy,falsy]
```

---

* All your truthies must be identical, and all your falsies must be identical. This includes output.

Comment: Can we use bit lists or other truthy/falsy list representations that are more natural in our language of choice?

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes, of course, I thought that was covered by [default rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/43319). No?

Comment: Well yeah, if you talk about "truthy" and "falsy" in the challenge instead of "booleans", "true" and "false". ;)

Comment: I'm not clear on the booleans. Can we use 0/1 even if our language has True/False?

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @xnor See edit.

Comment: @Adám Are we choosing which values to expect as Truthy value and Falsey value? Does the output have to use the same ones as the input?

Comment: @xnor Ah, good point. I think it would be fair to allow choosing input, but output must match, don't you think so?

Comment: @Adám I think that's reasonable, though it needs limits to stop people form embedding code into their choice of values (is that a loophole?). Matching output feels right for the challenge.

Comment: @Adám Actually, I'm a bit sad a language like Haskell can't use an arithmetic solution just because 0's and 1's aren't truthy or falsey. But saying "any two distinct values" would let people use True as False and False as True, which is also silly. Not sure how to handle that.

Comment: @xnor I hear you, but if Haskell cannot treat numbers as Booleans, or cannot do arithmetic on Booleans, then that is a real limitation in the golfing power of Haskell, and ought to be reflected in the byte count by necessitating conversions or other work-arounds. What do you think of the footnote formulation?

Comment: It doesn't matter for this challenge (because the language doesn't have a working interpreter yet), but I'm working on a language which has booleans but *not* the ability to store them in arrays (not even by printing them one at a time; outputting boolean false would exit the program). How would that work in this challenge? (Normally you'd just use if statements to make them into something else, but the challenge bans that.)

Comment: Just to be sure, the input Truthy/falsy values should also be equal to the output T/F? Or can you use 0/1 as input and get TRUE FALSE as output?

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam The first: *All your truthies must be identical, and all your falsies must be identical. This includes output.*

Comment: Are two trailing falsey values ok?

Comment: @Christopher What do you mean?

Comment: @Adám Input of 0 1 0 output of 0 1 0 0. Two extra false values at the end

Comment: @Adám https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#XY1RCsAgDEOv0s/kz/2XXkQ8SenZXYs4tyEUSV6SiT7oHvDo4FCjWknhsT7L@@muWzMwFCCNvjsKKNeKRqU0WwSpMslMe1g5imQy78kZ5bOT1afxWVv7czZpcsm5r3cD example

Comment: @Christopher I'd say no. That just isn't the right result.

Comment: @Adám thought so

Comment: If working a language with text input separated by newlines, is an empty line acceptable, or should the line be removed entirely?

Comment: @DomHastings An empty line is fine.

Comment: Could we take input newline-separated, but have output joined together? Or should both in- and output be newline separated, or both in- and output be joined together?

Comment: `No Truthies? No problem!` No problem = The problem (challenge) does not need to be solved. That pun is really clever!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## [APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), 2 bytes

```apl
<\
```

Evaluates to the function "scan using less-than".
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog-classic#@5@m8KhtgoJNzP9HfVPBzDQFAwVDIASS/wE)

### Explanation

In APL, the operator `\` (scan) reduces each nonempty prefix of an array from the right using the provided function.
For example, given the array `0 1 0`, it computes `0` (prefix of length 1), `0<1` (prefix of length 2) and `0<(1<0)` (prefix of length 2) and puts the results into a new array; the parentheses associate to the right.
Reducing by `<` from the right results in `1` exactly when the last element of the array is `1` and the rest are `0`, so the prefix corresponding to the leftmost `1` is reduced to `1` and the others to `0`.

Comment: Finally! I have been wondering.

Comment: Now I suppose you can answer in J too, no?

Comment: @Adám Yes, in J it's 3 bytes: </\ Jelly probably has an analogous 2-byte solution too.

Comment: No, I don't think so, because Jelly is left-to-right.

Comment: What a strange version of scan APL has. It's neither a left nor a right scan (rather, a mix between them) and doesn't allow the interpreter to reuse previous results in calculating the next. But, as we can see, it does things that can't easily be done with a normal (cumulative) scan operation. (Compare this to the [Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119504/29859))

Comment: @Hjulle Indeed, my answer implements precisely this scan "by hand" - although that wasn't how I thought of it originally. Haskell has both left and right scans, but both are aimed at reusing results, so neither works for this.

Comment: There are couple other two byters for this - ⊤\ and |\.

Answer (score 49):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 35 bytes

```python
while 1:b=input();print b;True&=b<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@1@ekZmTqmBolWSbmVdQWqKhaV1QlJlXopBkHVJUmqpmm2Rj@P@/W2JOcSoXSIALg4kkAAA) Input and output are lines of True/False.

Based on [Dennis's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119491/20260). Redefines the variable `True` to be `False` after a `True` input is encountered. That way, any further inputs of `True` will evaluate to `False` and be printed as such. Python 3 no longer allows `True` and `False` to be redefined, so this answer uses Python 2.

The redefinition is `True&=b<1`, i.e. `True = True & (b<1)`. When the input `b` is `True`, then `(b<1)` is False (since `True==1`), so `True` becomes `False`. See [Kevin Cruijssen's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203149/20260) for a shorter way to handle this redefinition.

Comment: You can redefine True??? This deserves a +1 just because hax >_>

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yes, but not in Python 3. (Which is fine because the language here is Python 2.)

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Okay thanks. That is just weird though...

Comment: @HyperNeutrino It's probably worth mentioning that you can do `True, False = False, True`.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Okay, thanks! Also, if I do `True, False = False, True`, will `bool(1)` return false (like, real false) and `bool(0)` return real true?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino - nope. Builtins still return the 'real' value, it's just 'True' that you type that changes. (Or modules, in some cases...). So bool(1) return True, but bool(1) == True returns False.

Comment: @TLW That's just... Weird... I won't be doing stuff like this anytime soon. :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino - That's probably for the best :-) It's up there with #define 42 43 for how much 'fun' you can have in a codebase with it. Oh, and with ctypes you can actually make, e.g. the internal Python object that represents int(2) actually have an integer value of 1. This breaks all the things.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Actually, you can. `import builtins` \n `builtins.__dict__["True"] = False`. :-)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 That doesn't seem to change anything?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon It might be good in a Python 3 port. Plus, it'll make `eval(input())` work the same as Python 2's `input` in this case, no matter the local variables.

Answer (score 27):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/L3viathan/aceto), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

#### New version (17 bytes):

This new version takes the characters one at a time and is best executed with the `-F` option. It works similar, but not identical to the previous solution:

```
 >,
Op0
p|1u
,ip^
```

---

#### Old answer (19 bytes):

```
|p1u
iOp<
|!`X
rd!r
```

This is the first Aceto answer that highlights what it can do relatively well, I would say. The "lists" are input streams, with one input per line, "1" for true, and "0" for false, with an empty string signifying the end of the list.

[image: code flow illustration]

Aceto programs run on a Hilbert curve, starting on the bottom left, and ending on the bottom right. First, we `r`ead a string, `d`uplicate, and negate (`!`) it, turning empty strings into True, everything else into False. Then there's a conditional horizontal mirror (`|`): If the top element on the stack is truthy, mirror horizontally. This happens when the string was empty. If we do the mirroring, we land on the `X`, which kills the interpreter.

Otherwise, we convert the remaining copy on the stack to an `i`nteger and do another conditional horizontal mirror: This time, because 1 is truthy and 0 is falsy, we mirror if we see the (first) true value. If we don't mirror (so we saw a 0) we `p`rint what's on the stack (since the stack is empty, a zero) and jump to the `O`rigin of the curve, where we started, starting the whole process again.

Otherwise, when we saw a 1, we mirror and land on the `u`, which reverses the direction we move on the Hilbert curve. `1p` prints a 1, and now we go on the same `O` we would have gone if we had seen a 0, but since we're in "reversed mode", our origin is at the bottom *right*, so we jump there.

Now we `r`ead another string, and negate it. If the string was empty, and therefore the top stack element is truthy, `` ` `` will *not* escape the next command (`X`), making us quit.

Otherwise (if the string wasn't empty), we *do* escape the `X` and ignore it. In that case, we go to the left (`<`), `p`rint 0 (because the stack is empty), and jump back to the `O`rigin.

Comment: Congratulations on your first proper challenge solved in Aceto.

Comment: Looks at diagram. *Right…*

Comment: @Adám It probably won't help (if you don't know Aceto) on its own, but I thought it might be good to see alongside the text to be able to follow it better.

Answer (score 18):

## Java8, <s>24</s> 19 Bytes

```
Long::highestOneBit
```

Hope this is legal; I got the impression the input / output doesn't have to evaluate as true/false in the language. Takes a long as input and gives one as output, with ones being true and zeroes being false in the binary representation. For example, binary 00101 is 5 and would return binary 00100 which is 4.

Five bytes thanks to @puhlen

Comment: Nice approach. Java being competitive‽

Comment: Wow, JAVA as a *competitive* answer‽

Comment: Not entirely sure if this is valid for codegolf rules, but this could be improved to 19 chars by using a method reference: `Long::highestOneBit` which produces the identical result with a shorter syntax

Comment: @puhlen expressions evaluating to anonymous functions are allowed.

Comment: @puhlen Thanks, didn't realize that would work here, but since it's completely equivalent..

Comment: This isn't quite valid.  You need to include the import to Long, as this doesn't compile by itself.  That said, `java.lang.Long::highestOneBit` compiles just fine.

Comment: @NathanMerrill The `java.lang` package is imported by default. From the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html) _"A compilation unit automatically has access to all types declared in its package and also automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package java.lang."_

Comment: @JollyJoker you're right.  I assumed that wasn't the case because my IDE auto-imports it.  My bad :)

Comment: @Adám, ZacharyT: +1 for exposing me to the Interrobang.

Comment: What's with all the weird question marks‽

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 33 bytes

```python
while 1:b=input();print b;True^=b
```

Port of [@xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119503/52210), minus 2 bytes. Normally I would just suggest it as a golf in the comments, but since [*@xnor* has specifically stated we can outgolf any of his answers for a bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18334/52210), here it is as a separated answer.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/vzwjMydVwdAqyTYzr6C0REPTuqAoM69EIck6pKg0Nc426f9/t8Sc4lQuEBdCIPEhTAwBhFp8GgA)

The difference? `True&=b<1` has been changed to `True^=b`.

**Why does this work?**

First we get some potential `False` inputs (`b=input();`). Each of those will be printed as is (`print b;`). And the `True^False` will remain `True`, so 'variable' `True` remains truthy.

Then we encounter the first `True` input, which will also be printed. After that, the `True^True` will evaluate to `False`, so the 'variable' `True` is from now on falsey.

After that it doesn't matter what our input is anymore, since `True` is redefined as falsey. So the `print b;` will always print `False` at this point. And in addition, the `True^=b` can now only be `False^False`, so 'variable' `True` will remain falsey.

Comment: Wow, TIL `True` can be reassigned. Nice golf!

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Yeah, I also didn't knew before seeing _xnor_'s answer. Then again, I think you can reassign most constants in Python. I think I've also seen someone user and overwrite the `id` constant in another challenge for example.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Nice find, bounty posted! I like how elegant the `^=` update is with it becoming harmless after the first `True`. What makes your find more impressive is that  a lot of voters on my answer apparently didn't think of this, in addition to me.

Comment: @xnor Well, most credit still goes to yourself. I wasn't even aware it was possible to use `True`/`False` as a variable and redefine their values before I saw your answer. If it wasn't for your bounty post, I would have just suggested it as a -2 bytes comment. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I'm pretty sure the redefining of `id` was also `xnor` in another of his answers :)

Comment: @RGS You're right, he indeed was. :) [Here is his answer I was referring to.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132634/52210)

Comment: Funny, because I was thinking about [this @xnor answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111594/75323) :p turns out this must be a recurrent trick, as `id` is the shortest predefined and reassignable name in Python

Comment: @SurculoseSputum always remember to sneak `True = random.random() < 0.98` into your colleague's  code ;)

Comment: @jaaq That's evil! XD

Answer (score 12):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 6 bytes

```
1>`1
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/hvaJdgyGXw/7@BIRAaGHJxGQABlyEIAAA)

Input is a list of `0`s (for False) and `1`s (for True).

Matches all `1` and replaces each except the first one (`1>`) with a `0`.

Comment: I can see it now. You working in an office on some OS. A manager comes over and yells at you for writing an entire OS with regex.

Comment: I was wondering who left that ^ dumb comment then realized it was me...

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
+\=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@68dY5v4////aAMdBUMdBTgJYsQCAA)

Here's a rather different algorithm to most of the other golfing language solutions (although after I posted it, I noticed that the R solution also uses this algorithm), and tying with the current Jelly record holder.

### Explanation

```
+\=a
+\    Cumulative sum of the input list
  =   Compare corresponding elements with the input
   a  Logical AND corresponding elements with the input
```

As long as all elements to the left of an element are 0, the cumulative sum up to an element will equal the element itself. To the right of the first 1, the two are different (because we're now adding the nonzero total of the elements to the left). Thus, `+\=` gives us a list containing 1 (i.e. true) up to and including the first truthy element. Finally, logical AND with the original list will give us a 1 for *only* the first truthy element.

Answer (score 11):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 7 bytes

```
f1òf1r0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@59meHhTmmGRwf//0QY6hjoQDCRjAQ)

My first V submission! \o/

### How it works

```
f1òf1r0
f1       "go to the next occurence of 1
  ò      "repeat the following until end:
   f1    "    go to the next occurence of 1
     r0  "    replace with 0
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Explanation added.

Comment: This fails for a 1 in the first position :(

Comment: @nmjcman101 fixed.

Comment: Since you changed the input format, you can swap `r0` with `<C-x>` to decrement the ones and save a byte.

Comment: Vim (not so sure about V) also has `;` to repeat last `t`/`f` jump, likely saving another byte.

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

Code:

```
ā<s1kQ
```

Explanation:

```
ā         # External enumeration, get a and push [1 .. len(a)]
 <        # Decrement each
  s       # Swap to get the input
   1k     # Get the first index of 1
     Q    # Check for equality with the enumeration array
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@k0abYMDvw//9oAx0FQx0FOAlixAIA)

Comment: `1k>sƶ-_` is another, worse though. The `lift` idea may have potential though.

Comment: Alternative 6-byter for the legacy: [`ηO‚øPΘ`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3Hb/Rw2zDu8IODfj//9oAx0FIDIEIyg7FgA), which would be 5 bytes in the new version: [`ηOøPΘ`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Hb/wzsCzs34/z/aQEcBiAzBCMqOBQA).

Comment: Actually, my 6/5-byter above is actually a 4-byter which works in both the legacy and new version: [`ηO*Θ`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3HZ/rXMz/v@PNtBRACJDMIKyYwE)

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 25 bytes

Anonymous function taking and returning a list of `Bool`s.

Use as `(foldr(\x l->x:map(x<)l)[])[False,True,False,False]`.

```hs
foldr(\x l->x:map(x<)l)[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#y03MzLPNzCtJLUpMLlEpzcvJzEst1stNLNAozsgv10vT0yhKTUyxsgouKcrMS9e1i3bKz8@J1dTUAyv8n2ablp@TUqQRU6GQo2tXYQXSWGGjmaMZHfv/f7RbYk5xqk5IUWmqDgYTIRDLFQ1EyKJIZCwXAA)

## How it works

- Folds over a list from the right, prepending new elements and possibly modifying those following.
- `x` is the element to be prepended to the sublist `l`.
- Uses that `False` compares less than `True`, so `map(x<)l` will turn any `True`s in `l` into `False` if `x` is `True`.

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>33</s> 26 bytes

```
a=>a.map(e=>e&!(i-=e),i=1)
```

I/O is in arrays of 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 6):

## [Turing machine simulator](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), 39 bytes

```
0 0 0 r 0
0 1 1 r 1
1 0 0 r 1
1 1 0 r 1
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?fd0141edeb1460e742a953adc34b8a25)

Comment: _Essentially_ the same thing I'm doing in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 3 bytes

```
</\
```

Defines a monadic verb.
This is a trivial port of [my APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119548/32014).
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGulYKMf8z81OSNfIU3BQMEQjIHkfwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

A port of my 05AB1E answer.

```
i1=J
```

Explanation (argument **α**):

```
i1        # Index of 1 (1-indexed) in α
  =       # Check for equality with the array:
   J      # [1 .. len(α)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@59paOv1////aAMdBUMdBTgJYsQCAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 55 bytes

```
+>,[[->+>[->-<]>+[-<+>]<<<]>>[-<-<<[->>+<<]>>>]<.[-]<,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#HYnBCQAwDAIHspb2Ly4Ssv8YqRRBvHPgVUXDKaqNouCWsuNEKY/xOX4XW6tnzk3OfQ)

Answer (score 4):

## Perl 5, 20 bytes

```
sub{map$_&&!$x++,@_}
```

Truthy is `1` and falsey is `''` (an empty string).

Explanation:

`map` loops over elements of the list it `@_`, the arguments passed to the subroutine, setting each element to $_ locally and returning an array of the return values it computes from each element. `$_&&!$x++` outputs `$_` if `$_` is falsey and `!$x++` if it is truthy. (Note that && is short-circuiting, so `!$x++` is not executed until the first truthy value is reached). `$x++` returns `0` (which is falsey) the first time it is run and then increments every time (and so remains truthy). The `!` negates `$x++`, and so it returns truthy the first time it is encountered and falsey thereafter.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 24 bytes

```r
cumsum(T<-scan(,F))==T&T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@59cmltcmqsRYqNbnJyYp6HjpqlpaxuiFvLfzdEn2FUhJCgUSiD4/wE)

Example:

For input `FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE`
`cumsum(T<-scan(,F))==T` returns `TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE`.  The F in the scan ensures logical input.
`FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE` and `TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE` is `FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE`. A single `&` does an elementwise comparison.

Comment: @rturnbull unfortunately the input format has to be the same as the output.

Comment: `cumsum(scan(,F))==1` works for 19 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 23 bytes

```matlab
@(a)diff([0 cummax(a)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkaiZkpmWphFtoJBcmpubWAEUiNX8n6Zgq5CYV2zNBZLRMdSBYCAZqwkRUjBQAAlAuEANAA)

First difference of cumulative max of the list.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 58 bytes

```
lambda x:[x[i]and x.index(x[i])==i for i in range(len(x))]
```

If `x[i]` is false, the output is false; otherwise, it gives whether or not the element is the first occurence in the array of itself.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 37 bytes

```
foreach($_GET as$v)echo$v*!$$v++,' ';
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
TḊṬ^
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x/ycEfXw51r4v4f3XO4/VHTGm8gjvz/PzraQMdQB4KBZKxONBAZgDkGYBZEEgQNYmMB)**

#### How?

This does what was asked in a pretty literal sense:

```
TḊṬ^ - Main link: list a   e.g. [0,1,0,1,0,0,1]  or  [0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
T    - get the truthy indexes   [  2,  4,    7]      [  2,  4,  6  ]
 Ḋ   - dequeue                  [      4,    7]      [      4,  6  ]
  T  - make a boolean array     [0,0,0,1,0,0,1]      [0,0,0,1,0,1  ]
   ^ - XOR that with a          [0,1,0,0,0,0,0]      [0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [unsure](https://github.com/Radvylf/unsure), 222 bytes

```
hm um err wait oops um but oops yeah umm err heh well wait oops then but heh wait oops no um um yeah err heh um but oops oops um heh well wait oops then um but oops yeah um err heh well wait then um but oops okay well wait
```

Unsure is a stack based esolang I recently created. This answer takes input as a string of `0x00` and `0x01` bytes.

First, here's the code broken into more readable sections:

```
hm um err wait oops

um but oops yeah umm err heh well wait oops then

but heh wait oops no um um yeah err heh

um but oops oops um heh well wait oops then

um but oops yeah um err heh well wait then

um but oops okay well wait
```

The first section is a loop, which first reads input (`hm`), and adds one (`um err`). The `wait` instruction usually ends a while loop, but because there is nothing to start the loop it defaults to the beginning of the program. Because it's adding `1` to each input, and EOF is `-1`, the loop will end once it reaches EOF with an additional `0` on the stack, which is discarded by `oops`.

The next line is a loop through the entire stack. For the first iteration, the stack length is unneeded, so it pushed `1` with `um`. The `but` starts a loop, and the `oops` discards the stack length. It then negates the top of the stack (`yeah`) and adds two (`umm err`, essentially the inverse of the input). It finally pushes this to the other stack (`heh`) and pushes the length of the current stack (`well`). Once the loop ends, the extra `0` is discarded and `then` switches the active stack.

The next line consists of two parts: `but heh wait oops no` (a simple loop which pops items to the other stack until one is `0`), then `um um yeah err heh` which pushes `0` to the other stack.

It then pads the other stack to the right length with `1`s (`um but oops oops um heh well wait oops`) and switches to the other stack (`then`). This is necessary because the output would be backwards otherwise. The other stack does about the same thing, but inverts each item by negating it and adding one (`yeah um err`).

Finally, the `um but oops okay well wait` loop just uses `okay` to output each item in the stack.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 9 bytes

```
.e&b!s<Qk
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.e%26b%21s%3CQk&input=%5BFalse%2CTrue%2CFalse%2CTrue%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5D%0A%5BTrue%5D%0A%5BFalse%2CFalse%5D%0A%5BTrue%2CFalse%2CTrue%5D%0A%5BFalse%2CTrue%2CFalse%2CTrue%5D%0A%5BTrue%2CTrue%2CFalse%2CTrue%5D%0A%5BFalse%2CTrue%2CFalse%2CTrue%2CFalse%2CFalse%2CTrue%5D&debug=0)

```
.e&b!s<Qk
.e          # Python's 'enumerate' (i.e., for each index k and each element b at that index)
      <Qk   # The first k elements of the input
     s      # 'Sum' these first k elements (with booleans, this is a logical 'or')
  &b!       # The value of the output at index k is [value of input @ index k]&&[the negation of the 'sum']
```

Comment: It seems to be more efficient to use a variable and just map over it normally: `m&!~|Z`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>45</s> 36 bytes

```python
r=0
while 1:n=input();print n>r;r+=n
```

Input and output are one Boolean (*True* or *False*) per line.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19ka8BVnpGZk6pgaJVnm5lXUFqioWldUJSZV6KQZ1dkXaRtm/f/v1tiTnEqV0hRaSoXBhNJAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>69</s> <s>66</s> <s>64</s> <s>60</s> <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```
lambda i:[k==i.index(j)and j for k,j in enumerate(i)]
```

Takes an array of `false`s and `true`s. This is a list comprehension of `false`s except if the current iteration's value is `true` and it is the first `true` in the input.

This seems a little long (and it's my first lambda), so if you can find a way to golf it, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: Oh, oops, misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Undeleted and fixed the answer

Comment: You can save one byte by making `0 for` `0for`.

Comment: It works for 1if and 1else, right? Thanks!

Comment: `1if i.index(j)==k and j==1else 0` -> `i.index(j)==k and j` would work the same if the input is a Boolean vector

Comment: Doesn't even have to be a boolean because python is awesome. Thanks!

Comment: I think @FelipeNardiBatista meant the whole thing, not just the `==1`.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 what i meant is that it it a lot shorter

Comment: `i.index(j)==k and` => `k==i.index(j)and`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Idris](https://www.idris-lang.org/example/), 98 bytes

The code is a bit longer, but on the plus side you get the compile time guarantee that the output has the same size as the input!

```
import Data.Vect
f:Vect n Bool->Vect n Bool
f[]=[]
f(x::y)=x::if x then replicate _ False else f y
```

I'm going to give an extensive explanation to have you understand the basic workings of Idris.

#### Explanation

```
import Data.Vect
```

The type `Vect : Nat -> Type -> Type` is not imported by default

```
f : Vect n Bool -> Vect n Bool
```

Contrary to Haskell, Idris uses a single colon `:` to specify types and also *requires* you to specify the type, as the dependent type checker can't possibly infer it in all cases. Since `Vect` takes a `Nat` (natural number) and a `Type`, we provide just that, `n` being a natural number and `Bool` being the type. Even though we didn't specify the type of `n` explicitly, Idris can infer it to be `Nat`. Since `n` occurs both in the argument and the resulting type, they need to be the same.

```
f [] = []
```

As the base case, the empty list returns the empty list. This is the only possible implementation, anything else such as `f[]=[True]` would give a compiler error, since the type of `[]` is `Vect 0 Bool` but the type of `[True]` is `Vect 1 Bool`.

```
f (x :: y) = x :: if x then
```

`::` is used as the cons operator in Idris, similar to `:` in Haskell. We put the first element in the resulting list, unchanged.

```
  replicate _ False else
```

If the first element is true, we want the rest of the list to be false in any case, so we just replicate the value `False`. Since Idris knows that the rest of the list has to have the same size as `y`, it can infer the value of `_` (namely `length y`).

```
  f y
```

If the first element is false, we just move on by recursively calling the function on the rest.

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 77 bytes

```c#
a=>{var b=1<0;for(int i=0;i<a.Length;){a[i]=b?1<0:a[i];b|=a[i++];}return a;};
```

Compiles to a `Func<bool[], bool[]>`. Nothing clever really, just a straight forward solution.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, <strike>85</strike> 73 bytes

```
:a
@(if %1.==. exit)&set/ar=(1-f)*%1
@echo %r%&set/af^|=%1&shift&goto a
```

Takes input as command line arguments. For eample: `1.bat 0 1 0 1 0 0 1`

Previous version

```
@set f=1
:a
@(if %1.==. exit)&set/ar=f*%1
@echo %r%&(if %1==1 set f=)&shift&goto a
```

Answer (score 2):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <strike>16</strike> 19 bytes

<strike>15</strike> 18 bytes sourcecode + 1 byte for -r flag (or -E flag for BSD sed).

```
:
s/1(0*)1/1\10/
t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#@2/FVaxvqGGgpWmobxhjaKDPVfL/v4GhARQZGP7LLyjJzM8r/q/rCgA)

**Edit:** Thanks **Riley** for pointing out a mistake.

Comment: @Riley Thanks for pointing that out! It looks like TIO has a version of sed that is different from mine (BSD). I can't leave the labels empty. Good to know this.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. TIO uses GNU sed. It's a bug turned feature.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>146</s> 144 bytes

```
([]){{}({}<>)(())<>([])}{}<>((())){{}({}<>)<>}{}<>(()){{}((){[()](<{}>)}{})(<>)<>}<>(())<>([]){{}(<{}<>>)<>([])}{}<>{}{}([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}<>{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#fYzBCcAwDANX6VP6dQDjRUImEZ7drZJ@CqUYjOWT1BiTUkEVyUjL8g2Qf8x/UAOcCFWaEMv3OHbAvnDo1aB7f7WbdJ/Hmgs)

```
# Reverse the stack and add a 1 between each to help with reversing later
([]){{}({}<>)(())<>([])}{}<>

# Add a 1 in case there aren't any truthy values (and another 1 like before)
((()))

# Reverse the stack back to it's original order using the 1s from earlier to know when to stop
{{}({}<>)<>}{}<>

# Push 1 to start the loop
(())

# Until we find the first 1
{

 # Pop the last value
 {}

 # Logical not
 ((){[()](<{}>)}{})

  # Put a 0 on the other stack
  (<>)<>

# end loop
}

# Put a 1 on the other stack
<>(())<>

# Push the stack height
([])

# While there are values on this stack
{

 # Move them to the other stack as a 0
 {}(<{}<>>)<>([])

# End while
}{}

# Pop an extra 0
{}

# Switch stacks
<>

# Copy everything back (to reverse it back to it's original)
([])
{
 {}({}<>)<>([])
}<>{}
```

Answer (score 2):

## c (with gcc builtins), 40

A slightly different approach:

```bash
f(n){return!n?0:1<<31-__builtin_clz(n);}
```

This may be ruled invalid - in which case I will happily mark this as non-competing.

Input and output "arrays" are 32-bit unsigned integers - this limits the input list size to be exactly 32 - this may be a disqualifier.  If the input is less than 32 bits long, then it may be padded with zero bits at the end.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#bdLhboIwEADg/zzFzWUJVdwKiMJg7kEcIazCbMLK0pbFaHh2VsQYhnc/2ubL5dL2rittQc6y0I0UD@KdvrpJ4rvLLPtseKW5yFh1Mhlx2z1ywapmX0Ci9J7Xz4etZXGh4TvnAuz@lMsv5gCrhdLADrmE@dzQL4GzBSb6FF0ozXJVqF0Kb1fvgx7pNZx7cxHzEPMRWyEWILZGbINYiFg0NRd5h4eYj9gKsQCxNWIbxELEookF3v3fR//60ca3FvLheFnKWprWm07SGDgkYCt@KurSvrWZwAtMbUdTQkz@YkFGE/AjTfHSnj3R8AjLLfT7h5g5o5HhqQPjOryvM1zPumzDGJvLWG33Bw).

Answer (score 2):

## x86 assembly instructions, 12 bytes

```
31 c0 0f bd cf 74 04 ff c0 d3 e0 c3
```

Or in gcc assembly:

```
    .globl  f
f:
    xor     %eax, %eax
    bsrl    %edi, %ecx
    je  .L2        
    inc     %eax
    sall    %cl, %eax
.L2:
    ret
```

This is a translation of [my c answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119665/11259) and has the same I/O specs.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#bZPbboJAEIavmaeY2JiAIiKelXrXXjXpA1gvcF10GwrN7tqQNj67XQ6lRGcudiZfmH8H5odFGjcYC6n0yFMYhvj0@ny1vGOS7RMrhngFWEeeyTJ3eZS75QnWXsnE6vKDKAAz4J1b3kvw19L0ipQ1vWCpKDFdLKlVTMMKLMn11dwNwNojsXokeDASyfnAMVT6IDLvtAEQqcaPSKRoF1Ukj8xFlqVKIztFEns9g74c/IFqBI2aK80ixdV2h481L8LP/TrcezYiWECwMcEmBJsSbEawOcEWBFveshHxHgHBxgSbEGxKsBnB5gRbEGx5w6bB/bdfEvuI66jYZd2sVVRlecTGpbYw2/XXKDBEW4lvnsV2s3oHh3jLtv7Occzz/b7TcsWnNOKx3en6ixwHGyzyW9pxWzYSOxfbOqLQqcaDMhlXn2VqhoELlO4@Mvbv7ea/G2R1Dd6wKq6/).

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript, 25 bytes

```
x=>x.map(c=>c&&x&&!(x=0))
```

- x holds the original array.
- Once the first truthy has been found, x is overwritten with a false value.
- This makes c && x return false for all values except the first truthy.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 230 bytes

```
([]){{}({}[()]<>)<>([])}{}<>([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>({<({}<>)<>>()}<(())>){({}[()]<<>({}<>)>)}{}(([])<{{}(({})())({<{}>{}((<()>))}<{}{}>)({}<>)<>([])}<>>){({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>{}{}([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>
```

<s>I will explain soon but my mom cooked me some fried potatoes</s>

```
([]){{}({}[()]<>)<>([])}{}<>([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<> Subtracts one from every item

({<({}<>)<>>()}<(())>){({}[()]<<>({}<>)>)}{} Loops down stack until current item is zero and adds one

(([])<{{} (({})())({<{}>{}((<()>))}<{}{}>) ({}<>)<>([])}<>>){({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<> On every item of stack if it is 0 do nothing and if it is -1 add one

([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<> Flip stack

{}{} Remove the two zeros at top of stack

([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<> Flip stack back
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#fY5LCoAwDESvkuXMru5DLlJ6kpCz1wTRqqAESpjPSyf6oHvAo4NDjWolhcexHN5Ldz01A0MB0ugnowLlWqVRLU2KIFVmMtseVo4iM9n3zBnlcSfRi3hd@/9Xcb68OZs02WS9t9kB)

### Special thanks

Special thanks to Wheat Wizard and Riley for helping me a ton with code!

Answer (score 2):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 12 bytes

**10 bytes code + 2 for `-pl`.**

```perl
$_&&=!$-++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXk3NVlFFV1v7/38DLkMoNIBDEPtffkFJZn5e8X/dghwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ŒQa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opMDE/4fbvTUj//@PjjbQMdSBYCAZqxMNRAZgjgGYBZEEQYPYWAA)

`ŒQ` was added to the language about two months after the previous Jelly solution.

```
ŒQ     Nub sieve: for each element, is it the first occurrence of that value?
  a    Take the logical AND of that and the original list.
```

[user62131's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119511/85334) can also be 3 bytes with a newer builtin:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
Ä=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wi23i/8Pt3pqR//9HRxvoGOpAMJCM1YkGIgMwxwDMgkiCoEFsLAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 63 bytes

```lisp
(d F(q((L B)(i L(c(i B(h L)0)(F(t L)(i(h L)0 B)))(
(q((L)(F L 1
```

The solution is the anonymous function in the second line; the first line is a helper function. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYw7DsMwDEP3nILj0@ZcIUOy@BJuM1SA23yXnN4VEkAk@CBRp/@u6sfaGrNGNsgaDFfmHT7wUbZkjJwR8IfjxIwuKtNdib2y@kZdyqzqr73sl3V8y6pJbIKkXo/CTcSkG1K8svYH)

#### Ungolfed/explanation

```lisp
(load library)                 ; Library contains ungolfed aliases for builtins

(def F                         ; Define F
  (lambda (L B)                ; as a function that takes a list L and an int B (where B
                               ; is a flag indicating if we're in the beginning section):
    (if L                      ;  If L is nonempty:
      (cons                    ;   Prepend
        (if B (head L) 0)      ;   head of L if B is truthy, else 0
        (F                     ;   to a recursive call
          (tail L)             ;   with tail of L as the new list
          (if (head L) 0 B)))  ;   and 0 as the new flag if head of L is truthy, else B
      nil)))                   ;  Else, return empty list

(lambda (L)                    ; Anonymous function that takes a list
  (F L B))                     ; and passes it to F with a second argument of 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 14 bytes

```
W;@.1I?>O;w..W
```

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=VztALjFJPz5PO3cuLlc=&input=MCAxIDEgMCAwIDAgMSAxIDAgLTE=&speed=10)

Cubix doesn't have proper lists or booleans, so we take the input as a sequence of space-separated 1s and 0s terminated with a -1.

Unfolded

```
    W ;
    @ .
1 I ? > O ; w .
. W . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

#### Explanation

The instruction pointer starts at the top of the left face of the cube, moving to the right.

Initially, we push a 1 onto the stack.  We then take one input at a time, with `I` and branch with `?`.

If the input is 0, we see `O;`, which outputs 0 and pops it from the stack.
If the input is 1, we see `;O;`, which pops the 1 from the stack, outputs the top of the stack (which will be 1 the first time around), then pops it from the stack.
If the input is -1, we see `@`, which ends the program.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 32 bytes

```rb
->a{i=1;a.map{|x|x&&[i,i=p][0]}}
```

Uses `1` for truthy and `nil` for falsy.

#### Explanation

```rb
->a{           # take an array a
    i=1;       # use i to keep track of if we've gotten a truthy value yet
    a.map{|x|  # for each element x in a:

        x&&[     # if x is truthy:
              i,     # remember the old i,
              i=p    # then set i to false
           ][0]      # and replace x with the old i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## vim, 19 keystrokes

```
2/1<ENTER>i<ENTER><ESC>:s/1/0/g<ENTER>kJx
```

`2/1<ENTER>i<ENTER><ESC>` puts everything after the first 1 to the second line and moves the cursor to that line.  `:s/1/0/g<ENTER>` replaces the 1s with 0s.  `kJx` then merges the lines.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 19 bytes

```
{@_ «&&»[\^^] @_}
```

This is an anonymous function that takes its arguments in `@_`.  `^^` is the exclusive-or operator, and `[\^^]` does a scan using that operator, returning a copy of the input list where the first truthy value is replicated until the second truthy value, whereupon it and all remaining values become `Nil` (which is falsy).  To falsify the replicated copies of the first truthy value, if any, the list is combined with the original using `&&`, the boolean and operator.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 44 bytes

```
s=>{var b=1>2;s.map{x=>if(b)!b else{b=x;x}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 29 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{$_-and!$b;$b=$b-or$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@SWJReXKNarRKvm5iXoqiSZK2SZKuSpJtfpBJf@///f5W0xJzi1P8qJUWlaCSSBAA)

Answer (score 1):

#### OCaml, <s>85</s> 60 bytes

```
let rec f?(b=true)=function h::t->(h&&b)::(f~b:(h<b)t)|_->[]
```

**Ungolfed**

```
let rec f ?(b=true) = function
    | head :: tail -> (head && b) :: (f ~b:(head<b) tail)
    | _            -> []
```

**Explanation**

`f` is defined as a recursive function taking an optional (`?`) boolean `b` and an unnamed list (`function`) and return according to the cases:

- if the first element of the list is `false`, returns it unchanged,
- if the first element if the list is `true`, sets it to `b` and flip `b` to `false` (*id est*, only let unchanged the first `true` since `b` is `true` by default and then set to `false`),
- if the list is empty (end of recursive call), returns the empty list.

**Usage**

[Try it online](https://try.ocamlpro.com/) (you'll need to copy/paste the function definition) !

```
# f [];;
- : bool list = []
# f [false];;
- : bool list = [false]
# f [true];;
- : bool list = [true]
# f [false;true;true;false;true;true;false;true;false;false];;
- : bool list =
[false; true; false; false; false; false; false; false; false; false]
```

**History**

25 (*yes, twenty-five*) bytes golfed off by [Ørjan Johansen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66041/%C3%98rjan-johansen), suggesting to merge the first two cases (see explanation).

Comment: You can merge the first two cases: `let rec f?(b=true)=function c::t->(c&&b)::(f~b:(c<b)t)|_->[]`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks, that's 25 bytes golfed!

Answer (score 1):

## F#, <s>79</s> <s>76</s> 72 bytes

```fs
let rec f o=function|[],_->o|x::y,1->f(o@[0])(y,1)|x::y,_->f(o@[x])(y,x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fs-mono#@5@TWqJQlJqskKaQb5tWmpdckpmfVxMdqxOva5dfU2FlVVGsY6hrl6aR7xBtEKupAeJqQsXjoeIVEPEKzf9pCtGxChrRBtYgaAjBsToKBppcNXYKBUWZeSVpeQpKqo5K/wE)

### Usage

```fs
let input = [0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;1]
printfn "%A" f [] (input, 0)
```

### Explanation

This is a very straightforward implementation.

*f* is a function with two arguments, first being the result list and the second a tuple of input and a value indicating if a truthy value has been found.

*Note: only 1 is considered truthy, every other number is falsy. Which sounds weird now that I think about it. This however, can easily be changed so that any value <> 0 is truthy. But I think it should be ok the way it is, as expected input is only 0 or 1*

```fs
// int list -> int list * int -> int list
let rec f output = function
| [], _ -> output                      // return result
| x::xs, 1 -> f (output@[0]) (xs,1)    // if truthy was encountered before, append 0 to result, process rest of input
| x::xs, _ -> f (output@[x]) (xs,x)    // if not, append 0 or 1 to result, process rest of input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 34 bytes

```php
foreach($_GET as$g)echo$f?0:$f=$g;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUol3dw2xTSwqSqzUMNABQUMQ1rT@n5ZflJqYnKEBVqGQWKySrpmanJGvkmZvYKWSZquSbv3/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 10

```
{_1#\,,f=}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/Ot5QOUZHJ8229n9dwf9oAwVDBQgGkrEA)

**Explanation:**

This is a function that takes an array of 0 and 1 from the stack, and pushes the resulting array on the stack.

```
_      duplicate the array
1#     find the index of the first 1 (it is -1 if not found)
\      swap with the other copy of the array
,      get the array length, let's call it n
,      make an array [0 1 … n-1]
f=     compare each element with the index we got earlier
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
ε¾›D½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3NZD@x417HI5tPf//2gDHUMdCAaSsQA)

explanation:

```
ε for each value in the (implicit) input
¾ push the counter variable
› check if it's bigger than the current value (0 0 - 0, 0 1 - 1, 1 0 - 0, 1 1 - 0)
D duplicate
½ increment the counter variable if it's true (which means that if the current value is 1 and the counter is 0, increment it)
```

Comment: Nice approach. I just had this 5-bytes alternative, which I added as a comment under the existing 05AB1E answer: [`ηOøPΘ`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Hb/wzsCzs34/z/aQEcBiAzBCMqOBQA). :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Isn't that trivially the same as `ηO*Θ` for 4 bytes? My 5-byter was `RƶRZQ` (or [`ƶWQ`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//2LbwwP//o5WUdBRA2BCFAjNjAQ) by bending the I/O rules a bit), interesting how different our three approaches are.

Comment: @Grimmy Ah, I'm an idiot. You're indeed completely right that `ηO*Θ` works for 4 bytes. And another nice alternative! EDIT: And I like that 3-byter, since only `1` is truthy in 05AB1E. xD I actually had something similar with `ƶWQ` in mind at first, but it obviously failed since `0` is lower. Hadn't thought about using a different falsey value, which technically is valid in 05AB1E, although indeed kinda bending the I/O rules. xD

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2], <s>83</s> 68 bytes

I try classic approach.

```
def t(l,b=1>0):
 r=[]
 for x in l:r+=[x and b];b=(1-x)*b>0
 return r
```

I use `and` boolean operator between each value of list and a value that is true until first truely value in list and false after.

es.

```
list val. --> F F T F T F F
b         --> T T T F F F F
and op.   --> F F T F F F F
```

Tanks @AdHocGarfHunter

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Three improvements I see right away are 1) You can put `r=[]` in the function arguments just like `b=True` 2) `False` is shorter as `1<0` and `True` as `1>0` 3) Your whole `if` `then` bit is just `not x and b` which can be rewritten as `(1-x)*b>0`.

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter Tanks. There is a problem to side effect of function parameter, if you call more time `t` function, `r` accumulate values and `b` assume False value.

Comment: @n1k9 you're right, I think the consensus here is that a function must be reusable. So `r=[]` must goes in the body. `b` is immutable, so it can stay in the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, 22 bytes

Input is STDIN.

```ruby
a|=p
p !a&&a|=eval($_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P7HGtoCrQEExUU0NyEwtS8zRUInX/P8/LTGnOJWrpKg0lQuDiUyChP/lF5Rk5ucV/9fNywEA)

#### Explanation

```ruby
                  # For each line of STDIN:
a|=p              # Set a to falsy if it wasn't defined before
                  #  (needed or else the next line crashes)
p !a&&a|=eval($_) # Output false if a is truthy, otherwise OR it with the value in STDIN
                  #  and output that instead
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 13 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{@[x;1_&x;~]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v9ohusLaMF6twrouttZAwRAIYaTB//8A)

**Explanation:**

```
{@[x;1_&x;~]} / the solution
{           } / lambda taking implicit argument x
 @[x;    ; ]  / apply func to target at indices @[target;indices;func] 
          ~   / not, the function being applied
       &x     / indices where x is true
     1_       / drop the first occurrence
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>52</s> <s>46</s> <s>44</s> 38 bytes

Input is a list of bools, requires Python 3.8 (for the walrus operator `:=`).

```python3
lambda x,b=0:[a>b and(b:=a)for a in x]
```

To be called as `(lambda x,b=0:[a>b and(b:=a)for a in x])(bools_list)`

Previous attempts:

Input is a list of `1`s and `0`s

```python3
lambda x,b=0:[(b:=1)if a>b else 0for a in x]
```

```python3
def f(x):a=[0]*len(x);a[x.index(1)]=1;return a
```

The above doesn't work with an all-falsey list, `list.index` throws `ValueError` if the value isn't present.
Edit: and neither do most (all?) other Python 3 entries, for the same reason.

Input `x` is an iterable of bools, returns iterable of bools.

```python3
map(lambda a,b=[0]:not(b[-1]or b.append(a)or 1-a),x)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$6\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 4.939 bytes

```
=1*eSk
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyI9MSplU2siLCJbMCwxLDAsMSwwLDAsMV0iXQ==)

cumsum builtin when

Comment: cumsums == `Y@S`

Comment: @Seggan that's no shorter than `eSk`

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 61 Bytes

```php
$n=[];foreach($_GET as$v)$n[]=$n&&max($n)?0:$v;print_r($n);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUol3dw2xjTbUMdAxjLX@r5JnGx1rnZZflJqYnKEBllRILFYp01TJi461VclTU8tNrNBQydO0N7BSKbMuKMrMK4kvAglY//8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
®?!T°:Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@39onb1iyKENVlH//0cb6BjoGIJwLAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 18 bytes

```
1(0*)1/1$10/#input
```

Fairly simple solution, ReRegex takes all pairings of `1(0*)1`, which is two 1s with any amount of 0s in between, and just leaves the first 1, replacing the second with a 0. As ReRegex keeps running the regex until no more change happens, which satisfies the challenge.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/reregex#@2@oYaClaahvqGJooK@cmVdQWvL/v4GBIQwBAA)

Comment: This solution removes ones from the input, but I believe the challenge asks to turn them into zeros. This can be fixed by adding a final `0` to the substitution pattern

Answer (score 0):

### 77 Bytes, Javascript

```js
var s=0;[0,0,0,1,0,0].forEach(function(c,i,a){if(c||s)s=c=1;console.log(c)});
```

I/O are zeros and ones.

Answer (score 0):

## F#, 88 bytes

```
let c2 u=
 let n=ref(1<0)
 [for i in u do if !n||not i then yield 1<0 else n:=i;yield i]
```

Use as follows:

```
let mutated = c2 [true; true; false; false; true]
```

or

```
printfn "%A" (c2 [true; false; true; false; true])
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 31 bytes

```
BEGIN{ORS=RS=" "}$1{$1=t-->-1}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#@@/k6u7pV@0fFGwLREoKSrUqhtUqhrYlurp2uoa1hv//GyiAoCECAwA)

Assumes input is space-separated `1` and `0`. Most of the code is just splitting the records on  for input and output.  The variables could be assigned via command-line options, but it only saves a couple bytes and TIO doesn't count them. :(

BTW

```
BEGIN{ORS=RS=" "}$1&&t++{$1=0}1
```

also works, but I find it a bit harder to read and has the same byte-count, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 10 bytes

```
,.
`z.
a\A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#S04sUbBTKEktLtFLzsgsULCxUVB39XdT/6@jx5VQpceVGOP4H8jn4iooyswrSVNQ0UgG6lBJy8xJ1VSoUdDPLyjRB2kEE3oFlUhG1ShkpFaklOYWKOiWKeimKqgrxcTEVCgpGOobKiipGhhFKKn/j6kwMIBiQyg2QKYB)

#### How?

The elements `a\A` will copy the lowest bit of input (`A`) to the lowest bit of output (`a`) so long as the switch is inactive (`\`).

When `A` is powered, due to a truthy input, it activates the delay element (`z`) via a wire (`.`). This delay element will wait one cycle -- that is, until the next input byte -- at which point it will send the signal onward. This activates the switch, cutting off the input from the output, and via some more wires (`` ` `` `,` `.`) activates itself for the next cycle.

If you change the normally-closed switch `\` for a normally-open switch `/`, you'd get a circuit that filters out only the first truthy value.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 16 bytes

```
+T`1`0`(?<=1)0*1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@68dkmCYYJCgYW9ja6hpoGX4/7@BgSEIfs3L101OTM5IBQA) My first Retina submission ever.

Comment: `0*1` can be replaced with `.*`

Answer (score 0):

## C++, <s>77</s> 75 bytes

Yay pointers and `memset`!

```
void f(bool*a,int b){bool*c=&a[b];while(a<c)if(*a++)break;memset(a,0,c-a);}
```

Function takes in a pointer to a bool array, and the length of that array as parameters.  It loops through the array until it finds the first true, increments one more cell, and `memset`s the remainder of the memory from that pointer until the end.  0 length arrays work too since the loop is skipped entirely and the memset gets 0 bytes as the length, however passing in null instead of an empty array will break things.

**Ungolfed + tests**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>

//void f(bool*a,int b){bool*c=&a[b];while(a<c)if(*a++)break;memset(a,0,c-a);}

void f(bool* a, int b)
{
    bool* c = &a[b];
    while (a < c)
        if (*a++)
            break;
    memset(a, 0, c - a);
}

void print(bool* a, int b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        std::cout << a[i] << '\t';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    size_t s = sizeof(bool);
    assert(s == 1);
    bool* t1 = new bool[5] { false, false, false, false, false };
    bool* t2 = new bool[0];
    bool* t3 = new bool[6] { false, false, true, false, true, true };
    bool* t4 = new bool[10] { true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true };
    f(t1, 5);
    f(t2, 0);
    f(t3, 6);
    f(t4, 10);
    print(t1, 5);
    print(t2, 0);
    print(t3, 6);
    print(t4, 10);
    delete[] t1;
    delete[] t2;
    delete[] t3;
    delete[] t4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 19 bytes

```
&:1`#@_1*:.70g\-70p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#@69mZZig7BBvqGWlZ26QHqNrblDw/7@BgqGCgQKENFQwAgA)

Input: stream of numbers, `0` (false), `1` (true), or `2` (EOF).

Output: stream of numbers, `0`/`1`.

### Explanation

The program works by reading the next number in a loop, multiplying it by a constant, and printing the result to stdout. The operation described in the problem statement is performed by modifying that constant:

```
&:1`#@_1*:.70g\-70p
       ^          v
       [ P[7]-= x ]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 66 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Dupe_0][S N
S _Dupe_0][S N
S _Dupe_0][T    N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_integer][T    S S T   _Subtract][N
T   T   S N
_If_negative_Jump_to_Label_FIRST_TRUTHY][S S S N
_Push_0][T  N
S T _Print_as_integer][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_FIRST_TRUTHY][S S S T N
_Push_1][S N
S _Dupe_1][T    N
S T _Print_as_integer][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgYsLiBXABBBxcnGCgQKYBRJT4OIECQPVgTkKCmCOAkzw/38DLkMgNOAyAJNgFgA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

The input is newline separated, and the output is all joined together. If this is not allowed, it's [80 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYrRCQAxCEO/zRSOYEcqpXD3V7iDjm811kh4CdnP@89v9THdVRVIC9ULhKdFqAVyxSC44wDJHEpmC3dDCxmMTjo) (both newline separated) or [82 bytes](https://tio.run/##LUtBCsAwDDrrK3xC8qQxCtut0MGen6ZpUURF/@f92ujX3SIkkUsSmyAEILsSZSyXPcC95/pUAM8VPD7C3M08YRM) (both joined together) instead.
Uses `1` for truthy and `0` for falsey.

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer flag = 0
Start LOOP:
  Integer input = STDIN as integer
  If(flag - input < 0):
     Jump to Label FIRST_TRUTHY
  Print 0 as integer to STDOUT
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

FIRST_TRUTHY:
  flag = 1
  Print 1 as integer to STDOUT
  Go to next iteration of LOOP
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 31 bytes

```kotlin
{List(size){it==indexOf(true)}}

{                             }  // lambda; input is `this`
 List(    )                      // build new list
      size                       // same size as input
           {                 }   // based on lambda
            it==                 // index of this element equal to
                indexOf(true)    // index of first true in input
```

To actually solve this challenge you only need to know two things about the input:

- its length
- where the first true is.

The shotgun approach of just generating a new list worked out best here.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxBCgIxDEX3c4osG1APIHYWrgXPULCBYExl2hGx9Oy1nVmNZpF8Hnn/HpKw1pcToCNcOKbTOQTxTseDQdiPWwa25g5M5I/HzMla1pt/X8mkafZYSqVZ4eFYm50HaNO7pTlgl9NeyUn0u3V37T/@AlyanhNrEjW9BmGDaIU4lPoF)

Answer (score 0):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 38 bytes

```
method(x,x map(i,v,i==x indexOf(1<2)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z/n5ZZVFyiYGWrEPM/N7UkIz9Fo0KnQiE3sUAjU6dMJ9PWtkIhMy8ltcI/TcPQxkhTUxOiQyMnE0ikJeYUp@qUFJWm6mAwEQKamgoFRZl5JTl5/wE)

### Explanation

```
method(x, // Take an operand x
    x map(i,v, // Map every item with index/value
        i==    // Is the index equal to
        x indexOf(1<2) // the index of true in x?
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Processing.js](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/truthy/5359761900584960)  (Khanacademy version), 67 bytes

```
var a=[];for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){if(i!==0){a[i]=0;}}print(a);
```

A is the input (khanacademy version of processing has no real input method)

The output is printed to console. Truth = 1, false = 0;

[Try it online!](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/truthy/5359761900584960)

Answer (score 0):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 8 bytes

```
0,/./!c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/30BHX09fMZnr/38uLkMoAkMA)

Note the trailing linefeed.

Inputs are linefeed separated. Any single character is truthy (I used `1`) and an empty line is falsey.

Input should not have a trailing linefeed, as that will be interpreted as an extra falsey value. Note that TIO adds a final linefeed, and thus a falsey value, at the end. This is a limitation of TIO, the program works just fine without.

Commented:

```
0,/./ #Run the following commands from the first line to the first line containing a character
#If we are *not* in the previous range, replace the line with an empty line
!c
```

To make it easier to read the output, you can make `0` falsey and replace the program with

```
0,/1/!c0
```

at the cost of one byte. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/30BH31BfMdmAC8jkMuAyhGIQCYEGAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
¦=*
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiwqY9KiIsIiIsIlswLDEsMCwxLDAsMCwxXVxuWzAsMCwwLDBdIl0=)

#### Explained

```
¦=*
¦   # cumulative sum
 =  # equal
  * # multiply bits
```

Comment: `ÞU*` would also work

Answer (score 0):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 3 bytes

```
×⟜∊
```

Anonymous tacit function; takes and returns a list of 0's and 1's. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgw5fin5ziiIoKCkYgMOKAvzHigL8w4oC/MOKAvzHigL8w4oC/MQ==)

#### Explanation

```
  ∊  Mark firsts: a list the same length as the argument, containing 1 at the first
     occurrence of each element of the argument and 0 for subsequent occurrences
×⟜  Multiply by the argument, itemwise
```

Comment: Nice. An alternative would be `⊢×∊` right? And makes me wonder why there's no APL answer here: `⊢×≠`. Hopefully, we'll be able to write your solution as `≠⍛×` soon.

Comment: Yes; `∊⊸×` also works, and `×` can be replaced with `∧` or `⌊` in any of them.

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 129 bytes

```go
func f(i[]int)(o[]int){k:=0
for _,e:=range i{if e>0&&k<1{k=1
o=append(o,1)}else if k>0{o=append(o,0)}else{o=append(o,e)}}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY9NagMhFID3nkKyCAq2OLsy1Jwh-xCCJJo-zKgYZ_VwkXNkMwR6iB4lt6kdhxLeH7zf790f5zD9RH10-mzooMETGGJI-X1lh7z6HrN9-3je7OiP1DLY7cFnzkKL6HoliQ2JHoTpVdK-7gAES81Grtfus0OnOhKUjtH4Ewui48VcrrXJUreR-FKRrfKaMrwUkkweky8LyNcM8ofJOBLwcczXXu32Mw-iFJ1oVn0RWFWKRequRgr_pPM4RbJNdfriGYj6IuekkOXeNLX4Cw)

Answer (score 0):

## x86-64 machine code, 9 bytes

```
56 59 31 C0 F3 AE F3 AA C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJNb9swDD2bv4Lz0FVulCLeug/ESy8977LTgCQHVZZjAY5sWPLmwPBfn0vJXYL0NAimRD7yPZGybJrlQcppEvaIDH/GDIp11HS2xNbqDJu6wVb2EPV1i0r03BuIWtUotFLY53BG6@r56CCJMclA9U61BuOnGIfftc6xYLIULd5VHLVxaJJsBHivjay6XOF363Jd35ePANYJpyUxtp106JR1JKNwCFUZBhax/ban@n@g3e5xgwMMX/mw4imfP7LjyIEiQ9gfPBhWcD@f3beB9DqQXgfS64yUv65L4FX@IprOd4ExA9/FUWjDEhggKmioTHSuxg8O1@dmbQIRoTPsKzS1t8poe7dBd09T0IsF5URR0xJcsPhGY8wJElu9p@lfgOVjHPyCEegzzOz@NzPe6DfMnfNvwG535tYHRojgnL0zP4QstVEo61ytg7aX6b0MxxO5eY3DhXz18RfRnzaMdcbqg1F5eOG7pEi2/WJBkiP@KXWlkJ38HVf90ydPemZg1PrziSaX7Awx9QSO0/RXFpU42Gl5/PJAhn7uDeWr6gU)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes in RDI the address of an array of 8-bit integers and its length in RSI, and modifies it in place, taking 0 as a falsy value and any nonzero value as a truthy value.

In assembly:

```
f:  push rsi; pop rcx   # Put the length into RCX.
    xor eax, eax        # Set EAX to 0. In particular, its low byte AL is 0.
    repe scasb  # Read bytes from the array and compare them with AL,
                #  advancing the pointer and counting down from the length in RCX,
                #  stopping when the comparison result is not equal or RCX is 0.
    rep stosb   # Repeatedly write AL into the array, advancing the pointer,
                #  and counting down RCX, stopping when RCX is 0.
                # This writes 0 into all the remaining places.
    ret         # Return.
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 7 bytes

```
Ans and 1=cumSum(Ans
```

Takes input as Ans (last input value)

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ṡ=&
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWSx_uXGirtqQ4KbkYKrJgfbSBjqEOBAPJWIgwAA)

##### Explanation

```python
ṡ=&  # Implicit input      ->  [0,1,0,1,0,0,1]
ṡ    # Cumulative sums     ->  [0,1,1,2,2,2,3]
 =   # Check for equality  ->  [1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
  &  # Logical AND         ->  [0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score -1):

### PowerShell, 25 bytes

```
$args|%{$_-and!$f;$f+=$_}
```

Previous "non legal" version

```
{$_*!$f;if($_){$f=1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#U0myrf6vkliUXlyjWq2oqJKmm1OiEm@tkqZtqxJf@7@WS0MlLTGnOFVHpaSoFEhi4yCJaepwOWgACQ00OWRKE2iTerS6tkqSXmZeWX52qoZKvKa2eqx67X8A)

The one more version with the same length of 25 bytes

```
$args|%{!!$f-lt$_;$f+=$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#U0myrf6vkliUXlyjWq2oqJKmm1OiEm@tkqZtqxJf@7@WS0MlLTGnOFVHpaSoFEhi4yCJaepwOWgACQ00OWRKE2iTerS6tkqSXmZeWX52qoZKvKa2eqx67X8A)

Comment: Is this a legal answer? I am honestly not sure. You cannot run this on its own as a function or program. It is a process scriptblock for the `foreach-object` cmdlet. I would have expected you to use `$args`

Comment: @Matt I would say no, it's not legal.

Comment: @briantist Well that is good then. I don't feel the need to go back to my old answers now.

Comment: @Matt [here's the relevant clarification for PowerShell specifically](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11938/30402).