# Clearing the most significant bit from an integer

Tags: code-golf, sequence, binary

#### Input

The input is a single positive integer `n`

#### Output

The output is`n` with its most significant bit set to `0`.

#### Test Cases

```
1 -> 0
2 -> 0
10 -> 2
16 -> 0
100 -> 36
267 -> 11
350 -> 94
500 -> 244
```

For example: `350` in binary is `101011110`. Setting its most significant bit (i.e. the leftmost `1` bit) to `0` turns it into `001011110` which is equivalent to the decimal integer `94`, the output. This is [OEIS A053645](https://oeis.org/A053645).

Comment: Clearing the most significant bit from `10` obviously gives `0` :D

Comment: @clabacchio I.. it... er...   wha?     (nice one)

Comment: It seems to me that the zeroes are just as significant as the ones. When you say "the most significant bit" you mean "the most significant bit that is set to one".

Answer (score 12):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>49</s> <s>44</s> <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```c
i;f(n){for(i=1;n/i;i*=2);return n^i/2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7LCsIwEEX3/YpQEBKxNJm2KRLql4gg1cgsHCXUVem3xz7A2mSW9x7OnTZ7tK33aCwn0duX49goQzka3DcgjLt3H0eMLpiDGfzzisRF0idsvLdD6ixPFctOTLLd7UzpwXIlhNn0sO0h7JWcAFgFMiJ0MKFjxywp9J8l0oCuJ0ip9Rddh1BRzaZj@YPGJISqZQ7KlaqWvcF/AQ)

Comment: You can replace `i<=n` with `n/i` for -1 byte. This isn't my golf, someone else tried to edit it into your post but I rolled it back because edits for golfing posts are not accepted according to our community rules.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I saw and approved the edit just now.  Wasn't aware of that rule but it's a nice golfing tip!

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah typically people are supposed to post comments for golfing tips and OP should make the edits, but if you accepted it, it's not really as much of a problem. :)

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda n:n^2**len(bin(n))/8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIc8qL85ISysnNU8jKTNPI09TU9/if0FRZl6JQpqGoYGB5n8A)

## 26 bytes

Unfortunately, this does not work for `1`:

```python
lambda n:int(bin(n)[3:],2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIc8qM69EIykzTyNPM9rYKlbHSPN/QRFQTCFNw9DAQPM/AA)

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
.²óo-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f79Cmw5vzdf//NzUwAAA)

Removing the most significant bit from an integer **N** is equivalent to finding the distance from **N** to the highest integer power of **2** lower than **N**.

Thus, I used the formula **N - 2<sup>floor(log<sub>2</sub>N)</sup>**:

- `.²` - Logarithm with base **2**.
- `ó` - Floor to an integer.
- `o` - **2** raised to the power of the result above.
- `-` - Difference.

Comment: [`b¦C`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/6dAy5///TQ0MAA "05AB1E – Try It Online") also works... doesn't it? Convert to binary, MSB is always at index 1, remove MSB, convert back.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn No that is wrong, fails for `1`!

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn [`b¦C`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6dAy5///DQE) works for `1` in the new 05AB1E version. Although I like your `.²óo-` more tbh. :)

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
BḊḄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/p4Y6uhzta/v//b2xqAAA)

## Explanation

```
BḊḄ  Main Link
B    Convert to binary
 Ḋ   Dequeue; remove the first element
  Ḅ  Convert from binary
```

Comment: Aren't `Ḅ` and `Ḋ` two-byte codepoints? This would change the overall size to 5 bytes.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Jelly uses its own [codepage](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), where those chars are only 1 byte.

Comment: Thanks for asking and answering this, that has bugged me for a long time!

Answer (score 9):

## C (gcc) -- 59 bytes

```
main(i){scanf("%d",&i);return i&~(1<<31-__builtin_clz(i));}
```

This gcc answer uses only integer bitwise and arithmetic operations.
No logarithms here! It may have issues with an input of 0, and is totally non-portable.

It's my first answer on this site, so I'd love feedback and improvements. I sure had fun with learning bitwise expressions.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and great first answer! We hope you'll enjoy participating in many more challenges :-)

Comment: You don't need a full program with `main`, [a function is a valid submission](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet). Changing this into a function and [taking input as an argument](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) to said function [saves 18 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1Ozuii1pLQoTyFTrU7D0MbG2FA3Pj6pNDOnJDMvPjmnCqhC07r2f2ZeiUJuYmaehiZXNZcCEBQUAYXSNJRUU5R0FNI0DA0MgOq4av8DAA).

Comment: You could even write it as a macro to [save two more bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIU0jUzNTrU7D0MbG2FA3Pj6pNDOnJDMvPjmnCiij@T8zr0QhNzEzT0OTq5pLAQgKioBCaRpKqilKOkDdhgYGmprWXLX/AQ).

Answer (score 8):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 23 bytes

```java
n->n^n.highestOneBit(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU7BSsNQELznK4ZCIJHk0VZawWpAD4IH8VBvovBMXtKNyb6Qt6mUkm@Pr7Uehhlmd2en1nud2s5wXXxP1Ha2F9TeU4NQo8qBcyHL6moTdMNXQznyRjuHF02MYwBcXCdaPO0tFWj9LNpKT1y9f0D3lYvPq8CbfWZ5umTeeW0q02co7ydOM/5ktaNqZ5y8snkkiTieNue70vYRsYBuweYHXvrgIxYJlgkWc4/1ib1Yrm8SXK@8Ws3nGP8fA9uDE9MqO4jqfDMpo1lYIM0QFiHPElCCUumuaw4PzheLKI7/fo/BCeP0Cw)

Sorry, built-in :-/

Comment: Java with a build-in that some other popular languages like .NET and Python has not?! o.Ô +1 to that. Was about to post something longer without build-ins.. Yours is 15 bytes shorter. XD

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Something like `n->n^1<<(int)Math.log2(n)` will work and is likely shorter than 38 bytes. It was my second (yet untested) idea, if the `highestOneBit` one didn't work appropriately. Out of curiosity, what was your solution

Comment: Mine was `n->n^1<<(int)(Math.log(n)/Math.log(2))` because `Math.log2` doesn't exist in Java. ;P Only `Math.log`, `Math.log10` and `Math.loglp` are available.

Comment: I was going to post the same, only minus instead of xor. Remembered the method from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119472/be-the-first-1-leave-only-the-first-truthy/119554#119554)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Oops, `Math.log2` doesn't exist indeed... My bad. See? One nice method (`highestOneBit`) exists but not another one (`Math.log2`). Java is weird ;-)

Answer (score 7):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Codepage)

```
ḋtḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GO7hIg/v//v7GpAQA)

**Explanation:**

```
    -- implicit input, e.g. 350
  ḋ -- convert number to list of binary digits (TNum -> [TNum]): [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]
 t  -- remove first element: [0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]
ḋ   -- convert list of binary digits to number ([TNum] -> TNum): 94
```

Comment: Similarly to the Jelly solution, this seems like it's actually 5 bytes, not 3.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Similarly to Jelly, Husk uses its own codepage, so this _is_ actually 3 bytes :P

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz See here for the codepage: https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Codepage

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
B0T(XB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38kgRCPC6f9/QwA)

Saved two bytes thanks to Cinaski. Switching to assignment indexing instead of reference indexing was 2 bytes shorter :)

#### Explanation:

```
          % Grab input implicitly: 267
B         % Convert to binary: [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]
 0T(      % Set the first value to 0: [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]
    XB    % Convert to decimal: 11
```

Comment: You could have used reference indexing (also for 6 bytes), if you used `4L` rather than `[2J]`. Another fun 6 bytes: `tZlcW-` (only works in MATLAB, not in TIO/Octave)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 30 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to caird coinheringaahing. <sup>I typed that from memory. :o</sup>*

```python
lambda n:int('0'+bin(n)[3:],2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIc8qM69EQ91AXTspM08jTzPa2CpWx0jzf0ERSDxNw9DAQFPzPwA)

Comment: Why not [`lambda n:int(bin(n)[3:],2)`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIc8qM69EIykzTyNPM9rYKlbHSPN/QRFILE3D0MBAU/M/AA)?

Comment: Well, a) that would error on **1**, b) I'm dumb enough to not think of that. But I did fix it with a minor change. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the code so that it works, (and saves 4 bytes)

Comment: That still errors on **1**.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing That was my [original answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148056/60919), but then I realised it errored on 1. The workaround ends up longer than a simple XOR method

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda n:n-2**len(bin(n))/8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIc8qT9dISysnNU8jKTNPI09TU9/if0FRZl6JQpqGoYGB5n8A)

## Explanation

```python
lambda n:n-2**len(bin(n))/8  # Lambda Function: takes `n` as an argument
lambda n:                    # Declaration of Lambda Function
              len(bin(n))    # Number of bits + 2
           2**               # 2 ** this ^
                         /8  # Divide by 8 because of the extra characters in the binary representation
         n-                  # Subtract this from the original
```

Comment: ...Just when I was working the bitwise math out. :P

Comment: @totallyhuman heh sorry but beat you to it :P

Comment: `2**len(bin(n))/8` can also be spelled `1<<len(bin(n))-3`, and then it will work in both 2 and 3 (no bytes saved/added).

Comment: @Mego Cool, thanks for the addition!

Answer (score 5):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 3 bytes

```
b(ó
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/P0nj8Ob//w0NDAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
function(x)x-2^(log2(x)%/%1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQrNC1yhOIyc/3QjIVtVXNdT8n6ZhqMkFJAwgJJgyMjPX/A8A)

Easiest to calculate the most significant bit via `2 ^ floor(log2(x))` rather than carry out base conversions, which are quite verbose in R

Answer (score 5):

### 32-bit x86 assembler, <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 7 bytes

Byte code:

```
0F BD C8 0F B3 C8 C3
```

Disassembly:

```
bsr ecx, eax
btr eax, ecx
ret
```

accepts and returns the value in the eax register.

Perform a reverse scan for the first set bit, and then reset that bit.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 37 bytes

```
Rest[#~IntegerDigits~2]~FromDigits~2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@z8otbgkWrnOM68kNT21yCUzPbOkuM4ots6tKD8XxlP7H1CUmVei75Cm71BtqGOkY2igY2gGJA10jMzMdYxNDXRMDQxq/wMA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>22</s> 20 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)*

```
a=>a^1<<Math.log2(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBDoIwEEDRq7hsk7GZ1oAb8AaewGCYQNESYZp2xOPXbv7u/ZUOylMKUc47z74sfaH@Rk/bdXeSt/nwyynSJSaefM4my8xfMb8UxKuHBQcWwba1CK69wqVBaBAHs1FU9bRUrM3KYR9Poy5/)

#### Another approach, 32 bytes

```javascript
a=>'0b'+a.toString`2`.slice`1`^0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBDsIgEADAr3grxHWzYFpP9RMejWaRUkOj0MCqz8de5jiL@7rqS1zlkPIU2jw2N547enR7h5IvUmJ6smWsr@gDG75TW0v2oVasMuWP4K9ECepqwIIhMMMmgR1OcOwJeqIbvt2qtnVWTmtccky8Y93@)

Comment: why would you do ``.slice`1`^0`` when `.slice(1)^0` would work just as well, haha

Comment: @ETHproductions. This one looks better :)

Answer (score 4):

## J, 6 bytes

```
}.&.#:
```

Pretty simple.

#### Explanation

```
}.&.#:
    #:  convert to list of binary digits
  &.    apply right function, then left, then the inverse of right
}.      behead
```

Comment: I was going to post this :(

Comment: @Cyoce Me too...

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 bytes

Tacit prefix function.

```apl
2⊥1↓2∘⊥⍣¯1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wSjR11LDR@1TTZ61DEDyHzUu/jQekOg1KEVCoYKRgqGBgqGZkDSQMHIzFzB2NRAwdTAAAA)

`2∘⊥`… decode from base-2…
 …`⍣¯1` negative one time (i.e. encode in base-2)

`1↓` drop the first bit

`2⊥` decode from base-2

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 26 bytes

-7 Bytes thanks to Ventero.
-2 Bytes thanks to historicrat.

```
->n{/./=~'%b'%n;$'.to_i 2}
```

Comment: You can save a few bytes by just skipping the first character and dropping redundant parentheses: `->n{n.to_s(2)[1..-1].to_i 2}`

Comment: `->n{/./=~'%b'%n;$'.to_i 2}`

Comment: @Ventero `-1` is not required: `->n{n.to_s(2)[1..].to_i 2}`

Answer (score 4):

## C (gcc), 38 bytes

Built-in in gcc used.

```c
f(c){return c^1<<31-__builtin_clz(c);}
```

Comment: Replacing `31-` with `~` should save two bytes.

Comment: @ThePirateBay it depends on hardware whether the shift is masked. On my computer, it will output 0.

Answer (score 4):

## ARM Assembly, <s>46</s> 43 bytes

(You can omit destination register on add when same as source)

```asm
clz x1,x0
add x1,1
lsl x0,x1
lsr x0,x1
ret
```

Comment: What flavour of ARM assembly syntax is this? My GNU assembler doesn't understand `shr`/`shl`/`ret` and wants instead something like `lsr`/`lsl`/`bx lr`.

Comment: Probably mixing syntax across multiple versions (ret is from aarch64), though I thought that the assembler would pseudo op these for you.  For purposes of here, though, using the older and direct lsl/lsr is probably correct.

Comment: Funny thing, i can do it in 1 less operation, but I the byte size goes up by 2.  Ah code golf.

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, <s>36</s> 31 bytes

`-5` bytes thanks to @IanM_Matrix1

```
=BIN2DEC(MID(DEC2BIN(A1),2,99))
```

Nothing interesting.

Comment: Reduce the size to 31 bytes by replacing REPLACE with a MID: =BIN2DEC(MID(DEC2BIN(A1),2,99))

Comment: Save a byte: `BASE(A1,2)` instead of `DEC2BIN(A1)`

Comment: @Calculuswhiz, I use Office 2010, which does not support `BASE`.

Answer (score 4):

**Excel, 20 bytes**

```
=A1-2^INT(LOG(A1,2))
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>21</s> 17 bytes

```
#-2^Floor@Log2@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@19Z1yjOLSc/v8jBJz/dyEFZ7X9AUWZeiUNatKmBQex/AA)

This is my first Mathematica answer, feel free to tell me what have I screwed up.

**-4 bytes** thanks to @HyperNeutrino!

So as it turns out, someone made a similar program before, and sent it to the OEIS. However, keep in mind that the floor of a logarithm is basically defined as the number of digits of a number. This is just a coincidence, or rather a task simple enough that many people will get the same answer.

Comment: The `()` is apparently unnecessary

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@19Z1yjOLSc/v8jBJz/dyEFZ7X9AUWZeiUNatKmBQex/AA)

Comment: 17 bytes: `#-2^⌊Log2@#⌋&`

Comment: @Jenny_mathy Someone came up with the same exact program? I didn't know this was a sequence in OEIS

Comment: Too bad we can't do `#~BitClear~-1&` which would be 14 bytes.  Seems like the natural extension of the syntax.  Maybe in version 12.

Comment: @KellyLowder Could you explain that syntax?

Comment: @NieDzejkob, Assuming you're OK with the infix notation, the idea would be that the -1 rolls around to the other side of the list of bits (the most significant side), like Part[x,-1] takes from the right of the list while Part[x,1] takes from the left.  Many other functions use this convention such as Take, Drop, Span.  Since BitClear only accepts integers this would cause no problems.

Comment: @KellyLowder no, I see how negative numbers should wrap around. I don't see how this makes Mathematica do `BitClear[#,-1]`

Comment: @NieDzejkob, well do you agree that `BitClear[#,BitLength@#-1]&` gives the correct answer?  I'm saying the syntax should allow the BitLength@# to be omitted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68715/discussion-between-niedzejkob-and-kelly-lowder).

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

```apl
⊢-2*∘⌊2⍟⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHXYt0jbQedcx41NNl9Kh3PpAPlDi0QsFQwUjB0EDB0AxIGigYmZkrGJsaKJgaGAAA)

-1 byte thanks to Adam

Comment: Completely correct, although I would have used [TIO](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR71bdY20HvV0GT3qnQ/k1ALFD61QMFQwUjA0UDA0A5IGCkZm5grGpgYKpgYGAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online") to generate a template for me. Anyway, [`⊢-2*∘⌊2⍟⊢`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHXYt0jbQedcx41NNl9Kh3PpAPlDi0QsFQwUjB0EDB0AxIGigYmZkrGJsaKJgaGAAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online") saves a byte.

Comment: I was sad that APL wasn't represented, and there is was, almost lost in the scroll!  I miss APL.

Comment: @cmm APL is alive and well. Feel free to hang out in [the Stack Exchange APL chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/apl).

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
a^2sl
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=a%5E2sl&input=1+%0A2+%0A10%0A16+%0A100%0A267%0A350+%0A500&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1+%0A2+%0A10%0A16+%0A100%0A267%0A350+%0A500&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
    l   Log base 2 of input.
   s    Cast ^ to integer (this is the position of the most significant bit.)
 ^2     Raise 2 to ^ (get the value of said bit)
a       Subtract ^ from input
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 8 bytes

```
./-l
o@i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/19PXzeHK98h8/9/UwMDAA)

#### Explanation

```
.   Duplicate an implicit zero at the bottom of the stack. Does nothing.
/   Switch to Ordinal mode, move SE.
i   Read all input as a string.
l   Convert to lower case (does nothing, because the input doesn't contain letters).
i   Try reading all input again, pushes an empty string.
/   Switch to Cardinal mode, move W.
.   Duplicate. Since we're in Cardinal mode, this tries to duplicate an integer.
    To get an integer, the empty string is discarded implicitly and the input is 
    converted to the integer value it represents. Therefore, at the end of this,
    we get two copies of the integer value that was input.
l   Clear lower bits. This sets all bits except the MSB to zero.
-   Subtract. By subtracting the MSB from the input, we set it to zero. We could
    also use XOR here.
/   Switch to Ordinal, move NW (and immediately reflect to SW).
o   Implicitly convert the result to a string and print it.
/   Switch to Ordinal, move S.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
^2p¢ÊÉ
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=XjJwosrJ&input=MzUw)

#### Explanation

```
^2p¢ÊÉ
   ¢     Get binary form of input
    Ê    Get length of that
     É   Subtract 1
 2p      Raise 2 to the power of that
^        XOR with the input
```

### If input `1` can fail: 4 bytes

```
¢Ån2
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=osVuMg==&input=MzUw)

**Explanation**: get input binary (`¢`), slice off first char (`Å`), parse as binary back to a number (`n2`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 20 bytes

```matlab
@(x)x-2^fix(log2(x))
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KzQtcoLi2zQiMnP90IyNX8n1hUlFiZVpqnkaajEG2oYKRgaKBgaAYkDRSMzMwVjE0NFEwNDGI1/wMA)

Answer (score 3):

## PARI/GP, 18 bytes

```
n->n-2^logint(n,2)
```

Alternate solution:

```
n->n-2^exponent(n)
```

Comment: The first one seems to give wrong answers. Should it be `n->n-2^logint(n,2)`? The second one is not supported in my version of PARI/GP, nor in the version used by [tio.run](https://tio.run/#pari-gp). Is that a new function?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Oops, fixed -- that's what I get for submitting from my phone. Yes, the second one is a new function.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I just checked, `exponent` was added 5 days ago, compared to this challenge which was added yesterday. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes

```
{2b()b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v9ooSUMzqfb/fwA)

Explanation:

```
{     }  Block:         267
 2b      Binary:        [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]
   (     Pop:           [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1] 1
    )    Increment:     [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1] 2
     b   Base convert:  11
```

Reuse the MSB (which is always 1) to avoid having to delete it; the equivalent without that trick would be `{2b1>2b}` or `{2b(;2b}`.

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
^(^1|\1\1)*1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qkaCnzaWi9T9OI86wJsYwxlBTy5Drv95/Qy4jLkMDLkMzIGnAZWRmzmVsasBlamAAAA)

Input and output [in unary](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary) (the test suite includes conversion from and to decimal for convenience).

#### Explanation

This is quite easy to do in unary. All we want to do is delete the largest power of 2 from the input. We can match a power of 2 with some forward references. It's actually easier to match values of the form **2<sup>n</sup>-1**, so we'll do that and match one **1** separately:

```
^(^1|\1\1)*1
```

The group `1` either matches a single `1` at the beginning to kick things off, or it matches twice what it did on the last iteration. So it matches `1`, then `2`, then `4` and so on. Since these get added up, we're always one short of a power of 2, which we fix with the `1` at the end.

Due the trailing linefeed, the match is simply removed from the input.

Answer (score 3):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>26</s> 18 bytes

Thank you, @DLosc, for saving 8 bytes!

```
≈q*2<=:|q=q*2]?a-q
```

### Explanation

```
≈     |  WHILE
 q*2       q doubled (this doesn't actually double q, but evaluates 2q) 
    <=     is less than or equal to
      :    the input number (cmd line param, variable 'a')
q=q*2      double q (2, 4, 8, ...)
]          WEND
?a-q       PRINT a - q (ie 100 - 64 = 36)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>32</s> 29 bytes

```hs
(!1)
x!y|2*y>x=x-y|z<-2*y=x!z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BDoIwFET3nGIgLkBoAhhwYzmBrlyKMQ0BMQI2tsYP4ezWwmIyb@b/ZFqhnnXXmYaXxneTwCF3nNPtWBAnNs7TgdnAyZ2MrpVW4LgkEdIISWyVL24hzfcRdpmlLI6vTi8eg/3shTzd4JcEVkB@9Fm/jwM2UO3rC0IYwlsu3kJr5zegIMC6ZH5V04m7MqyS8g8)

-3 bytes thanks to @Laikoni

### Older solution, 32 bytes

```hs
f x=last[x-2^i|i<-[0..x],2^i<=x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY4xD4IwFIR3f8WFOEBoScGAC7i4yuSIaJqIobG0hNbYwf9eC8PL@@7eJfdGbt6DlF5Ms14szlrZRcus1Yo//QuukdzYztHiLn6iph3LMteToOrG9d4Oxho06HKCgiBnYap1ByiqI8GhDFQy1u8mLlRITnxuH4hvDvSE@WOvdrko7GFG/YVDmiJaL9FKmxeHJ5IEW5P/Aw)

Comment: Anonymous functions are allowed, so you don't need the `f=` in the first variant. Additionally `z<-2*y=x!z` saves a byte: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BDoIwFET3nGIgLkBoAhhwYzmBrlyKMQ0BMQI2tsYP4ezWwmIyb@b/ZFqhnnXXmYaXxneTwCF3nNPtWBAnNs7TgdnAyZ2MrpVW4LgkEdIISWyVL24hzfcRdpmlLI6vTi8eg/3shTzd4JcEVkB@9Fm/jwM2UO3rC0IYwlsu3kJr5zegIMC6ZH5V04m7MqyS8g8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 24 bytes

```julia
n->n-2^length(bin(n))÷2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59m@z9P1y5P1yguJzUvvSRDIykzTyNPU/PwdqP/aflFChUKmXkK0YY6RjqGBjqGZkDSQMfIzFzH2NRAx9TAIJZLQaGgKDOvJCdPQ0mlQkFFI02jQlNTSZMrNS/lPwA)

`Int(floor(log2(n)))` is too long.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 31 bytes

```
->n{(0..n).find{|i|n-i&n+~i<1}}
```

Another bit-twiddling approach, might work better in a language where 0 is falsey. Finds the smallest number `i` such that `n-i` is a power of two, using the property of powers of two that they're the only numbers with no 1 bits in common with their predecessors.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>6</s> 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ì2_Å
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7DJfxQ&input=MQ) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7DJfxQ&input=WzEsMiwxMCwxNiwxMDAsMjY3LDM1MCw1MDBdLW0)

```
ì2_Å     :Implicit input of integer
ì2       :Convert to base 2 digit array
  _      :Pass through the following function and convert back to decimal
   Å     :  Slice off the first digit
```

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge, 22 bytes

```
&:1\v\*2\<
$%.@>2/:#^_
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=JjoxXHZcKjJcPAokJS5APjIvOiNeXw&input=NTAw)

**Explanation**

Befunge doesn't have bit manipulation instructions, but we can instead use the mod command (`%`) to mask out the bits that we want to keep. So basically we calculate *n* % 2<sup>*b*</sup>, where *b* is the number of bits in the number minus one.

```
&:              Read n from stdin and make a copy to work with.
  1\            Push the initial mask value below it on the stack.

    v           Start a loop to determine the number of bits to mask.
    >2/         Divide the copy of n by 2.
       :#^_     Check if it has become zero.
        \<      If not, turn back and swap the mask value to the top of the stack.
      *2        Multiply the mask value by 2.
     \          Swap the modified copy of n back to the top of the stack.
    ^           Repeat the loop.

$               Once the copy of n becomes zero, we can exit the loop and drop it.
 %              We can then mod the original n with the mask value to get the result.
  .@            Finally output the result and exit.
```

Answer (score 2):

### REXX, 52 bytes

```
b=x2b(d2x(arg(1)))
parse var b '1' b
say x2d(b2x(b))
```

Explanation:

1. Convert argument 1 into hex, then into binary representation.
2. Use *parse* to find first '1' in `b`, then store the rest of the string in `b` again.
3. Convert `b` into hex, then into decimal.

Comment: an explanation would be nice

Comment: Consider it done.

Answer (score 2):

## IA-32 machine code, 12 bytes

Hexdump:

```
91 0f bd c8 33 d2 42 d3 e2 33 c2 c3
```

Corresponding assembly code, with inline disassembly:

```
91          xchg eax, ecx;
0f bd c8    bsr ecx, eax;
33 d2       xor edx, edx;
42          inc edx;
d3 e2       shl edx, cl;
33 c2       xor eax, edx;
c3          ret;
```

Answer (score 2):

## Motorola 68020 Assembler, Unknown byte count, possibly 8

```
BFFFO D0{31:32}, D1 # Scan D0 from MSB to LSB, looking for the first set bit,
                    # from bit 31 for 32 bits
                    # Store this in D1
BCLR  D1, D0        # Clear the D1'th bit in D0
```

It's been a *long* time since I've done 680x0 assembler, and I can't find an online simulator. 
This takes a 32-bit input in D0, and returns it from there. It also trashes D1. Flags are also changed.
Bad things will happen if D0 is zero; but the rules exclude that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

[16F48A Microcontroller](https://github.com/dcgs-cc/OCR_Emulator), 155 bytes

```
IN Q,s0
MOVI s0,s1
MOVI s2,00
MOVI s3, 09

A: INC s2
SHR s1
JNZ A

B: DEC s3
DEC s1
JNZ B

C: MOVI s3,s4
SHL s0
DEC s3
JNZ C

D: DEC s4
SHR s0
JNZ D
OUT s0
```

explanation:
This particular microcontroller takes inputs in binary, starting at the top of the code and working its way down. It can only use 9 registers (s0 through s8, but cannot output s8) and each of those registers can store 8 bits - again, in binary.

The first section takes the input and sets some values for later use.

section A shifts the input right, effectively removing bytes at the end, until it reaches zero, all the while, s2 is keeping track of how many shifts have taken place.

Section B then takes the amount of right shifts from 9, to determine how many times to shift left until the front byte that is a 1 has been removed.

Section C actually shifts left, but saves the amount of shifts to be able to shift right again.

Finally, section D shifts it right, to move it to the original position, minus the first 1.

Comment: Often assembly submissions are rated in the size of their assembled machine code output (which usually results in a way better score ;-) )

Comment: @MatteoItalia that's something I'm going to look into then!

Answer (score 2):

## J, 8 Bytes

```
#.@}.@#:
```

#### How it works:

```
  @  @       | Verb conjunction. Makes sure it isn’t executed as a hook
      #:     | Converts Number to binary, with no leading 0s (except if arg is 0)
   }.        | Drop leading 1
#.           | Convert back to int
```

Works for 1 and 0 since #. will convert an empty array into 0

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
bḢB
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiYuG4okIiLCIiLCIxXG4yXG4xMFxuMTZcbjUwMCJd)

#### Explained

```
bḢB
b   # binary
 Ḣ  # remove first item
  B # binary back to base 10
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>66</s> 62 bytes

```powershell
($c=[Convert])::ToInt32(0+($c::ToString("$args",2)|% su* 1),2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0Ml2TbaOT@vLLWoJFbTyiok3zOvxNhIw0AbKAPiBpcUZealayipJBalFyvpGGnWqCoUl2opGGoC2f///zc2NQAA)

*Thanks to cogumel0 for -4 bytes.*

Does exactly what it says on the tin. Takes input `$args`, `convert`s it `toString`, replaces the leading `1` using System.`su`bstring, then `convert`s it back `toInt32`. Output is implicit.

Yay for lengthy .NET calls.

---

Using the mathematical method that others are using, we can get down to

#### PowerShell, <s>59</s> 56 bytes

```powershell
param($a)$a-($m=[math])::pow(2,$m::floor($m::log($a,2)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRUyVRV0Ml1zY6N7EkI1bTyqogv1zDSEcl18oqLSc/v0gDxMrJTwcq1THS1NT8//@/oQEA)

*Thanks to cogumel0 for -3 bytes.*

This takes input `$a`, takes the `log` in base `2`, then `floor`s that. The floor is needed because if we simply cast to an integer, PowerShell does Banker's Rounding which could lead to erroneous results. Then we take `2` to that `pow`er, and subtract that from `$a`. Output is implicit.

Comment: You can get down to 48 bytes actually: `$m=[math];$_-$m::pow(2,$m::floor($m::log($_,2)))`

Comment: @cogumel0 That's using `$_` for input, which I consider to be a snippet and not a function or program. The `$m=[math]` trick is pretty clever, though, thanks!

Comment: Both `filters` and `functions` allow access to `$_`. But `filters` only have a Process block making them ideal for these scenarios. If you consider a function to be acceptable than so would a filter, and therefore this code is valid ;)

Comment: You can also save a few more bytes on the first one too though: 61 bytes (even if you use `$args` instead of `$_`): `$c=[Convert];$c::ToInt32(0+($c::ToString($args,2)|% su* 1),2)`. It uses `string.Substring()` instead of `-replace`, which shortens it somewhat. It does however need the `0+` to account for cases where the string has a length of 1 before you remove the first character (less bytes than doing `[int]`)

Comment: But if using a filter, we'd need to have `filter` listed, which is going to be more bytes yet. Thanks for the substring idea, though, even though quotes around `$args` brings it up to 62.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
it.BQ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P7NEzynQ6P9/QwMDAA)

Comment: [-1 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148066/55696)

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 7 bytes

```
;╘L2ⁿ@-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/60dQZPkaPGvc76P7/b2hgAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
bS1¸-JC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/Kdjw0A5dL@f//41NDQA) or [Try all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVvk/Kdjw0A5dL@f/Ov8NuYy4DA24DM2ApAGXkZk5l7GpAZepgQEA)

```
b       # Convert to binary
 S      # Split
  1¸-   # Subtract 1 from the first element
     JC # Join and convert to decimal
```

---

[`b¦C` works except for an input of `1`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVvk/6dAy5/86/w25jLgMDbgMzYCkAZeRmTmXsakBl6mBAQA)

Comment: [The logarithm version is a bit shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148081/59487), too bad we need to handle `1` though :(, otherwise the 3-byter would be the shortest

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder the answer that you've linked doesn't look like it's using logarithms. However, the formula `n-2^floor(log2(n))` handles 1 correctly, if that's what you are referring to

Comment: @NieDzejkob The answer I linked to is my own answer and **does use** logarithms.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder then the StackExchange app is utterly broken, let me see

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>28+13=41</strike> 35 bytes

```cs
n=>n-(1<<(int)System.Math.Log(n,2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc69CoMwFIbhubmKjAmoVIt28GdooZNCqUPnkKb2gJ6AiUIRr90K0q1Ds5zp4f2ONL7UvVoGA9jQ@m2s6lIiW2EMvU7EWGFB0suAMgO0Hl1PQW@q06OqoUF4ghRoT2BpThfMC/RZmGVsZXyLBZWwr6DUDUMv4nxJyTc6anjQSgAyTiayO2s0ulXBvQerSkDFfs2wkPP0bxy54HDvpBO3tlM8So4u/BA71ePtmZnMywc)

#### Acknowledgements

All credit for this answer goes to NieDzejkob; the mathematical approach is significantly better than binary string manipulation (below).

-6 bytes thanks @raznagul for seeing that `System` could just be included directly in the code, rather than as `using System;`.

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 86+13=99 bytes

```cs
n=>{var t=Convert.ToString(n,2).Remove(0,1);return t.Length<1?0:Convert.ToInt32(t,2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY5BS8NAEEbP7q@Y4wZiSFJawW1aqCAIFcQIPS/rGAfaWdidBCTkt8dAES8e3Mt3et/juXjrfMC5j8QdtF9R8GKUO9sY4WVUUayQg8ee3ZZYclhmB6948QO21DF9kLMsBxJoYOZmNw42gDQPngcMUrz5VsJi1pzXWXH96TKvMhNQ@sAgxRG5k89ttS/vf19PLKtay3Iy02zUT8fg6R2eLbHO1KhuFj76MxanQIJHYtR/lekqy8y/4ToFrsokepPmTpLXm7sUfLVOsq@vMZOa5m8)

+13 bytes for `using System;`

#### UnGolfed

```cs
n=>{
    var t = Convert.ToString(n,2).Remove(0,1); 
    return t.Length < 1 ? 0
                        : Convert.ToInt32(t,2);
}
```

Unfortunately `Convert.ToInt32` throws an exception on `""`, instead of returning `0`.

Comment: Well, [there's a better way](https://tio.run/##lc69CsIwGIXh2VxFxgRqsZXWoT@DglMLYgfnEGP9oP0CTVqQ0muPBXFzMMuZHl6ONFupB@VGA9jS5mWs6jMiO2EMvczEWGFB0vOIMge0AV2npFfV60k10CI8QAq0R7C0oA6LErcsynO2Ml4L@wwr3TIMYs5dRr61ScOd1gKQcTKTzUmj0Z0KbwNYVQEq9qvPIs6zv3Hsg6Odl0792l7xOD348H3iVU8@ZxayuDc)

Comment: “unfortunately” … err. 

Comment: @KonradRudolph "unfortunately" in the sense that it stops me having a shorter answer :-P. Probably "fortunate" in every other use.

Comment: In the mathematical approach you can directly write `System.Math.Log...` and remove the `using`-Statement.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 26 bytes

```matlab
@(x)bi2de(de2bi(x)(2:end))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzKTPPKCU1WQOIjYBsoIiGkVVqXoqm5v80DWMTU02uNA1DMxBpBGaCCAPN/wA)

Note: The TIO-link uses `dec2bin` and `bin2dec` instead of `de2bi` and `bi2de`, because the communications package is not installed. The code works fine on Octave-online.net.

#### Explanation:

```matlab
@(x)                        % Anonymous function that takes a decimal number x as input
    bi2de(                  % Convert the following to decimal:
          de2bi(x)            % Convert x to decimal
                  (2:end)     % And take all elements except the first
                         )  % That's it.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 17 bytes

```
{$_+&+^(1+<.msb)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcRBCoAgFAXAqzxCpBDia2gLtaMkBbkqilyJeHZrFvMc72nalcEjfCssCC7WXgo3XmkfarNIW0bHAvyCEsFC7RDvF05CQRKk@ScoM2PSBE202PYB)

- `$_` is the argument to the function.
- `+&` is the bitwise AND operator.
- `+^` is the bitwise NOT operator.
- `+<` is the bitwise left shift operator.
- `.msb` returns the most significant bit of the function argument.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 37 + 2 (`-lm`) = 39 bytes

```c
f(x){x-=pow(2,floor(log(x)/log(2)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcrRCsIgFAbg@z2FLIpzYJYMutrWu4imiU7HXDQYe/VMqc7Nz//9R1AtRDoYL9xT3kkfF2nC@XFLClbcVjpM4QVto1wIM7igs15KtIjY7cn4hYzceMCtqki@ApYMhHXfHgX3CuqjrBtysvjTac5/f1ZgsQx7ujL2FspxHRN14wc)

Saved some bytes thanks to a tip pointed out by [@JustinMariner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69583/justin-mariner)! This is my first proper C golf :-)

Since there is no plain **log<sub>2</sub>** built-in in C, I just (ab)used the fact that **log<sub>e</sub>(x) / log<sub>e</sub>(2) = ln(x) / ln(2) = log<sub>2</sub>(x)**.

---

#### [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 34 bytes

```c
f(c){c-=c^1<<31-__builtin_clz(c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpBCsIwEEX3PcVQURIwkiKumnoUQ50YHRJHsenG0rPHFPXv3nsf1RUxr4gxju4CZkiOHrvbMXuBckLV4akxZt8oa88jxURsMb5La@dMnODeEws5VRWULSJAB7r98oA9e1GvXb2FTZA/@3yV3197EeQS5nzQ@gM)

Comment: I think you can save some bytes by using [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106067/69583): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dh9z9No0KzukLXtiC/XMNIJy0nP79IIyc/HSiqD6KMNDU1rWv/Z@aVKOQmZuZpaFZzcRYUAblpGkqqKUo6aRqmBgZAJVy1//8lp@Ukphf/183JBQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus),  <s>24</s>  14 bytes

```
D,f,@,BBEP2$Bb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HQcfJyTXASMUp6f///4YGBgA)

### How it works

```
D,f,@,   - Create a monadic function.
         - Example argument:   10
      BB - To binary; STACK = [[1 0 1 0]]
      EP - Dequeue;   STACK = [[0 1 0]]
      2  - Push 2;    STACK = [[0 1 0] 2]
      $  - Swap;      STACK = [2 [0 1 0]]
      Bb - From base; STACK = [2]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyjTKEnD2ijp/39TAwMA) - 8 bytes

```
ri2b(;2b
```

#### Explanation

```
ri    # Reads input as integer
2b    # Convertion to base 2
(;    # Removes first element
2b    # Convertion from base 2
```

Comment: You can replace `(;2` with `()`.

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks, great idea

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 44 bytes

```
<>(()){((({}{}))){<>({}[()])}{}}<>([{}]{}<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/38ZOQ0NTs1pDQ6O6trpWE8gEilTXRmtoxmoCBWqBvOjq2thqIEPz/39TAwMA)

#### Explanation

The bulk of the modulus program is `{(({})){<>({}[()])}{}}`, which decrements two counters and resets the base counter every time it reaches zero.  To deal with powers of two, the counter needs to be doubled each time it resets.  The obvious way to do that is by replacing `(({}))` with `((({}){}))`, but this won't work since the doubling happens before the first iteration.

Instead, `((({}{})))` pushes the initial counter an additional time, and then adds these two copies together in the next iteration.  In the first iteration, a 1 and an implicit 0 are added together to start with 1 as desired.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 62 bytes

```
@set/an=%2+%2+1
@if %1 gtr %n% %0 %1 %n%
@cmd/cset/a%1-n/2-1
```

Edged out this 63-byte attempt:

```
@set/an=%2+%2+1,m=%1^^n+1
@if %m% gtr %n% %0 %1 %n%
@echo %m%
```

Which itself edged out this 64-byte port:

```
@set n=1
:l
@if %1 geq %n% set/an*=2&goto l
@cmd/cset/a%1-n/2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), <s>23</s> 20 bytes

```
n=>n~1<<math.log(2n)
```

<s>I'm quite pleased with the result of this one.</s>

Firstly, this calculates `math.floor(math.log(2,n))` incrementing a variable `i` whilst dividing `n` by two until it is <1. Then, get's two to the power of that value, which removes all but the most significant bit from `n`. We can then get the answer by xoring this with `n`, which in funky is done with `~`.

Turns out the Javascript method works for this too, although `math.log2` can be replaced with `math.log(2`, because `2` and `n` are seen as two separate tokens in Funky, and thus is parsed like `2, n`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678n2b7P8/WLq/O0MYmN7EkQy8nP13DKE/zf0FRZl6JRpqGoYGBpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 22 bytes

```ruby
->n{n^1<<Math.log2(n)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOi/O0MbGN7EkQy8nP91II0@z9n81l6GCrZ2CgQ6XEZQ2NAAxjIAMM7gIWMjYDKjIzBzENDTU4TI2BYtamuhwmUIUGJkA2bV6qYnJGQrVNSU6RTUKBaUlxQpKytUltSAFytVp0SWxtToKqRUFqcklmXnpQKGiWqXa/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 27 bytes

```bash
bc -l<<<"$1-2^(l($1)/l(2))"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PylZQTfHxsZGScVQ1yhOI0dDxVBTP0fDSFNT6f///6YGBv/yC0oy8/OK/wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>28</s> 25+1 bytes

```php
<?=$argn^1<<log($argn,2);
```

Run as pipe with `-nF` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f5d3870e4ac996f48ac13a26423ed27071540c8).

Comment: -4 bytes by replacing `&~` with `^`.

Comment: @ColeraSu -3 bytes. +1 is for `-F`. But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## C 35 bytes

```
N;f(n){for(N=n;n&n-1;)n&=n-1;N-=n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/9/POk0jT7M6Lb9Iw882zzpPLU/X0FozT80WRPvpAoVq/@cmZuZpaFZzFRRl5pWkaSippijppGmYGpmYampac9X@BwA)

> n&=n-1

Does the opposite of the problem statement, it clears the **least** significant bit.
I have a vague memory of there being a similar trick for most significant bit from seeing it on coding game but may remember wrong.

Recursive function, <del>45</del> 43 bytes

```
N;g(n){n&=(N=n&~-n)?g(N):n;}f(n){N=n-g(n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5BCoMwEEX3niIIlQk0kESNtMH2BjlBNyUl4sKhlO4kvXpqFGqNs/z/8f5Y1lkbgtEdIB2xaMG0WHwY0msHhp5RexebKWUR0T4M9x6BZmNGpnu@enw7yAVhF8LJ4XHD/OhAUKo3vdz2Mu0Fj4BcBXxHqGRC7R2zpFR/lp1GqiZCQqy/qCaFyno2naofNCUpVC9zslqpetnz4Qs)

[cleblancs code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148077/75884) shortened to 34 bytes

```
i=1;f(n){for(;n/i/2;i*=2);n-=n^i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7LCsIwEEX3/YpQEBIxNJk2KRLil4gglUgWTqW4K/322AcYm8zy3sO50/Fn14XgrTSOIhtdP1CDla/A@KMFZpBbvHkzhdfdI2XFWJD53oPHj6OlJPxCBDk8rlieHJWMmV0P@x7SXooFgCgQGaGTCZ07Vkmt/yyZBnS7QFLGX3SbQrVaTefmB81JCqltDppIqW1vCl8)

28 bytes, possibly cheating , using pointer instead of return

> f(*n){*n^=1<<(int)log2(*n);}

[Try it on ideone!](https://ideone.com/03Xfpw) , doesn't work on tio.run

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 38 bytes

```php
<?=bindec(substr(decbin($argv[1]),1));
```

Straightforward way to do it. Convert the input to binary, remove the first character of the "string", convert back to decimal.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42KTMvJTVZo7g0qbikSAPIBApoqCQWpZdFG8Zq6hhqalr////f1MAAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 19 bytes

```
.-pow(2;log2|floor)
```

This is just a jq version of the formula `n - 2^Floor[Log2[n]]` from [OEIS A053645](https://oeis.org/A053645)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtBCsIwEADv@4qAF4WuZLdpigj@xUulJWRjTeilb3ctpNLbzMBMb6XGnPBhLPAfyFZiIH@0PbYe2PeViaDt9n5z0Flr6ugcrHrFJMuZ70FevA5BZL6ofiXlUeJHEWMJAceYSt5kfi4oJW/yAw)

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 40 bytes

```
(lambda(n)(- n(expt 2(floor(log n 2)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY0xDoMwEAS/MkKKci6QbEeQLn9xQoiQwLaIC1f@OhxbTLU7@1mXfz5kTSkzp53KErmLw@MsblRa/PjkMVgGaw1TQrS5hUKha4H@RQvt1ulW1BS29xQkGumJ8q254GVW/64nPyLeXDnqhRM)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 32 bytes

```
lambda n:n-2**(n.bit_length()-1)
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to our site! There are a few things that this is missing. First off, you'll need to provide a byte count, which in this case is 25. But unfortunately, this breaks two of our standard rules: 1) This assumes that the input is stored in `n`, and 2) this simply evaluates to the answer rather than printing/returning it. You could fix this by taking input from STDIN (`n=input();print(n-2**...`) or by wrapping this in a function (`def f(n):return n-2**...` or `lambda n:n-2**...`, which is probably the best option).

Comment: Also, you could remove the spaces around the minus sign: `n-2**(n.bit_length()-1)` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem thanks for the courteous pointers.  appreciate the gentle schooling

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>74</s> 65 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
	J =1
R	J =GE(I - J) J + J :S(R)
	OUTPUT =I - J / 2
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NTwdbTLyA0hIvTS8HWkCsIRLm7angq6Cp4aSp4KWgDsVWwRpAmF6d/aAhQIVA9SE5BX8GIy9XP5f9/MwA)

```
	I =INPUT			;*read in input
	J =1				;*set J to 1
R	J =GE(I - J) J + J :S(R)	;*if I-J>=0, double J and repeat, otherwise
	OUTPUT =I - J / 2		;*output I-J/2
END
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n-1and 2*f(n/2)+n%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qT9cwMS9FwUgrTSNP30hTO0/V6H9BUWZeiUKahqEmF4xphGAaGiCxzZDFDTT/AwA)

Uses no built-in methods. 3 bytes longer than [this solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148056/20260) using `bin`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
FB+@>TBa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@O@WGG2oYKRgaKBgaAYkDRSMzMwVjE0NFEwNDGIVAv67OWk72IU4Jf7/DwA)

#### Explanation

```
     TBa  Convert cmdline arg to binary
   @>     Take all but the leftmost character
  +       Convert to number (required for turning "" into 0 so FB works properly)
FB        Convert from binary to decimal
```

Answer (score 1):

## Manufactoria, 24 Bytes, 3 Blocks

```
c12:6f3;c12:8f3;p12:7f2;

?lvl=32&code=c12:6f3;c12:8f3;p12:7f2;&ctm=Level_Name!;Level_description!;:*;5;3;0;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 23 + 1 (`-p`) = 24 bytes

```perl
$_-=2**int((log)/log 2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXtfWSEsrM69EQyMnP11TH0goGGn@/29oYPAvv6AkMz@v@L9uAQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v84oKbE4VcMaTP3/b2pgAAA) - 13 bytes

```
~2base(;2base
```

#### Explanation

```
~      # Parse argument
2base  # Convertion to base 2
(;     # Cut away first byte
2base  # Convertion from base 2
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 45 bytes

```
puts [scan [regsub 1 [format %b $argv] 0] %b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCG6ODkxTyG6KDW9uDRJwVAhOi2/KDexREE1SUElsSi9LFbBIBbIif3//7@pgQEA)

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 23 bytes

```
f=x=>x^1&&f(x/2)*2|x&1
```

Not the shortest JS solution overall, but it beats the `.toString(2)` solution.

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 63 bytes

```
[](decltype(0ul)x){auto y=x;return x^_BitScanReverse(&y,x)<<y;}
```

Usage (works in MS Visual Studio):

```
#include <intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    auto h = [](decltype(0ul)x){auto y=x;return x^_BitScanReverse(&y,x)<<y;};

    printf("%d\n", h(10));
}
```

I added an artificial constraint on my code:

> It must use `_BitScanReverse`

The effect this had on my code is quite severe.

1. I used `decltype(0ul)` as an euphemism for `unsigned long`.
2. `_BitScanReverse` outputs its result by pointer, so I had to declare another `unsigned long` variable. This time, I did it with `auto y=x`.
3. The output of `_BitScanReverse` is "whether the input is nonzero", which is 1 (luckily).
4. The returned expression modifies `y` and then uses it, which is Undefined Behavior. There are no warnings though, and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

## ARM (Thumb mode) machine code, 12 bytes

```
b0 fa 80 f1 01 31 88 40 c8 40 70 47
```

Disassembly:

```
fab0 f180       clz     r1, r0
3101            adds    r1, #1
4088            lsls    r0, r1
40c8            lsrs    r0, r1
4770            bx      lr
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 42 bytes

```
int f(int n){return n-exp2((int)log2(n));}
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to an online compiler where this works? I doubt this works without `int n` in the declaration, and I'm not sure that C++ has `exp2` and `log2` functions without some `#include`

Comment: Added the return type. About the includes, I don't see them counted in any of the previous C/C++ replies and I don't see you downvoting them or hassling them about it. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh I didn't downvote you! I'm sorry if you got that impression. That's due to [a bug that sometimes hits new users with short posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276269/286591). Which is really unfortunate, but SE seems to not care.

Comment: I see. No problem then.

Comment: In K&R C, any undeclared functions are assumed return an `int`, and take whatever type is passed in. Most modern compilers accept this, but create a warning. In golf we can make use of this.

However, in your submission, you marked it as C++, not C. C++ does not allow undeclared functions. Also you are passing an int into exp2 (and log2), which won't be promoted to float.

However, you _can_ remove the `int` for the return and input for your function `f` - saving 8 bytes.

This should work, for 50 bytes, when split over two lines
`#include<math.h>
f(n){return n-exp2((int)log2(n));}`

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 8 Bytes

```
ig.BQ2 2
```

Explanation:

```
ig.BQ2 2
i      2 Convert to base 2
 g   2   Slice from position 1 to the end (g slices from b-1)
  .B     Binary String representation of
    Q    Input
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$3\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 2.469 bytes

```
Bpb
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJCcGIiLCIyNjciXQ==)

Same strategy as every other golflang.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 27 bytes

Just realized this is a port of [@xnor's python2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150742/112488).

```c
f(n){n=n>1?2*f(n/2)+n%2:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY7LDoIwFETX7VfcYDBUQdsS8IHgj7ghLY8meDGCuiD46daymWTOTDKjokYpa@sA2YQ5FuIqN87sJduiL888m@3KoOpeuoLLMGrT79qCUoMjvZcGg3dvNKMTJY4AZpR8WtNVEHwHVWIdeL72QlgjY5SQx9OVFhbFGqICfH1Dl2IIyzzL6GwFSBAcROqUg0wPECccEs5/qu7KZrCR@5Cr4@kP)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḃḣ0|Ḃ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWqx_uaH64Y7FBzcMdTUuKk5KLoeILFhsaGECYAA)

##### Explanation

```python
ḃḣ0|Ḃ  # Implicit input      ->  100
ḃ      # Convert to binary   ->  "1100100"
 ḣ     # Remove first item   ->  "100100"
  0|   # Logical OR with 0   ->  "100100"
    Ḃ  # Convert to decimal  ->  36
       # Implicit output
```