# Codegolf the Hafnian

Tags: code-golf, math, permutations, matrix, linear-algebra

The challenge is to write codegolf for the [Hafnian of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafnian).
The Hafnian of an \$2n \times 2n\$ symmetric matrix \$A\$ is defined as:

$$\operatorname{haf}(A) = \frac 1 {n!2^n} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{2n}} \prod^n_{j=1} A_{\sigma(2j-1),\sigma(2j)}$$

Here \$S_{2n}\$ represents the set of all permutations of the integers from \$1\$ to \$2n\$, that is \$[1, 2n]\$.

The Wikipedia link talks about adjacency matrices but your code should work for any real valued symmetric input matrices.

For those interested in applications of the Hafnian, the [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273324/applications-of-hafnians/273325) link discusses some more.

Your code can take input however it wishes and give output in any sensible format but please include in your answer a full worked example including clear instructions for how to supply input to your code.

The input matrix is always square and will be at most 16 by 16. There is no need to be able to handle the empty matrix or matrices of odd dimension.

### Reference implementation

Here is some example python code from Mr. Xcoder.

```python
from itertools import permutations
from math import factorial

def hafnian(matrix):
    my_sum = 0
    n = len(matrix) // 2
    for sigma in permutations(range(n*2)):
        prod = 1
        for j in range(n):
            prod *= matrix[sigma[2*j]][sigma[2*j+1]]
        my_sum += prod
    return my_sum / (factorial(n) * 2 ** n)


print(hafnian([[0, 4.5], [4.5, 0]]))
4.5
print(hafnian([[0, 4.7, 4.6, 4.5], [4.7, 0, 2.1, 0.4], [4.6, 2.1, 0, 1.2], [4.5, 0.4, 1.2, 0]])
16.93
print(hafnian([[1.3, 4.1, 1.2, 0.0, 0.9, 4.4], [4.1, 4.2, 2.7, 1.2, 0.4, 1.7], [1.2, 2.7, 4.9, 4.7, 4.0, 3.7], [0.0, 1.2, 4.7, 2.2, 3.3, 1.8], [0.9, 0.4, 4.0, 3.3, 0.5, 4.4], [4.4, 1.7, 3.7, 1.8, 4.4, 3.2]])
262.458
```

---

The wiki page has now (March 2 2018) been updated by  ShreevatsaR to include a different way of calculating the Hafnian.  It would be very interesting to see this golfed.

Comment: I think this would be easier to digest with an informal explanation of the hafnian. Something like, take all subsets of n matrix entries where their n row indices and n column indices form a partition of 1..2n, take the product of each, add them, and scale the sum.

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>150</s> <s>142</s> <s>127</s> 119 bytes

```r
function(A,N=nrow(A),k=1:(N/2)*2)sum(apply(gtools::permutations(N,N),1,function(r)prod(A[cbind(r[k-1],r[k])])))/prod(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY6xDoIwGIR3n8Lx/82P2BKjaWTgBTq5EQYoYgjQNqVEefpaHBguXy6Xu5wL3fGRhG7RyvdGQ0Ey1858oEAaciZAphxPHOdlgtracYW3N2achbAvNy2@3lozSJJIjPYZh9aZFopSNb1uwZVDwiqKqLBCxPSfDhg6mGrv@i8oyOhyvkbdKEPixBEPe8rEnbZXeYQyY0SzbvaJGH4)

Uses the same trick I discovered golfing down [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156888/67312) to index the matrix `P`, and [@Vlo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30693/vlo) suggested an approach to entirely remove the `for` loop for -6 bytes!

To create a new test case, you can do `matrix(c(values,separated,by,commas,going,across,rows),nrow=2n,ncol=2n,byrow=T)`.

Explanation: (the code is the same; it uses an `apply` rather than a `for` loop but the logic is otherwise identical).

```r
function(A){
N <- nrow(A)                   #N = 2*n
k <- 1:(N/2) * 2               #k = c(2,4,...,N) -- aka 2*j in the formula
P <- gtools::permutations(N,N) #all N-length permutations of 1:N
for(i in 1:nrow(P))
 F <- F + prod(A[cbind(P[i,k-1],P[i,k])]) # takes the product of all A_sigma(2j-1)sigma(2j) for fixed i and adds it to F (initialized to 0)
F / prod(k)                    #return value; prod(k) == n! * 2^n
}
```

Comment: Apply is cheaper by 2 bytes, which allows for additional 4 bytes of saving by cramming the other lines together. https://tio.run/##PY6xDoIwEIZ3nsLxzpxiS4ymkYEXYHIjDFDEEKBtSokS47PX4sDw5/svX@5y1re728G3s5Ku0woy/OSpsvoVWtSnTEAec9zzaJpHqIwZFng6rYdJCPOw4@yqdW2CnHIkRtsdi8bqBrJC1p1qwBb9gZUUUGKJiPHf9vj1LYyVs90bJCR0Op5DLpQgceKI0WaZuNL6Vhog9RBQL@t4R/Q/ It is also quite interesting how base R lacks a permutation function for a statistical programming language

Comment: @Vlo very nice! we can move `N` and `k` into function arguments to get it to one statement, removing the `{}` and saving another two bytes.

Comment: @Giuseppe Darn keeps on forgetting that you can define them in the function args. Spent a few minutes trying to ember those variables...

Answer (score 8):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 24 bytes

```
sm*Fmc@@Qhkek2d{mScd2.pU
```

**[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%2aFmc%40%40Qhkek2d%7BmScd2.pU&input=%5B%5B0%2C+4.7%2C+4.6%2C+4.5%5D%2C+%5B4.7%2C+0%2C+2.1%2C+0.4%5D%2C+%5B4.6%2C+2.1%2C+0%2C+1.2%5D%2C+%5B4.5%2C+0.4%2C+1.2%2C+0%5D%5D&debug=0)**

---

#### Old version, 35 bytes

```
*c1**FK/lQ2^2Ksm*Fm@@Q@dtyk@dykK.pU
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2ac1%2a%2aFK%2FlQ2%5E2Ksm%2aFm%40%40Q%40dtyk%40dykK.pU&input=%5B%5B3%2C0.7%5D%2C%5B0.5%2C3%5D%5D&debug=0)

Comment: Currently the lead but you have to fear the Jelly answers to come.... :)

Comment: Eh Jelly will definitely beat my by about 10 bytes. Pyth ain’t the best tool for the job

Comment: 05AB1E is looking like it may even tie Pyth (believe it or not, finally a matrix challenge where `a[b]` is enough to compete).

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I already have an 05AB1E solution that beats Pyth :-) Not going to post it (for now, at least)

Comment: Is it something along the lines of `xÍysè<¹sès·<ysè<è` lmao? P.S. Mine is 40 bytes and isn't working so well hah, so feel free to post it, unsure I'm able to finish before I have to go home.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn [status-completed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156997/59487)

Answer (score 7):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <strike>23</strike> <strike>22</strike> <strike>19</strike> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü;Y╙◘▌Φq↓ê²╧▐å↑┌C
```

[Run and debug it online](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%C3%BC%3BY%E2%95%99%E2%97%98%E2%96%8C%CE%A6q%E2%86%93%C3%AA%C2%B2%E2%95%A7%E2%96%90%C3%A5%E2%86%91%E2%94%8CC&i=%5B%5B3.0%2C0.7%5D%2C%5B0.5%2C3.0%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1.0%2C2.0%2C3.0%2C4.0%2C5.0%2C6.0%2C7.0%2C8.0%5D%2C%5B1.0%2C2.0%2C3.0%2C4.0%2C5.0%2C6.0%2C7.0%2C8.0%5D%2C%5B1.0%2C2.0%2C3.0%2C4.0%2C5.0%2C6.0%2C7.0%2C8.0%5D%2C%5B1.0%2C2.0%2C3.0%2C4.0%2C5.0%2C6.0%2C7.0%2C8.0%5D%2C+%5B1.0%2C2.0%2C3.0%2C4.0%2C5.0%2C6.0%2C7.0%2C8.0%5D%2C%5B1.0%2C2.0%2C3.0%2C4.0%2C5.0%2C6.0%2C7.0%2C8.0%5D%2C%5B1.0%2C2.0%2C3.0%2C4.0%2C5.0%2C6.0%2C7.0%2C8.0%5D%2C%5B1.0%2C2.0%2C3.0%2C4.0%2C5.0%2C6.0%2C7.0%2C8.0%5D%5D&a=1&m=2)

The corresponding ascii representation of the same program is this.

```
%r|TF2/{xsE@i^H/m:*+
```

The program suffers from some floating point rounding error.  In particular, it reports `33673.5000000011` instead of `33673.5`.  But I think the accuracy is acceptable given that this program operates on floating point values.  It's also very slow, taking almost a minute for the example inputs on this machine.

```
%                             get size of matrix
 r|T                          get all permutations of [0 ... size-1]
    F                         for each, execute the rest of the program
     2/                       get consecutive pairs
       {        m             map each pair... 
        xsE@                      the matrix element at that location
            i^H/                  divided by 2*(i+1) where i=iteration index
                 :*           product of array
                   +          add to running total
```

Comment: Very impressive!

Comment: Finally, I actually see someone using Stax! I thought I was the only person that knew about it.

Comment: I know a lot about it, but I'm equally surprised to find someone else who knows about it. :)

Comment: you created Stax?! No way!

... also could I create a chat room for Stax? I don't know, I want to chat with the legendary tomtheisen (at least legendary to me)

Comment: I used to have a chat room some months ago, but it's fallen into disuse.  I have no problem with you creating a chat room.  The idea of being legendary over is pretty amusing to me. :)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ā<œε2ô{}Ùεε`Isèsè;]PO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//SKPN0cnnthod3lJde3jmua3ntiZ4Fh9eAUTWsQH@//9HRxvoKJjomYMIMxBhGqujEA0WAEoY6RkCaT0TiJgZTEBHwVDPCCJmCpYHCwBZsbEA)

---

#### Old version, 32 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
āœvIg;©Lε·UIyX<èèyXèè}P}Oθ®!/®o/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//SOPRyWWe6daHVvqc23poe6hnZYTN4RWHV1RGgMjagFr/czsOrVPUP7QuX////@hoYx0DPfNYnWgDPVMd49hYAA)

**How it works?**

```
āœvIg;©Lε·UIyX<èèyXèè}P}Oθ®!/®o/ – Full program. Argument: A matrix M.
ā                                – The range [1 ... len(M)].
 œ                               – Permutations.
  v                    }         – Iterate over the above with a variable y.
   Ig;©                          – Push len(M) / 2 and also store it in register c.
       Lε            }           – For each integer in the range [1 ... ^]:
         ·U                      – Double it and store it in a variable X.
            yX<                  – Push the element of y at index X-1.
           I   è                 – And index with the result into M.
                yXè              – Push the element of y at index X.
                   è             – And index with the result into ^^.
                      P          – Take the product of the resulting list.
                        O        – Sum the result of the mapping.
                         θ       – And take the last element*.
                          ®!     – Take the factorial of the last item in register c.
                             ®o  – Raise 2 to the power of the last item in register c.
                            /  / – And divide the sum of the mapping accordingly.

* – Yeah, this is needed because I mess up the stack when pushing so many values in the loop and not popping correctly ;P
```

Comment: No kidding `èsè`, hah... haha... I'm punny.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>84</s> 78 bytes

```r
h=function(m)"if"(n<-nrow(m),{for(j in 2:n)F=F+m[1,j]*h(m[v<--c(1,j),v]);F},1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/LCsIwELz7FcFTVtOQl1pf1/6EeJBCsUJTKFoF8dvrbrtVFMKG2RlmZpuuO@@LW8yvZR1lBdOymMq4S2JT3xGqZ1E38iLKKNwmQrbP5tXBqstxdpbVod0lSS4RgmqPsM1eykKHxOnalA@ZS6NE0AseBpRw@AAm/5IVjeVHjBDXTlv8dWBugEpY7UZD4npI1qT7tbbak9KOIm1orGkXmAhEOApkSe84QjcUW38qooHv2@lvkRXpHBGedilncHHDhBkuCzz6DD8Epbzz2uEZeOkSoHsD)

Edit: Thanks to Vlo for -6 bytes.

It seems that everybody here is implementing the standard reference algorithm with permutations, but I tried to take advantage of the community knowledge gained in the [related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157049/calculate-the-hafnian-as-quickly-as-possible), which is basically the same task targeted for fastest code instead of golf.

It turns out that for a language that is good at slicing matrices (like R), the recursive algorithm: `hafnian(m) = sum(m[i,j] * hafnian(m[-rows and columns at i,j])` is not only faster, but also quite golfy. Here is the ungolfed code:

```r
hafnian<-function(m)
{
    n=nrow(m)
    #Exits one step earlier than golfed version
    if(n == 2) return(m[1,2])
    h = 0
    for(j in 2:n) {
        if(m[1,j] == 0) next
        h = h + m[1,j] * hafnian(m[c(-1,-j),c(-1,-j)])
    }
    h
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer. -1 for calling `If` with parenthesis, -4 for using `F` as initialized variable, -1 for assigning `n` within the `if`. https://tio.run/##XU/LCsIwELz7FcFTVtOQl1pf1/6EeJBCsUJTKFoF8dvrbrtVFMKG2RlmZpuuO@@LW8yvZR1lBdOymMq4S2JT3xGqZ1E38iLKKNwmQrbP5tXBqstxdpbVod0lSS4RgmqPsM1eykKHxOnalA@ZS6NE0AseBpRw@AAm/5IVjeVHjBDXTlv8dWBugEpY7UZD4npI1qT7tbbak9KOIm1orGkXmAhEOApkSe84QjcUW38qooHv2@lvkRXpHBGedilncHHDhBkuCzz6DD8Epbzz2uEZeOkSoHsD

Comment: neat! I'd say post it in the speed challenge, but there are probably some more optimizations (like threading) that can be made, and while R isn't exactly known for its speed, it'd be good to have it there for reference.

Comment: Do it for benchmark purposes!

Comment: I actually tried testing this for speed, but got quickly discouraged by the results. The slowest Python submission in the speed challenge using the same exact algorithm crunches 24x24 matrix in a few seconds on TIO, but R times out. On my local machine it also didn't respond in a reasonable time, even when aided with memoization from package 'memo'...

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
LŒ!s€2Ṣ€QḅL_LịFHP€S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n6CTF4kdNa4we7lwEpAIf7mj1ifd5uLvbzSMAyA/@f7gdSEX@/x/NpRAdbaCjYKJnGqujEA2kdBQMYmN14MLmIMIMSQFQAChhpGcIpPVMIGJmMAEdBUM9I4RBeiZgAYSRhnrGIKMMYcJ6BiDCEiQGNcoQxDYCmWcOVwQ2xRwkbwiXMoHoArOAhhhD5MEGghWBpYxALGOQnYZ6FhB5S6iBUF3GIK4pkv0Qu8AGgnWBpUBcI5AXYgE)

#### Alternate version, 15 bytes, postdates challenge

```
LŒ!s€2Ṣ€QœịHP€S
```

Jelly *finally* got n-dimensional array indexing.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY89DsIwDIV3ThH2yKqTtKU3YGAAMaEoIwvqxsTKwsBWbsDMBRAj6kHKRYLt9G@Jn9@zPyunY11fYty0zfL8u75M935S2bWP7nNfb0nu4/dG5RCjXyjvM60c5EErT0WrLAQ92iU/xWyADAoMIFVwySsGQysEM4HAiTEhESyjcLAh46dir0cha8O8chwSSsk5jpFLW6IIYlMuQBmSyLCyfBNhlfKqB/Zbltt8dj/dEqBsScSt4S@EPw)

#### How it works

```
LŒ!s€2Ṣ€QœiHP€S  Main link. Argument: M (matrix / 2D array)

L                Take the length, yielding 2n.
 Œ!              Generate all permutations of [1, ..., 2n].
   s€2           Split each permutation into pairs.
      Ṣ€         Sort the pair arrays.
        Q        Unique; deduplicate the array of pair arrays.
                 This avoids dividing by n! at the end.
           H     Halve; yield M, with all of its elements divided by 2.
                 This avoids dividing by 2**n at the end.
         œị      At-index (n-dimensional); take each pair of indices [i, j] and
                 yield M[i][j].
            P€   Take the product the results corresponding the same permutation.
              S  Take the sum of the products.
```

The 19-byte version works in a similar fashion; it just has to implement `œị` itself.

```
...ḅL_LịFH...    Return value: Array of arrays of index pairs. Argument: M

    L            Length; yield 2n.
   ḅ             Convert each pair of indices [i, j] from base 2n to integer,
                 yielding ((2n)i + j).
     _L          Subtract 2n, yielding ((2n)(i - 1) + j).
                 This is necessary because indexing is 1-based in Jelly, so the
                 index pair [1, 1] must map to index 1.
        F        Yield M, flattened.
       ị         Take the indices to the left and get the element at these indices
                 from the array to the right.
         H       Halve; divide all retrieved elements by 2.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>288</s> <s>285</s> <s>282</s> <s>293</s> <s>292</s> <s>272</s> <s>271</s> 263 bytes

- Saved three bytes by fiddling with two post-increments and for loop placement.
- Saved three bytes by fiddling with anothter post-increment, moving both variable initializations before the branch -- golfed `if(...)...k=0...else...,j=0...` to `if(k=j=0,...)...else...` -- and performed an index shift.
- Required eleven bytes by supporting `float` matrices.
- Saved a byte thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder); golfing `2*j+++1` to `j-~j++`.
- Saved twenty bytes by removing a superfluous `int` variable type declaration and not using a factorial function but instead calculating the factorial value by using an already existing for loop.
- Saved a byte by golfing `S=S/F/(1<<n);` to `S/=F*(1<<n);`.
- Saved eight bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```c
float S,p,F;j,i;s(A,n,P,l,o,k)float*A;int*P;{if(o-l)for(k=0;k<l;s(A,n,P,l,o+1))P[o]=k++;else{for(p=j=l;j--;)for(i=l;i--;)p-=P[j]==P[i];if(!p){for(F=p=1,j=0;j<n;F*=j)p*=A[P[2*j]*2*n+P[j+++j]];S+=p;}}}float h(A,n)float*A;{int P[j=2*n];S=0;s(A,n,P,j,0);S/=F*(1<<n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vY89a8MwFEXn9le4gYI@rlvLsdMWWUMWz4aMRkMIcWPZtUWSzei3u7KblNKh2QriwUPnXs7bhe@73ThWbb89BxtY5NKglieyRocCLXo0dP5la1l3Z1bIoa5IH7a06o@kUZFssvYnzwWlRdlr1XAu9@1pP0ygVUa10oShnHO1X@ppsaEqSqOVn7WWvvnB0jmQK6sEjO83WSdzpgy1TK3LooyZ0SxmHfdBzrnRWm64stI593XGYZL5lh68deBR5SOe9IVXWYOIys2zyhkRWdZR6caPbd0ROtzf2aOPVWTxWCFY4EDIXFdqOgjEWCJBihVe8Io3iAhCQMQQS4gEIoVYOcSUyr960glPEAoHcQMNBa7vNvzb7593h@SGYIQgeUovI7oc5MZP)

## Explanation (271 bytes version)

```c
float S,p,F;                    // global float variables: total sum, temporary, factorial
j,i;                            // global integer variables: indices
s(A,n,P,l,o,k)float*A;int*P;{   // recursively look at every permutation in S_n
 if(k=j=0,o-l)                  // initialize k and j, check if o != l (possible  permutation not yet fully generated)
  for(;k<l;s(A,n,P,l,o+1))      // loop through possible values for current possible  permuation position
   P[o]=k++;                    // set possible  permutation, recursively call (golfed into the for loop)
 else{for(p=-l;j<l;j++)         // there exists a possible permutation fully generated
  for(i=0;i<l;)                 // test if the possible permutation is a bijection
   p+=P[j]==P[i++];             // check for unique elements
  if(!p){                       // indeed, it is a permutation
   for(F=p=1,j=0;j<n;F*=j)      // Hafnian product loop and calculate the factorial (over and over to save bytes)
    p*=A[P[2*j]*2*n+P[j-~j++]]; // Hafnian product
   S+=p;}}}                     // add to sum
float h(A,n)float*A;{           // Hafnian function
 int P[j=2*n];S=0;              // allocate permutation memory, initialize sum
 s(A,n,P,j,0);                  // calculate Hafnian sum
 S/=F*(1<<n);}                  // calculate Hafnian
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVRLb9pAED6XXzGpVMmPocEE0ofjQy6oRySOCFWLvYY1613XXqNS5P51OoshIUCanoqQZVsz32tmHXcXcbzbpVIzAxMscBTCld/tLSyknjMJbeWalYLNJa@@gtGGXld1jmB4XuiSlRuElMVGU43sZCiuQl5CC2X4gpen4EIlIuZVp3IeUeEYJWpcuXsN3mNIDd443LYgJY/rshJrLjcgtV4ByeRrXm6g4GVeG2aEVgQIk@@qAyJ1VlEW9VB3pXtVlFDCkH7xiwNhqQQyhHjJ4xX1goabCCQ4ha4qQVLhBYnSBjbcQFpLErPgipfM8MTtAKS6dMLVgwxPHPmB6z7RkvQCzLLU9WIJT/BrJmte2W4glyVXBs6oW2Z6KewNMcF4qmfRyvdfG2jFL0Ba/fgiy5hJMrrQMuWJHZEmdXyvxEolT1xWfGt9FVFXhhl5y3zfPWWihpID/ykqUwF7Jj3N7CyrQ1Qi6oWCEN1rBgyvjB2G1XMVU1i2uch4fMyk8KPxNJtFdBW@PwvPIdsBW3O1Ej9qEi15TmlX1Ewrc1O429fXmJaV8wRBmJb5RIrltn5GUREFSHtHOalw5EXZ8@S/sVQJRjMsdVLHpt0Eu3g0gbiWlEqb/PFkgaNpvfcV@xuaTMXWHOYbCsbuGtn1osfpeNr3spnX95RP3ru/aTozcn7JaFsmflSETdO85pElyZ6ozjvtl2Bp9/jpRG5fVh8J0lodRkALRIuZRaRmFk4oh0sGKXVszZ5OMue5tp@Vk0NpJcDxFGXYc8Orgp/DO4rZN05uo5HnBA8Pyg2bf2vc5Uwox9123hUl2Uid9x9ShPe4dJy9/enM3QbYxzsc4BDv8RN@xi8Y9DAIMOhjcIfBAIMhBvcN9l03/BvO0JYPsBs0GLxR2g3w@H@7@Fzff35ucPCGwB7C4OPwcOkdDDW7Pw)

At the program's core is the following permutation generator which loops through `S_n`. All Hafnian computation is simply build upon it -- and further golfed.

```c
j,i,p;Sn(A,l,o,k)int*A;{          // compute every element in S_n
 if(o-l)                          // o!=l, the permutation has not fully been generated
  for(k=0;k<l;k++)                // loop through the integers [0, n)
   A[o]=k,Sn(A,l,o+1);            // modify permutation, call recursively
 else{                            // possible permutation has been generated
  for(p=-l,j=0;j<l;j++)           // look at the entire possible permutation
   for(i=0;i<l;i++)p+=A[j]==A[i]; // check that all elements appear uniquely
  if(!p)                          // no duplicat elements, it is indeed a permutation
   for(printf("["),j=0;j<l        // print
   ||printf("]\n")*0;)            //  the
    printf("%d, ",A[j++]);}}      //   permutation
main(){int l=4,A[l];Sn(A,l,0);}   // all permutations in S_4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLBTuMwEIbvfYqh0koxcUWRuGVz6DNw7EbIJJN2Esf22g5SVXj2Mm4JFCj4kEv@@TTfzNSLTV0fDp0k6Yp7k62kllb2gky8XhV7eH83N1DbwY0RAZ/Q7wA1DmgikIH7BzMDajO70AJ@fEywV6WWELcIDv0wRhXJGtiqAMZGaEetd/CIaGCDBr2K2MwAWuuzvlwW/V9d9HkuLnC1tY6x3o6b7RHP7eMGfYD1UoIRTIHV2lZlLyfH/FYUXyiDbajdnbcmoVZag8d69IGeUO9m7B1wD/Crp7Mh0KP@rnlRzpULLTs27Niw@2x4kutBxaMXD5w8XuQnx0QjBhGDiEEuL1frrir5S1Vx3OEW655RzEtmb0sMoJxD5WE09H88aqZ9Xrnf12ksNKPTVDNtIkkgvonAG2gQG1CXWnSe99Nm8/VcTN7nw0t/U/T5eQpW/8xcXC8L8aWBNJOUhCn4p5Ewl@yc55UoXl4@kp/6GBSZTOy5BnR5x3ldTce/5LJTSZrPWVE4Xfrd4fAK)

Comment: `2*j+++1` is equivalent to `j+j+++1`, which is the same as `j-(-j++-1)`, so we can use the bitwise complement efficiently to save a byte: `j-~j++` ([Try it online](https://tio.run/##vZDLasMwEEXX7Ve4gYJkXTcex04fiij5A0OWxosQ4saPyibJzii/7o7TtJQuml1BDEicM3NHm@BtsxmGomnXR2@FTpf26FUodSGs7K2xr9YvxCmw8oW0O4glLFI0aFHLs@QvR8VPdV8WojaVCdEGjSzavdD1otE/FEVSplmbm1opvW0O236kOhM0umKyUuqslSbUJd9lp0yaVbnhWiqVax5w18mLROBR7FnmfLPM0izyq9yPfKtYCk7cLc/1SplOO@c@99uNWb5j9@OqzBp2mORuX1krhJIfVtPxE6aCFgsrtRve16UVsr@96fasFmJyX8CbYCfEuWWWy54QYYYYCeZ4xBOeQSGIQBFoBopBCWjuEEmp/@qTjHiMgBzoChoQvs51@He@f747xFcChvDih@RSwstCbvgA))

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 136 bytes

*-14 bytes thanks to ovs.*

```hs
import Data.List
f m|n<-length m`div`2=sum[product[m!!(s!!(2*j-2)-1)!!(s!!(2*j-1)-1)/realToFrac(2*j)|j<-[1..n]]|s<-permutations[1..n*2]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3ZBBboMwEEX3nGKyCxG42JDQSGRXddXuukOWYiWkIcWAwHSVu9MZh0QQblAsLM@fr/fHPqv2JyuKvs91XTUG3pRR7CNvjXMCfS0Tv8jKb3MGvT/mv3uxazud1k117A4m1YvFssVfrC6@cH3ujmpO9UuTqeKrem/UgUT3ekn8lDNWSnltE7/OGt0ZZfKqbK28ElL2WuUl7ECr@hOWdZOXBhicXAfwS2kFHkRsLa0A4EGKlQeBBOk4gwJpiAqLR6aATOHUZEkxbZs5E3XsC8aJFE1am7vuAWdiNgmLrD6bibOQYvi9ywLatqRN@ZwkQSHxw2uZ4wvxhyO6MewJkeHTvYOBYR2CTiENwtnrxLYdUgaGfcD1fLbbHDbFMqyDSvF0WcxCGdseIAafDP3jxH9tAFz9Hw)

Ugh...

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 29 bytes

```
LHµ2*×!
LŒ!s€2;@€€Wị@/€€P€S÷Ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/H49BWI63D0xW5fI5OUix@1LTGyNoBSAJR@MPd3Q76EHYAEAcf3n64/f///9HRhjpGOsY6JjqmOmY65joWsTrkiShQyaBYAA)

I think the `;@€€Wị@/€€P€` part can likely be golfed down. Need to come back later to check and add an explanation.

Comment: Identical to my [solution](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=43147022#43147022) (except the `J`) before [golfed down](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=43147080#43147080). _Jelly minds think alike_? [source](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=43058190#43058190)

Comment: I was able to reduce it a bit more by refactoring the part that you mentioned as well as the division by 2 and the factorial. ``LḶŒ!s€2ḅL‘ịFZµPS÷JḤ$P$`` [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n4Y5tRycpFj9qWmP0cEerz6OGGQ93d7tFHdoaEHx4u9fDHUtUAlT@H24Hyv//H82lEB1trGOgZx6rE22gZ6pjHBurAxIz1DHSMdYx0THVMdMx17EAypIlokAlg2K5YgE)

Comment: @user202729 haha nice

Comment: @miles Wow that's a lot of savings. I'll edit it into my answer but it's pretty different so feel free to submit your own answer if you want

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>29</s> <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
Zy:Y@!"G@2eZ{)tn:E/pvs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6rSKtJBUcndwSg1qlqzJM/KVb@grPj//2hjBQM9c2sgYapgHAsA) Or verify all test cases: [1](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6rSKtJBUcndwSg1qlqzJM/KVb@grPj//2hjBQM9c2sgYapgHAsA), [2](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6rSKtJBUcndwSg1qlqzJM/KVb@grPj//2gDHQUTPXMQYQYiTK0hXKCwkZ4hkNYzsYbIQbg6CoZ6RiARU7AcmAtkxQIA), [3](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6rSKtJBUcndwSg1qlqzJM/KVb@grPj//2hDPWMdBRM9Qx0FQz0jHQUDPQMQYQkSM7GGSJiAJIz0zOFKTEAsc2sIFyxhAtEBZgENMAbJgo0CKwFLGIFYxiDbDPUsrCF2gI2C6jAGcU3h9kLsABsF1qEDETPWM4oFAA).

#### How it works

```
Zy       % Size of (implicit) input: pushes [2*n 2*n], where the
         % input is a 2*n × 2*n matrix. 
:        % Range: gives row vector [1 2 ... 2*n]
Y@       % All permutation of that vector as rows of a matrix
!"       % For each permutation 
  G      %   Push input matrix
  @      %   Push current permutation
  2e     %   Reshape as a 2-row array
  Z{     %   Split rows into a cell array of size 2
  )      %   Reference indexing. With a cell array as index this
         %   applies element-wise indexing (similar to sub2ind).
         %   Gives a row vector with the n matrix entries selected
         %   by the current permutation
  t      %   Duplicate
  n:     %   Number of elements, range: this gives [1 2 ... n]
  E      %   Double, element-wise: gives [2 4 ... 2*n]
  /      %   Divide, element-wise
  p      %   Product
  vs     %   Vertically concatenate and sum
         % End (implicit). Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>121</s> <s>119</s> <s>117</s> <s>115</s> 101 bytes

```javascript
A=>(F=(a,t,r)=>{a--?A[t].map((x,i)=>F[i]=F[i]||F(F[i]=a,i,a%2?r:r*x/(a+2))):s+=r})(A.length,s=0,1)||s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/LboMwEEX3@Qo2lezGDNi8QiQnYsNPIBZWShNX1CCDqkil305tQx5SuxnP3DtzD3yILzGctOxHX3VvzdxrqUZ@6tTQtQ203XlzEe9KCsXngh9QyZEgI9GYH76F7x@LaqzhU/QIXYk0YlnJmtsyTSVygyCSiBd21Hv9eg2Q2DKM8X7Ycv2DUQFto87jhQw8JBRP07B8AFqhqKpC4sWQ1MSrzEO8sK4x3gSBGTb/rma2pE9HRjAGA2peiBctvQnEo8Ae4RA74YGhKeTRHxCFyALobRlCW3KrrQBqe2Yp2X3JZWfWp3crXq5cZ0KixXeBbslZzHaRZVLYLX6@Bq5XkR2TJ/7CcoHuyll2ZOuPsZRBnOzmXw)

### Explanation & Ungolfed

```javascript
function hafnian(A) {            // Main function taking an array
 return (
  F = function(                  //  Helper function, and also a temporary storage
   a,                            //   how many numbers left
   t,                            //   previous number
   r                             //   the product
  ) {                            //   The braces are to avoid returning value
   a-- ?                         //   If a > 0:
    A[t].map((x, i) =>           //    Loop from i = 2n - 1 downto 0:
     F[i] = F[i] || F(           //     Skip if F[i] is truthy, i.e. i used in the permutation    
      F[i] = a,                  //     Otherwise: Set F[i] to truthy* & start a new recursion
      i,                         //      with i as the previous number
      a % 2                      //      If a - 1 is odd:
       ? r                       //       r does not change
       : r * x / (a + 2)         //      Otherwise: multiply A[t][i] to r, divide by a + 1
     )                           //      Set back F[i] to undefined after the recursion
    )
   : s += r;                     //   Otherwise: add r to s. The factor 1/(n!*2^n) = 1/(2n)!!
  }                              //   has been included in the recursion
 )(
  A.length,                      //  2n = size of the array
  s = 0,                         //  Initial sum s = 0
  1                              //  Initial product r = 1
 ) || s;                         //  Return s
}

/* Note that when a = 1 F[i] will be falsy, but the next recursion will just 
   skip this part anyway. */
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), <s>165</s> <s>145</s> <s>128</s> 127 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder

```
m->sum(reduce((o,j)->o*m[p[2*j]][p[j-~j]]/-~j/2,range(len(m)//2),1)for p in permutations(range(len(m))))
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rU7NDsIgGLvvKTjC8m3sR50X9yLIYZnMsAw@wuBmfHXEm/Fo7KFtmqbpjDPaGNJyuSZTjXs01KtbnBWlCCurRiyNcKIrVymzrtUzG56Zd@Ane1d0U5YaxnnHoGULeuKItsQpb2KYgka7089iRrF4NEQH5QPithNtHPpQJiF6aOpBgmjqI/RSksdIljc5r20oCiFa6KCHAxzhBAOcc/WnhPxp6OthegE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 84 bytes

```
aTr[1##&@@(a[[##]]&@@@#~Partition~2)&/@Permutations@Range[n=Tr[1^a]]]/(n/=2)!/2^n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1NasMwEIX3OcUUgUlAlSzZiZOFi45gSnfCAVGc1gsr4KoroxyiN@gJewRXIzk/m/l5b943g3Gf3WBc/27mE9Sz@fv5fRu1ICRTam20JqRtw6jIpTGj611/the5ybhqunH4dgaFL/Vq7EenbY3Ro2nblq8tr@XmicujnZuxt04TeH6Bkw48yICr1TRNOYWSbT2FKTQKufd0BYtcYdk9HAQhGJKJ0FmZtN1VoCCYvINYGYU7UrACUeIqsxzLAbUFJXCWyKtuR5FSoS9uVplScQqQIvkRGI@iJXEq8Kdg@@QfFuCSKnDdPvxPvyIwpqKFq/Tez/8)

---

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 68 bytes

```
If[#=={},1,Sum[d=Rest@*Delete[i];#[[1,i]]#0@d[d/@#],{i,2,Tr[1^#]}]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY09T8MwEIb3/oqTLHVAh5tz0oYKBWVgYUPAZrlSRFxhiTAUM1n@7cFnpx/Lfbzvvc9Ng/@y0@Dd5zAfoZtfjlp0XYhI@P436bF7s7@@v3u239Zb7cyj0JrQGSOqftTjphcGg0OFHydNB2GiMev59eR@vBZw/wQJZwysYdOvQggVQiO3ESGkhlDFiCtY5JbL7uYgCclQklKXTdF2ZwGBpLqCZJOFK5JkzSg6y7LismdtQRHPinnt5ShTWvbpYjUllacEqYufgfkoW4qnmn@SfCj@fgEuqZrX7c3/8isDcypbvKoY4/wP)

Comment: Very slightly disappointed Mathematica doesn't have a function for this :)

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 6, 86 bytes

```
{my \n=$^m/2;^$m .permutations.map({[*] .map(->\a,\b{$m[a][b]})}).sum/(2**n*[*] 1..n)}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>87</s> 86 bytes

```javascript
f=A=>A[0]?A[0].reduce((y,x,i)=>i&&y+x*f((g=B=>B.filter((_,j)=>j&&i-j))(A).map(g)),0):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/dboMwDIXveQquULKlLgl/ZVKY6GsgNCEKLIgBomxqn57Fgf5I241jn2OfT2mLn@JcTmqcd/1wqpZxUv0sy6E/D10F3dBYn0Xdq6KXSy1TmaSZm79jgak6fZcVIVd2YYrKRDnO9fXyUhPSyKNMjlCrbq4mQj5Yq@3WcdSupZSkFL6KkTSUMpe@8ZVINgrJMpfZPgQ5szP9MNvNc0qt/V4P1r@rEZbw6UgL2hDA9Qv@qoU3gdkcxCMcfCM8MDyE2PsD4uAhgN@WwcUSo7YBOPYCKdF9yWRH6PO75a9XptMh3uqbQLNkLIGdh0wOh9WPt8DtysMxeOKvLBNoroyFo9g@JkIBfnBYfgE)

This is a port of Kirill's algorithm, and this turns out to be shorter than the naive approach! However I'm retaining my original answer and posting this as a separate one.

#### Explanation

```javascript
f = A =>                               // A function receiving an array as input
 A[0]                                  //  If A is not empty:
  ? A[0].reduce((y, x, i) =>           //   Calculate the sum
   i                                   //   for i = 1 to 2n - 1:
   && y + x * f(                       //    A[0][i] * the hafnian of
    (g = B =>
     B.filter((_, j) => j && i - j)    //    array A removing rows 0 and i
    )(A).map(g)                        //    as well as columns 0 and i
   ),
   0
  )
  : 1                                  //  If A is empty: return 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 51 bytes

```
h(m)=if(#m,sum(n=2,#m,m[1,n]*h(m[^n,^n][^1,^1])),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7dDsIgDIVfhcybYbpmhek0y3wRwhJv1CVCiD8XPv2kRXdTes6hX5vOj7m5pmW51UGP86XeBHi@Qx1HA7kNjiD6bQ7dFGGK3k0EE3mtgfRyTun@qYNqTio95vjKbcWiUkzToJxrQXW4G7iAan22xOm57Ncsy2wbpPxiN5SsSFCE5j@PncgfidAygf4etlyO7AmDuDMM6tcvAuiHIk2547helAGWU0HJFwkMd5a3ER6GskNQvwnLcrfuLTsEJRNQPIvGe718AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>185</s> 181 bytes

```python
def f(m):
 a=0;n=len(m)//2
 for x in itertools.permutations(range(n*2)):p=1;[p:=p*m[x[2*j]][x[2*j+1]]for j in range(n)];a+=p
 return a/(math.factorial(n)*2**n)
import math,itertools
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NbsMgEITvfoo9GgcRg8m//CSIA2rtxlEMiBApfXp3107Tqj3AwMzsB/Ezn4Nv9jFN03vXQ1@O7FiAa@uTb6@dx@t6rQroQ4IHDB6G3KUcwvUmYpfGe3Z5CP5WJuc/utJXirFjbOXJxGMbq9E8jKou1i66ktYS6EKg5wSzJ7dqYwGpy/fkwa3L0eWz6N1bDmlwV6xUqqo8K4YxhpSBYv76xhTT4HPZl8bUHLTYWA4GhUNtLWPFn3hH2/ZXEQ0MlJCoQi/e9tvgIIX6AQo9G//RUjRc4wSFtahxHfCONEOuRlfhQ0uqUXeYyKer5y5pzZs5IQKl5CrUBulS7OfkMBOWboPnzeudmUsE6pKLZ0X/nL4A)

Golfed reference implementation provided in the question.