# Output Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

## Challenge

The goal is to output `Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo`.

[Context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo). (Maybe another interesting challenge could be printing all of the [other examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_linguistic_example_sentences#Lexical_ambiguity)? This would probably use similar logic but involve either a function or just a for loop.)

## Rule(s)

1. You cannot output anything other than the string with correct casing and spacing. Trailing new lines are allowed, trailing spaces are not.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes win!

Comment: By the way, there is also an [anarchy golf](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?Buffalo) version of this question.

Answer (score 98):

## [Buffalo](https://bfalo.com/), <sup><s>2711</s> <s>2571</s> <s>2517</s> <s>2447</s> <s>2279</s></sup> 2183 bytes

*It takes 304 buffalo to produce 8 buffalo?!* Yep, you herd that right.

```
BuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffalo(buffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffalo(buffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffalo(buffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffalobuffalobuffalo)buffaloBuffalobuffalobuffalobuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffalobuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffalobuffalobuffalo)Buffalobuffalobuffalobuffalo)buffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffalo..buffaloBuffalobuffalobuffalobuffalobuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalobuffalobuffalobuffalobuffalobuffalobuffalobuffalobuffalo.BuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffaloBuffalo.BuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffalo.buffaloBuffalo..buffaloBuffalobuffalobuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.BuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalo..buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffaloBuffalo(BuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffaloBuffalo.BuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffalo.buffaloBuffalo..buffaloBuffalobuffalobuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalobuffalobuffalo)BuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalo..buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.BuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffaloBuffaloBuffalo.BuffalobuffaloBuffalobuffalo.buffaloBuffalo..buffaloBuffalobuffalobuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.buffaloBuffalo.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Vlbb@M2Fn73r2CnRi1NHDst0H2I47TJTNIam9qDXHZQBIFBybRNjCxpJSpOtuvfPnt40V2U5Exmb6geYok8PPzO/ZDx1/7nk5/8td8Zvn3beYvOo@USOx66wu4KTVxGAj8g8Bd9@PVDhxP8jQQh9Vx0NPhefL/HLiUO@oU@uuQZrRnzj4fDFWXryBrY3ma4WIkZQXtFbeKGZIEidwEs2ZqgMx/b8KNm@gn7HwZHyOAEb9TUG3MEHJ69CG3wM3I9hqKQAAsaoiV1CCJPNvEZoi6CXX2HYtcmaAs4xDaKyQBY/K5YeBbDQI2B3oevZZYOYSYAK3G22@0AC6ADL1gNHUkUDq8m7y6mNxeHAFaQ37kOCUMUkL9HNAAxrWeEfcBiYwsQOniLvADhVUBgjnkc6zagjLqrPgq9JdvigACXBQ1ZQK2I5RQVIwN5swSgKuyiN2c3aHLzBp2f3Uxu@sDj4@T219ndLfp4dn19Nr2dXNyg2TV6N5u@n9xOZlP4ukRn09/RXyfT931EQE2wDXkCWwN@AEm5CsmC6@uGkByApScBhT6x6ZLaIJe7ivCKoJX3SAIXxEE@CTY05IYMAd4CuDh0QxlmYqQk1EBo72eHup@QepTmLe6M3I8081WOxgkl1AxhKxMOO7aDQQEqCDLu3/mj0@HceJAItmAmsqQuqMHbEHAhN2TYZaGaHIpfMYpu5@9mv/12Mb1FY9RLPnqjHMn53eXl2dVsfvfucnJ9o0gLg5olV7OPF9f5BWKoQA7e8OFOMZbvBYKr2ezD/Pzil8lUEqXfVYQX0/cZMvgCoqKG5sz7BFpWn/Hoz48YgiAIIAS7igKB0j2bYu7QDjg3j0bfA//hYROTuAvuMhQc59kneUX7gceIzVcnHMdyC6MTO0xInOXxcYWmT4uU/OmFzy7DTz0@3VPu0EsozL6WrbJGM1OrBdPYZs3cBrV8sqZt5mU08xLWb@ZkZjiJN7PCScB4qwBv6rxEkXAP5Dk7FLkjHrSIyDg44IUFhzyhr@O1Wi@JF4@RGzlOBSpuHgj7ClA898KGXUWSB2VHQUBc5kDitxl9JEgRQarfkI0X6BEpQi2gkP6DVMGhkKRWsLArKKCyPQGHjQUjEER4seAZXZSfELIfCVsgEXzG6Icf/1IBI7e20liSotJWodpaYtECUERxCFc6jcflDmqdRpLkgYRktQH7ZOwkyeJ63KCamGcdtKWDV7U5TxAUYD2HjGzAtSAFoiyDMgS5ugaADMAaAJIgD0BkTbD7Qi1HDJoUhJeMSA8TZVCU7zywyIJKmrDUOe@CWNGqCpHleQ6B/qUrKEBO2EtoIVR7E6jYiMKbfm@5dAyII1JhjrkoW0FkMzAuW3uLIg7IHHiTRHU@G8WzeZzJJOgkClz06NFFFbRl5NocdhaE0U1TT6/XT@FDMQiJzJJ/JFmzy/vbw9OYRhKPitMi9yWMTTm/K6sCUgFhl8J/6lSh3OQTeQ6bJU08MxU23cYQTFJnLYpHl8j4RtCYmVEhWW5hbipbjFQz1dcSFKp9M6Go33oyWZH182mlbaCBCpojMFOr7lL7ClXGapjDOceZc8VIvfbRkVnyhXx@gFQarMA1snN9xVbvJ3Ey0HjJPr4QszJKni3r3RVxV3BEG/P4c4ibIJWzcXbjDxw7eDJIKJLOESSHhpD3G10xxl0p70tiuLwTH72P@5WH7F6xb@ZWnuYxFz1WdchwmuNpKDu6KzMOIwtgzPlJFc58Ban7qIitjw6zUEw0Ho/B@EVBE9g53Z7mFFBawJ/vvkNdwCIqI0@kdKMQlpAdFaGYlSgyDilluH/QB7MmqDUNZvHJNpyxENoFZuWMOSoN78oy7SVPwSc7LbbMq1qUh1EZhQy@ooPl3ypCOqnhZ47zCmGdZWdoilamWToqp6l8jydSm3HUT6Z5D1qd3zLVpWI2AWbkzKXPdcmCNiVRtTm3omOTbZIH54@0QyKLwsINfQLFGaK4/1O16iZ0GUo1H9fERVaAXXvNuw8Y9OD84nieH/OBR9xx5bq1uItWzawEQR6xE4kjNGaCirPphYi4i6KNJSpuaY5pVQYi6eRm1F2QJ86T88uya@EeRtoZqhagnwqv6XlEBlNmK@YWKAJGVwLiXoXU@wmoJ3KT3cx44uCgMjuFW8qgkkANjVfcS/oHfTb7Fl2B@OicrKhbSWDjkFS0AcfaXJTIoV4OKpxYBkfIb6tiqP2U/nuzXww2kw@PtHtaUEM/jWolvIjt2ygftDDHHe1Wwoyxqb8Zx8bW6TdfdrM54j7m8pCWPdTwKD@XmhrVku86bRiV00tijVjzI71gO0RA9gbc5Ikyo3eJGXYQCQIvOEZ3LnnyZXD10KB8BTOAYVFfeqZeyJ3O3F7E/Ig1G1v2vHpHJvbaQ/Y6KNkt75oP5kv9Ut2/NSMtdPtN3pntiu81PB6a3K1BaB7f9RQHB@iU37b82OjVP3EqdNy45agV4EwhlblZd2aqPiOZZv02yqR7emU72wgArS2T1pvCiNS8oWpHTqkmOoT02sIi2sUZO8UA/oft8i2y9g1Cgeb432fmFwfg4SE6gbrSwthHfwbf/olRG34v0/v/QTAtyBJHDqtpDXMGqOpTH9DBuEWjV9/s7KpuPNILxyoDi1rfO4EW6JR3JOLCdl6s/H1xF2vy9uRkKEhH@zJSVv5yTnGbVs8nowndEVpcsr7oCrntLXH@GldcAGiO1sVDVfkcnDLh90yh71CWvSDuVIV7PF1x6MrdvMW8@dWbOsPwq5c1Dqo8pnCtMRhLUv39R3plqL/l0J/7xYVEfNrfdVyyrfhvvnFycqLi/LOabfFjWK1JX2nhi9m8dMM/1xVIXvUr/2O2oGmP0Gqe@ypC7C/hF5pwYNV97sFn0EI865X3bL9lLZy9bXfeYmFRyFqw9Ropfn6NYGrYcj@Ar2Rf4wtF@w@bqY6T@fXT49e06H@9KT6rfsQcff4X)
Link is to a Buffalo interpreter written in PHP (the header is copied from [GitHub](https://github.com/bfalo/buffalo-lang/blob/master/interpreters/PHP/BuffaloInterpreter.php)). You can also copy-and-paste the code above into the [official online interpreter](https://bfalo.com/#showcase).

Buffalo is a cell-based language like brainfuck or COW. It has seven instructions:

- `Buffalobuffalo` and `buffaloBuffalo` move the pointer to the left and right, respectively,
- `BuffaloBuffalo` and `buffalobuffalo` increment and decrement the current cell value, respectively,
- `(` and `)` begin and end loops, and
- `.` outputs the ASCII character corresponding to the current cell value.

Aiming to get the ASCII codes of `Bufalo`  into successive cells, we first do a coarse initialisation using three nested loops. A correction is then applied to each cell (outside the loops) as necessary. The selected iteration counts (3 for the outer and middle loops and 4 for the inner loop) are apparently [optimal](https://tio.run/##hVRNb9swDD3Pv@KtBtakdb1@3ApkQ7dTD90OuwwIgkG26VaJLbn6SJcl@e0Z5bhulg4pgQhi/B5FkY8yPltsNjHupJK1r6F8nZGBLqEbMsJJrSwMPXppqIDTuCeHmx9fb2@R64JsQB5/8aWoNI4hFSOsz3OyVs4JOVWVjSJD1lfOYoTlGjFmtIC0EMaIReBXWjew8g/ZBHNRefrna58HH@iVs1HJcc4@DfJEDbFEnpaFnA/UMDX8ucA6urv5yYiryyi6TH3j9ID/GKLQWMkVgsU7t5Suv6VU0J7dNp8I2GdPVwe5tSyKip7JwMUefbY6QJZKvRwcrOYrSJxg2vmK/Zr9WefP2D@HLMNmhIuQmKgq/WRRaoNGc/0zWUnXlnDqrYN70u0B4TzrSBThi3swRFEXM8a3Pj1RFPJ18y03/6VbW1ZHdpzQWCaYJphNDkb8aH3mjMi34bm7rUzavHeE1Yc9HSEopxdZmi0c2bQWTVvWbBW9G3fgYA1jy3GWQE0S7Fq8V@d3wGOLNbxmOGPmCVSCmnnxfkMZbBjyyJAaexYH2VhZbKG2z2XS7UgV/6tHo3laeFvrOdXEwsZAabcVuVT33BptiVfhoPPcm5ASzckskAtLw936vNz/khMc2NRIVdDvJVYiAZciX0HgfRDMGqcsFp7HnKfsfJi8qsqbgbJDgfZnoFNqIHzm3zWu8LbFvVREtVOdpwdSXA4y2@eBt9IUu0f1quuem3Evxwl32EXPvdiubVdqGeaqw6ft28PKkupXtgh35rKlZSWcI5VaXw8@XIvMDvmJabjhOPreOFlzjjsTMUK8fA7Hz9yAYw3XR5vNXw). The ASCII code for the lowercase `b` does not get its own cell; rather, we generate it on the fly in the `a` cell.

Once the ASCII codes have been generated, the output is printed character-by-character as `Buffalo buffalo Buffalo (buffalo )Buffalo buffalo`, where the segment in parentheses represents a loop that runs 3 times.

Comment: The right language for the job?

Comment: The code-golf rule should make an exception. This one _is_ the winner

Comment: Brings new meaning to the "thundering herd problem".

Answer (score 61):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 28 bytes

```bash
echo {B,b,B,b,b,b,B,b}uffalo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1@h2kknSQeEkyB0bWlaWmJO/v//AA)

[Brace expansion (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)

Same length, slightly more interesting:

```bash
echo {B,b,B,b{,,},B,b}uffalo
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @mowwwalker Added a link to the Bash Reference Manual.

Comment: Nice. Bare word in bash doesn't even require quoting.

Comment: @jimfan That's Bash's secret: everything is a word. `echo foo` is the same as `'echo' 'foo'` is the same as `"echo" "foo"` is the same as `x=echo y=foo; $x $y`. Quoting just changes whether splitting or globbing happens.

Comment: Tcl with trailing space: https://tio.run/##K0nO@f8/JzexQCFZodpJIUkBhJMgdK1CdUFpSbGCbl5@Xmp5TmZeqoJKdXJtaVpaYk5@jELt//8A

Comment: I like the choice of language (Bash is 'GNU' software).

Answer (score 29):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 36 bytes

```python
for c in'BbBbbbBb':print c+'uffalo',
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFZITNP3SnJKSkJiNWtCooy80oUkrXVS9PSEnPy1XX@/wcA)

Relies on the Python 2 print magic that automagically adds a space before a printed object [if it thinks it's not at the beginning of a line](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement).

### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) (anagol), 36 bytes

```python
print'uffalo '.join('BbBbbb'*2)[:63]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EvTQtLTEnX0FdLys/M09D3SnJKSkpSV3LSDPaysw49v9/AA)

A trivial modification of the [anagol solution](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?Buffalo/kt3k_1265291869&py) is the same length.

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 38 bytes

```python
print(*[x+'uffalo'for x in'BbBbbbBb'])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQyu6Qlu9NC0tMSdfPS2/SKFCITNP3SnJKSkJiNVjNf//BwA)

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 41 bytes

```python
print(*map("{}uffalo".format,'BbBbbbBb'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQys3sUBDqbq2NC0tMSdfSS8tvyg3sURH3SnJKSkJiNU1Nf//BwA)

Comment: -1 for using `x` and `c` for variable names instead of `b` 

Answer (score 20):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 14 bytes

```
wM?Im_ḋ162¨Ḃ=F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v9zX3jM3/uGObkMzo0MrHu5osnX7/x8A)

This was a simple challenge but fun :)

#### Explanation

```
wM?Im_ḋ162¨Ḃ=F
          ¨Ḃ=F    Taking the compressed string "Buffalo" (uppercase B)
 M                For each digit in    
      ḋ162         the binary digits of 162 ([1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0]):
  ?               if the digit is 1
   I               return the string itself
                  if the digit is 0
    m_             convert each character to lowercase
w                 Join all strings with spaces
```

Answer (score 13):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 32 bytes

```perl
@_=<{,b,B,b}uffalo>;say"B@_ b@_"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/98h3tamWidJx0knqbY0LS0xJ9/OujixUsnJIV4hySFe6f//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

Beats the best anagol answer by one byte:

```perl
@_=($_=Buffalo,lc)x2,print"@_ \l@_." # Mithran
@_=<{,b,B,b}uffalo>;print"B@_ b@_."  # Sisyphus
```

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

*Inspired by [@Leo's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393/leo) [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218298/94066), so make sure to upvote him!* <sub>and me too please ;)</sub>

```
Ƶzbε'±ˆsi™]ðý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9vc2FiaWX//8a1emLOtSfCscuGc2nihKJdw7DDvf//)

```
Ƶzbε'±ˆsi™]ðý  # full program
            ý  # join...
    '±ˆ        # "buffalo"...
   ε           # for map over all digits of...
Ƶz             # 162...
  b            # in binary...
         ™     # in title case...
        i      # if...
       s       # current digit in...
   ε           # map over all digits of...
Ƶz             # 162...
  b            # in binary...
        i      # is 1...
           ð   # by spaces
          ]    # exit if statement and map
               # implicit output
```

## Boring, trivial alternative, 64 bytes

```
"Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fyak0LS0xJ18hCUqj85Pwy///DwA)

```
"...  # full program
"...  # literal
      # implicit output
```

**EDIT**: I have stood unbeaten for three months... Brownie points to anyone who outgolfs me.* Oh, and possibly some rep if I like your answer. ;)

<sub>*Just to clarify, outgolfs in any language will be accepted. It doesn't have to be 05AB1E.</sub>

Comment: +1 for winking buffalo `'±ˆ`

Comment: @workoverflow lol

Comment: get golfed. ¯\\_( ͡~ ͜ʖ ͡°)\_/¯

Comment: @Lyxal well yes, but actually no. :P

Answer (score 10):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 20 bytes

```
8ibuffalo <esc>xbb~5b~0~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3yIzqTQtLTEnX0G6IimpzjSpzqDu/38A)

- `8ibuffalo <esc>`, write "buffalo " 8 times. cursor at end of line.
- `x` remove current character (the space at end of line).
- `bb` move to the 2nd words beginning from cursor (move left).
- `~` toggle letter case, and also move cursor 1 char right.
- `5b~` move to the 5th words beginning from cursor (move left). And toggle case.
- `0~` move to line beginning. And toggle case.

Answer (score 9):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 25 bytes

```
BbBbbbBb
.
$&uffalo 
 $
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fyynJKSkJiLn0uFTUStPSEnPyFbgUVLj@/wcA) Explanation:

```
BbBbbbBb
```

Insert the `b`s in the correct capitalisation.

```
.
$&uffalo
```

Expand the buffalo (buffaloes?).

```
 $
```

Remove the trailing space.

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Dingus*

```r
cat(c('buffalo','Buffalo')[1+!21%%1:8])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCNZQz2pNC0tMSdfXUfdCcrSjDbUVjQyVFU1tLKI1fz/HwA)

Chooses whether to output 'buffalo' or 'Buffalo' by indexing with the vector `2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1`, which is constructed as the zero values of `21` modulo each of `1...8`, plus one.

Sadly, trying to recycle the 'uffalo' is significantly longer ([54 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKMgsbgkVaM4OTFPQ0ddXVNHvTQtLTEnX12nOLXAFiigyeXElQTGSVD6/38A)) due to [R](https://www.r-project.org/)'s somewhat cumbersome string-manipulation functions (*Edit after reading the 'Anarchy Golf' link: still longer, but can be done in [46 bytes](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?Buffalo/pooq_1265963786&r)*)

Comment: @Dingus - Nice!  Thanks!  How did I manage to miss that?

Answer (score 8):

## TI-BASIC, 47 bytes

```
"uffalo
Ans+" b"+Ans
Ans+" B"+Ans
"B"+Ans+" b"+Ans
```

Builds the sentence up in chunks to eliminate the need for string variables which are two byte tokens; Ans is always a single byte even when it holds a string. The strategy also minimizes use of the lowercase letters as they are two byte tokens. The final line is automatically output and you can scroll left-right for the full sentence.

Comment: Is this actually 47 bytes? Shouldn't Ans count as 1?

Comment: The lowercase characters are 2 bytes

Answer (score 8):

### LabVIEW, 20 bytes

[image: LabVIEW code (masked to 0)]

[image: LabVIEW code (masked to nonzero)]

Graphical languages are harder to count, so here's my attempt:

- 1 byte loop termination
- 1 byte for the loop
- 1 byte for the integer we encode the capitalization in
- 6 bytes for the 'uffalo' string
- 1 byte for the mask we apply to the integer encoding
- 1 byte for the case structure
- 1 byte for the AND
- 1 byte for the left shift function
- 2 bytes for the capital and noncapital letters in the case structure
- 1 byte for the concatenate string function
- 2 bytes for format string spec
- 1 byte for the delimiter (space)
- 1 byte for the array to spreadsheet string function

And yes, how'd you know about my EE degree?

Comment: This is like asking how Python counts the literal `"uffalo"` as 6 bytes. Of course the underlying implementation uses more bytes, but for the purposes of *counting* bytes in code golf, graphical languages [are counted differently](https://meta.ppcg.lol/a/7589/41024). If we're talking purely memory usage, it's more like 240k bytes, but that's not how any other languages are counted.

Answer (score 7):

### Batch, <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```
@set s=B_b_B_b_b_b_B_buffalo
@echo %s:_=uffalo %
```

Batch's string handling is so poor it's golfier to explicitly include the last "buffalo" rather than trying to trim the trailing space at the end.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 46 bytes

Builds the string recursively and in reverse order.

```javascript
f=n=>(n>6?'':f(-~n)+' ')+"bB"[n&n!=3]+'uffalo'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1k4jz87MXl3dKk1Dty5PU1tdQV1TWynJSSk6Ty1P0dY4Vlu9NC0tMSdf/X9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqbmfwA)

#### Alternate version

```javascript
f=n=>(n>6?'':f(-~n)+' ')+"bB"[25/n&1]+'uffalo'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1k4jz87MXl3dKk1Dty5PU1tdQV1TWynJSSnayFQ/T80wVlu9NC0tMSdf/X9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqbmfwA)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = n =>             // f is a recursive function taking a counter n,
                     // which is initially undefined (zero'ish)
  ( n > 6 ?          // if n is greater than 6 (last iteration):
      ''             //   append nothing
    :                // else:
      f(-~n)         //   append the result of a recursive call with n + 1
      + ' '          //   followed by a space
  )                  //
  + "bB"[n & n != 3] // append "B" if n is odd and not equal to 3,
                     // or "b" otherwise
  + 'uffalo'         // append "uffalo"
```

Comment: `' Buffalo buffalo'.repeat(4).slice(1) ` saves a few bytes

Comment: @Alexbries The expected output is not `Buffalo buffalo` repeated 4 times. The 5th word is in lower case.

Answer (score 7):

### x86-16 machine code, <s>43</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

- -1 byte thanks to @CodyGray.
- -1 byte thanks to @640KB.

```
0BED:0100  BA 19 01 BE 22 01 B4 09-B1 07 CD 21 AC A2 19 01   ...."......!....
0BED:0110  E2 F8 C6 44 F7 24 CD 21-C3 42 75 66 66 61 6C 6F   ...D.$.!.Buffalo
0BED:0120  20 24 62 42 62 62 62 42-62                         $bBbbbBb
```

Instruction listing (nasm syntax):

```
    org 100h      ;           | Execution of .COM files start at CS:0100

    mov dx, msg   ; BA 1B 01  | DX = offset of "Buffalo $" (for INT 21H)
    mov si, buf   ; BE 24 01  | SI = Address of "bBbbbBb"  (for LODSB)
    mov ah, 09h   ; B4 09     | AH = Opcode code INT 21H   (Output string up to '$')
    mov cl, 7     ; B1 07     | CX = 7 (we want to iterate 7 times before the last 'Buffalo')
loop:
    int 21h       ; CD 21     | Output string at msg
    lodsb         ; AC        | AX = [SI], ++SI
    mov byte [msg], al
                  ; A2 1B 01  | Set the first character of msg as the current character at buf
    loop loop     ; E2 F8     | Jump to tag 'loop' while CX >= 0
    mov byte [si - 9], "$"
                  ; C6 44 F7 24 | (After loop) Replace the last space with a '$'
    int 21h       ; CD 21     | Print the last 'buffalo'
    ret           ; C3        | Exit to DOS

msg:    db "Buffalo $"
buf:    db "bBbbbBb"
```

### Example run

```
C:\test>debug code.com
-g
Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo
Program terminated normally
```

Comment: Thanks to DOS's CP/M compatibility, you can exit from a .COM executable simply by returning. That takes your 2-byte `int 20h` down to a 1-byte `ret`. (The return will return to address `0000h`, which already contains an `int 20h`. See also: [Why does MS-DOS put an `int 20h` at byte 0 of the COM file program segment?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200309-00/?p=103547))

Comment: Very nice! I think you can -1 byte by replacing `mov byte [msg + 7], "$"` (`C6 06 22 01 24`) with `mov byte [si - 9], "$"` (`C6 44 F7 24`).

Comment: I couldn't help but take another look at this with fresh eyes and came up with a [riff on your answer that's 39 bytes](https://godbolt.org/z/WebET3). Oh, and it's got more of those one-byte instructions as a bonus. Now I'm done, for sure this time! :)

Comment: Wait, no, lies. [38 bytes](https://godbolt.org/z/f1vocf)...

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>62</s> 61 bytes

Realised the 61 byte version was not compliant (outputted a space at the end). Reverted and updated it to be.

-1 byte thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)

```c
f(n){for(n=8;n--;)printf("%cuffalo%s","bBbbbBbB"[n]," "+!n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcNBCoAgEADAc76iFoRdynsgXfxGdFBhQ6g1rE7R262BiWaNsVZGoYdzQZlGK8ZYOkqSixF0vJn9lvUJAwQXwt/BLMsALfSdkH3r7pMgqUc1jGTVWz8)

Comment: I noticed that in TIO is not possible to use `0` (that is the right character to use) in place of `10`, so to regain the byte lost, I checked for a substitute of `32` and found that `9` works.

Comment: @Davide Ehhh tab is not the same as space, so I disagree that 9 is a replacement for 32. Also not sure what you mean by 0 instead of 10; same thing there: Different characters.

Comment: 0 would be the null character, so you don't print nothing more than your buffaloes. However in TIO the 0 is displayed as an empty rectangle, so we have to use a newline at the end.

Comment: @Arnauld Neato!

Comment: @Davide No, if you order printf to print a NUL character, a NUL character will be printed. It won't magically disappear.

Comment: @Davide: the question says to output the string as shown.  It doesn't say "so it looks the same on a terminal which ignores `0` bytes", so you're not allowed to print garbage bytes like ASCII `0` at the end.  That would be noticeable piping into `hexdump -C`, or redirecting to a file.  Tabs instead of spaces is *maybe* justifiable, especially since standard tab-stops are 8 spaces, and "buffalo" is 7 letters long.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance please. I thought the null character was literally nothing when printed.

Comment: @Arnauld Very nice. Sadly, I lost compliance using it, so must find a way around it.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 43 bytes

```javascript
write(a=`B${b='uffalo'} b`+b,a,c='b'+b,c,a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v7wosyRVI9E2wUmlOslWvTQtLTEnX71WISlBO0knUSfZVj1JHchK1knU/P8fAA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
init$"BbBbbbBb">>=(:"uffalo ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v9g2My@zREXJKckpKQmIlezsbDWslErT0hJz8hWUNP/nJmbmKVhZKXj6K2hocoF5tgoFpSXBJUU@eQrF/wE)

(Cf. [Are objects in Haskell valid if there is no input?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12924/are-objects-in-haskell-valid-if-there-is-no-input/12945#12945))

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
Ｆ⍘¹⁶²bB«ιuffalo→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwymxODW4pCgzL13D0MxIR0EpyUlJU1OhmoszAChYopGpaQ1jKpWmpSXm5CuBRHzzy1I1rIIy0zNKgNza////65blAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⍘¹⁶²bB«
```

Convert 162 to base 2, but use `b` for 0 and `B` for 1, and loop over the "digits".

```
ι
```

Print the `b` or `B`.

```
uffalo
```

Print the rest of the buffalo.

```
→
```

Prepare to leave a space before the next `b`, if any.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 38 bytes

```perl
$,=$";say$_=Buffalo,lc,$_,(lc)x3,$_,lc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19Fx1ZFybo4sVIl3tapNC0tMSdfJydZRyVeRyMnWbPCGMTKSf7//19@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQwMA)

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 45 bytes

```javascript
_=>[...'BbBbbbBb'].map(x=>x+'uffalo').join` `
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcNbCoAgEADAq/SnEu0N7MNrROQjDcVcyQpvvzUwybymuSvWeyq4ewqSNjkvAMCUVdb@2QqnqbzLuY/sCcFkZAISxqIHTQ5Lw@wh48EDF4I@)

Comment: Does JavaScript code like this even need to be in lambda function form? Python3 code doesn't have all their code in `lambda: CODE`. For something that requires input, it would make sense, but this challenge is to just output the `Buffalo` string, and an evaluation of `[...'BbBbbbBb'].map(x=>x+'uffalo').join\` \`` works fine

Comment: @Samathingamajig by removing `_=>`, an `alert(...)` may be required to _print_ it out.

Comment: but shouldn't the `f= ` be counted too?

Comment: @Alexbries Anonymous function as submission is allowed as long as you do not need to (recursively) invoke it.

Comment: [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcTBDYAgDADAVfy1xNgN8MEaxhhAaiCEGhHXRx53yX62@ife71LkDJ11P/S6EREYZ5wbYKcksSA2DY3ZZgE1wzRq3UupkgNluZBRqf4D "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 63 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @Arnauld

```c
n=7;f(){printf("%cuffalo%c","bBbbbBbB"[n],9+!n),n--?f():(n=7);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dh9z/P1tw6TUOzuqAoM68kTUNJNbk0LS0xJ181WUlHKckpKQmInZSi82J1LLUV8zR18nR17YHqrTSAGjWta/8DdSnkJmbmaWgqVHNxKQABUNYazAATRaklpUV5CgbWXLX/AQ)

Could have been shorter if it wasn't for the reusability rule killing recursive functions.

Comment: @Arnauld i couldn't see it. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is invalid, you init `n=7` by calling this as `f(7)`. It *has* to be called as `f(7)` or it doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you just write it as `f(char*s){printf(s);}` and pass in the output string? T_T

Comment: @Noodle9 oh thank you! I swear that the `Kolmogorov-complexity` wasn't there when I read the challenge, so I assumed I could have passed the number of words to output as a parameter

Comment: Regardless of a [Kolmogorov-complexity] tag, requiring the caller to hard-code a `7` based on the internal implementation details is not ok.  Generalizing the task to print some pattern of buffalos and requiring the caller to pass a `7` is solving a different question (and very hard to justify when only numbers <=7 work because you hard-coded a lookup table of that length.)  TL:DR: I would have downvoted the first version of this answer regardless of tags, but this is good.  I'm not sure tabs are allowed instead of spaces, but I like that `9+!n` enough to upvote anyway :P

Comment: @PeterCordes all right, I need to make less assumptions. Anyway this `9+!n` is @Arnauld's contribution

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <del>39</del> 36 bytes

```powershell
''+('BbBbbbBb'|% t*y|%{$_+'uffalo'})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X11dW0PdKckpKQmI1WtUFUq0KmtUq1XitdVL09ISc/LVazX//wcA)

-3 bytes thanks to @mazzy!

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X11dW0PdKckpKQmI1WtUFUq0KmtUq1XitdVL09ISc/LVazX//wcA "PowerShell – Try It Online") ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: OMG @mazzy you saved my 3 bytes, you are always a life saver!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 42 bytes

```
join(collect("BbBbbbBb").*"uffalo ")[1:63]
```

Very similar to what was done with Python above.

Comment: [-4 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPhfUJSZV6LxPys/M0/DOSOxSE8jSckpySkpCYiVNPW0lErT0hJz8pV0lBSUNP9r/gcA)

Comment: -9 bytes here https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218439/47730

Comment: This appears to be just a literal string. A [full program or function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/92901) is required. Or if it's supposed to be used in a [REPL](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7844/92901) then the header should say so.

Answer (score 4):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), <s>86</s> 79 bytes

```
> "Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo"
>> Output 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTkHJqTQtLTEnXyEJSqPzk/DLK3HZ2Sn4l5YUlJYoGP7/DwA)

Well, this is embarrassing...

The first line alone could even be enough, as a function returning the string

For something a bit more interesting, here's my previous solution:

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 86 bytes

```
> "Buffalo "
> "buffalo "
>> 1+2
>> 3+3
>> 2+2
>> 5+3
>> 4+6
> 63
>> 7ᶠ8
>> Output 9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTkHJqTQtLTEnX0GJC8hJQnDsFAy1jUCUsbYxiDKC8EwhPBNtM6B6MzDb/OG2BRYghn9pSUFpiYLl//8A)

First approach to the [language of the month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20698/62393) for me :) It looks like building the string by manually concatenating pieces is the best approach in Whispers.

#### Explanation

Whispers starts the execution from the last line of the program, and then follows references from there. Any number in a line starting with `>>`  refers to the result of the corresponding line, while numbers in lines starting with `>`  have their normal value. We can only have a single operation per line (hence why so many lines).

Most lines here simply concatenate two strings, while line 9 takes the first `63` characters from the string in line 7, which is all except for the trailing space. It should be pretty easy to read, but here's the value computed by each line:

```
> "Buffalo "        1:"Buffalo "
> "buffalo "        2:"buffalo "
>> 1+2              3:"Buffalo buffalo "
>> 3+3              4:"Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo "
>> 2+2              5:"buffalo buffalo "
>> 5+3              6:"buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo "
>> 4+6              7:"Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo "
> 63                8:63
>> 7ᶠ8              9:"Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo"
>> Output 9         10:prints out line 9
```

Answer (score 4):

## TeX, 34 bytes

`\def~{uffalo }B~b~B~b~b~b~B~b~\bye`

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, nice first answer!

Answer (score 4):

## `awk`, 22- or 41-bytes. basic approach is 41-bytes:

```
echo Buffalo |
```

> ```
> mawk 'NF+=sub("  ",OFS=" "tolower($2=$4=$1)" ")'
> ```

```
Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo
```

but if we're going with the entirely hard-coded approach, that can massively cut it down to just 22-bytes (and that's already inclusive of the single quotes for `OFS`) :

```
echo BbBbbbBb |
```

> ```
> mawk NF++ FS= OFS='uffalo '
> ```

```
Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo
```

Trivia tidbit - if we view `"B"`'s as `"1"`'s and `"b"`'s as `"0"`'s,

then the requirement would appear 10100010, while its decimal form can be reached via either

> ```
>   2 * ( 3 ^ 4 )
>                 or
>   3  *  6 * 9
> ```

Comment: Nice approach, but you can't rely on your code receiving input (in this case 'BbBbbbBb'), so you need to include the ```echo``` in the byte count [like this](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/BKckpKQmIFWoUEsuzFfzctLUV3IJtFfyBhHppWlpiTr6C@v//AA)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen : u know full well that `awk` entries are instantly pre-penalized with having to either (1) invoke a `BEGIN { }` block, (2) use `echo/printf`, or (3) do `<<<` at the shell level, and that's before any of the code logic even began, with all options being rather costly, golfing-wise. if you're willing to use the byte-count only for the logic inside the `BEGIN { }` block itself instead of end-to-end, then i can write it with birdies and eagles

Comment: It may seem 'unfair' that awk entries are pre-penalized with ```BEGIN``` or ```echo``` or other costly code, but that's how it's scored.  Everyone should play by the same rules.  Other languages have seemingly-wasteful boilerplate too.  In the case of your ```mawk NF++ FS= OFS='uffalo ' ``` code as it is now (which is 27 bytes, not 22), you're not even counting the ```'BbBbbbBb'``` string, which is a fundamental part of the code logic.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen : say that "x86-16 machine code" entry below : can a file with only that and nothing else, with ".exe" extension, execute ?

Comment: I assume so, yes.  The screenshot below the entry seems to show it being run directly from the command-line prompt.  In any case it certainly doesn't need to be given any 'BbBbbbBb' or similar as input.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen : now you know why `DOS` had so many security holes . The best i could get to for now is `mawk 'BEGIN{print $(($(OFS="uffalo "(FS=_))="BbBbbbBb")*++NF)}'`

Comment: Well, I think you should simply amend your answer to 'bash+AWK' and include the ```echo``` for [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/BKckpKQmIaxLLsxX83LS1FdyCbRX8gYR6aVpaYk6@gvr//wA).  Your approach is really nice, and shorter than the [pure-awk one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218956/95126)

Comment: (I got 49, by the way: [try it](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06860VapNC0tMSdfQcnayVbJSSlRKUkp0bqgKDOvRMFJwQnEA2EFp9r//wE))...

Comment: The x86-16 machine code answer: no, it couldn't run as a `.exe`.  But yes as a `.com` executable which is how it's written; they have no metadata, they get loaded at a known offset into the OS's choice of segment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file#DOS_binary_format  .  Machine-code answers for other OSes typically still only count the machine-code itself, especially when the answer is just a function that could be part of a larger program.

Answer (score 3):

## [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/), 54 bytes

```
Print@@Riffle[#<>"uffalo"&/@Characters@"BbBbbbBb"," "]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxMEhKDMtLSc1WtnGTqk0LS0xJ19JTd/BOSOxKDG5JLWo2EHJKckpKQmIlXSUFJRi//8HAA)

Comment: [-6 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/d85I7EoMbkktajYQckpySkpCYiV6oIy09JyUuuUStPSEnPyFZRs7KBMpf@x/wE "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online") if you can assume a notebook environment (which I don't know if you can)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
162Bị“¢OỊ“¦ȯø»K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/QzMjp4e7uRw1zDi3yf7i7C8RYdmL94R2Hdnv//w8A)

(Alternatively, `162Bị“¢OỊ»,Œl¤K`)

I might be doing something wrong if this comes out two bytes shorter than title-casing dynamically...:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
Œt⁹¡
162B“¦ȯø»çⱮK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//xZJ04oG5wqEKMTYyQuKAnMKmyK/DuMK7w6fisa5L//8)

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 21 bytes

```
'BbBbbbBb',¨⊂'uffalo'
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv7pTklNSEhCr6xxa8airSb00LQ2oU/0/UPZ/GgA)

This could be shortened to 5 bytes if the two strings were given as input rather than being hard coded.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to ngn!

```
" "/"BbBbbbBb",\:"uffalo"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/19JQUlfySnJKSkJiJV0YqyUStPSEnPylf7/BwA)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 30 bytes

```
echo}:,/'BbBbbbBb',"{'uffalo '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I7/WSkdf3SnJKSkJiNV1lKrVS9PSEnPyFdT//wcA)

Comment: k: slightly shorter if you use _join_ (`" "/`)

Comment: @ngn I totally forgot `join` - thank you! I'll update the solution when TIO allows me (can't open it right now)

Comment: @Dingus Thank you! Apparently I haven't copied the text :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 49 bytes

```java
v->"B b B b b b B b".replaceAll("\\w","$0uffalo")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY09C8IwEIb3/oojOLSiwd0P0MHNSXBRh2ttJPWahORSEfG311TdHI6Xl@fhvQY7nDaXW69bZz1Dk7qMrEmqaCrW1sjxPPuDgX2N7YAqwhBgh9rAMwNwsSRdQWDkFJ3VF2gTy/fstbkez4D@GoqPCrD9vVgckjf5KitQsOy76UpsoIThym8K6WtHWNVrolycTncxEaNZVArJiqKffxb3j8B1K21k6dIak8mVROfokZtIVBSD9spe/Rs)

### Credits

- -14 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)
- -1 byte thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY27rsIwEET7fMXKokh4WLfnIZGCjgqJBlGsQ4wcNrZlryMhxLcHA7ejml2do5kOB1x0l9toeu8CQ5d/mdiQ1Mk2bJyV02XxAyOHFvs3aghjhD0aC48CwCdFpoHIyDkGZy7QZ1YeOBh7PZ0BwzVWHxVg9z@xOmZv/lU2oGE9DouNqFWtlKqFDK0nbNotUSmkmIvJX9IayYGoZkJ9bzEuP5WHe@S2ly6x9LmOSy3Re7qXNhFV1Vt6Fs/xBQ)

Comment: Nice find, @KevinCruijssen I was golfing byte by byte and you with a totally different approach, thanks :)

Comment: You can save another byte by moving the spaces to the string. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY09C8IwEIb3/oojOLSiwd0P0MHNSXBRh2ttJPWahORSEfG311TdHI6Xl@fhvQY7nDaXW69bZz1Dk7qMrEmqaCrW1sjxPPuDgX2N7YAqwhBgh9rAMwNwsSRdQWDkFJ3VF2gTy/fstbkez4D@GoqPCrD9vVgckjf5KitQsOy76UpsoIThym8K6WtHWNVrolycTncxEaNZVArJiqKffxb3j8B1K21k6dIak8mVROfokZtIVBSD9spe/Rs "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY09C8IwEIb3/oojOLRSg7sfoIObU8FFHK61kdRrEpJLoYi/vcaPzeHlOJ6H9@1wwEV3vU@6d9YzdOmXkTVJFU3D2ho5X2V/MLBvsX@jhjAEOKI28MgAXKxJNxAYOZ3B6iv0ieUVe21u5wugv4XiowIcfhPrU/LKr7IFBZtpWGzFvt7XdYqQvnWETbsjyoUUpZgto1JIFkQxrT5N1Ri47aWNLF1qYTK5kugcjbmJREXx1p7Zc3oB)

Comment: @branboyer actually, trailing spaces are explicitly disallowed, but thanks!

Comment: @Olivier Grégoire Ohhh, oops. Technically, OP didn't say anything about leading whitespace, so you could put the space at the start, but I doubt they would actually allow that and would just add a new rule.

Comment: @branboyer yes, they said something about it: "You cannot output anything other than the string with correct casing and **spacing**."

Answer (score 3):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 98 bytes

```
> 81
> 2
>> 1⊥2
> "Buffalo "
> "buffalo "
> "buffalo"
>> If L 4 5
>> Each 7 3
>> 8+6
>> Output 9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsHCkMtOwYjLzk7B8FHXUiBDQcmpNC0tMSdfQQnEScLCUQIp90xT8FEwUTAFsV0TkzMUzBWMQWwLbTMQ5V9aUlBaomD5//9/3RAA)

Comment: [94 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsHQzIjLTgGElZxK09ISc/IVlECcJAQHqOhR11IjEMMzTcFHwVjBBMR2TUzOUDBTMAWq1jUECZg/3LbAAsTwLy0pKC1RsPz/HwA) (spoilers)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 20 bytes

```
‥bB.¢`b}®:_”cåχíð”↔ù
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//1HD0iQnvUOLEpJqD62zin/UMDf58NLz7YfXHt4AZD9qm3J45///AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 39 bytes

```python
print('uffalo '.join('BbBbbbBb ')[:-2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ700LS0xJ19BXS8rPzNPQ90pySkpCYgV1DWjrXSNYjX//wcA)

### Potentially invalid, 35 bytes

```python
print('uffalo '.join('BbBbbbBb\b'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ700LS0xJ19BXS8rPzNPQ90pySkpCYhjktQ1Nf//BwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 370 bytes

```
>++++++++[>++++++++<-]<++++++++[>++++<-]>>++.--------[>++>++<<-]>+.>--------------..[>+>+>+<<<-]>-----.>++++++.+++.<<<<<.>>>>+.<<.>>>>..<<-.>---.+++.<<<<<.>++++++++[>>++++++++<<-]>>++.<.>>>>..<<.>---.+++.<<<<<.>>>>+.<<.>>>>..<<-.>---.+++.<<<<<.>>>>+.<<.>>>>..<<-.>---.+++.<<<<<.>>>>+.<<.>>>>..<<-.>---.+++.<<<<<.>>>.<.>>>>..<<.>---.+++.<<<<<.>>>>+.<<.>>>>..<<-.>---.+++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fThsKouEsG91YG1RRoIgdkKGnCwUgUSCyAYlr69npogA9PaA0CNqA5SFiUMP1QNgGBPTsgADEBjP0gAxdsEHIKhCOQLgN5hSEPgxthA2mjgoy3fD/PwA)

Not exactly the most optimized answer and could probably be golfed much further. Makes lots of use of copying cells, as well as repeadedly performing the same print function near the end.

Original un-minified version (sadly uncommented) [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/TheThunderGuyS/1fc08e8de4354b912f476b20c2074a16).

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL, <s>45 51</s> 47 bytes

```sql
PRINT REPLACE('B0 B0 b0 B0',0,'uffalo buffalo')
```

`PRINT` is shorter than `SELECT`. Using a numeral in the `REPLACE` eliminates a set of quotes and saves 2 bytes.

**EDIT**: Fixed trailing space, at the cost of 6 bytes. Saved 4 by replacing a longer phrase, thanks @Giuseppe

Comment: This has a trailing space, which isn't allowed in the rules

Comment: @ijustlovemath Fixed

Comment: You should be able to do something like [this](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCO9uDRJw1BHqTQtLTEnXyEJQivpKDkZKgBREojUU9LU/P8fAA)

Comment: Thanks, @Giuseppe, that save a few bytes. I don't believe the period at the end is required, though.

Answer (score 3):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>35</del> <del>33</del> 32 bytes

```
00000000: b820 09b1 e7ba 1801 cd21 d0e9 7409 7303  . .......!..t.s.
00000010: 3044 19cd 29eb f1c3 4275 6666 616c 6f24  0D..)...Buffalo$
```

Listing:

```
B8 0920     MOV  AX, 0920H          ; AH = 9 DOS string function, AL = ' ' 
B1 E7       MOV  CL, 11100111b      ; magic buffalo number 11100111 
BA 0118     MOV  DX, OFFSET BUF     ; 'Buffalo' pointer for display 
        STAMPEDE:
CD 21       INT  21H                ; write our *uffalo to screen 
D0 E9       SHR  CL, 1              ; LSB of magic buffalo number into CF 
74 09       JZ   BYE_BUFFALO        ; loop until CL is 0 
73 03       JNC  HI_BUFFALO         ; if LSB bit is a 0, don't change case 
30 44 19    XOR  [SI+BUF-100H], AL  ; swap case on first letter 
        HI_BUFFALO:  
CD 29       INT  29H                ; if not last of the buffalo, display a space 
EB F1       JMP  STAMPEDE           ; keep 'em coming 
        BYE_BUFFALO: 
C3          RET                     ; return to DOS 
        BUF:
            DB   'Buffalo$'         ; the real Buffalo
```

[Try it online!](http://twt86.co/?c=uCAJsee6GwGL2lDNIVjQ6XQIcwIwB80p6/DDQnVmZmFsbyQ=)

**Explanation:**

Uses the byte `0xe7` (`1110 0111` binary) to determine if the case should be swapped. Each `[Bb]uffalo` corresponds to the next least significant bit of the byte where a `1` means to change the case and a `0` means don't change.

The case of the first character can be alternated by doing an `xor 0x20` on the ASCII value. Now `0x20` just happens to be the ASCII value for a space character, so we can put that in `al` and use for both the `xor` and to write the space character.

[image]

**Props:**

- -1 byte thx to @peter ferrie!

Comment: XOR [SI+BUF-100h] allows dropping the MOV BX,DX, if SI=100h on entry like it is in MS-DOS.

Comment: XOR [SI+19],AL is 3 bytes.

Comment: Oh, I see - it looks like my assembler was using the 4 byte opcode (`80 84 1A 00` / `XOR [SI+001A], AL` when doing the pre-processor math.  In that case, it's a 1 byte win!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>47</del> 45 bytes

```php
while($x<8)echo~_[!$x],BbBbbbBb[$x++],uffalo;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwMWVmpyRr6CupG79vzwjMydVQ6XCxkITJFgXH62oUhGr45TklJQExNEqFdrasTqlaWmJOfnW/xH6AA)

*-2 bytes thx to @manatwork!*

Comment: Impressing one! Including bending a bit the “correct casing and spacing” rule by outputting [no-break space](https://unicode-table.com/en/00A0/) instead of regular space. BTW, no need for the braces.

Comment: @manatwork thanks! Of course I don't need the braces! Silly me!!

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 49 bytes

```java
v->"B b B b b b B b".replaceAll("b|B","$0uffalo")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY09C8IwEIb3/oojOLRSg7sfoIObk@AiDtfaSOo1CcmlIOpvr6m6ORwvL8/Dey32OGsvt0F3znqGNnUZWZNU0dSsrZHTRfYHA/sGuxHVhCHAHrWBRwbgYkW6hsDIKXqrL9Allh/Ya3M9nQH9NRQfFWD3e7E8Jq/8KmtQsBr62VpsoYLxqm8K6RtHWDcbolxUz60oxWQelUKyohgWn8XDPXDTSRtZurTGuZLoHN1zE4mKYpRe2Wt4Aw)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, nice first answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <strike>41</strike> 38 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @mazzy

```powershell
'BbBbbbBb'-replace'.',' $0uffalo'|% *m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X90pySkpCYjVdYtSC3ISk1PV9dR11BVUDErT0hJz8tVrVBW0cv//BwA)

Comment: you can use method `trim` instead `substring` :)

Answer (score 3):

## [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), 43 bytes

```
u$="uffalo buffalo
?"B"u$" B"u$" b"u$" B"u$
```

Abuses a couple tricks with the autoformatter (besides the standard `?` for `PRINT` shortcut): the missing double quote is added at the end of line 1, and semicolons are inferred in the print statement whenever a literal string is next to a variable. After expansion, the code becomes

```
b$ = "uffalo buffalo"
PRINT "B"; b$; " B"; b$; " b"; b$; " B"; b$
```

The semicolon trick, plus the fact that string variables need the `$` sigil, meant that approaches using more variables to build the string ended up longer.

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <sup><s>190</s></sup> 179 bytes

```
+++[>+++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+++>+++>+++>+++>+++>+[<]>>>-]>->->+>->->-[<]<-]<-]>>>+++.>->.>+++.>+++.>--.>.>+++.>----.[<]>>[.>]<[<]>.>>[.>]<[<]+++[>>[.>]<[<]>-]>.>>[.>]<[-]<[<]>>[.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5RCoAwDEMPVNITlFxk7EMFQQQ/BM9fuw6dP7IuvCRjdD6n7VivZXcXkcJHUhv832KVJCoRR1IRmaFNNPFII9MO3UH5Ypj8oiirNdLBucBo8CnRo3TuNw)

The ASCII codes are initialised using a similar method to my [Buffalo answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218330/92901), though here both `b` and the second `f` get their own cells. Printing the output requires fewer instructions in brainfuck compared with Buffalo because of a key difference in the way that loops are handled: brainfuck uses the currently active cell to decide whether a loop ends, whereas Buffalo refers back to the cell that was originally active when the loop was entered. Consequently, we can print runs of letters in successive cells with a simple `[.>]` loop in brainfuck, a construction that isn't possible in Buffalo.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 57 bytes

```
prin collect[foreach b"BbBbbbBb"[keep rejoin[b"uffalo"]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcPRCcAgDAXAVSSjOEJ/Qz6MPqmtGAnt/GkPztHiQGOJ7WOlanOiPtzNUeqZlLJm1T/xDezkuGwsVnp7L9NIRCI@)

### Alternative:

### [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 60 bytes

```
parse s:"B b B b b b B b"[any["b"insert"uffallo"|" "]]prin s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@78gsag4VaHYSslJIUkBhJMgtFJ0Yl5ltFKSUmZecWpRiVJpWlpiTk6@Uo2SglJsbEFRZp5C8f//AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Æ▼.#t!♦ΩÿN+╪\7êI
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=921f2e23742104ea984e2bd85c378849&i=)

Uses mixed base conversion and some zipping.

Made with a lot of @recursive's help.

Answer (score 2):

## [C++11](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 126 bytes

```cpp
#include<random>
#include<cstdio>
int main(){std::knuth_b g(7);for(char i{},s[]=" buffalo";i-8;++i)s[1]^=*s&g(),printf(s+!i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcy7DoIwFADQna@omJjWwuCkocKPEDTl1sKN0DZ9TIRvr0yuZzjgXD0B5HxGA0tSn6eXRtm1K/4AISq0XYEmklWioWw7pGm@JsX5PZKJ3pnQ1lOYpSe47VXoh7YkY9JaLrYUWD8E58hCfxte7TVcJsoq549P08BPyMSe8w8)

Not a serious contender for shortest program — but I was inspired by the (original, now-deleted) requirement not to use a random number generator. ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 37 bytes

```perl
say"@{[map{(21%$_?b:B).uffalo}1..8]}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLJoTo6N7GgWsPIUFUl3j7JyklTrzQtLTEnv9ZQT88itlbp//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 117 bytes

```python
o=['buffalo']
for x in ['B' if int(i) else 'b' for i in bin(69)[:1:-1]]:
  o.insert(0,x+o[-1][1:])
print(' '.join(o))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCsMgEEX3nmJ2o7QNlUKhQja5xuCigtIpwQnGQHp6q7vH5/23/epH8qM1mQnDkdJ7FfQqSYETOAPhgsCpY9VsIK57BAwIQ@AhBM76@TLkrLtZ750CkInzHkvV9@t5EeozWeeN2sqoIOD0lf4SY1r7Aw)

69 is the reverse of the binary representation of the capitalization pattern.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, nice first answer! I don't know much Python but you may want to check out [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python).

Comment: `'B' if int(i) else 'b'` -> `'bB'[int(i)]`, and you can remove a space before `for`. Also, you could `.append` instead of `.insert` and use `o[::-1]` later, and you can then write `o+=[item]` in place of `o.append(item)`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 17

Obligatory bubblegum answer generated with `zopfli --deflate --i1000 -c buffalo.txt | xxd`

```
00000000: 732a 4d4b 4bcc c957 4882 d2e8 fc24 fcf2  s*MKK..WH....$..
00000010: 00                                       .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypNSspJTS/N/f/fAAqsFMyNjRIVTFJMkhRMkpKTFZItTc0VTCwsjBRSjFItFNKSjUyARJqRgkKxlq@3t55euIceEKjo6XFBTDAEmmFgoEAc0Pv/HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>33</s> 30 bytes

```perl6
put "BbBbbbBb".comb X~"uffalo"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@gtERBySnJKSkJiJX0kvNzkxQi6pRK09ISc/KV/v8HAA)

Comment: `>>~>>` can just be `X~`

Answer (score 2):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), <sup><s>51</s> <s>46</s></sup> 42 bytes

Rattle just hit release today - this is my first golf with the released version! If you're interested in learning a fun and easy new language, I would highly recommend checking it out!

```
B&b&uffalo& |I=[b0[2b^b1]b2b3b1b2[3q]b3+]4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7T1te9s2kt/1KxDqEou2JIty0qRqHCdNk2fzPHttnyS7@0FRWkqEJG4oUuFLHPd8@eu9GbyQAAhSUpxcb3vrNrJFAANgZjBvGIDbq3ydxGe/d8ngeEAWSRDGqwkp8uXgAT7pOI7TeZpSP6cBSWLyel2QJ8WKeGdk9GBy98Hk7D4Zj8ajTuexXwCkdEJ@8OOQRp3HH2iahUk8Id5wNDzrdP62DRgUqO4NRuPB6AEZjyejEXn26jXrBn7wV56QIJl0CPywj4DOocNlES9yAHeLVCXVx8Z/R4lfViIAA4aTbPw8XPhRdEWyPEmhRkz8NPWvSBiTDd0k6RU8Csgm@UBJvqZkm4RxTlNsjl9j@jEnH/yooFUnNMooQIOZbGicZxckSaHgak7JP4ssJ3GSa6UPBwNyuQ4Xa7LAzhc58TMTBukxyGFOikyMcbWM/NWFK9CCn@@LcPGObNNklfqbTEHP8/C33@58X/z22/WtF9PVyUtvnt0@m47mo/nb0Wx1@x786eGf3888wHWYsQZYnwyIH8FsY0DSBxpdTTRY2avMe@Vl45/PVKBeBXRcAmXDuETQaxpFCblM0ihgD6@n3vn72a1BdvIom64e3v40HZ1v389Wg@zR7NO5tyWLNV28yxDfGQUMLIEw2yJHUNs03FCyzvNtNjk9Bb6kqyRaDgFri3f042Ltxys6XCSb0/cFzZDm2em9@99490/DbJCv4SMuNnOaDvwBgySGM3o/m25nI2AwCr1CtclhXXwzvn82Pg0324iRDqDnKbD9YOMv1mEsegFS54eCHZ@NTjMGdwCtB4LOpAf8RCfkeoso@fGn18DjCFwU98mcLnxkGuRWjroVBYba@mkGK@1yTYHPfWB2aI2cSTfb/Mplo/z@zvxOsVz6UXKHAOesRovx4ix7tPLY7@n87vzebDy/B//dBaqPPxtjY@/B@MHd06TIYXSDOe/yc39XXD@nOS5UziWc1JyZKEig6@XoO@C85UxjvGXJd7AqJQCJwKukkCu0YALDDwKUhrAel1hvObKJHePjOoPeRifAY9DTw@NP2BvKh@sX44e154QMHhGyhA6TNPQj0kuiYMKBDAQUVhWazD49XCF84gphwD6eA2RGcy4MOPk3KISAAhRmtkSRh5xxDRImXK25dFr7H1DIXJHro4yzAiw7nP6lH2P7KA@BCzm4rC9F0h2UWz6sUmAtH0ZMeiCuLsMoMuTsgqmKStCieGXcCMwIjJtfbUGEgmYArQOKhmTrpIgCGGt9JCATFkkM3E5jhLj202CABAnETC/DfI2jE0gA/KVcBOcoTJMYhT7iIQQpm@Hoq7qumBZ5w3rFH/rRx8U3IW/ubBOQzMmbO@M3aqc4kSua3Rn3CQW03NUhwhOGjBVIUjJ1oKLTJ1DV4cD417sz1h0s42cTpAsqJPgXJwBx4QNiYAGlwA@gN0mPDldD8iZ2kX/eFwgF9drGT0Fc9pz@kQsQAKHIs6B7cM4xDknIz5hR@BIIUMQRzTKG1iAp5hHjiM2wnPhbwDkvCPrVKoigKSx3WF1IdPgNtJpfkRR5Coid4/ciw8@XYw9JBWKHpCGYCEvGcSAMsFdz4LDu2LwcJwf54DjX2HoA64B/70gTABcU/AR0yZmnhzRwFaW3ipI5rBmUbep3qf8z9WFKt8CT6hMujJ7kz@JAfZwn25@Wr1CWqU/RcvBXVH0kzAT1UZQk26dJUT7uKs8BZKr1vyjSFLTH02SzAbZ6EQf0ownLGNqCV83Man8Ns9xW72myvTInQYMnuCS1xxSWGDxeqQ/B@ngO1oc2YWCA/HuQwfqkRc3xThLYhr8DCdm7cPs6UZ/QOHgugJvjC2NZYhuK6KKGq/oAnlvKbZBVNGtttiEFxrfpBgMaOScDTy3QhgGlUy4sLHPAwumsf@P/Z6SL@hxtA1yyUbgBkQ7rGwTSENfxUtBQmyx03oRWoYWUGT73wdCtygwC1itwmleTb8IP1ODquFsuL/2RWInlQ2nXy@9iTWNPoxk5JtKIrSRAWVWusmpUylpSHsqVBI9@TIQlKNaHNlG5ZrSHyvoyZs8@FHkFxa9T4Y@ohJHdchwESXyEmj4OQN7TNE1Ao3DKXtp48@joqDIhrlGofieJ7JV/jYfsR3798TsyzdG@REMJJlVwV4ZpNe7woG7juGLuGGByUYlTrr43/kfkNHRMmJuVzZjDhIbutsjWvCWzLvvS9IBnoIj60ly4luy7DFO0fKQG7VeeBNeN@TpNitWaP@65Q/JiKXRwiIaNcw0ams0H7RS0UJgVlUkzKuROiT6oIfkJQVyGGe2jGmewlbWwtI2M@Z7CJveF6Sq6xtqsaEPBlQ64SQHanWsw7BhV/gZVex7i4HrhkBKPNWF10wKAXIYL6qJxmW3pAi3LhY/jG@EjDikDjCPdQiQkKj4ODDnE88S3HDR35Oo8wpmLWcXnzDgeArzIX9CeQ5y@4/DqXAbKGtk2CvOe8x0UCic6RNHAK8HqM1gxXPaAFBJHQuWXpaIGFknA146La/j8HIwKpXptNQu6KxUq2w@WYUvLem9a3fKLmJlZ3ZtZsaRMxTp4JhJ61UBcrTSleZHGdeQgCZHTEIFVWx0y9MqqQK9Hb94cGf3Wpl99qebx5o3Tlxjte24NQKeOVl2GcdHHOUL8AjN96zHp10WXYsAMv0zxbMG6ZT4ELMXSbShbjlW5m6dXVcdNkxEkuqPQA7FHwbNvw54Gu/Ie6KLn@NCBQ07QXu4hGLeOGDlUJguznjt1fEdnJ7Sct/mksSUC7pgF3tDfbkG99lgtt2HuWNG6niIaq5yGnOG1raXqi1wM5qhrWKpjSOnQbe7KjigbkrZ@lkmGUi2nrJI23mQyE4XoOyOZUwxZMASU9V1l6uXDaThTTB/8WlvVOmo1DHCxy6RQzpY84M21CQ4@RIU0siWYIwZFSpjeqN6P@OOEeFbyVG31QUuLAkrAoVMMPDboPm/m1qoLA8TWRHTl6v10TenWJ7x2iWDZsF924hqaoovKThZy22SolDJJyEuRzrLihHSzS3/LvoPBAjo1CmMQM5EvPTfWWqNel6GskAZvT8Cq5tQ18dstGbJ80taes2SabJjuJeFmm4BFu6Xp8peFsGRB@AlD@DVWEYYoN3yVgp6rre0KH2CSReBGW2zphwS5v8SywmX1IWdTCwSFk23wT2pcJpWQpfJtZgtauL2qL6b5SEz/hNyzaDDOX87PIoyKaA1QBQ3JD2HAwhzAHxizgD9B5n8MMWgWc4PowqnL7XlK/XfqLBROY2FHrjuA1zBwD1wG1iDXeH3xGzhMt09pvtDMHkVBKhOCAtU5uIX60WopOM7wn@DlqLUVucp0sUYAu43RkWEXYy0vce2rAZhtkmXhPKLg8aC0cEbe@OzuvW/uP/j206@P77y9GDpdcgfXcEoz5hj4YI6CtGSWCRqkPDhXCemY4lpMoCY4BKU/wTH8lkXfLphHIYs4okv9r7to3HPz2SMeTiKNYt/VsR0nMFuU9lBLnaRrKkTRqdS82EbnG9E/FrSZmgLOdOChhmGNTvRGCjC1dt0K5VZhr8THMRLArQsD5QNpra5zMcuDYl@WgJEWGSrVMcoqzeT3mb@8qLRe6QO8ZT4AlCto57Xhs1K9b3WDunK4SydZx7jNIy/7vNivzwtrn@OdnY7rvcqusZdbhhNQM6FwiEPLEPWhLqPEzxGgzox1xquaoBComrm7rSxz6Kb/4uthEFv1T/X6OAzBcFPBZTOLOlOA/GoHYjpNZrPH9maiT9fSIXgJiHc0WxmKJl2@15Wx5jy6IcNgOtc0eBmGEOJAd/sZUI8bojhe/sXdy3vQbBHDCgM4fbYxI8hvsKcU0T@EC5RA/6XBdk6ciR8Eff3hwJlkxTxHTWeUHDsTscN0ZZScOpMg/BAG1Hh@6UzYrvI/cFPZKHvpTOSORJ90Eekj9gOWIO59it0vHn8JwhWP4bAtqJ53DlPvk/E539zok7NztgRcMmBb0XMaJZeMVAHN/TACSs9BQ4NARUMVNz4YwEwfUAYTx4iXMc6VMwF9ajx86EwEx/2QXMZG4aOy8G9bo@hn6IPmP/NSo2wLzdLY7OmWM0FlaTxdOBO@v2Y8n@IcwLL6a5KYXc@cCag6S8FtIGsSFFFiPP8PgAXWtvE0xRmIcCnT5Ub5uTOplvCz9wXITKPGLxI9wd8xbPgifsXlhrVyjhNCIsvgs1HeR6QBsKdgmz0xx@IDf2Ok90UclrF7s4Mnos5PYLH7vEKX734m5RPM8cAkkSVLF4HhLFiMLdGXr7MBRGLpx7b@XiH@IrrIn4PLwOLQRoW5JO3r5OfKHDQqfS@m/SQOXoKNZq8UikovANerWul7Z/K@CHNhZRuFL8RaeIHBG6NsCYz0kS6KnDbQJABpgGk/1bZQzYPAn/9WzHAWYVCFFfvigjHlgIt@ImX3ieMKWaxVnuKXmVspTtPb5OQz84zQBw3jLMQ8AfL3/wThgdvgfNMSnLYVyIoL3h5UW8hL8pDtlBcwNXRRYxhZwaDxjrssoM7MWyVzKEmxtp7hhJ2z@AhAG5BwSIdsg98HOi7YDq2IJWOek3BVoC4WHC2PWAAeJRrPN@I2NUXfH2Wm8LXK7pidaJCsxB8jkm44tm/I7dwbrG/@7dgtbNkbbNyr@3rbg9rObH1brDQTVS3syOFMQCIRHbWaFaMVoT2DdpZiPNR32cr@tPXTGBF4zlwRHhaw4GhqTHzm1l31fZpNm7qeyXj@zLFYuQGt8Fvzgr5u17Jb6fKNGgLfLdEQjlsMiZgNuvZ9Tr4Shttk2xsogXbJNGLHlOcoQSXGPPyha/FE6pvQGjfVwp5tSKwH/KroqAZ1pu4QaKvxC8Fs@ePwoFpzYK2jQbYR18IYX22VmXxvLHsL@7ZtvzfHuuz9WcWZJW54s9Xo7r@cOk14aWzVGGr8jHDj1wg52klhw8jO5awLGjHQANQG2aV0lAYWUvatNHHb10hNlFn8YSHBXCOizh@jBwwkb1g4FrHQFUJUrE5rkLoRXJPMrUlaK4VaZ2ntzphyucEBViZN84bBe/Av7FvFtowQqLaGZUtFpIzwVE3FzBwQ3jEJMTJbuTMAJiHvC1pQfa5N@T9oP1YWfa@KYElulNuCWII2O1n7mHxBY2l2Bo5rxi2F769AW25Qbks4Yieo7v/3eWp/WMZvMD7C0jqK@WCpWnScbhgqwJrQIAuZ65/JTR/yG00TFtGu6rNIQtmCBwqEjg7oItxgtm@aoAMQuG1wZGxCABJ5WUqWKCZoophhao764CtQkTfYUbZ2ASm1PV1E1AnG7R3duNzk0gTyVBNog0RiUgAqYLTWleaF3misNUI67NHoTGvEI5GWZhXh2WiAEEiH85HueRhJnNCTqGiKeiM7RIZA1W1p0rHkW@gWFcM88OBaGhhRsioL5wIyPKtD73sj1z1gNKfe6Pi4Nz/xBmJCML7j2rOOwJBYAruxI4KiI8wzFn8bDoU2NGPn3pbp0ZQqANAnA7YuZwop@Ty/KDFrqLNnpGht2HK0EIlUiG1N/8e5VHFKLpG67EGfn4fhCW8f/DT05b4Wxz631rqYOR6TtyzNPq1YSIjHv1QHaxxlEcmdhbL9xe72twwAFoqrjfrkH02tRvUma8s4zZ1HK/RjBHriua4Fr34gESpyDcsEvDJgkhGWhQ6UQwmplHG0sBA3qyZa1yraGU5wp6uQ6/y8eXlohqgiMvQqSJ5qcjJQLmYov7KBMuGiTEYW4my5Z9M236p2CevrTHuwe9oDNu0aZXnEX0ydf@GDO5U8LJ7yqJQ6fMwCHatzHgnW75OyiVFdJMqI@gmmbrY38PXE@Jth6fRcjNfAkn096Q21FB8bfk8FfjUtKTZaJGdhxePzErGiODwMt2qrfdHb0uaLYvj4czF8vAeGj1UOVrDMYtwCxSLhV5hrONC@kq0IhnRO/YDI83oyxqruqHcZOI0i@CfHF56famon1r1c@u1Q2ABj2@6@5ZHdZLhVUxpy6xZKZ5rit6hec5tXry8TUBS7vpvhsUbrfMRZXZY/LlHUhpq9ARm8eQPUGBZUhaddVomJp4rtyt1BFUl4jjnTDjIXWxsObPUYU7AMh6wp3aPRXsAkJQEIJv/tt2aCkijT1GM9IcE8pGEY2rr/XE@B2DGIxoE0Z0eYA7J7@Ao1cCO3nR4B1NiPIljzy9Fk1ECSwb4k@fbbm9Nk1EKSwaEkgQHV6VBtjFtlh3G831jgKlqrfkSGhLs7xFNxQxprsosZvFldSpkSyMYYTW2bRfhnnWKsUkHcdrayH0vQicXrqHJOCcohgnBvU0VQkfFDNVAWxrQ8t8JTKTsiFnaLoFrG9ECOMjwsHy5AvYr8SoGYZz89Jz2@bwo6mB0Dxnb89gr1ggF2LMhtOxbaYHHYTjLUdyBwnnwTXp2pcqI5q2kbyZdWvthbC7W66zzGppGGn8DgpoxI@9AWDz4UJwShiAyIzqAMw2kR88MZR5ncDi8bhIJefKZJrGhcoALFjA1zQaIhJTP1emxf@63LT0iF2IOPe@4faIrZ2@GyukjjkNOldTS2Hac9ALIlGdK@Gb5rf7lpe1o789g0mI6SzVp1r0aXzc1MCyS32@2q@kSTCJhMwE71yzQrbvDPU7wKImfRWyWzoNOYjKbGMeraQ3SpsHBdJ7DwPiniPIy4fRwl7GS6GEqtvtiSa8toZ8mY1j3gvbLc2yru0LhaTl7D4S9B1zpu/lzIkZKgXN/siAeZ@xkX5lleLJeKEgSxjyE2kTqD4fMEz1HCbG1Kag/@r@9Pu7ZzDH@qZXGzDduDWcOygbuz9r/ECvoXwaPViG1@wNPAeAqoaiSUeWNWE4HdMsDOJ7NiZungGWPN3iVv@0oddvsWv9UHLSF2IpmZhcuQHwCv2U52Y9h2lUa7/raq/IZbNSxnIfY2yL@sUbAr100zbuRGNt65grvYexzuMptIeIc0tuw6wzpUN4yFNa2eM5IJ@L866ik@e2f6amnXYeft5dVpj19xm1/sY@qWtKedr8JBfvqjBvlJGWTtCEVtmI//qGE@VoYpT1u4rnEWvzr98yVHCNJUOD8139RtSh77HN2eSo9FNVx05dOYwajurXlt6V77kgPFgLWOTWHqy3OvdMuucl5Y7VNxG2pj75Y7hSk1sp66xq0GWhcsb8jmpOw2BVrRhUkIFWO0V@XJCO6XWxoHd04Gxm0LDWmjpY9okKK5tiRwE@0MDVApgPYZ9onzJnbc2vrSiVVJ@BsmDOr0v6ERdn5DADdRIn9OPHyOnvpzYuJAVfh/CwmtyvRfSI/eGBHt2ezNTf@tf7@Y/v2DV7Q@/BvC@loq/rm8XKBZzxupI@ww50H777yJLKrWrwB15rKgQKZuT9wmZ@5h2R@7shM14OPWhLXmdt6o0yZF2hqO9k@HhPpyu8OWS4jHZjn@ywxtfNSU0xEHygZnoNxZbmY/7IaxR1TFHtHYEQ1ppiDdbF/hnTwN@Q67E0Yar7tCsDaS1HssszF2p7K091TfBdTPOlsXFa9SncO0b1Drt7WqN06K3K@KhVjH5iHqg9YzW8FJSkZ9Ec2LE1JuD@/KJm5boyOyI9PKksrWcthbmdTOrW7SPkwLk1mzwiz1yqXM91HV0@bqWQc/y7pyk5tfqlxdgIMKeUKWUbg9TfH@SbyzcR7Gp2uQ9j12avwdvpHgEu9lZZkXQKWMun08UpBs8J4deWu0N/4GWrJrwNlj3Pnrk4VPMz8l2Tpc5vJu5erYu8obKr21DAR2baBgFnj4mXkMDIolUesm@Qs78hUW65rvpZgRCmn16k0uipKaXLsbQEUk8T2ZiifuA1iyYx6UXXIU0XiVr1XOt2WvAYxf@L2jWXWrusD2PMnzZGPJiCb@2NamfN0DMF4Ss8JADmggBEp51kQmL/L9fxiaN9SrjIzy0ZA8izLeiut6tW8pruDrUSaVTNU9u9lUjo/2OVgcJ9vTg9EMsKKYHV64EgQTnnbUxxvc2N1SfbIfH9kuwt7roiNdAHfKdxEwMhh3/0L3T5RrbXhCUnntn3a7i9peq83sQesFfvo1PNV1ek9wrZXw9Ei7HJFuzrCzNNqVpMpwasupQfzxW5QterLtrlJN5E/LXg1I9dGP1TNy4r0GeHnYmGtQdSqKjrROhWvuMF@sibl1hkXGHc8NaW8Vuu23djIo6gWdvEfXduhUKbbv/WkjHtXP@Fqz5nZN1TRm@PLQ/WkNlaM2PI7@jUcNj1ZX3H4RXAlYlzT/L3DZMOV2nMrrCo37d0Q@fhGDqRXild0dRVhg/n1lcIu8vKtFhFoHjSO8elTYXyeD49PbffLy5bPnTM1QP43w5VEBRcT5eCx043883eDVpeIPvGGAH8VcJFGxiU/T5LJPfAAIMvMUvGHsptjUXmXRoK5qGqfZ1OmKYXNkdBpvbJMXjpmaoCHdsQ5DuQWyunNX/2hOjrVcb2Skglpdolv4s/PVFQYS27MahHOmXaR0iDfR0PEBrpCpScvblPc/EaA7rrb0U@0OKBXV7Dwcu7tOvuCF3zGKooQZFPisuhfXlpTJbD2WtUHx9RHsRT0sDQRvq8QX77BTpaQ8lFYlPSnQxgLchQIuALLYYDHOKPNA8GkJLaahPHKEUEU2CRdxLW4KtNQ9FbOZzC6zGOd7vCLlJu@U2XWvphrK9Zy@OOUop1@eDTVFh5FS1siqpT/EZyViiOI61YbzAkp1ETxxHGI7r9rZEY9uHRUGxY2RtQzKrK0cvGl3G3l9qSXNO8sbtjIbWuqbJKr/rd@/1nBuQLxHQ1@oeNNYEqMnx3RTGze2HhP5AvcLGzOv7BMDOXjNQpe/CQzf8siCHhcVLsQ1c3sFI@oBTJEZnu@IPygLGnGiN/tfPERhBiQaT1LUN9k6dWGvXMRXV2JNOW@NI2zI4h17d@/ffXD2zd37NZVTHYZkF/7Vx7B30Ngi9lTE1/3nJApe24PsyoXumrNZfZu1u9eHS8x93iHR4EXXXu1wwEmtnUexDhnbIeOzjrFFsu4zhn36rp3lO/Bo2teikzUHtx7i1nm2djOvPMCrHpcuQ2L42j/9DDCZojklom3l8V/mhTDLCd82FLNT7njaRrz5NsPb1mfiRKxyNA6fi9tqMEDHXijK43WIKszlZTVsUla8JBRkrL9B640rq9xI@ZXne02Lu1x13ZXcnWDX9GBrdcxsWPxFk0qMkQUK8d2GumzsdJQXc3Tw7q2n/P1FjuO8@V17C@qL8@l8NB3P38692Xw8P8P3nk7P3s/mZyezu7@z924q7eWf0wmaHx3@nkL5EDT87/8D)

Try to out-golf me! You'll probably want to consult the [documentation](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle)

### Explanation

```
B&b&uffalo&      creates an array of hard-coded strings: ["B","b","uffalo"," "]
    |            syntax for taking input
     I           stores this data in first memory slots
      =          sets top of stack to 0
       [ ... ]4  loops 4 times
    b0           adds item in slot 0 to buffer
      [2 ... ]   executes statements inside if top of stack is equal to 2
        b^       deletes last item from buffer
          b1     adds item in slot 1 to buffer
    b2b3b1b2     adds item in slot 2, 3, 1, 2 to buffer
    [3 ... ]     executes statement inside if top of stack is equal to 3
      q          ends program - buffer is implicitly printed
    b3           adds item in slot 3 to buffer
      +          adds 1 to top of stack
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate), 27 bytes

```
B((uffalo) b$2 B$2 b$2) b$1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdcGCpaUlaboWu500NErT0hJz8jUVklSMFJyAGEiDOIYQFVCFMA0A)

Pretty simple: golf repeated substrings using capture groups.

Answer (score 2):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>35</s> 33 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [user41805](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41805/user41805)*

```
s/^/BbBbbbBb/
s/./ &uffalo/g
s///
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlwYKlpSVpuhY3lYr14_SdkpySkoBYn6tYX09fQa00LS0xJ18_HczVh6iEaliwkAvCAAA)

34B solution:

*-1 byte thanks to [user41805](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41805/user41805)*

```
s/^/B b B b b b B b/
s/\>/uffalo/g
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlwYKlpSVpuhY3lYr14_SdFJIUQDgJQutzFevH2OmXpqUl5uTrp0NUQjUsWMgFYQAA)

35B solution: *(The regex matches empty string at first and then is reused for the second `s` command)*

```
s/b*/B b B b b b B b/i
s//&uffalo/g
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlwYKlpSVpuhY3lYv1k7T0nRSSFEA4CULrZ3IV6-urlaalJebk66dDlEJ1LFjIBWEAAA)

Comment: Hint: you can get 34b with both solutions.

Comment: @user41805 Hmm, I am unable to figure it out, what is the solution?

Comment: For the above approach, it seems the `$` in `s/.$//` is annoying, something you can do to remove its need? For the second approach, try finding an alternative to `\w` so you can rid the `&` in the substitution

Comment: @user41805 Thank you! Both solutions are smart and something I couldn't think of without your help. And it even got to 33B.

Comment: Nice find! Btw if you're interested, I have an infinite bounty for a sed submission to a specific challenge https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23852

Comment: @user41805 Sadly I wasn't able to come up with solution myself. But I was able to golf down existing one: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63901/101306

Comment: If you post that as an answer I can start the bounty. But can you get even shorter with this tip https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235144 ?

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
9G*âx{ûbB§╕«Γ╢ô };
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9tYXRoZ29sZv//OUcqw6J4e8O7YkLCp@KVlcKrzpPilaLDtCB9O///)

`âx{ûbB§╕«Γ╢ô` could alternatively be `à{ENR**╦\i╛δ` for the same byte-count: [try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/SXevwgmpXvyAtrUdTl8VkPpo6@9wWhVrr//8B).

**Explanation:**

```python
9G*               # Push 9*18=162
   â              # Convert it to a binary list
                  # (which is unfortunately in reversed order due to a bug)
    x             # Reverse it to the correct order
     {            # Loop over each of these bits as integers:
      ûbB         #  Push string "bB"
         §        #  (0-based) index the current bit into it
          ╕«Γ     #  Push compressed string "uffa"
             ╢ô   #  Push compressed string "lo"
                  #  Push a space character " "
     };           # After the loop: discard the final space
                  # (after which the entire stack is joined and output implicitly)

   à              # Convert it to a binary string (in correct order..)
    {             # Loop over each of these bits as characters:
     ENR**        #  Push 15*25*29=10875
          ╦       #  Get the dictionary word at this index: "buffalo"
           \      #  Swap so the current bit is at the top of the stack
            i     #  Convert it from a character to an integer
             ╛    #  If it's truthy:
              δ   #   Titlecase the string
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu), 8 blocks

[image: hi if you’re reading this]

[Try it on scratch!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/754657063/)

I tried to refrain from doing anything too illegal like setting the costume as `Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo` or setting a variable as that.

Here is the scratchblocks code (102 bytes):

```
when gf clicked
for each[i v]in(8){set[B v]to(join(B)(join(letter(i)of[BbBbbbBb])[uffalo ])
}::control
```

Usually when people submit scratch, they submit Tosh (https://tosh.blob.codes/), which is Scratch but text-based or an image of the blocks compiled on scratchblocks (https://scratchblocks.github.io). I would’ve done both, but the `for each [i v] in (8)` block is old and removed and I can’t figure out how to do it on Tosh.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `S`, 11 bytes

```
⁺>bƛḃ‛ḋ¤$ßǐ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=S&code=%E2%81%BA%3Eb%C6%9B%E1%B8%83%E2%80%9B%E1%B8%8B%C2%A4%24%C3%9F%C7%90&inputs=&header=&footer=)

### Explained

```
⁺>bƛḃ‛ḋ¤$ßǐ
⁺>           # Push 163
  b          # and convert it to binary
   ƛ         # for each digit:
    ḃ        #   push whether the digit is "truthy"
     ‛ḋ¤     #   and push the string "buffalo"
        $    #   swap those two values
         ßǐ  #   and if the digit actually is truth, title case it
```

Comment: I like the answer, but you added the `S` flag after I posted my answer. You also slightly modified the behavior of `Ɓ` (seems to be virtually identical to me, but who knows). So sorry, no brownie points.

Comment: Wow you actually checked the interpreter and understood it. The `Ɓ` was changed to act like 05ab1e does (i.e. Handle the string "0" as falsey). It acts as a shortening of `0=0=`

Comment: Ah ok. I was a bit confused when I saw that "compare" function there, but decided not to waste time trying to look for its definition. But yeah, I thought it was a bit suspicious, so I checked the interpreter and sure enough you just added the `S` flag.

Comment: Note to self: obfuscate flags

Comment: Python is my main language so it probably won't be too effective. Lol

Comment: Haha! Your edit and your old answer are now invalid! That's what you get for trying to outgolf me :)

Comment: @Makonede I'm sorry what were you saying? Vyxal is forever. Get good

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 48 bytes

```
##<>#&//"B"~Print~#["uffalo"~#~b~#~" B",b=" b"]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7875@WFh1cUpSZl@6Vn5lnZVUMZsf@V1a2sVNW09dXclKqCwAKldQpRyuVpqUl5uQr1SnXJQGxkoKTkk6SrZJCklKs2v//AA)

Port of TiKevin83's [TI-BASIC solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218303/81203).

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org), 60 bytes

```
(clojure.string/join " " (map #(str % "uffalo") "BbBbbbBb"))
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (V8), <s>57</s> 50 bytes

```javascript
a='uffalo';b='B'+a+' b'+a;c='b'+a;print(b,b,c,c,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P9FWvTQtLTEnX906yVbdSV07UVtdIQlIWSfbqoPpgqLMvBKNJJ0knWQgTNL8/x8A)

You have to run these at `Try it online!` because running it in a browser console will try to print this webpage

57 bytes:

```javascript
a='uffalo ';b='B'+a+'b'+a;c='b'+a;print(b+b+c+c+b.trim())
```

47 bytes but `Try it online!` doesn't understand `String.replaceAll` and it outputs a trailing space:

```javascript
print('B'+('bBbbbBb'.replaceAll('','uffalo ')))
```

46 bytes but it outputs a trailing space (thanks to @lm42):

```javascript
print('B'+('bBbbbBb'.replace(/|/g,'uffalo ')))
```

This is my first golf.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, nice first answer!

Comment: Surely that last approach includes an unwanted trailing space?

Comment: yes, I did not see that

Comment: `print('B'+('bBbbbBb'.replace(/|/g,'uffalo ')))` for last of your

Comment: @l4m2 this has a trailing space

Comment: so do `replaceAll` trim output?

Comment: No, it doesn't, as @Neil pointed out. I've added your suggestion anyway, since I already have one with a trailing space.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia REPL, 33 bytes

`join("BbBbbbBb ","uffalo ")[1:63]`

### Julia, 40 bytes

`print(join("BbBbbbBb ","uffalo ")[1:63])`

Comment: @Dingus Thanks for informing me of that. I editted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike><sup>23</sup></strike> 22 bytes

Save a byte thanks to @Scott!

```
V"BbBbbbBb"p+N"uffalo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/381PySnJKSkJiJUKtP2UStPSEnPyFf7/BwA)

---

I wanted to be smart and encode the state of the upper- and lowercase letters as bits, but that ended up taking a byte more. Here's the code and explanation anyway!

#### 24 bytes

```
FNj162 2p+?N\B\b"uffalo
```

```python
FN                         # loop with N
  j162 2                   # convert 162 into binary as list of bits
        p                  # print without newlines
         +                 # concatinate strings
          ?N\B\b           # ternary operator, checks if the bit is falsey (0)
                "ufallo    # note the trailing space
```

Comment: The 'V' function is equivalent to FN, so you can save a byte with V"BbBbbbBb"p+N"uffalo

Comment: Also 22 bytes using map: jdm+d"uffalo""BbBbbbBb

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>49</s> 39 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to Dingus

```ruby
$><<('BbBbbbBb '.chars*'uffalo ').strip
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XOxkZD3SnJKSkJiBXU9ZIzEouKtdRL09ISc/IV1DX1ikuKMgv@/wcA)

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 131 bytes

```
using System.Linq;using System;class A{static void Main(){Console.Write($"{String.Join("uffalo ", "BbBbbbBb".ToArray())}uffalo");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B4jteX)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 22 bytes

```
jdm+d"uffalo""BbBbbbBb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyslVztFqTQtLTEnX0nJKckpKQmI//8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 35 characters

```
"BbBbbbBb "/""|join("uffalo ")[:-2]
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ jq -nr '"BbBbbbBb "/""|join("uffalo ")[:-2]'
Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU@7CgIxEOz9iiE2CgbB0tJOCy0sxSJ3t2okt3uXbBTBbze@ECymmve5L0NEauVC0BPB2uiuVrJ2WVFL2zpubPBMkE69MFRwJMVqu1njKxsMMVqiJceTH/tOSho9H0FcB0nUwDMayVUg9FmU0gRJcJOMRJ/qSPAJLNDofHhbU@dqGhezqBZV9QLM1Jj7WTyPTD4cXBCY8W5uZ/tSHt95qVjLOQTr@bWs/L95Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 57 bytes

```
console.log('BbBbbbBb'.replace(/./g, '$&uffalo ').trim())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcNRCoAgDADQq/QRTaHmHbyJmoqxnKh1/dWDd7nXjdBLm0flM4oEroMpInFWYL31/g/YYyMXojJo8r7Auj0pOeIFNM5ebqW1yAc)

If a trailing space is allowed, it can be 50 bytes:

```
console.log('BbBbbbBb'.replace(/./g, '$&uffalo '))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcNRCoAgDADQq/gRTaH0Dt5k2pRiONHq@qsH78IXZx5nv/cmB6lmaVOYPEu1EFNM6Q9@UGfMZIMPdTOwrE8pyGLAOdUP)

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Seems like JavaScript to me. Works perfectly in JS.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 226 bytes

```
--[++>+[<]>+]<++++[>++++++++<-]>>>---->-[<++>>++>++<<-----]->>>----[<<<+++++>>>--]----->++++++>+++++++++>-[<<<++>++>++>-----]<[<]>>.>>[.>]<[<]>.>>[.>]<[<]>.>.>>[.>]<[<]>.>>[.>]<[<]>.>>[.>]<[<]>.>>[.>]<[<]>.>.>>[.>]<[<]>.>>[.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY09CoBQDIMPFPpOUHKR0kEFQQQHwfPX91MEBwcztU3ydT6n7VivZY8QMYAwdcIVVUakVJykVFGsemSLQrWdxCVNU@1F9N27mYwHBWZsIDgI2t6ykFY4lvf87fxoRNw)

The cells are set to `<space>Bbuffalo`

```
<[<]> Goto the space cell
.  (dot = print a space)
>. (dot = print B)
>. (dot = print b)
>[.>] print uffalo
```

`Buffalo` is printed using `<[<]>.>.> >[.>]` but is this if it is the first time, we use `<[<]> >.> >[.>]`

`buffalo` is printed using `<[<]>.> >.>[.>]` but we can golf this to `<[<]>.> >  [.>]`

The only thing that I can think of that could probably be better golfed is the preparation part.

If you put the B before the space you might be able to save some bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [ThumbGolf](https://github.com/easyaspi314/thumbgolf), 31 bytes

Machine code (little endian pairs):

```
a005 22ba 0852 bf2c 2162 2142 de11 de00
d001 de3b d1f6 4770 6675 6166 6f6c 00
```

Commented assembly:

```c
        // Include ThumbGolf wrapper macros
        .include "thumbgolf.inc"
        .globl main
        .thumb_func
main:
        // r0 = "uffalo"
        adr     r0, .Luffalo
        // Bitmask representing the case of the B.
        // 0 = B, 1 = b, little endian bit order.
        // Also allows us to determine the length.
        // This fits perfectly into a narrow movs.
        //             bBbbbBbB
        movs    r2, #0b10111010
.Lloop:
        // Read a bit from the bitmask into the carry flag by shifting right.
        // Also detects when we have read all of the bits: lsrs will set the
        // zero flag.
        lsrs    r2, r2, #1
        // r1 = (r2 & 1) ? 'b' : 'B'
        ite     cs
        movcs   r1, #'b'
        movcc   r1, #'B'
        // print either 'b' or 'B'
        putc    r1 // udf #0021
        // print "uffalo" (w/o newline)
        puts    r0 // udf #0000
        // Yes, none of the output instructions affect the flags despite using
        // stdio AND executing the stdio call on the main thread (since stdio in
        // signal handlers is unsafe), and this is proof.
        //
        // If the bitmask is zero, exit.
        it      eq
        bxeq    lr
        // Use the "put special" instruction to print a space.
        putspc  ' ' // udf #0073
        // More flexing that the flags are preserved, it is just as good to do
        // `b .Lloop`.
        // The proof is that this won't crash, since the ASCII as code will store
        // random garbage to uninitialized registers.
        bne     .Lloop
        // string literal
.Luffalo:
        .asciz "uffalo"
```

Mostly a demo to show how ThumbGolf preserves the condition flags on output instructions.

I could do the same thing with `cbz` and an unconditional `b`, but this is a nice party trick.

As I explained in the code, I use a bitmask to control whether `Buffalo` or `buffalo` is printed. It just happens to be a perfect 8-bit constant for `movs`.

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin, 63 bytes

```kotlin
fun main(){"BbBbbbB".map{print(it+"uffalo ")};print("buffalo")}
```

[Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/nSWkY6kPk)

I used the fairly common strategy of concatenating the first letter to `"uffalo"`, but I had to print the last one to avoid trailing white space, I'm yet to find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, 52 bytes

```
BEGIN{B="Buffalo";b="buffalo";print B,b,B,b,b,b,B,b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06/ayVbJqTQtLTEnX8k6yVYpCcYuKMrMK1Fw0knSAeEkCF37/z8A)

I could not come up with a shorter example.

Comment: I managed to get it to 49... with this

    ```BEGIN{for(u="uffalo ";++a<5;)b=b"B"u"b"u;print b}```

Comment: @cnamejj - unfortunately the seqeunce of B/b is not alternating, whereas your output is: check the 5th buffalo (not Buffalo)...

Comment: (I got 49 a different way: [try it](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06860VapNC0tMSdfQcnayVbJSSlRKUkp0bqgKDOvRMFJwQnEA2EFp9r//wE))...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen : got it to 48 : `BEGIN{print (C="B"(_="uffalo ")"b"_)C"b"_"b"_ C}`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto - When I run it [here](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06@6oCgzr0RBw9lWyUlJI95WqTQtLTEnX0FJUylJKV7TGUSCsIJz7f//AA) the output for the 5th buffalo doesn't seem right...

Comment: another 48 : `BEGIN{print (C="B"(_="uffalo ")(_="b"_))C(_)_ C}`

Comment: @DominicvanEssen : ah ha ! found the reason :  `mawk2 'BEGIN{print (C="B"(_="uffalo ")"b"_)C"b"_"b"_ C}'
Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo 
gawk -e 'BEGIN{print (C="B"(_="uffalo ")"b"_)C"b"_"b"_ C}'
Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo bbuffalo Buffalo buffalo` - it comes out properly in `mawk-1/2` but not in `gawk/nawk`, and that's a long standing discrepancy regarding precedence

Comment: @DominicvanEssen : here - this version should work on both `mawk` and `gawk` for the same 48 : `BEGIN{print (C="B"(_="uffalo ")(_="b"_))C _ _ C}`. All 4 `awk` variants confirmed identical output via `xxHash-128`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto - don't worry: you can remove the space between ```print``` and the first ```(```, and then insert a space after the ```_``` [like this](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06@6oCgzr0TD2VbJSUkj3lapNC0tMSdfQUlTKUkpXtMZRCqACefa//8B) and it'll work in awk/gawk.  Possibly with ```print(``` it'll work with mawk for 47?  I can't test it...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen : you're right - the hashes confirmed it

Comment: @DominicvanEssen : the worse about the precedence difference happens when you try to increment `NF` as part of `lvalue` : `jot 5 | gawk '$++NF=($++NF=($1)^2)^3'
1 1 1
2 4 64
3 9 729
4 16 4096
5 25 15625` :::: with `mawk` it's : `1 1 1
2 64 4
3 729 9
4 4096 16
5 15625 25` : `gawk` cubes on 3rd column, going inside out. `mawk` cubes on 2nd column, because that's the first one declared in the code, left to right.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto - I think you should post the final [47-byter](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06@6oCgzr0TD2VbJSUkj3lapNC0tMSdfQUkTxElSitfUdFaIB0Ln2v//AQ).  Edit: fixed link.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen : the `print` thing is ur idea i can't claim credit for ur work

Comment: Nice approaches! Please mind no trailing spaces are allowed.

Comment: Ha!  I just checked mine on `gawk` locally and `AWK` on TIO.  It needs 50 chars to get rid of the trailing LF.  ```BEGIN{for(u="uffalo ";++a<5;)b=b"B"u"b"u;printf b}```

Comment: The 47 char one is slick!  For gawk/TIO I got it to 44 chars... ```BEGIN{C="B"(_="uffalo ")"b"_;printf C C C C}```

Comment: @cnamejj - unfortunately your 5th buffalo is still mistakenly a Buffalo.

Comment: @PedroMaimere - drat.  You're right.  So we're back up to [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06@6oCgzr0TD2VbJSUkj3lapNC0tMSdfSVNJAcxNUorX1NRx1okHQufa//8B) then...  Edit: actually, [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06@6oCgzr0TD2VbJSUkj3lapNC0tMSdfSRPEVkhSitfU1HFWiFeI13Gu/f8fAA)...  I think...

Answer (score 1):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 69 bytes

```
> "BbBbbbBb"
> "uffalo "
> -1
>> L+2
>> Each 4 1
>> 5ᶠ3
>> Output 6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTkHJKckpKQmIlbiAnNK0tMScfAUQW9eQy85OwUfbCES5JiZnKJgogIVMH25bYAxi@JeWFJSWKJj9/w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 463 bytes

```
{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{{i}ddddd}ic{d}dddddccdddddc{i}iciiic{{d}ii}ic{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{i}{i}dc{d}dddddccdddddc{i}iciiic{{d}ii}ic{i}{i}{i}iiiic{{i}ddddd}ic{d}dddddccdddddc{i}iciiic{{d}ii}ic{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{i}{i}dc{d}dddddccdddddc{i}iciiic{{d}ii}ic{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{i}{i}dc{d}dddddccdddddc{i}iciiic{{d}ii}ic{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{i}{i}dc{d}dddddccdddddc{i}iciiic{{d}ii}ic{i}{i}{i}iiiic{{i}ddddd}ic{d}dddddccdddddc{i}iciiic{{d}ii}ic{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{i}{i}dc{d}dddddccdddddc{i}iciiic
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f@/ujqzNgUIajPBIBnGBwokV6dAmMnJEAoolZkMUQRSX4tQDdedWQsSIUYnWCVInK62DoROevr0/38A)

Answer (score 1):

### [BBC BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC_BASIC), 55 bytes

```
F.I%=1TO8:P.CHR$(98+32*((I%AND(I%+1))=0));"uffalo ";:N.
```

[Try it online!](https://bbcmic.ro/#%7B%22v%22%3A1%2C%22program%22%3A%22F.I%25%3D1TO8%3AP.CHR%24%2898%2B32*%28%28I%25AND%28I%25%2B1%29%29%3D0%29%29%3B%5C%22uffalo%20%5C%22%3B%3AN.%22%7D)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 1):

## R, 48 bytes

Similar to Dominic van Essen's recycling solution, but with `paste0`.

```
cat(paste0(scan(,''),'uffalo'))
B
b
B
b
b
b
B
b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKMgsbgk1UCjODkxT0NHXV1TR700LS0xJ19dU5PLiSsJjJOg9P//AA)

Same idea, also 48 bytes

```
cat(paste0(scan(,''),'uffalo buffalo'))
B
B
b
B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKMgsbgk1UCjODkxT0NHXV1TR700LS0xJ18hCUKra2pyOQFhEhD//w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Pascal, 84 B

This program complies to ISO standard 7185 “Pascal” (level 0 sufficient):

```pascal
program p(output);const s='uffalo buffalo B';begin write('B',s,s:15,'b',s,s:14)end.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 60 bytes

```c
f(n){for(n=8;n--;)printf("%cuffalo%*.s","bBbbbBbB"[n],!!n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcNBCoAgEADAu68wQdgN7RxIF78RHVTYCGoNq5P0dmtgkl1Tao2AsVIuwNPo2FqHZ9n4JlA6PURhz7ofLmVU9DH@vZp5MV3H6N52hI0BRRVSSgJ04m0f)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES6, 51 bytes

```
(c=n=>n?c(n>>1)+'bB'[n&1]+'uffalo ':'')(162).trim()
```

Made sure to trim a trailing space. If we don't trim it, we get 44 bytes (but of course that violates the problem description).

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 62 bytes (using binary properties)

```c
n=8;f(){while(n--)printf("%cuffalo%c",98^(n==3^n&1)<<5,9+!n);}
```

Explanations:

- 98 is 'b'
- If we clear bit `1<<5` (32) from 'b' we obtain 'B': `'b' ^ (1 << 5) = 'B')`. This property is true for all letters.
- We want to clear this bit when n = 7, 5 and 1, which means when n is odd: `n&1` with the exception iteration: 3 `n==3^`
- `9+!n` allows to have spaces (horizontal tab) except when n == 0: `!n`, then this expression will equal to 10 which is a new line return `'\n'`.
- When n == 0 the `while(n--)` loop will automatically stops.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dh9z/P1sI6TUOzujwjMydVI09XV7OgKDOvJE1DSTW5NC0tMSdfNVlJx9IiTiPP1tY4Lk/NUNPGxlTHUlsxT9O69j9QqUJuYmaehqZCNRfQHGuu2v8A)

Thanks to  caird coinheringaahing for catching the superfluous extra newline ;)

Comment: Welcome to the site and nice first answer! You can remove a byte by removing the final newline ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dh9z/P1sI6TUOzujwjMydVI09XV7OgKDOvJE1DSTW5NC0tMSdfNVlJx9IiTiPP1tY4Lk/NUNPGxlTHUlsxT9O69j9QqUJuYmaehqZCNRfQHGuu2v8A "C (gcc) – Try It Online")) and be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in C page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c) for more golfing tips

Comment: Thanks I will take a look, I removed the '\n' that wasn't even showing up in the formula!

Comment: Can't be called twice

Comment: This is code golf, if you want to use it as a **function** then you just have to move `n = 8` inside the function `f` and add `int ` in front of it. It's purposely outside of the function to save 4 bytes (int + space).

Answer (score 0):

## [StupidStackLanguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/StupidStackLanguage), <s><sup>89</sup></s> 84 bytes

```
avvqmddlblbqaviqvmlblblqqqaviqvmlblblaviqvmlblbtfavvdqvdmfwwwffwfvvifiiifbvvvvdfbbbu
```

[Try it online!](https://lebster.xyz/projects/stustala#6028417087173a3d2f5cbd96)

Answer (score 0):

## VBScript, 68 bytes

```
s="'BbBbbbBb'":k=""
For i=1 To Len(s)
k=k&Mid(s,i,1)&"uffalo "
Next
```

Comment: 67 bytes ;-) `k="Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo"`

Answer (score 0):

## BRASCA, 30 bytes

```
`bBbbbBbB`[o` olaffu`7[aoA{]x]
```

[Try it](https://sjoerdpennings.github.io/brasca-online/?code=%60bBbbbBbB%60%5Bo%60%20olaffu%607%5BaoA%7B%5Dx%5D&stdin=)

### Explanation

```
`bBbbbBbB`                     - Push the first letters of each [Bb]uffalo
          [                  ] - While non-zero: 
           o                   -   Output the b/B
            ` olaffu`          -   Push "uffalo "
                     7[aoA{]x  -   Output it and clean up the counter
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 49 bytes

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,CHAR(98-{4;4;0;4}*{8,0})&"uffalo")
```

### Explanation

```
98-{4;4;0;4}*{8,0} =>  66 98 CHAR()=> B b
                       66 98          B b
                       98 98          b b
                       66 98          B b
```

### Shortest Alternative, 51 bytes

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,MID("BbBbbbBb",ROW(1:8),1)&"uffalo")
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 38 bytes

```julia
show(join(["BbBbbbBb"...].*"uffalo "))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vzgjv1wjKz8zTyNaySnJKSkJiJX09PRi9bSUStPSEnPyFZQ0Nf//BwA)

Comment: This solution prints a trailing space. Removing the space from the base string and passing it as the separator argument [only adds 3 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vzgjv1wjKz8zTyNaySnJKSkJiJX09PRi9bSUStPSEnPylXSUFJQ0Nf//BwA).

Answer (score 0):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2), 30 bytes

```
O S^+@'BbBbbbBb.''uffalo '63T@
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyJPIFNeK0AnQmJCYmJiQmIuJyd1ZmZhbG8gJzYzVEAiLCIiLCIyLjAiXQ==)

Answer (score -9):

## Python 3, 72 bytes

```python
print('Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo')
```

I mean, that works.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ92pNC0tMSdfIQlKo/OT8Mura/7/DwA)